# Flag dispute - Should answer be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, deleted-answers, link-only-answers, vote-to-undelete

[A link-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18239653/1) was posted to the question [What is the difference between LL and LR parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975741/what-is-the-difference-between-ll-and-lr-parsing/)

> There is a great recent article about that: http://blog.reverberate.org/2013/07/ll-and-lr-parsing-demystified.html. It's not exactly a simple exaple but explains the matter very well.

This was given the comment

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. –  Bill the Lizard♦

and closed.

It was then [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18239653/2).

> [image: Still closed, but much better.]

I flagged this for undeletion, saying

> Should be undeleted; deletion reason now invalid.

This was declined, stating

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

I found the answer useful and the edit fixed the original complaint. I see that the question itself may well be too broad, but surely that should only result in a lock on the question, not the deletion of a reasonable answer.

What are your opinions?

Comment: I can't vote to undelete either, since a mod deleted it.

Comment: It's an old(ish) answer on an even older question. It has a score of -1 while the other answer on the question has a score of 201. It may no longer be a link-only answer - debateable, seems like you still have to click a load of links to really get a decent answer - but I'm not sure there's anything to be gained from undeleting that answer. Also, a comment slightly more detailed than "deletion reason now invalid" probably wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Old or not, it's getting a lot of views. Further, I doubt the score would stay at -1 for long - and I don't think "the other answer on the question has a score of 201" is a fair point. The answers are complementary.

Comment: FWIW I'd spell flag message a bit differently. "Please consider undeletion: post revision history suggests that it does not qualify as link only answer after changes made in rev 2 ([http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18239653/revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18239653/revisions))". Moderator clicking a link in such a flag message would immediately see that change is worth more attention

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I agree, that seems like a good enough update (bringing relevant information into the answer itself), so I've undeleted it.

I'll ping the moderator who declined the flag, but I bet it was an honest mistake. I usually see answers that have been edited like this after deletion get undeleted.

Comment: I would definitely have put more in the reason than "flag reasons invalid".  That makes it hard for a moderator to make a decision.  "Answer was updated with more information that makes it now a good answer" would be more helpful.

Comment: Yes, this was a mistake by me. I should have undeleted it when flagged.