# 10 Million Questions - Let's Share Some Stories That the Number Doesn't Convey

Tags: discussion, announcement, 10m-questions-milestone

> **Have a look at [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272623/208518) for the current status of your swag!**

---

It's easy to look at numbers; numbers tell us that many developers have been helped by what we built. That alone is very warming and makes us feel exceptionally great about what we're doing, wouldn't it be nice to take a little time on a Friday to share some stories that the numbers can't convey?

As I mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302938/why-only-top-users-on-the-10-million-page/302944#302944), we're going to be running some special events here on Meta to celebrate hitting 10 million questions and reflect a bit on everything we've done together; this is the first of those events.

Your mission, if you choose to accept it, is to regale us with a tale of a Stack Overflow user going *way* above and beyond the call of duty in order to actually *teach* something to someone that wanted to learn, and anyone else that desired the knowledge going forward.

This could be written from several perspectives:

- You just happened to be around when the answer was posted, and saw them continuously expand their answer to *teach* the subject more effectively.
- You wrote one of these kinds of answers - don't be shy to share your own awesomeness. Talk about the experience a little, how did you feel when the person eventually 'got it'?
- You asked a question and someone provided an answer that gave you more than some stuff you could try in your editor, they gave you the *knowledge* you needed to figure it out properly for yourself.

Examples of this don't need to be nearly as epic [as explaining branch prediction like a boss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902) - it could be as simple as an answer where someone *finally* grasped how memory is addressed, or *why* a regular expression did what it was doing, or the like. Let's pick some of our 10 million moments that we're the fondest of, and allow others to share in them.

#### Can you get to the part about the swag, now?

Why yes. The good news is, this isn't a contest, everyone that shares something here will receive:

- 1 Stack Overflow T shirt (Men's or Women's)
- 1 Stack Overflow mug
- 1 Stack Overflow padfolio and aluminum pen with the logo, and some extra pens
- 1 Stack Overflow 'Koozie' (it keeps canned beverages frosty)
- 5 Stack Overflow stickers

***In addition to this, we will contact the author of the answer that you mention and offer them the following:***

- 1 Stack Overflow T-shirt (Men's or Women's)
- 1 Stack Overflow Ruled Notebook (acid free, high-quality paper, I'm not mentioning any brands because we have several and it depends on availability)
- An autographed copy of "[Smart & Gets Things Done](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598385)" by Joel Spolsky.

#### Rules:

- Answers must be at least two paragraphs and link to the answer on the main site you're talking about. You need to tell the story, with as much detail as you can. Put emphasis on what was learned, why it can be hard to teach, how someone could *possibly* have so much patience, etc.
- If you're the author of the answer, you get both prizes.
- Submission deadline is September 4, 2015
- Allow 6 - 8 weeks for delivery after the submission deadline

Comment: Actually, I need a coaster to go with my SO mug. Do you guys happen to have any of those?

Comment: @BoltClock The koozie can function as a coaster. Wait, I think we actually _do_ have some that Careers made. I'll look. It'll be a surprise addition if I find any.

Comment: Also, isn't "teach" a trigger word around these parts? What with the whole "SO is Q&A, not a classroom!" deal.

Comment: If "teach" becomes a trigger word on Stack Overflow, we're screwed.

Comment: @BoltClock Soon SO will be flooded with question for I want to do this. Kindly do my homework till I am watching movie or spending time with my girlfriend . :-)

Comment: Tim, should we keep this to just one?

Comment: Does this have to be an answer that was continuously expanded? I have an answer in mind, but it wasn't edited, it just does a really good job at explaining something that I personally found hard to understand. So I'm not sure if it fits in here.

Comment: @codeMagic If you can think of several, and have the time to write them up, have at it :) It's better to keep them one story to an answer so they can be linked to easily, but contribute as many as you want that fit the criteria :)

Comment: @Stijn That would be fine. _Many_ of these types are heavily edited as the question author keeps asking questions in comments, which is why i mentioned it, but that's no means a requirement. If someone really nailed it the first time, not only is that exceptional, it surely qualifies :)

Comment: Are we given *"carte blanche"*? grin - Have I got some stories for you!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Let's start with the ones that don't involve you walking uphill to school in the dark, in the snow, with no shoes and see how it goes :P

Comment: @TimPost Ah yes... the 'ol *"If clues were shoes..."* bit. In some cases, "snowshoes", depending on the season of course. ;-)

Comment: Did I actually have to be there when the answer was made? I've stumbled across some really excellent answers that were first constructed many years before I joined SO, but the author clearly put in effort to teach and repeatedly edited (actually, the last of the edits are usually also before I joined). Is that a valid perspective to write from?

Comment: Should this be [featured]?

Comment: @Justin I don't feature these events because on the main site, [we pretty much still hate fun](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/). Some folks feel like this sort of thing is a distraction, and would be upset if we made it _purposefully_ prominent on the main site by featuring it. We love them all the same, so we do our best to keep it contained here on meta, and they appreciate that. It'll probably end up in the hot meta posts section of the community bulletin, and that's fine if it does as it earned the spot all on its own.

Comment: Has Mystical gotten swag for the branch prediction answer yet?

Comment: @durron597 no, but maybe Mysticial

Comment: `billions of developers` Wait, really? That means at least 13% of all the people in the world are developers who have been helped by Stack Overflow. That doesn't seem correct

Comment: Stack Overflow is the best way to learn about communtiy interaction.

Comment: @TimPost - Tim just a friendly reminder that it's not just answers that help but even something as simple as a comment can lead to an answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303302/168703

Comment: I'm sure everyone has an answer they're proud of, but I think this is a good platform for thanking and showing appreciation to other users. By the way, the "swag" [sic] is better for the poster anyway.

Comment: well people are aggresive to newbies

Comment: @PeterOlson They mean [Mythical Developer-Helps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month), of course.

Comment: Are chat logs eligible?

Comment: What when I simply can't decide what (single) story to share? Give each story its own answer or write them up into one answer? Don't worry, the single answer won't be THAT long... I just can't decide between three stories, as imo each of it had its own enlightening or satisfying moment.

Comment: meh, I do understand the purpose of this thread. There are certainly questions (with answers) which deserves recognition. Still, it is not important. The most important thing is that these contributors have helped others to solve their problem(s), even if it's "silly" (read: easy). So, i hope that if these persons who receives a swag ( _sic_ ) item, that they still continue with what they we're doing on this site. Also a thumb up for all contributors.

Comment: All of my favorite answers of this kind have been deleted because the questions were bad or off-topic.

Comment: What do downvotes in this thread actually mean? Lousy **answer** or lousy **story** about the answer?

Comment: @PM77-1 My downvotes are for lousy stories, especially on posts where they are submitting their own answer.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET- Out of curiosity, what is your definition of a bad (or a good) story?

Comment: @PM77-1 In a nutshell, the extent to which the author goes to explain what happened. If the crux of the story is "This awesome guy answered my question and made me want to be a better programmer" thats not really an interesting story. If its more like "I was totally clueless about X and asked Y and then this really awesome guy helped me realize that it was really about Z and taught about A, B, and C in the process and made me a much better programmer because of it" then its a much better story.

Comment: @TimPost: Can I post two answers and get twice the swag? :-) Regardless, you'll have to figure out what you're gonna do with people who have been mentioned multiple times, as has happened with bobince and BenjaminGruenbaum!

Comment: I expected a large number of submissions. I feel this post did not reach a lot of SO users.

Comment: @haris:  Not a lot of users care to look at Meta, let alone participate on it.  I think that this was about the right amount, considering.

Comment: @Makoto But wasn't this aimed at rewarding everyone who had contributed so far. And there will surely be people who contribute in the main website but don't come to Meta.

Comment: Sept 5: wheres my email to fill out the form and get my SWAG?

Comment: Am I the only one who came here *several* times after 4th of Sept ?

Comment: are we supposed to recieve a email? :,(

Comment: The suspense is killing me!

Comment: I'll be contacting the initial round (folks that wrote something here) tomorrow, and then those that you've nominated through writing about them near the middle of the week. Hang tight!

Comment: @TimPost When for the rest if us? :)

Comment: @Matt - I suspect that will be the standard 6-8 weeks.  :-P

Comment: Tim, when you say the initial round, is that everyone that wrote an answer within guidelines on this question?

Comment: @TimPost Sorry to be so annoying but what is the contact method? An email or an SO message/notification?

Comment: Just askin: who all (_did not_) get a mail (_yet_)? 1. me.

Comment: I think T-shirts with new *logo* are under production. Just wait. Keep calm and enjoy StackOverFlow.

Comment: A mail with a confirmation will be nice. The suspense is killing me.

Comment: I wonder what mr. @TimPost means by "tomorrow"

Comment: Sorry about that, something exploded while I was sitting on it. Mail going out on 9/18 for everyone that answered here, and on 9/22 - 9/25 for mail going to the folks that wrote the awesome answers you linked (it's a more manual process, hence a few days to get it together).

Comment: @TAsk happy of not being the only one coming here every ten minutes :)

Comment: Emails sent! If you feel like you should have gotten one but didn't, let me know (after checking your spam folders, and connecting your computers directly to your modems after  turning them off and on again).

Comment: @Tim your _"Instructions for the locationally challenged"_ have made my day better, hilarious.

Comment: It was really challenging because the form didn't ask for my name so I had to add it to the street adress but it was requiring state/province which we don't have :)

Comment: I think I'm locationaly challanged, I had to create a twitter account!

Comment: Is there any deadline for filling the Google form

Comment: @TimPost do I get something like a confirmation mail after I submit the form? (I checked out [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306399/what-is-my-first-last-name?cb=1) which has a mail above the circled one which I thought was some kind of acknowledgment mail). Do i need to fill the form again if I  haven't received it?

Comment: @Kamehameha He received two mails because he answered [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303988/how-did-stack-overflow-help-you) question too. :) But I don't know about confirmation for form submission...

Comment: @Kamehameha Yes - please answer both. While the forms are quite similar, they're linked to two different spreadsheets which our warehouse will use to send two distinctly different boxes of goodness.

Comment: @TimPost Just asking : Whether the mails are already sent out to the authors of linked answers? (Sorry, I know that it's manual process and time consuming. But just verifying...)

Comment: @TimPost - I sent the email about where to send my stuff but nothing ever arrived.  Just wondering if anything is being shipped to Michigan any time soon?

Comment: @TimPost, Same here.. i heard some people got the package in India. But i still didn't. Is it because i posted my details a little late??

Comment: The post clearly states to expect 6-8 weeks for delivery after the given deadline. The deadline was september 1st, so there is still just about two weeks left. So: patience is key :)

Comment: @DamienOvereem I guess programmers aren't known for their patience..  ;)

Comment: Patience... We need to speed this up and refactor this service! :D

Comment: I got the email on the 18th September, so it'd be Friday 13th November which is the 8-week 'cut-off date'.

Comment: For folks asking about the **swag deliveries:** Tim actually answered this question over in the [comments on the new Teams question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308601/the-goal-of-teams-our-follow-up-to-your-questions?cb=1#comment261964_308601) a couple days ago.

Comment: I totally forgot about this, and just noticed that I never received one of the emails ([as the author of one of the answers mentioned on the first page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303212/1633117)). So I thought I'd have a look what the status of this is... oh well. It's not a big deal if I just missed out on it, but I thought I'd let you know...

Comment: @TimPost - Hello, I have added my experience here but haven't got any email so far. Is it still going on?

Comment: Time is up! Bring out the tar, feathers and pitchforks!

Comment: @TimPost So, were there 2 forms (for posters and answerers)? I only received one email :/ And no swag yet…

Comment: @TimPost - I have not received any swag ever since my post.  Tim you mentioned stuff  should of been shipped weeks ago in another thread.  Can you verify if everything has shipped?  Ive been waiting on a mug, a tshirt and some other swag for 2 months now.

Comment: An update on the swag --> http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309770/stack-overflow-shirt-lost-in-mail]

Comment: @TimPost Just a suggestion (not to be interpreted as a complaint), but perhaps it is a good idea to update this thread/question with the current state of things.

Comment: Few people got [#SOreadytohelp](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303721/who-are-the-winners-in-the-soreadytohelp-t-shirt-drawing) lucky draw t-shirt... [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303721/who-are-the-winners-in-the-soreadytohelp-t-shirt-drawing#comment276450_306299) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311288/what-is-the-exact-method-of-delivery-for-the-10m-event-participants-merchandise#comment277183_311288)...

Comment: Nope. And I'm moving tomorrow. I can only hope that some miracle will make the package appear at my new doorstep :)

Comment: Every day I hope to see a package in my hallway when I come home from work.. No luck yet.
The lack of information is a little bit.. Frustrating (to say the least)

Comment: @Jordumus I agree. I am excited to receive some SO swag at all, so no rush - doesn't matter to me if it takes 6 weeks or 6 months for the package to arrive, either way it's great. But I would just like a little conformation that the packages are being shipped and that everything is working out. I guess I am just confused why there hasn't been any real update in more than a month. I am assuming there are some delays?

Comment: Folks asking for updates, there _is_ a question with a post from Tim here, with more recent information on the shipments: [Where's my swag?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310598/wheres-my-swag)

Comment: @TimPost I'm not sure if you'll see this, but I have a question for you--I filled out my order form for the swag a while back, and it hasn't come. I also sent you an email where I indicated concern that the form hadn't properly been submitted to your database of orders; should I refill the form, or can you check to see if it did go through properly?

Comment: @BenKnoble The form data is sent to a Google Sheet, which I assume is fed into some system.

Comment: @cybermonkey I'm aware; I think it had an issue when i submitted it. I never got the box (and I submitted months ago...). I was just wondering if I should resubmit it

Comment: Oh well. I guess this is a dud. Been months without any reply..  in the meantime i've sold my house, bought a new place and moved. Guess the stuff goes to my old house (if it ever arrives). Nice concept, bad execution. Time to move on.

Comment: Swag would have been a good Christmas present

Comment: Hey, I was mentioned twice here but was not _contacted_ by SE, who do I talk to? @TimPost

Comment: @TimPost updated his answer to question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310598/wheres-my-swag on December 30th stating things are moving forward!

Comment: Swag status updates @ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272621/what-happened-to-that-contest-swag-i-was-promised/272623#272623

Comment: Most of my really informative answers have happened over on Worldbuilding or Game Development, heh.

Comment: For swag giveaway posts, please add [swag] tag so that people find them easier! `:)` (btw, I really _need_ a SO T-Shirt, but couldn't get one yet unfortunately `:'(`)

Answer (score 214):

## The day Stack Overflow made me understand open source

**The Details**
The Question: [How to close a PST file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27164693/2422776)
My Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27164871/2422776

**The Story behind them**
This isn't an especially highly voted, or even a very popular question, nor is my answer, but it's a great experience I had with Stack Overflow, and I'd like to share it. I've been a software engineer for over fifteen years, and I've worked *with* open source software from pretty much the get-go. For the last three and a half years, I've actually been paid to work *on* open source. And yet, I didn't really **get** open source until I came across this question eight months ago.

The question itself was pretty mundane, to be completely frank - how can you close a `PSTFile` object? Despite never using that library, I thought, hey, Java is Java, I'll give it crack. I skimmed over the javadoc, confirmed the OP's fear that there's no good way of doing this, wrote down an answer, and was about to hit the "submit" button. And then it hit me - this is an open source library. Don't settle for the javadoc, read the code. A quick `git clone` and some nosing around later, I found an (ugly) <strike>hack</strike> way of doing this and added it to my answer.

Half a morning later, it really hit me. This is **open source**. It took me a couple of minutes to whip up a pull request to provide a sensible way of doing this, and a couple of days later it was merged by the project's maintainer.

I've been using open source for a decade and a half. I work on open source professionally. And it took a question on Stack Overflow about a library I don't even use to really make me understand what open source is all about.

Thank you for this experience.

Comment: Quite frankly, I had a simlilar experience. It wasn't a huge project, nor a huge contribution from my side. But seeing how it all got put together make me love Open source

Comment: Me too http://stackoverflow.com/a/27143779

Comment: I can feel the love for open source after seeing this post. <3

Answer (score 136):

## Jon Skeet isn't an expert at everything.

I've always seen excellent answers from Jon Skeet.  He is a legendary contributor to the site.  His answers always strive to explain the *why* behind the problem, and for someone like myself who strives to collect as much knowledge about their profession as possible, these sorts of answers are awesome.  When I post answers, I often try to make the same effort [as was mentioned in an earlier answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303095/2792531).

But... there's basically no overlap between my personal areas of interest and Jon Skeet's typical domain.

Then one fateful January day; Jon Skeet posted a [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) answer.  Someone pointed this out to me, and I thought "Oh cool!  I'll go see what insight Jon Skeet has on Swift.  Surely, I'll learn something reading this answer."

But I didn't.  Don't get me wrong, Jon Skeet's answer was good and correct.  But Jon Skeet's answer was an educated guess based on his experience with generics in the Java language.  Having read his answer, I couldn't help but think... I have more to say on this topic.  I could write a better answer...

### [And so I did.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27922252/2792531)

I arrived late to the scene; Jon Skeet's answer was already marked as accepted.  But every time I arrive on a question, I always think about how often I've come across questions in my own quest for solutions.  The accepted answer isn't always the best answer.  I know this and always keep it in mind.  As such, I never hesitate to post what I consider to be a better, more complete answer whenever I can.  Satisfying the asker is only a small piece of the puzzle.  As of this posting, my answer there has 27 upvotes, and yet it was posted even after an answer was marked as accepted.

Not all of my answers are marked as accepted, but they're all written with the thought in mind that there are going to be several developers who have this exact same question in the future.  **I write my answers not for the visible asker, but for the numerous invisible askers.**

Occasionally, that means earning the populist badge over a Jon Skeet accepted answer!

Comment: Nevertheless, it's Jon Skeet's avatar that appears first in the "And your efforts here matter" background.

Comment: @YehudaShapira Contributes by the tonne != knows everything :)

Comment: It's always very exciting to compete with Jon Skeet for the best answer. Once I stole an [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31923337/4856258) from Jon Skeet, though I arrived two hours later.

Answer (score 112):

## The day I met someone famous on SO

**The Question**

[Creagen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5212656/creagen)'s question: [Saving and Remembering In-App Purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968441/saving-and-remembering-in-app-purchases/31969296#31969296)

**The Answer**

My answer here: [Saving and Remembering In-App Purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968441/saving-and-remembering-in-app-purchases?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

**The Story**

As a full time college student and part time app designer I really love to make games. On SO I stick to answer `iOS` questions and lookout for `Game-Center` and other game related questions.

A couple of weeks ago I came across this question, where someone was trying to integrate an IAP to remove Ads from their app. While creating my last app I integrated the exact same IAP into my app so I knew I could help.

While the question was put on hold for being too broad I was able to get in a quick answer and helped walk the asker through the intricacies of NSUserDefaults and how to keep track of if someone had removed the ads from their app.

With 78 comments on my answer and multiple hours walking him through the process nothing says thank you like this quote:

> Thank you so much for your help. I don't know who you are, but you are
> awesome! Hopefully I can return the favor one day.

And who knew that this was the actor, Creagen Dow, who would become a fan of one of my games and tweet about it to his 33k followers.

I guess helping others does pay off sometimes!

Comment: Best answer I have read on this thread until now!

Answer (score 71):

#### [Why is variable1 += variable2 much faster than variable1 = variable1 + variable2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25503703/189134)

[Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) is known for providing very high quality answers, especially in the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag. His answers are informative and high quality. I'd like to nominate his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25503738/189134) on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25503703/189134) question, though, as one that was very helpful to both myself and others.

The post has had several [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25503738/revisions). The first starts as a very informative, short, answer. However, Martijn expands on this answer through several more versions before realizing what the real problem ultimately was. The short and informative post expands to be an excellent explanation of how `+=` and `+` differ when concatenating two vs. three strings. It goes into behind the scenes details on what python is doing, while remaining accessible enough to be an easy read. Then it provides code samples demonstrating the difference clearly.

This answer was updated over the course of several months, proving new sources and new code showing improvements.  Answers like this, that evolve and update to provide new and better information, are important to helping others not only understand their immediate problem but solve problems they haven't encountered yet. The user asked a simple question about why two seemingly equal statements performed so differently and got a great answer.

I've utilized this answer many times in code reviews at work. It's a practical question with a useful answer. It's also a problem that we've encountered at work and with an answer like this, it's easy to show others *why* something is happening instead of just saying "you should do it this way instead for better performance".

Comment: Before SO I always thought the only friendly ninjas were mutant teenagers.

Comment: This guy is going to be more popular than Jon Skeet.

Comment: @FrancescoMenzani In my opinion, he already is.

Comment: @FrancescoMenzani : Dont forget  **Gordon Linoff The DBA** and one of the respected SQL Legend :)

Answer (score 35):

### [Is Storing Graphics objects a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31416048/4293417)

Yes, I am definitely nominating this. Being a horrible Java programmer that has high hopes in building some <s>awesome</s> that never works, I was about to do something really stupid. Yes, really, really, really, realllllllly stupid.

I learned Java in my Grade 10 Computer Science course last year (I'm going into 11 now) but I had built a simple painting application, but I wanted to build on it and possibly release it. I had run into the simple action of undos/redos to fix drawing operations made by the end user.

Of course, I learned that the `Graphics` object in Java doesn't actually store anything, but only has ways of 'drawing' to the screen, or an object. HaraldK (the author of the answer) told me exactly (and concisely) what was wrong with my idea of doing this. It was remarkably simple to understand the flaws in my logic. The biggest issue (you can ask any of my friends) is that I think something is wrong, then I think it might work, and then I get horribly confused). You could probably find people in chat that would say the same about me.

He then noted the baseline of what I was attempting to do, and gave me *three* alternatives (yep, three) each explaining the pros and cons to each of them. He also provided me with a way to integrate it within my overall application. It was really helpful, and I managed to get from doing something that would forever be broken, to going to get something that works absolutely flawlessly. P.S. I did do the combination, holding two images in memory and the rest serialized to disk :)

We had a quick comment, and he immediately set me off to the correct docs on where to go. I'm forever glad :D

HaraldK really deserves some recognition: He really helped me and is probably the reason why my application is going to work. I'll tell you guys when I release it :)

Comment: I've basically never touched Java, and I remember reading this question and the answers just because of how interesting it was. Good nomination.

Comment: It is. I mean, it doesn't matter what capabilities whatever languages you're using has, at least parts of the suggested approaches would always be applicable. It's just an interesting concept. And not limited to images, could be applicable to any type of undo operations.

Comment: This is a fun entry. Its partially because its hilarious just how far you can get DoingItWrong(tm) because you just don't see the light yet (and lets be honest: because you haven't *allowed* yourself to see the light yet is usually closer to the truth). It ends up with people attempting to serialize network connections and send them to other computers. In the end, everyone laughs.

Answer (score 35):

## Self-answer Self-help

As a programmer, it can be incredibly easy to feel like you're just treading water while everyone else is writing code that you'll never be able to touch.  I've watched many friends (and myself, several times) fall victim to [impostor syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome).  The solution is as simple as it is difficult to get through one's thick programmer skull: Don't compare yourself to other programmers, compare your current self to your earlier self.

My earlier self was enthusiastic but had a lot to learn.  At my first job (an internship, really), I was struggling with the asynchronous nature of JavaScript (coming from the straightforward Python & Java).  As such, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10557809/1216976).  Sadly, it only attracted a few comments and no answer.  Fortunately, I've learned an abso-flippin-loutely ***enormous*** amount from the gracious, generous, golden, gooey, graceful (and many other `g` adjectives) folks in the [SO JS chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascriptball-pit) (they're the real heroes here).

Two years later, the chat room was pulling up terrible questions we'd asked (boy, were there some doozies).  I found my previously-unanswered question.  I said to myself: "Self, you know the answer now - you can answer this!".

[So I did.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23838687/1216976)

What started as a little goof on a dreary afternoon  ended up going (semi) viral.  Several users contacted me and said that my answer helped them make new connections about events in JavaScript, leading to a better understanding of frontend dev as a whole.  Whenever I think I'm stuck in a rut, I look back on that Q/A and realize things aren't as bad as they seem.

### What was learned

- I learned that I'm learning.
- JavaScript is "tyrannically asynchronous" and managing multiple events firing everywhere can be tricky. Newcomers often don't realize that an event can be fired before they're ready for it.

Comment: I'll upvote this post if you **rename your question to something that people will find easily in google** when they get that problem. *627 hits isn't (semi) viral*

Answer (score 29):

I have a hard time picking out which answer I like the most but [How does the clock work in Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162423/how-does-the-clock-work-in-windows-7/29164665#29164665) is probably my favorite. It's a question with very low traffic (115 views in 5 months) but the answer basically exudes knowledge.

The thing that I like about Hans Passant's answers is that they are always on-point (I don't recall the last time I saw an answer of his not accepted), it's very high quality from the first revision and every sentence you read teaches you more than the previous one. Another example of such an answer is [Testing for a float NaN results in a stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205112/testing-for-a-float-nan-results-in-a-stack-overflow/25206025#25206025). Another example would be [Why doesn't NullReferenceException contain information about what is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719047/why-doesnt-nullreferenceexception-contain-information-about-what-is-null/4721113#4721113) which really clarified to me what a NRE is behind the scenes. I once read a quote which said, paraphrased, "*If you can't explain it in simple terms, you don't know it well enough*". This is an answer of which I really feel that it shows just how much of an expert he is: the explanation is perfectly understandable yet teaches you about some quite advanced concepts of the inner workings. These three have to be my favorite answers on the site, and I've read a lot of them by now.

On a more personal note and with the risk of receiving a restraining order: seeing his answers time and time again have acted as an inspiration to become an expert in the .NET/Windows internals. It's still a far way off but if I can express my gratitude for his superb contributions to Stackoverflow by making sure he gets a T-Shirt, then it's my duty to write this post.

Comment: So wait... Your story was about HansPassant too? Mat's Mug and I both had a story about Hans too. I hope he's ready for a lifetime supply of coffee mugs.

Comment: @RubberDuck actually he won't get a single mug until he posts something here. But he'll get a pile of T-shirts and a library full of Joel's book :)

Answer (score 29):

### **[The answer that made a package to plot squirrels in a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28248212/2706826)**

SO is a great help to virtually everyone who's ever been here. Sometimes, with so many snarky and unimaginative answers and comments, it can be easy to forget that and take all this effort for granted. Then there are things that come along and are **just delightful**.

I had the pleasure to observe one of these occasions. [Someone wanted to plot birfurcation diagrams of "squirrels" in a "tree"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163979/how-can-i-plot-a-tree-and-squirrels-in-r). User @jbaums "over thought" the problem and went on to demonstrate at length how to do it, to much appreciation, and explain in comments how it worked. Great!

But this was not enough. @jbaums then decided this was evidently sub-par, and came back several days later demonstrating an R package, [trees](https://github.com/johnbaums/trees), which germinated trees, foliated them, and placed squirrels on them.

Chapeau monsieur!
[image]

That was then **updated due to new interest from this post** to plot squirrel-squirrels, not just dot-squirrels!!!
[image]

Answer (score 26):

## Rubberduck uses SO as a rubberduck and gets some unexpected help.

> [How to create a read-only property exposed to COM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489915/how-to-create-a-read-only-property-exposed-to-com/28490784#28490784)

I posted the question and the answer, but [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) is the real hero here.

I was working on a COM library to be consumed by VBA. I'd never done anything like this before, so needless to say, I spent a good amount of time digging around the [com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/com) tag. Along the way, Hans kept answering my questions; questions that I never had to ask myself because someone else had already been down this road and had the same problems I was having now. Each step of the way, there was Hans, patiently explaining how and why COM acts the way it does.

I finally hit a wall. I kind of knew what I was doing, but I was having some trouble with something that *didn't* already have an answer. So, I set myself to writing an MCVE and by time I was done writing my question, I knew a way to solve my problem. StackOverflow had been my rubberduck. (Yes, I see the irony in Rubberduck using StackOverflow as a rubberduck.) Instead of discarding my draft, I thought someone else may benefit from what I had just learned, so I immediately wrote down my solution in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28490784/1). It wasn't a *good* solution, but it worked well enough.

Before I had finished posting my answer, Hans had left a rather simple comment on my question nudging me in the right direction. *There he was again.* This guy had basically taught me everything I knew about COM programming and here he was again, not *giving* me an answer, but guiding me to figure it out for myself. After a very brief clarifying question and answer in the comments, it just clicked.

> Ohhhhh. Genius! Thanks again @HansPassant!

Once it clicked, I went ahead and [wrote the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28490784/3198973) that he could have written himself, but I got so much more out of doing it all myself than I would have gotten from anyone else's answer. I couldn't have done it without that nudge though.

Every now and then that answer gets an upvote. I just smile to myself, knowing that someone else **did** end up benefitting from that answer and it makes me glad I wrote it. Not only did I learn something, but I know that somewhere out there, someone else just did too.

Comment: Wait wait, that's *[RubberDuck](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3198973/rubberduck)* using Stack Overflow as a *[rubber duck](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/)* while working on... *[Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com)*. Awesome!

Answer (score 26):

### Case-insensitive string comparison is tricky

Digging through my favorited posts, I found this question:

[How do I do a case insensitive string comparison in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/319426/1157100)

The answer seems like it should be obvious and trivial.  Several answers, including the "accepted" one, suggest doing case normalization using `str.lower()` or `str.upper()` on both strings.

But those answers are in fact wrong.  Several users have pointed out that the popular approach fails to take diacritics, final-letter forms, and special cases such as `ß`/`SS` into account.

[@Veedrac's answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/29247821/1157100), which suggests using either `str.casefold()` or `unicodedata.normalize()`, is, I believe, the only truly correct answer there.  I'm awarding a bounty on that answer.

That answer illustrates the difference between a junior and a senior programmer: the naïve approach will appear to work, but the correct approach actually solves the problem correctly in all cases.  And that is the value that Stack Overflow provides to me, a reasonably proficient programmer: there's always something new to learn!

Comment: it only scratches the surface. If you are interested; read about [multi-level Unicode collation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That's the 3rd level after Junior/Senior => Domain Expert :D

Answer (score 24):

When I started answering questions on SO (or at least, attempting to answer them) it was primarily a personal challenge to myself to improve and broaden my R skills. I was immediately introduced to an amazing community of R experts that have become significant role models for me.

One of the most generous contributors I've encountered here is [Gavin Simpson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429846/gavin-simpson). It is commonplace (and understandable) to frown on answering poor quality questions. What I have observed from Gavin on several occasions is the ability to take a terrible question and see in it something that can be molded into a remarkable contribution. The one that sticks in my head the most is his answer to [How to apply a hierarchical or k-means cluster analysis using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5648425/324364).

It is important to look at the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5648383/revisions) of that question, to grasp the magnitude of what he did there. The level of patience and selflessness on display there is, IMHO, truly remarkable.

I understand that many people may see a question like this and feel that the appropriate response is to simply get rid of it as quickly as possible. I have learned from Gavin that it is sometimes important to step outside that (entirely reasonable) impulse and think about whether you can make a positive contribution to a body of knowledge regardless of whether the question asker is putting in their fair share of the effort.

Comment: The edit history of that question surprised me, amazing story !!

Answer (score 23):

## The question that changed Oracle

<sub>*or at least, just a little*</sub>

A younger version of myself thought it would be a good idea to use MySQL with ASP.NET MVC, and I did.. for a long time. Along the way I received so many bruising experiences that I eventually had to move away to the expected technology to pair with ASP.NET MVC; namely MSSQL.

This is one of my harrowing stories, and how a fellow user assisted me in changing a library published by Oracle. That user is none other than the *epic* [slauma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270591/slauma); if you are slauma, and are reading this, thanks for all the insights :D.

I was attempting to use a nested projection in Entity Framework to eager load an object graph, which seemed from all the documentation to be straightforward. And it worked at first, kind of, in the way that sometimes you turn off that light switch in your house that somehow was linked to the entire entertainment center or perhaps even your computer. Which is to say, it didn't exactly do what I expected it to do, and included a lot of duplicate data instead of properly formed data. **[How can I use Entity Framework on an object graph past a depth of 2 with MySQL Connector / NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11676513/1026459)**.

It was a massive conundrum. What made this worse was that every test other users ran came back working as expected! It just looked like I was doing something wrong and everyone else was just fine. Great, except that my computer would turn off every time I tried to turn off the hallway light.

What finally came to light was that the MySQL provider was malforming the SQL statements and causing the problems I encountered. Slauma had stuck with me the entire time trying to get this solved (even in comments on a [second related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12825643/1026459) I asked), and a large part of getting this solved was comparing the actual composed MySQL I had with the composed SQL he had. There was a clear discrepancy.

I was stuck in a rock and a hard place here. What could I do? I mean, in all honesty manually changing the compiled library for MySQL Connector / NET wasn't really an option. But I had no choice, I reflected the whole thing and dove into its massive visitor pattern. That was more of a learning curve than I expected. Eventually though, I had a set of explicit places that were exhibiting the problem. It was time to file a bug report with Oracle. **[Malformed Query while eager loading with EF 4 due to multiple projections](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67183)**.

Down the bug report rabbit hole I went, hoping for the best, thinking it would be a simple fix for a team of engineers. Apparently it was a little complicated for them as well. After a month of working with Fernando Gonzalez Sanchez (one of their engineers on the project) we were able to both come to the same conclusion; there was indeed a bug present in the formation of the query statement. Seven months later, another of their engineers got back to me, Philip Olson, with the exciting news that the issue had been fixed and that the changelog had reflected the bug.

So thank you, Stack Overflow and Slauma. While this was only one (technically two) of the 10 million questions, it was significant to me. I had only been on the site at that point for 6 months, and had never interacted with another team as large as the MySQL Connector / NET through a reporting interface before. The experience of following this through led me to believe that I could make changes to even extremely large products, and that is a belief I still carry.

Comment: A big YES to this. I had the privilege to operate with Slauma for a couple of years in the Entity Framework tag. Although I clearly just started we always had collegial discussions and mutual respect. I regret the day he decided to stop contributing to Stack Overflow for reasons I don't know.

Answer (score 21):

When I saw this post on meta, I really wanted to share. The problem is that there are simply too many helpful posts for me to easily pick any single one. The sheer volume of exceptional information that I've enjoyed learning about for the last four years and nine months is what has kept me coming back again and again. I selected a few answers worth calling out and picked one at random.

My response matches the first perspective listed.

> You just happened to be around when the answer was posted, and saw them continuously expand their answer to teach the subject more effectively.

One of the greatest things about Stack Overflow (and the entire Stack Exchange network) is how knowledgeable people lead by example by sharing what they know in great detail. Even when the topic seems relatively trivial. Scratch that, **especially** when the topic seems really trivial.

---

In 2012, when I had <20k rep and [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) already had more rep than I do now, [we both answered the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/497418).

Our original answers started off as pretty similar, covering the basics of looping in JavaScript. Nothing I didn't already know.

But over the course of the last three years, T.J. has shown how to properly answer a question. You don't need to say everything all at once, you just need to keep coming back and expanding. Every time he found something new to add, his answer was updated. His answer is on its thirtieth revision and was just updated in June.

With the changes in ES6, I suddenly found myself coming back to make sure that I was aware of all the details. When I had previously thought there was nothing more to learn (I mean, really, how hard is it to iterate through an array?) I was being taught the basics all over again. T.J.'s score soared, and deservedly so; my "[good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/24/good-answer)" pales in comparison.

*This* is what Stack Overflow is all about: smart people sharing knowledge to try to make more smart people. It's extraordinary answers like these that give me pride in my magical unicorn points.

Thank you.

Comment: And this is surely not the only instance of him doing that :-)

Answer (score 20):

## [Why does this string extension method not throw an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30176240/3160466)

And I thought I was decent with C#.

May 11, and I came across a problem while developing a chat server/client pair. It seemed that its solution required finding every index of a substring within a string. Of course, C#'s `string.IndexOf` method finds *single* instances of substrings, and I could have simply written a couple of lines that would recursively call `IndexOf` until no more indexes could be found. However, it was a problem that I recognized would come up more than once, so I thought it would be a good idea to code a new extension method into the `string` type.

I found my initial code in [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641383/3160466), used it, and it worked perfectly (kudos to you, Matti Virkkunen). It sat there in my project, got used heavily, and never came up with a single problem. Until I wrote tests. When tested against null arguments, it failed to throw the exception I thought it would. Confused, I asked the title question.

Lucas Trzesniewski explained to me firstly *why* it didn't work, then the mechanism behind *how* it didn't work, and finally broke that mechanism down into the compiled version of my method. Not only did this solve my problem, but also taught me about iterators in C# and how, essentially, they defer execution until a different method is called. The exception *would* have been thrown, just not when I expected it.

This answer was a prime example of going above and beyond to answer a question and explain fully, and Lucas deserves both the gold badge he got for it, and the swag.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you that much. It's a pleasure, thank you for this! :D

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Hello there! Yes, it certainly did. It - essentially - explained a whole new concept of the language to me

Answer (score 19):

## You want teh codez? Let me first give you a university-level lecture on the topic.

**Question and answer:** [Mutual information and joint entropy of two images - MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691398/mutual-information-and-joint-entropy-of-two-images-matlab)

I remember the old times when I first came to Stack Overflow. I think I found it the same way any of us had: Google that annoying thing that is not working a couple of times and realizing that Google always throws you here if it is programming involved.

"Hummm, let's put this webpage in the bookmarks, just in case...". 
                                                   - Past me

At the time I was a young undergrad working for the first time in image processing and computer vision. Someone without much programming experience suddenly playing with a field where not only programming, but some maths are required. I remember it took me a while to understand many of the concepts of image processing, and once understood, it took me a while to get them coded. Playing a bit on that I got some experience and suddenly started answering some questions here and there.

I mainly use MATLAB, and because of the nature of the language, a lot of image processing questions are posted there. I generally try to answer them as good as I can.

But, about a year ago, a Canadian guy started to answer questions around. And they were AMAZING. In less than a year, he rocketed from 1 to 40K reputation. Yeah, I am talking about [@rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3250829/rayryeng). Every decent question about image processing he answers comes with a university-level lecture about the topic, not only answering the question *"How do I do this in MATLAB"*, but additional explaining (without the OP asking) the whole theory behind it. I learned more about image processing reading his answers than in my three university courses of master level.

I specially like the question linked because it explains how to code (and why) mutual information brilliantly, being a concept very little used in the literature. I was working on the topic when he wrote that answer and his knowledge helped me get an academic article published! That has to mean something.

But it's definitely not his best answer!

- Why not learn how [SURF features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127181/matching-images-with-different-orientations-and-scales-in-matlab/29128507#29128507) work?
- Ever wondered [how interpolation works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142288/resize-an-image-with-bilinear-interpolation-without-imresize/26143655#26143655) on images?
- Or are you more of [an image segmentation person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731810/segmenting-license-plate-characters/24732434#24732434)?
- Does [knn search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475978/finding-k-nearest-neighbour-with-matlab/27476929#27476929) confuses you?
- Is [identifying fake money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580747/paper-currency-recognition-by-image-processing/25583882#25583882) key in your life?

I could go on and on with his incredibly detailed answers on image processing, but you can just go and check his profile. Answers like those ones are what keep Stack Overflow as AMAZING as it is.

Comment: Very rightly put and agreed on all accounts, that guy's a legend!

Comment: @Divakar So you are!!!! but could add 2 people in the post :P

Comment: I'm so honoured :) thank you so so much. It is people like you that make me want to continue and keep writing more image processing answers.

Comment: @Divakar "Legend" is an understatement. rayryeng is exceptionally willing to teach, and is as skilled as they come. On questions where all I could think was "Good luck, OP!", Ray would step up to the plate and knock it out of the park.

Answer (score 15):

When I started using Stack Overflow, I was just learning programming. I graduated college as a networker, then was hired on as a programmer at my current place of employment two days later. Naturally, Stack Overflow has been priceless in terms of usefulness to me while I have learned to code and debug in a trial-by-fire manner.

Several of my questions were basic questions when I started out. My first question was really a problem of misunderstanding how regex works. As I worked on projects and bug fixes at work, I learned more and my questions became a bit better.

At one point, one of my coworkers asked me to figure out ajax calls. No one on the team had used ajax before, so it was all on me to sort out how it all worked. As I muddled along, I turned to Stack Overflow when I hit snags that I couldn't solve myself or through research.

One of the first issues I ran into, once I had the ajax call hitting the controller properly, was getting an error about an undefined callback. I was confused, and Googled the error. After several frustrating hours of not figuring out the issue, [I posted my question to Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234006/ajax-callback-is-undefined-error) One user answered my question more directly, but [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david) pointed out another issue that would cause me more trouble in [his answer to the same question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19234313/2607247) Not only was this a well-explained answer, but he *also* taught me about not misusing Stack Overflow by updating my questions as I encountered related issues.

After directing me to post [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234704/populating-dropdown-from-ajax-database-call) for the new problem, he found it and answered that question as well. (To be fair, I don't recall if I had commented that I had posted a new question on his original answer. If I did, it has since been deleted. Either way, he had no obligation to go look at it and help me figure it out.) The answer he posted to the second question was also very detailed, and upon encountering a small issue with implementing his answer, he gave me direction in the comments on what to look at to fix it.

David was one of the first users to really help me see how Stack Overflow worked, and how much more valuable to me it could be due to how it worked. His two answers really helped me to not only get the ball rolling faster on the project we were doing, but also to come to appreciate Stack Overflow even more than I had.

Answer (score 15):

**It's all about vectorisation**

I pinpoint [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29022586/4137985) because I really liked this one and the request is for answers and not questions but actually, everything in this Q&A was highly interesting.

It all begins with a general question, posted by a high-rep and very skilled user, about a family of functions that are well known and very often used in R. 
Those functions usually permit to write less code but are known not to be "really" vectorised so all the question was about that.

I followed one by one the posting of really interesting answers and comments. To try and answer the question, the C code that is underneath the R functions was dig up. But, most of all, there was a whole discussion about what exactly "vectorisation" means.

The answer I'm highlighting today discusses very deeply the definition of vectorisation with links and references, ***it's more a talk than just an answer really*** and I had the feeling I was in a kind of amphitheater, listening to a fascinating conference. So, yes, I didn't quite understand everything but kept the question as favourite to go back on the answer later because I know I can learn even more from it.

This is what made this answer special to me.

Answer (score 13):

[Martin Büttner's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1633117/martin-b%C3%BCttner) answer to [**What are regular expression Balancing Groups?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17003799/7586) is an excellent answer.

The question is simple and straightforward, and Martin took the opportunity to write a great canonical answer, and probably the **best introduction to balancing groups on the Internet**.

.NET regular expression balancing groups are a [hobby](https://kobikobi.wordpress.com/tag/balancing-group/) of mine, and I have answered several questions on the subject, but I always approached it as an advanced topic. Martin presented the subject in a simple and clever way without any assumptions on prior knowledge - starting from simple concepts, and only complicating as needed to get to the goal - exactly what is needed for a great canonical answer.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the kind words. They mean a lot, especially coming from you. And also thank you for helping me improving the answer with yours. :)

Comment: I wanted to post this one here too but you beat me to it ;)

Comment: I love playing around with regex in my spare time, just to see what I can do with them- The answer you linked here taught me a whole new aspect of regex I haven't played around with yet. Thanks for posting this one. =)

Answer (score 13):

### If you're having code problems I feel bad for you SOn,

### I got 99 comments, but the problem is done!

**My Question:** [CSV to XML converter using Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429956/csv-to-xml-converter-using-groovy)

**Their Answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/21430831/2641576

**The Issue:**

This was the first time during my Stack Overflow use that a user really went above and beyond! Most questions I had posted were all answered well and correctly, but if anything else ever crept up the revision to answers were never as urgent or had as much effort put in as this.

The question was a pretty standard "I want to create X using Y" and in this case creating a CSV-to-XML converter using [Groovy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29). This was my first foray into using Groovy as I predominately work with SQL, so I was literally at the end of my tether (and ability) with it.

It had the makings of a very standard question, current code, what I had tried, sample data and expected output, nothing untoward with attracting such a brilliant effort.

Then 37 minutes later the most patient and helpful user I have ever dealt with on Stack Overflow answered.

7 days, 99 comments and countless GitHub revisions later we had an answer! Even with my lack of knowledge and no doubt stupid questions he stuck with me until the end.

I've been using Stack Overflow for around two years (as a member) and longer as a lurker, and I have never (and most likely never will) come across another amazing effort like this!

[Thanks Tim!](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509/tim-yates)

Answer (score 12):

> That alone is very warming and makes us feel exceptionally great about what we're doing.

Your words reminded me why I have been part of this wonderful community for almost 2 years now. In the recent times, I have just been flagging stuff and keeping the mods busy, but amidst all this, every time that I took some time out to help someone on SO, I did experience this wonderful feeling that makes us feel exceptionally great.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25395773/2982225)
almost two weeks after it was asked. The asker had attempted an interesting excercise with GridLayout alignment, and recieved an answer soon after, and the conversation between them had ended with [these words by the answerer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395773/gridlayout-align-children-within-column#comment39818022_25430366)

> "Yes, that is the challenge. I referred to it as "driven by content". The only way I have found so far was my first response. I am going to watch this entry to see if someone has a better solution."

The problem was interesting, and the existing conversation between the two users clearly indicated that both of them had attempted it in order to learn about the concept, this wasn't an assignment for either of them.

Since two weeks had already passed since those users had been active on this post, I didn't expect any immediate response for 
[my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25623421/2982225)

However, soon after I posted my answer, the answerer responded with his/her feedback and I revised my answer to include the use case they mentioned. A few hours later, the OP responded and I realized that he didn't fully understand that the composite viewgroup becomes non-flexible if we align it w.r.t. an axis. I was happy to receive responses from both the users whose conversation had encouraged me to write the post. I modified the answer with a longer explanation. After a couple of revisions and addition of some colorful images, it felt good when the OP wrote: ["I definitely learnt a lot about GridLayout from this little exercise!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395773/gridlayout-align-children-within-column#comment40129832_25623421)

When the asker finally gets it, irrespective of the simplicity of the solution, it feels so good to have helped someone.

Answer (score 12):

## How a simple comment solved my issue...twice

In July of 2015, I started to help on an older web application to try to figure out why the system began to slow down and affect thousands of users.  I tried everything from checking database indexes, to ensuring pages were optimized by keeping some of the workload on the client machine vs the server side.

I got desperate so I decided to post my question:

*[Performance deteriorating after async postback - scrolling becomes horrendous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359065/performance-deteriorating-after-async-postback-scrolling-becomes-horrendous/31597664#31597664)*

After about a weeks time I had absolutely no answer to the question and our user base was complaining about the lack of a fix. I decided to add a bounty to the question....[and even after the bounty I had zero answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299481/bounty-wasnt-large-enough-no-way-to-increase-it-what-could-be-done).

The second bounty was a little better as people started to chime in, but still no answer...at the same time I saw further issues that inspired me to create yet another question, *[Why is telling jQuery to click my link button slowing my page down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572986/why-is-telling-jquery-to-click-my-link-button-slowing-my-page-down/31588358#31588358)*.

### How a hint helped me...

I originally thought this newly created question had nothing to do with the original question I posted...but a comment helped drive me in the right direction.  The comment was made by a user named [Radio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3311552/radio). The comment he made can be found here: *[Why is telling jQuery to click my link button slowing my page down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572986/why-is-telling-jquery-to-click-my-link-button-slowing-my-page-down/31588358#comment51104552_31572986)*.

> I see what you're saying. I wonder if the update panel is somehow
>   causing multiple instances of the apply button to exist on the dom,
>   yet not visible. So clicking a single button manually triggers a
>   single event, where as calling the whole class to click may cause the
>   click to fire on many instances of ".apply". Worth checking the length
>   of $(".apply") I suppose. Hopefully it's 1. Intuition says this is an
>   event stack leak. This is a tricky issue.

His comment lead me to fix this issue (the second question I had posted) with [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31588358/168703). But then I realized [it fixed my original question as well...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31597664/168703).

Not only did Radio's comment fix my second issue, but he solved a more mysterious bug indirectly...without him even knowing he solved it. I just wish he could read this post, because I owe him my paycheck! He saved me from thousands of complaining users...and they think I am the superstar..when in reality he really is.

**Thanks for the simple comment @Radio that changed the way I approached the problem!**

Answer (score 12):

Question: [In R, what is the difference between these two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227734/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-these-two)

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2228139/2338862

This question addressed a common problem in [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r). Specifically, it asked why two seemingly equivalent numbers (`.9` and `1.1-.2`) were deemed not equal by the R interpreter.

[Alex Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121332) posted [a relatively brief answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2228139/1). That was an OK answer to the question. It points out that issue is well-known, included a link to a useful article, and provided a brief explanation highlighting the always confusing nature of floating point arithmetic.

What eventually made this answer great, however, was that [Alex came back 8 more times that day](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2228139/revisions), transforming the answer to the question into a comprehensive overview of floating point in R that both solved the user's specific problem but also showed them the underlying logic of floating point (using code examples) so that the answer would be useful to others who encountered similar situations.

The question has now been marked a duplicate of what we [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) users call an [r-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-faq) or a "canonical Q&A" that we point duplicate StackOverflow questions to. The [canonical Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) is indeed an identical problem that features [a very comprehensive "community wiki" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/2338862) by [Brian Diggs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892313).

Yet, a quick read of [the revision history of Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9508558/2) reveals that about half of the content is in fact from Alex's original answer. While Brian leveraged a variety of sources to create a canonical answer for floating point problems in R, his answer reveals how useful StackOverflow (and its permissive content licensing) can be. Not only did StackOverflow allow Alex to solve a specific user's problem in a compelling way, it also allowed later users (like Brian) to create even more valuable and comprehensive resources to teach programming and solve problems. Alex's answer is an underappreciated gem in the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag that is a great example of how StackOverflow can be used to share thoughtful, detailed solutions to programming problems.

Answer (score 11):

## The Pingsort algorithm

Stack Overflow contains a large number of excellent answers that have been, and continue to be, helpful to many software developers around the world. Some of them have already been mentioned in the other answers to this question.

I want to bring up an old favorite of mine, solely for its comedic value.

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748246), which appears to be a remix of an old Google job interview question, was asked back in 2012 and outlined a problem wherein a computer would receive a list of 1 million numbers over a network connection, and had to sort the list before sending it out over another network connection. To complicate things a bit, the computer only has 1 MB of RAM available.

A few answers were posted that attempted to provide practical solutions to the problem, using various approaches.

## [...and then there was this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13000176/1524450)

Rather than exploring elaborate compression schemes to fit the data in the limited RAM, this answer suggests badly abusing the network by sending out a huge number of [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) echo requests, thereby using the network as a sort of non-random access temporary storage.

I'm not particularly savvy when it comes to network protocols and infrastructure, so I can't really judge whether this approach even would have a *chance* of working in practice. But I believe that anyone working with engineering or any kind of technical problem solving can appreciate the creative spirit and nerdy tongue-in-cheek character of the answer. To quote one of the comments: *"This solution isn't just outside the box; it seems to have forgotten its box at home :D"*

Answer (score 11):

### [CSS selector for first element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

Had to mention **the answer by BoltClock** in the above thread. It helped me to understand how the various child selectors worked in CSS. The quality and comprehensiveness of the answer from a technical point of view is there for all to see and the no. of other threads where this answer has been referred to is a testament to it. But beyond the technical aspects, it has been such an inspiration for me on how to write a good detailed answer.

I am a hobby programmer and had joined Stack Overflow to share whatever little I knew about HTML, CSS and JS. Almost all of my early answers were code solutions with very little explanation and they always addressed only the specific question that was asked in that thread. I had never thought of the broader set of users who would have a slightly different problem but probably need the same solution (and) the novice users who would need an explanation to understand why a certain thing works while another would not.

I had come across this answer when another question was closed as a duplicate of this one. Reading this answer taught me a few things (in addition to helping me understand the technical aspects) which have helped me remodel and refine my own way of answering questions:

- A small piece of code may give users an immediate solution to their problem but it would not tell them why the problem had happened. Without knowing the ***why***, the ***how*** (to fix) becomes less obvious. Eventually the answer becomes equivalent of giving the guy a fish.
- A good answer is one that not only solves the problem of the person who asked the question but also that of future visitors. It is always better to provide a generic answer (while also answering the current question).
- You can add an answer to a question which already has an accepted answer (a highly voted one at that) as long as it adds a substantial amount of value to the thread and covers aspects that the other answer(s) didn't cover.
- Long and detailed answers are not unwelcome. They are the ones which are most welcome and are the ones that tend to help people over a long period of time.
- A good answer is not always one that is written once and stored forever. It is one that constantly gets updated as and when more information are discovered.

As a person who is not a native English speaker, writing detailed answers have helped me focus on and improve my communication skills also to a good extent.

**Thank you BoltClock!** Your answer(s) have been invaluable to the entire SO community. Following your example has got me positive feedback from other fellow users and a good portion of the credit goes to you.

I have written about the answer that inspired me the most but it doesn't mean that the others haven't helped or made a difference. I've never really *asked* any question here because there was never any need to. All questions that I've ever had were already answered. I would like to take this opportunity to thank each and every person who has contributed to the quality of Stack Overflow (in the form of questions, answers, edits, reviews) and has made it such a wonderful and trustworthy knowledge-base.

I understand that this thread is more about the ***answer*** that has made a difference but I would also like to **thank the members of the [CSS Shapes, SVG and Design](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/css-shapes-svg-and-designs) chat room**. I am one of the owners of this room and each member has made a difference one way or the other. The discussions we have had there, the questions and the solutions have helped me learn a lot.

#### Last but not the least, Thank You Stack Overflow!!!

Comment: Thanks! It's obviously one of my all-time favorite answers, though I mostly see it as just a canonical answer and not one that was meant to teach (I can think of answers where I do actively teach the asker but sadly don't have any links on hand), it's great that it served as such an inspiration to you.

Comment: Hope to see a revival of both the user and chat room.

Answer (score 11):

## Let me introduce you to one of MATLAB's most powerful functions and his most passionate advocate

I've been programming with MATLAB for 19 years now. I have some basic knowledge of other programming languages, but MATLAB is the one I know better.

About two years ago I decided to learn to program on Android. Just for fun. That involved learning Java first, and then delving into the depths of the Android API. Being an absolute beginner at both, I obviously resorted to Google quite often. And I soon noticed that the best results always came from Stack Overflow.

One day a wild thought occurred to me: *Perhaps I could also be an answerer here. I know MATLAB pretty well, and I can help with that. And it will be good practice for me*.

At that moment I didn't quite grasp *how much* my MATLAB knowledge would improve in the process. Indeed, seeing other people's answers lets you know new functions, tricks or approaches. Also, answering a question often leads you to push the limits of what you already know (just like your own programming problems do).

One of the functions I didn't know about, and which significantly changed my approach to MATLAB programming, is called `bsxfun`. For many of us, it's the Chuck Norris of MATLAB functions. An answer using that funcion usually beats any other answer, because of performance, compactness and elegance. And without discussion :-)

So I'd like to draw your attention to one of MATLAB top answerers, and `bsxfun`'s most prominent user by far:

[Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar).

He has got nearly 40k rep in 1 year and a half, answering almost only in such a low-activity tag as MATLAB. Believe it or not, [40% of his MATLAB answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/273107/which-matlab-users-have-the-most-answers-containing-a-certain-function) are based on `bsxfun`. He has a special ability to visualize all sorts of operations with multidimensional arrays (which is what `bsxfun` is all about), and many of his answers on the matter are impressive. I have learned a lot on the use of MATLAB thanks to him.

I'm highlighting the following question and answer (both by him), in which he analyzes the performance of `bsxfun` in typical scenarios. Divakar's answers tend to have an emphasis on performance, and this one is also a good example of that.

[Comparing BSXFUN and REPMAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719674/comparing-bsxfun-and-repmat)

Answer (score 10):

## [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I just registered on stackoverflow to search for some regex question that I needed to fix. After some time looking for what I wanted, I saw this question (mine was not related to HTML parsing with regex)

I laughed so hard at that answer that I decided to just learn regex, some time after I was just answering simple regex questions in stackoverflow but there is a lot of competition to answer simple regex questions so I am still learning a lot of everything I can so I can return the favor that StackOverflow has given to me.

Now, years after, I am a Junior Java Developer for an awesome company where I am happy, and happier because I am programming, I've grown with StackOverflow!

Edit:

I actually would like to add this question and answers to what I actually love about stackoverflow, the people.  People really care about other people and rely that when they have a question, they will get the same answer quality that they are giving, and they do. That is the key.

Sometimes I feel bad because I may not have the experience or knowledge of something but the feeling of helping someone is just awesome. I must say congratulations to one of the best built sites in the Web and without any doubt, the community with the best people I will find, keep up the good work everyone, you all rock.

Comment: The center cannot hold. He comes. He comes.

Comment: He totally deserves it. Also for coining the [too less jQuery meme](http://www.doxdesk.com/updates/2009.html).

Comment: You should make the hyperlink the header to your post, so it's more noticeable.

Answer (score 10):

### You can learn by answering

One time I was going through some new questions and one of them struck me as odd. It was titled ["automatically change org.mysql to org.sqlite"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18746245/179864). Having a little experience dealing with JDBC, I decided to check it out, and found that the asker was having a very perplexing problem: their code was trying to connect to a MySQL database, but it was throwing an exception related to SQLite!

That made absolutely no sense, so I set out to find what the OP was doing wrong. I wasn't able to reproduce the problem, and there didn't seem to be anything particularly wrong with the code (related to the question), so I dug deeper into the JDBC code to see how it handles multiple drivers.

What I found was quite surprising: DriverManager tries all the available drivers, and if the connection fails, it throws the first exception it got (if any). And the key part is that the SQLite driver wrongly throws an exception for the MySQL connection string, instead of reporting that it's not a matching driver (by returning null).

Having solved the mystery, I wrote [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18748754/179864) and explained the details to the OP and provided some suggestions for fixing the error. The problem was solved, I learned something new about JDBC (and found a bug in the SQLite driver too), and even got an "i love you" from the asker :)

Comment: My experience too: answerers can learn as much as askers!

Answer (score 10):

## [What is "entropy" and "information gain"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859554/what-is-entropy-and-information-gain)

The above linked post is probably one of the best examples of an epic answer that StackOverflow has, written by [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97160/amro).  Back then when I was a graduate student and learning about information theory, the textbooks I was reading were insufficient in allowing me to fully grasp the material.  I figured that because textbooks were published, they were the authority in learning a topic and these were the end-all-be-all of learning something.

I decided to try my luck on Google and when I typed in `entropy` and `information gain` into the search engine, this was the first result that popped up.  This post not only went into a good in-depth detail about the theory behind the topic, but he goes through numerical examples and shows graphics and illustrations on how a decision tree can be formed.  Decision trees have to be known before talking about entropy and information gain, and I dare say that this StackOverflow post is better than all of the textbooks I've read and my professor's slides at the time.

The post is still continuing to evolve.  If you see the edit history, Amro keeps updating the post with new theory, updating broken links and more examples.  This is exactly the same behaviour that StackOverflow embodies - always evolving and updating... just like his answer.  In actuality, that post is what got me started in answering questions.  The fact that you can provide just a few minutes of your time, with the potential of reaching millions of people and imparting on them the knowledge and experience that comes so easily to you has its benefits and also some great personal satisfaction.

---

If that isn't enough, then you may know Amro from his post on a [Single Layer Neural Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455660/single-layer-neural-network/3458036#3458036) which is a really good example of the reversal badge.  The OP did not show any effort in his answer, and not only did Amro correct the code, he posted animated GIFs and pictures of the code actually working and also explained what was wrong with his original defunct code.

---

Amro is a perfect example of what a StackOverflow user embodies and if you take a look at the comments in the entropy and information gain post, you can see that many of the users that read that post agree.

Comment: Thank you for thinking of me, and in return thanks for all your excellent contributions on SO! I'm not surprised to see you featured in a [story](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303507/97160) :)

Comment: @Amro - You're welcome :) I tried contacting you by email but I didn't receive anything back so I wasn't sure if you got it... but I guess you did!  Once I wrote this up, I've seen some more upvotes to both of your NN and entropy posts.  Hope those votes keep coming, and again thanks for being awesome :)

Comment: @Amro I was hesitant to [feature you again](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304062/2778484), but one positive experience with [a certain excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20083075/2778484) stood out (for me) above all others.

Comment: @chappjc - This post is for you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341953/change-vector-if-even-odd-in-a-matrix/32341979#32341979 - lesson learned... *never* use `length`.

Comment: I'm very honored, thank you @chappjc!

Answer (score 10):

**Jonathan Sampson is an amazing human being.**

This is a bit different from the example perspectives given, but I'd really like to call out and appreciate [Jonathan Sampson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54680/sampson).

[mOxie is undefined, yet very clearly defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283245/moxie-is-undefined-yet-very-clearly-defined/28284236#28284236)

I was having an issue with IE11 one day. The situation was that I was attempting to use `console.log`, but doing so outputted `undefined` while in IE8/9 document mode.

Sampson stuck around in the comments (of which he left 11) to help guide me to the solution. He was extremely patient with my frustration and ignorance while he tried to understand my issue.

After we threw the issue back and forth a few times, he--being an IE dev--looked at the IE bug tacker, and found that the issue was actually logged, and fixed.

At the time, IT had locked my IE version, so I was unable to update and receive the fix, but it was really great to know that an IE dev cared about us lowly developers enough to give me his time in order to help me solve my issue.

While the question and Answer are both authored by me, I'd like to submit [Jonathan Sampson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54680/sampson) as someone to receive some of the awesome swag :)

Comment: I can personally attest to this. @jonathansampson took time to address my question about IE developer tools and rollback versions to a new level. We communicated for a while on twitter, and he restored my faith in Microsoft.

The man is very nice, and often stays late at work just to help people with their issues with IE or to teach them about new features! Plus he's a great follow on twitter. Please give Jonathan some fun swag!

Answer (score 10):

He recognized the question that mattered, [gave an insightful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20083075/2778484), stole the accept away from my answer, and got my respect (rinse and repeat).

The Question: [What's the “right” way to organize GUI code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064610/whats-the-right-way-to-organize-gui-code/20083075) ([matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab))

The title poses a very general and subjective question.  The body of the question has many specific questions about various obscure aspects of GUI programming in MATLAB.  Hot damn, I thought, I've spent tons of time grappling with these issues! (**tl;dr**: I took the bait and regurgitated every relevant nugget of information.  [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97160/amro) gave a useful answer).  So, I wrote [a very detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20065967/2778484), going through each bullet with a spattering of undocumented tidbits and trivia that is typical for me. It was a thorough, well-cited... wall of text.  Oh, well.  I was happy enough and apparently so was the OP as it got the accept. Yay!

Then I went to bed.  In the morning, I was surprised to find [Amro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20083075/2778484) had popped up, gathered just as many votes as my answer, and stolen the accept.  The first thing he did right was to read the title of the question and see through the cruft.  The OP wanted to know a *lot* of things, but mainly how to organize GUI code in MATLAB with some demonstration.  (Forgetting that the question would have been closed as too broad or opinion based without a more specific question body.)  The second thing he did was to bring some serious talent to the table, and gave a theoretically sound answer with a full working example.  Finally, he had the patience and generosity to teach someone a new concept, demonstrated in detail.

[image]

In just about every answer, [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97160/amro) has something to teach and is gracious all the while he makes you look like a beginner.  Of course, at user id 97160, he's had plenty of time to practice the art of the perfect answer.  As [quasi-peers in our micro-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mex/topusers), [mex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mex), Amro has schooled me [time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20577537/2778484) and [time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26460963/2778484) and [time again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271154/how-can-i-make-a-mex-function-printf-while-its-running#comment41220192_26272307).  And it has been a pleasure. (How's that for [sportsmanship](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship?userid=2778484)?  I think I've just sealed the fate of my "competing" answers!)

I should mention that I could easily write similar accounts for users [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo), [rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3250829/rayryeng), [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar), [Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/shai), [Eitan T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336150/eitan-t) and others I know who embody #SOreadytohelp.

Comment: Someone should write a story about you!  My love for `accumarray` came from you!  I wrote about Amro already so I'm not sure if writing another story about you would be taboo :(.

Comment: @rayryeng Nah, you and Amro are far more patient and generous than I ever was, and I think that's what makes a great contributor.  Cheers!

Comment: Great story! And thanks for the mention!

Answer (score 9):

> [VB6/COM Interop: where do these events come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16600023/1188513)

One day I got confused and used the wrong attribute in COM-visible C# code meant to be exposed to a VB6 library, which resulted in every single exposed member being exposed as an event... and I couldn't figure it out, so I asked Stack Overflow.

The question was [almost closed as a "too localized"/typo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600023/vb6-com-interop-where-do-these-events-come-from#comment23879876_16600023), but Hans Passant's and Dan Busha's invaluable answers went out of their ways to explain things I hadn't the slightest idea about, leaving what I deem an incredibly useful post that made the Internet a better place.

Googling "`COM interop events C#`" brings up that question in 2nd position, which is awesome.

I ended up marking [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16600940/1188513) as accepted, because [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600023/vb6-com-interop-where-do-these-events-come-from#comment23873018_16600940) triggered that wonderful "oh!" moment that I'm after when I post a question on Stack Overflow. The funny thing is that, at first, I thought Dan's answer wasn't even about my question.

Answer (score 9):

## A lesson for the answerer

**The lesson**

Every tiny bit of information can make the key difference, although it suggests itself to be unimportant.

**The answer**

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27441982/1564895) to the question [init an NSNumber from enum element in mixed-language project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441097/init-an-nsnumber-from-enum-element-in-mixed-language-project/27441982#27441982)

### The Story

I decided to share this story, because it taught me the above lesson the hard way. And in this case, what turned out to be wrong was the assumption that Objective-C and Swift enums are handled in the same way. Let's return to the beginning...

**How my first attempt failed**

I already had some experience with programming in Swift and found the mentioned question. While reading it, it seemed to be quite simple, especially as the error message suggested that the author simply used the wrong initializer for the type he tried to hand to it. As I always try to test my answer before giving answers that don't work, I opened up my Swift Playground and tried a few things which supported my guess about the wrong initializer. And I wrote the first revision of my answer.

While I knew that I tested this with Swift enums instead of Objective-C enums like the author did, I thought that it should not make a difference. And why should it? Swift is a brand new programming language, there are enums in both, Swift and Objective-C, so I assumed that enums are handled the same, no matter in which language they are defined.

That's what I thought. Meep! Wrong! Almost one day later, @quanguyen informed me in the comments that my answer did not work. And he already pointed in the right direction.

**The second attempt**

I revisited my answer, checked my tests in the playground, read over the question, looked for differences, and eventually made more tests with enums actually defined in Objective-C. And while intuition says they both should behave the same, they actually did not.

So, I updated my answer and besides showing the solution to the question, I also included a description of the (in my opinion confusing) differences I found, to hopefully save many other programmers time.

Answer (score 9):

I spent a lot of time and love in SO, it's hard to pick one specific story.

Some of my joys come from the easy answers that got me unreasonnable comments from enthousiastic developers pretending that I "saved their life" or that I am "a genius" or "a God". And there's also [*this* particular comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305631/ie9-float-with-overflowhidden-and-table-width-100-not-displaying-properly/10305733#comment15551708_10305733)...

[image]

I'm also proud of those answers that I simply made complete enough so that they're useful for a lot of developers. My answer on [how to use MySQL in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353679/whats-the-recommended-way-to-connect-to-mysql-from-go) was rather easy to come with, even at that time, but by extending it from the strict answer to the question to a small guide, I made it more helpful for the community.

I could also tell the story of [that case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292899/javascript-literal-keys/25292921#25292921) where I was immediately upvoted for an answer that I later realized was *totally wrong* and that I fixed before anybody noticing. But the 10M celebration isn't the right time to speak too much about this malfunction (too often do I go to SO while waiting for the effect of the first morning coffee to kick in, or just drunk from some good wine).

So I'll speak of this case I solved with EaselJS.

EaselJS is one of the most popular libraries for Canvas based games in the browser. I had made a small open souce smart game with it, [SpaceBullet](http://dystroy.org/spacebullet/), because I wanted to learn that kind of technology (go play it! it's fun and of course totally free of any ad). I thus had some basic knowledge of it.

So my interest was picked up by this question: [**EaselJS onclick takes over entire canvas**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246361/easeljs-onclick-takes-over-entire-canvas/19247485#19247485).

There was obviously nothing wrong in OP's code, so I dived into the code of the library. I could identify the problem, reproduce it in the official demonstration, devise a workaround, then raise an issue in GitHub with a fix suggestion. The small question that almost nobody saw leaded to a [bug fix](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/375) in a very popular library. That's another way SO helps developers everywhere.

That wasn't terribly hard to solve, I choosed this story because it's also a success story of the open source community and I think SO is a big natural complement (and even part) of that community. I'm sure it's at least the same, great, spirit.

Comment: Yeah see, I have a slightly more pessimistic view on that. This is an alternative path that is just as likely to happen: person asks about a problem on SO rather than in the discussion forums or bug tracker of the library itself where the devs can instantly see it and identify it as a bug. SO produces a workaround or less likely convinces said OP to use an alternative. The end, and not such a happy one because SO actually got in the way of progress. The points in your story go entirely to you for actually going the extra mile, SO has little to do with the success. **Thank you**.

Comment: so wheres the picture with the tatoo?

Comment: @SMR Unfortunately, he didn't deliver :(

Answer (score 9):

### How a user on Stack Overflow personally introduced me to the Perl Community

This is not about one question, but rather about a single comment that turned into much more interaction.

In the summer of 2012 I had just discovered Stack Overflow and started answering questions in the Perl tag. I considered myself quite able to do that, but of course was pretty much in awe of all those high-rep users.

I jumped at every question and tried to answer as much as possible. If I didn't know what the question was about, I went and did research. I installed modules and read documentation just to find an answer. That did not go unnoticed by the veteran users in the small Perl tag community.

One of those users was [daxim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46395/daxim), who like me is from Germany. He often replied to my posts and offered corrections. One of those included a little personal note. It was on the question [Syntax error using Perl DBI module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11046728/1331451), for which [I had written an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11046803/1331451), and read:

> simbabque, it works better when you include a hyperlink to what you're talking about: [**open a new question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) – Also, come meet me at [YAPC](http://act.yapc.eu/ye2012/)

That was a first for me, and I was excited. A user with more than 10k reputation asking me to meet at a conference?! At that point I thought that is only for really professional people. And YAPC Europe is **the** Perl conference in Europe. But it was in Germany, only 3 hours away from me by train! So I decided to go.

Because I had never been to a conference, I was unsure how that works. But  daxim is one of those people who contribute a lot to open source, it was easy to get hold of actual contact data. And since he invited me, I contacted him and asked a few questions about how conferences work, if I should come early and stuff like that. I wasn't sure if he would reply.

When there was a reply only three hours later I was even more excited. That anonymous person on the internet hat taken the time to help me a lot more. In fact, he wrote a short story that should be a blog post for first-time IT conference visitors. It was awesome.

A few weeks later I met him at the conference. An anonymous internet person that took the time to correct people to help them help others turned into an actual person with a face, just because he left a couple of extra words in a comment on Stack Overflow.

He introduced me to the Perl community, and that happened through Stack Overflow. I'm very happy and thankful for that. Since then, I am trying to encourage people that use Perl to use Stack Overflow, and I encourage people that know Perl and are active on Stack Overflow to go and visit conferences, because I believe that community works both ways.

Comment: Thats a great story. I can relate to it. Code Review introduced me to a developer who I now share an OSS project with. Bringing people together. Yeah. I can dig it.

Answer (score 9):

### How StackOverflow question inspired me to build an extension used by 35k people.

One day I've found a website rendering bug in the Chrome browser and decided to report it. I needed a minimal test case, but it was cumbersome to create one by hand. So, I started looking for a tool that would allow me to extract a small part of the DOM tree, together with styles, out of a website. I ended up finding **[this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4911338/1143495)**. It was already very popular and quite old by that time. Even though it had couple of answers, none of them seemed to solve the issue completely. Seeing that so many people are looking for such a tool I decided to create one. That's how SnappySnippet Chrome extension was created. As soon as first version was ready, I posted **[an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18928130/1143495)** to the original question linking to my extension and explaining in detail how it was created and how it works. Extension immediately got popular and got mentioned by couple of front-end rockstars, Smashing Magazine and many others. Today, it's in the official Chrome DevTools extensions gallery and is actively used by ~35k people.

Building SnappySnippet I learned a lot about CSS and browser internals, got contributions and advice from some awesome people and uncovered couple of, previously unknown, Chrome bugs ([1](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=313670),[2](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=298972),[3](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=315028),[4](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=319328)).

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of answers by [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) that I've found incredibly interesting, often due to his rather unique insights into C# and its associated projects. One in particular that stood out to me was actually not about anything along those lines, though - it was [this very thorough explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2704795/390989) to the question [Monad in plain English? (For the OOP programmer with no FP background)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2704652/390989).

The story goes like many others: I came across the term "monad" being used in various pieces of documentation and literature, but had not been previously exposed to the concept. Eric's answer provided a truly exceptional starting point for my understanding, and it also happened to include examples based in a language I knew (C#). Despite many other similar answers and posts floating about on the web, I personally found this one most useful because he did such a great job of approaching the answer without having to dive too deeply into functional programming ideas (which I had very limited familiarity with). It's simply a very approachable answer for anyone from an OOP background.

His answer was so detailed, in fact, that he actually ended up spinning it off into [an excellent, 13-part blog series](http://ericlippert.com/category/monads/). I'm not sure if you can go much more "above and beyond" than that, really.

IMHO, this answer is a great demonstration of the power that is Stack Overflow. When experts come together to share their knowledge, there is a much greater opportunity to really learn and understand something. People willing to take their time to impart fundamental knowledge like this has been much more valuable to my own personal and professional growth than having a million lines of code written for me ever would.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. Writing that answer and later the series helped me clarify my own thinking on the subject.

Comment: Thanks to you for letting me know about this post. I've been wanting to know for a while what a monad was, but everything I'd read seemed to be steeped in functional programming jargon that I found impenetrable.

Answer (score 8):

### The Question

[Why is "if not (a and b)" faster than "if not a or not b"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29551438/2615940) posted by [Augusta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3408500/augusta).

### The Answer

I feel a little weird about tooting my own horn, but you encouraged it. :) It was my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29551787/2615940

### The Story

The question itself is very simple: why do two logically equivalent operations have different performance profiles? It interested me because I *didn't* know the answer upon reading it. We all know that a lot of questions posted are straightforward debugging questions. Experience helps a lot of us see the problem right away, and we often have a solution in mind before we even finish reading it. This one was different to me, because it asks *why*, and I had no idea. Reflecting on it now, it reminds me of the Isaac Asimov quote:

> The most exciting phrase to hear in science, the one that heralds the most discoveries, is not "Eureka!" (I found it!) but 'That's funny...

This question made me think, "Hmmm. That *is* odd...". They're my favorite type of question to try to answer, because the process of answering it forces me to learn something new.

Once I had the answer, I admired the question even more, because discovering it required diving into an aspect of Python that is often neglected in high-level languages: bytecode disassembly. The answer was in how the Python interpreter translates Python code into bytecode differently for the two operations. High-level languages were invented specifically to relieve programmers of the burden of dealing with assembly, yet that's exactly where the answer to this question was hiding. It highlights the importance of understanding the underlying mechanics of our software, even with modern tools like compilers and high-level languages. These tools allow us to create *sufficient* software more quickly than ever before, but making *optimal* software requires a deeper understanding of the whole stack, from CPU to end-user.

I feel like this question and answer pair exemplifies that idea.

Answer (score 8):

An answer I think deserves recognition is this:

### [Is VBA an OOP language, and does it support polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31861832/3296811)

As a kid, I'd written many VBA scripts for little things like changing settings files out, and from I what had seen, I thought VBA was OOP, and despite that the answer wasn't to a question I asked, it changed a view I had on VBA for years.

It can be hard to convince people that it may not be OOP language with 3/4 requirements met, but, Mat'sMug, wrote a really complex answer on what makes VBA OOP and what doesn't make it OOP. Adding a lot of content and understanding, he wrote a really complete answer, even formatting with little ticks and crosses to put the icing on the cake.

This kind of work is clearly the work of someone who loves their language, and wants to teach others about their language, and to help them love the language.

If this isn't dedication, then I'd better redo my definition of dedication.

Answer (score 8):

## No guaranteed reward or money incentive, just goodwill and generosity

A couple months after joining Stack Overflow I saw a question that really interested me.
A little gem hidden in the 10 million questions not many people have seen:

[Is there an efficient algorithm for segmentation of handwritten text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015001)

I thought about this question over and over "how can this problem be solved"? Again and again I came up with ways that all ended up being [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome)'ish idea's.

I knew the author wanted a algorithm but didn't think anyone would provide a 
rock solid solution. Heavens above, doing that would take hours *I thought to myself*. So I shared my idea's with the OP...

About two months later I revisited the question and some guy/girl (@Rethunk) had written up a full on working app, with algorithms, histograms and all! This dude must have spent hours and hours on it, for no guaranteed reward or money incentive, just good-old fashion goodwill and generosity. This guy had just taught me the definition of going above and beyond the call of duty. It had a profound effect on me. I came to realize why Stack Overflow is so powerful. The developers who contribute to Stack Overflow really care about quality. Not some half baked idea's some goon thinks are creative!

SO is filled with people that come out of the wood work, are specialists in their fields and share incredibly high caliber insights. Quality answers that are better than SOX's in Microsoft Visual KB and even better than MSDN Articles. That's what makes SO such a great place, really difficult subjects are answered by masters in their respective fields. Thank you Rethunk, whoever you are and a toast to Stack Overflow; you have surprised an industry of our beauty and benevolence.

Edit: 3 yrs later and I'm now in the top dozen or so  bounty hunters, globally.

Comment: You're welcome, Jeremy! I just heard about 10 Million Questions today (2016-03-14: Pi Day!). Sorry for taking so long to thank you. I've been helped out by SO many times myself, and given the days and weeks of debug and development time many SO posts have saved me, I figured it's only fair if I spend a few hours here and there trying to help. (Admittedly, solving problems is fun, too.) I'm honored that you mentioned me here, and your post has brightened my day considerably. (Also, though somewhat irrelevant: I'm a dude.)

Comment: Cheers, check my profile pic, I just got my T-Shirt, Mug & etc :)

Comment: Sweet threads and mug.

Answer (score 8):

One interesting place to be on Stack Overflow is in low-volume tags. You nearly never get the upvotes or visibility you get on the more popular tags. Many of my questions there (in [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) are unanswered).

But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338071/1048539) I wrote was a culmination of many painful experiences working with an Internet Explorer object in [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba).

Because of a near-bug with the IE COM interface, the "ready?" question for Internet Explorer is... less than trustworthy. I had written a method to get around this, which turned out to precisely answer another user's question. It's not clear from reading M$ documentation (what? no way) that this "near-bug" exists.

Given how frustrating that it was for me to beat against, it was a delight to post an answer which clearly was well received:

> [Enderland: You are a beautiful person. It's frickin' awesome! and works like a charm. This cleared up all the issues I was having. Thanks! –  user3232254 Jan 24 '14 at 20:18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335370/vba-inconsistent-error-91-in-loop-w-ie-doc-reference/21338071#comment32175361_21338071)

Explaining to the asker why my answer worked and why it was a better solution than the rabbit trail they were going down (and I had already traveled down) is quite the feel-good experience. Especially considering how painful the trail was for me...

Comment: [Don't get me started on Microsoft's VBA documentation...](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/11/06/meta-programming-in-vba-the-vbide-and-why-documentation-is-important/)

Comment: @RubberDuck yeah I've found bugs/ommissions/etc. Fortunately I am skilled enough to know that's the problem...

Comment: If it hadn't been for a friend using the library in C#, I'd have never known.

Answer (score 8):

## Oh Yes You Can Use Regexes to Parse HTML!

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491) by [tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist) surprised and delighted me. It's detailed, it's long, it's mildly self deprecating, and it's got plenty of links to a whole lot more reading. It also got me into reading a whole book on programming again; one by [Tom Christiansen](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all). And after doing so I decided I should never have stopped reading good programming books, so I put together a list of what I'd been meaning to read and a schedule to read it. It's been a real joy.

But the story is also about how I got to even read this pretty great answer and thus add to my reading list.

I've loved using SO from the beta days, even before comments etc. But for even longer, I've kind of loved Perl (and scheme, but Perl does more... so), and when I get a little tired of C, C++, C# and Java leading me to so many incremental changes on projects rather than new different projects, I tend to pull out a little bit a Perl (also lately Python and Go, thanks SO) to play with because it's so welcoming to just trying something right this minute. That's why on SO I watch the Perl tag.

Quite recently I got a little tired of that tag's frequent "fix my regular expression" questions that seemed to drown out the Q&A that I better learned from. Thinking on it, I thought that maybe I had a suggestion that could help people self-help a little better in regards to regex being more of a different dsl inside your normal day-to-day language (though my view of Perl is that this dsl is the first part you should learn thoroughly...). I [asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300740/can-stack-overflow-notice-a-regular-expression-question-and-maybe-suggest-someth) on meta if there was an solution to this, thinking I could then propose mine if there wasn't (and I hadn't noticed till then that the meta about stack overflow had broken off from the original meta site). Basically instantly [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) pointed out how this was already solved, and it was almost identical to what I thought could help. I'd just never seen it because I rarely ask these kinds of questions myself, and I often write "regular expression" or "regexp" instead of instead of "regex".

That interaction is what lead me to this great example of building up a regex in to a whole parser based on regexes; and led to my renewed joy at reading about software and languages. Thanks everyone.

Oh and, I recall feeling a little special when I got a [sarcastic chide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6480/would-you-play-a-stack-overflow-board-game/6708#comment11960_6708) from Jon Skeet on a meta post:

> Please provide more detail next time. These quick, throwaway answers aren't terribly useful.

Comment: tchrist is Tom Christiansen :)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Also it's worth noting that he's a top 5 rep user on English.StackExchange.com.

Comment: Yes, just making it clear for those who don't know.

Answer (score 7):

**What is the meaning of this?!?**

For me, the first thing that jumps out is [CommonsWare's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) answer about Context in Android. I know for me, and it has seemed for others, that this is a hard concept to grasp when first learning Android. What is a context? How/when do I use it? There's more than one? Crap! Which do I use when? I give up I'll just use whatever!

**Oh, yes, that's what I was looking for!**

Fortunately, CommonsWare gave [this answer about Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context). This answer has very good, detailed information about the differences complete with reputable links which clear up the issue even more if someone is still confused after reading the answer.

**It takes time but that's ok**

This business about the different types of Context, at least for me, is so confusing that I had to read the answer several times (links included) before feeling like I had a better grasp on it. There are many answers saying you should use "this context" or "that context" but I haven't found any which explain it this well and which have external information for further reading that also help. After many efforts, this answer finally made me feel more confident about which to use and when. For me, it explains more of the *why* to have certain ones instead of just "use this Context for this situation and use that Context here". Answers like this are **soooo** much more beneficial than simply pasting code. It is also answers like this one which made me understand that aspect of SO which is so very important. You know, kind of like the teach a man to fish story. I have much pride in the fact that I typically try to explain the *why* an answer should be used instead of the *how* and answers/members like this is what had opened my eyes as to how to use the site more effectively and to better help others.

**A side effect of the answer?**

Furthermore, what makes this answer so good is that it's a good lesson to beginners to not use things you don't understand. *"...only use getApplicationContext() when you know why you are using getApplicationContext()..."* that is a very important lesson on any topic (especially programming). I've given several comments/answers on not using `getApplicationContext()` which have solved issues and the linked answer is a good part of the reason how I was able to clearly(?) convey the reasoning in my posts.

**Think I'll keep this answer under my pillow**

I've referenced this answer many, many times in closing questions, giving answers about the subject which can't be simply closed as a dupe, in chatrooms, comments, etc...

Answer (score 7):

**My Selected Answer**

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/4771017) I've chosen to write about is in the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) section of StackOverflow. Written by [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc), is an accepted answer posted on a question requesting [tips for avoiding Java code within JSP files.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

The submission was [substantial to begin with](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3180202/1) and offered suggestions for replacing JSP scriptlets
`<% %>` with server side functions (the bits *I* was interested in), as well as some code for execution on the client side. Over the course of its still active lifetime, the answer has been updated to include disadvantages of [scriptlet tags](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3180202/2), as well as sources from [Oracle's own documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3180202/3).

I mention its active lifetime, because as an answer written in 2010, it has had revisions each year since then (minus 2013, a boring year), the majority of which help to keep source links updated.

**Why I've chosen it**

The second and third level Computer Science courses at my university were Java based and centered around a foundation of developing and understanding web applications. My professor utilized the valuable feedback loop of students seeing their efforts revealed in a recognizable format, through web pages. His efforts weren't lost on me and I eventually began several server&client-interaction projects in my spare time, eventually finding a job supporting a web application.

I came upon this question in 2014, my graduating year. The year of my research project and courses which encouraged design patterns and the [MVC architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

At this point I had been spoiled and learned to love the fluidity of JSP pages in my projects, but then was the time to professionalize my education. I found BalusC's answer and linked sources helpful in finding the dividing line between server and client side functionality, which scriptlet tags helped blur so easily. Even this year, I've used some of his linked resources as references.

**Bonus answer**

My [first experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292040/updating-old-read-pre-java8-posts-with-new-answers) with MetaSO was a question I posted,  which asked about updating Java answers with fancier Java8 solutions. Over the course of that discussion, I had eventually [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo/26350973#comment48097053_3001879) on one of BalusC's answers (posted in 2010), asking if he could update it. And he did, 10 minutes later.  I hadn't noticed right away that he was the author of both posts (who pays attention to usernames when you're a research-greedy student?).

Answer (score 7):

> [Swift: Class does not implement its superclass's required members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126295/swift-class-does-not-implement-its-superclasss-required-members/32108404#32108404)

Hanging out in The 2nd Monitor on the Code Review chat has it's benefits, one of them was the discovery of this gem by [nhgrif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2792531/nhgrif). If you read through the question, and all the comments, it tells it's own story:

The OP had written code, and for some reason, it was throwing the error after they updated their Xcode environment. This was because the new Xcode version was enforcing a very specific rule, about `init` method inheritance. Now, while the other answers definitely clear up the *how can I fix it* portion of the question, they don't completely clear up *why am I receiving this error*.

The first thing I noticed with this answer that made it stand out is that it was *very descriptive* about the problem, even providing a *very good* example on how to duplicate it. And while the other answers were **good** and helped the OP resolve his issue, this one actually put it in a format that *is extremely useful to future users*. Were I working on a Swift application and I had this issue, this particular answer would be of **much** more value to me, as it clearly shows that the person writing the answer cares a great deal about helping out future readers.

The biggest takeaway from this answer is that Swift is *very* specific about inheritance of `init` methods, which is something none of the other answers really point out. They are either "code-only" or workarounds, not really *teaching* the user (or future readers) anything. Even without the context of the OP's code, this answer explains *in great detail* a very possible pitfall of Swift development.

Now, I've never written a Swift application before, but *because of this answer* I actually began investigating Swift. *This answer* piqued my interest into that language and it's structure. Personally, not even being a Swift user I found more help out of this answer than any of the others posted.

Lastly, what really made this stand out to me, was that it was an answer to a *year old question*, with 23k views, and an accepted-answer with a score of 91. And *yet*, nhgrif went out of his way to post *one of the most detailed answers I've ever seen* to this question. If that's not dedication, I'm not sure what is. :)

Answer (score 7):

### [How can I make a chain of function decorators in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/739654/359284)

Specifically, [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/739654/359284#1594484) who I'm going to give the credit to [e-satis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9951/e-satis) because the system is crediting 77% of the answer to them.

[e-satis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9951/e-satis) has provided a few [highly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python/6581949#6581949) [upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python/231855#231855) [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/622308/359284), which is probably why a co-worker first described them as "this really smart Python guy" and finished off that sentence with "this really informative answer". I was first learning Python when a co-worker mentioned using decorators and I had *no idea* what they were. That was until after I read over that answer, which goes in depth to explain how decorators work and the different ways that they can be set up, and felt that I knew exactly how they worked and why they can be such a difficult concept to grasp.

It was actually the first answer I had read on Stack Overflow that **went into so much depth** and **made sure that people understood** which inspired me to actually stay around and look for more helpful answers. It's not that I hadn't found helpful answers, but up until that point I had associated the website with short answers that get the job done (or half of it) and required more searching to learn *why the answers worked*.

I've since gone on to recommend that answer to both new interns and co-workers who have never dealt with decorators before.

Comment: Hard to believe I had to go all the way to the third page to find a e-satis answer. Along with his [metaclass](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/2359271) and [yield](http://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/2359271) answers, these are the reason I started using the "favorites" feature on SO.

Answer (score 7):

### The Time Someone Spent More Time on Helping Me Than I Spent Helping Myself

About a year ago I was developing a PhoneGap app. It lets you create a web app using HTML, CSS and JS and convert it to a "native" Android or iOS app. I really liked the concept back then because I was good in web development and I knew nothing about Android development.
It was cool and all, and at some point my app was almost complete, but for some reason when I loaded it on my phone, it didn't really function. I tried over and over to find the problem and I couldn't, so I came to SO.

Then this really nice fellow called [Tony Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2949443/tony-chen) saw my question and started helping me. Right away he followed up with some comments, and from there to an answer. In the answer, he explained that my code is working perfectly for him and I should try again with a couple of modifications. I did and it still didn't work. **He actually gave me his email and said we can continue our conversation there.**

So we kept messaging through email, trying to find the problem; I sent him my codes, he sent me the compiled versions, he tried it with different variations and some three days later it finally worked for me. All thanks to him and all the time he dedicated for me and my little project. He showed amazing patience and understanding of the situation and never quit just because things weren't working, he kept trying and I kept trying.

---

[**Link to the question on SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228599/phonegap-app-works-on-desktop-not-on-mobile)

Answer (score 7):

I had participated on Stack Overflow for a little bit of time beforehand, and I had written some well-received answers, but [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20877115/1079354), and *especially* the way the asker genuinely felt like they had learned something from it, hammered home the reason I participate on the site.

In the past, I had been a Computer Science tutor for my college.  When I transitioned into another job on campus, I started to miss helping others out; that's what led me here in the first place.  By the time I had come across this particular question, I was well into my first professional job and was used to giving others a hand here.  However, this particular question was one that was nuanced enough that it was perfectly understandable as to why someone could get mixed up on it.

I had written a response on it in a fairly straightforward manner, explaining why `==` on an `Integer` wouldn't be reliable for values not in the cache, clarifying a few of the nuances that they were diving into.  I had edited the question a few times beforehand to make sure that it was clear, and responded to a few of the questions posed.

Then I went to bed.  It was pretty late local time.

When I woke up to check on the question again, I was *stunned* to find that the OP had received it so well!  It was a bit before I had to go to work, but seeing the response from the OP on it and seeing that they actually understood the answer was such a rush of nostalgia and adrenaline.  It took me back to the reason I first jumped into tutoring.  The desire to share my knowledge with someone on a subject I'm familiar with

From then on, that interaction inspired me to help more people in the same manner, both here on Stack Overflow and in my professional career.

Answer (score 7):

#### [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/717383)

Asynchronous behavior is something that can be very confusing to newer programmers--or simply those new to JavaScript. Add to this, JavaScript libraries with utility functions that make it even less obvious that asynchronous calls are even being made and you end up with tons of people who just can't wrap their heads around the topic.

There was a time when it seemed like half of the JavaScript questions I opened turned out to be someone confused by [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). Many of the questions got specific answers that addressed the problem in the code, but they did not explain the concept in a way that the asker went away with a new understanding. Felix's thorough answer changed this.

Even more than the 1650+ score of the answer, I think the most telling number that illustrates the usefulness of the answer (and related question) is the nearly 3200 linked questions. Such a thorough answer to a commonly misunderstood concept is invaluable.

Comment: Oh dang, I wanted to nominate him as well :-) Do you think he'd get twice the swag if I tell a story about him and his invaluable canonical [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/1048572)?

Comment: @Bergi Couldn't hurt.

Comment: Oh my, I didn't even know about this meta post. FWIW, I never received any swag :P Thank you for deeming this q&a worthy :)

Comment: @FelixKling Hah, me either!

Answer (score 7):

A long time ago, before I even had an account on Stack Overflow I was looking for help for a Java problem I've had. So the first result on Google was, obviously, Stack Overflow. So I've checked the answer and saw, that it's possible to upvote an answer. Curious about what the highest voted answers in the Java section were, I've clicked on the Votes-tab and found this question:

**[Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result)**

I've read that question and thought at first:

*Nobody would or could answer that question, because nobody ever could have had the same problem and knows the answer to that problem.*

But I did not expect [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). [His answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/2497492) was short, but understandable and explained why that happened.

I was so excited at that moment that somebody takes the time and tries to help somebody at such an unusual problem for free (well, eventually he will get *some* upvotes).

So sometime later, I did this *find the most upvoted question* thing again and checked the question again. Now with even more upvotes. But not just with more upvotes, but also with some edits from Jon Skeet. He updated his answer to be correct again, because some timezones changed. These edits made me smile, because I found it awesome, that someone takes responsibility for his answer, even over one year has passed and updates it, to keep it useful.

This q/a is just one of many, many awesome answers on this site.
So many people do such an amazing job on Stack Overflow by helping others for free and updating their answers, etc. to save their *coding-bros* time. Keep up the awesome work.

Answer (score 7):

[msiemens's long-deleted post on "What is the difference between LL and LR parsing?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18239653/1763356)

#### That's just any other post, isn't it?

Way back in 2013, msiemens wrote an answer to an interesting, albeit open question. Problem was, it wasn't a very good answer and it lasted only two hours before deletion.

*On any other site, that would be that.*

Early next day, msiemens edited his question into something more informative, and a lot better written. Sadly, a week later, nobody had picked up this change, and the answer remained deleted at negative score.

*On any other site, that would be that.*

A week later, and a week later the answer remained deleted. Until **a year and a half later** I stumbled across the question. Although the 200-votes primary answer was great, I saw a decent, deleted answer in red. After checking its revision history, I understood the picture. I voted to undelete. But, alas, somehow it was rejected.

*On any other site, that would be that.*

But not on this site. [One post to Meta later](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289113/flag-dispute-should-answer-be-undeleted), with responses from not just a moderator but a site employee, and the post was undeleted. Not long after, +5 in the green. +10. +16.

**There are so many things that needed to be to make this happen.**

1. Deleted posts are encouraged to be fixed, not burned.
2. Stack Overflow shows votes and views, so the value of questions and answers is shown in the clear. I doubt I'd have cared so should I have thought the post was covered in cobwebs.
3. I, a non-moderator, could see not only deleted answers but their whole history. It's amazing that deleted answers are visible at all, and the revision history made all the difference.
4. Every question and answer can be flagged straight for a moderator's attention, and the results of those flags are documented in one's profile page.
5. The site must have a forum to talk directly about its maintenance. Not only does this forum exist, my question garnered the attention of a moderator, a site manager and a ton of community force.

On any other site, a question would have one chance. It boggles my mind how open a community like this can be, and how successful that can be. Although some would claim it should never have gotten this bad for a good answer to remain in the shadows for so long, with 10,000,000 questions that every answer can get a second, third *and* fourth chance is a true marvel.

#### Thank you Stack Overflow, thank you mods and thank you community!

Not only have I learned a little more about LL and LR passing, I've learned how damned awesome you all are. Keep it up, and see you again at 100,000,000!

Answer (score 7):

*How does it feel while answering(having a meagre 2k reputation at that time and being just passed junior year in my college) a question asked by a person holding more than 26k (worth of ~1600 answers in the same field Java) !*

Talking about the feeling and the way I clarified OP's doubt...

[image: Clarification of the fact]

> Question :- [Different compilation error when final local variable is
>   used with while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25470879/3482140)
>
> Answer :- It's somewhat peculiar to blow one's own trumpet, but [this
>   answer given by me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25471086/3482140)
>   raised my confidence to an unprecedented level. It might be a very ordinary answer for many, but, for me, it was only because of this answer which changed my thinking, my confidence, my feeling and an overall me. The OP took 2-3 days before accepting my answer.

***Story :-***

I was very careful while adding answers and always ensured that I answer only beginner level questions early in my days when I had joined SO (May-June 2014). I was pretty much excited to answer questions those days and used to stay online on SO for 10+ hours of a day, either learning(reading) or posting or asking(rare though). I also used to feel that I was late in joining SO and should have done in my freshman year in the college. But, *It is never too late to change the way you think*.

Then came this day after 4 months(~approximately) that I saw a question asked by user *Braj*, who was holding more than 26k at that time. I thoroughly went through his profile and my fear started haunting me before touching the keyboard. No one had even left any comment though there were probably 25-30 views at the time I saw the question(after 10 minutes of posting of the question).

Firstly, I did a careful analysis of what OP was facing. Then, it struck me that it was not so difficult problem and I should give it a try with a belief that I could, at any point of time, withdraw answering(discard my draft).

After a while I started writing an answer, there came [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25471048/3482140) by an author with nearly similar reputation as mine. My nerves were wrenching at that point of time and my blood pressure was at the peak. As I was in the midway somewhere, I paused for a while, and took a deep breath.

I clicked on the `1 new answer to this question` and without even reading that, I immediately checked the profile of the answerer. I might have even turned unconscious, but, anyhow held myself. Finally after checking answerer's profile, I took a deep breath. His answer prodded me into completing my answer.

The moment didn't end here. It took me some time to help OP understand what both of us had written. Other answerer wrote a short, but correct answer without any detailed explanation. I extended in my answer to cover every point in detail and added necessary quote(from Wikipedia) so that OP could understand significantly. I felt that *If you could make a higher reputation person understand a good concept with a clear description and enough time, you are obviously having qualities of a great developer.* Though OP took some time grasping it, but, after 2-3 days finally accepted my answer.

That very day pumped blood in my body with a new spirit, and this SO experience helped me acquire the much needed valour in this field.

---

Apart from this, I am very much thankful to Stack Overflow team and the noble developers present here who are contributing with their utmost dedication and helping people like me become an asset to the Earth. Thanks all for their presence here and "Hearty Congratulations" for crossing the milestone of 10m questions.

*(Hailing from a non-native English speaking country, I might have not expressed certain words/phrases clearly. Please improve the answer wherever you feel it should. Thanks in Advance.)*

Answer (score 7):

## Finally a teacher.

I'm a self-taught programmer and my school doesn't offer any programming classes. Well, I can't really complain because most don't.

When I first really started, I just wanted to create apps, iPhone apps. I had an iPod touch. *I loved it*. Could I create my very own apps on it? I googled a little bit a found out about StackOverflow. It was love at first sight. Well - no, but it helped me.

One day I was struggling with a bug in my code. I didn't know where to ask for help. My classmates? Hmmm, they have no idea what programming is. My
teachers? Neither. They don't teach programming at all! I then
remembered about that website. *Huh, was it like Stuck... Stack?
Stack Overflow?*

I found it and I asked questions. *Many questions*. They got votes. *Mostly downvotes*. But, hey - all the answers were good. They really helped me understanding how things worked. I felt like I had to repay the entire community. I went to the homepage and browsed through all the questions. *Oops, they all look pretty hard to answer.* SQL? I didn't even know what that was!

*There should be some way to filter questions* - I scrolled the page and saw the Favorite tags. That sounded like a great way. I finally typed in C and iOS and pressed Done.

I finally see a question. An iOS question. *Oh well, I must know this stuff.* The asker looked like having the same issue I had the other day! *I can help. I must help.* I clicked the answer button and answered fiercely. And then the post button. I then started refreshing the page many times until the asker went online and accepted it.

It was the first time I truly felt like I helped somebody at programming. Me, a programming noob, just helped someone! Me? *Really?* I was no more a learner, but a real teacher. Just like the ones in my school.

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27765153/1135714) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27749349/1135714).

Answer (score 7):

### [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg)'s [fantastic contributions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:315935%20%5Bjqgrid%5D) to the [jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jqgrid) tag

Several years ago, our development team discovered a wonderful little jQuery-based library called "jqGrid". In short, it puts some panache on HTML tables. Anyway, as great as the product is, its documentation and features are sometimes confusing or lacking, and where they fail, Oleg has succeeded, coming to the rescue <strike>3,911</strike> [**3,916**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A315935%20%5Bjqgrid%5D%20is%3Aanswer) times (~73% are accepted). It seems every question I've landed on while looking for help or suggestions with the library has been answered by Oleg, enough to burn his username into the back of my head.

To me, and likely to the countless others he's helped, this is a hefty and invaluable contribution to a slightly obscure tag, but what amazes me even more is the quality and content of the answers. There are far too many examples, but his answers usually contain well-explained and runnable code, and he more often than not keeps them up-to-date as the jqGrid product evolves! Here's his top three answers in the tag:

- [How to filter the jqGrid data NOT using the built in search/filter box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819)
- [jqGrid does not render correctly in Chrome/Chrome Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588587/jqgrid-does-not-render-correctly-in-chrome-chrome-frame/10621951#10621951)
- [can jqgrid support dropdowns in the toolbar filter fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328072/can-jqgrid-support-dropdowns-in-the-toolbar-filter-fields/5329014#5329014)

In them you will find screenshots, hyperlinks to documentation, working through issues through comments, updates, references to other questions, etc. And I don't see him slowing down anytime soon. I've even seen his name in comments and contributions to the project itself in the form of bug fixes, bug reports, so his work here is going full circle.

He is, of course, [the sole earner of a jqGrid gold badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1221/jqgrid).

I think this effort should be recognized, and that's why I've decided to write this entry today. He is a model answerer, and if you and I put half as much effort into our answers as he does, we'd still be writing good answers.

Thanks Oleg, and please, keep it up!

Answer (score 7):

## Sometimes it's better to turn off the computer and start thinking

One day I stumbled upon this question: [Object in NSMutableDictionary suddenly becomes null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620084/object-in-nsmutabledictionary-suddenly-becomes-null/15624023#15624023) . Usually, I can just read an Objective-C question and I immediately know what is wrong. However the poster of this question knew what he was doing. He knew how to log to console, he knew how to use a debugger. He obviously spent several long hours on the problem and he couldn't solve it.

The question was interesting - you put an object into a dictionary and if you check the dictionary in debugger, you can see the object is inside. However, if you try to access the object or even log the whole dictionary, the object is not there.

It was looking like a strange memory problem. I was trying to reproduce it with my code for two hours but I couldn't find a way to do it. Then I switched off the computer dissapointed and went for a walk. I started thinking - how does a dictionary work? Then I realized that every dictionary implementation has a warning "make sure your `hash` and `equality` implementation work correctly". Well, but how comes the debugger shows the objects stored correctly? And then it clicked - because the debugger knows the memory layout and doesn't have to calculate hash or compare objects! It is just listing the objects in memory.

When I returned home I had the correct answer prepared in my head. I didn't have to verify it. Sometimes using the brain is better than using a debugger.

The answer never received any upvotes, it was probably helpful only to one particular developer but it's still my favourite answer. Probably because I still remember the feeling of satisfaction when the solution clicked in my mind.

Comment: Possibly due to the Meta effect, your answer now has upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

That feeling you get when every answer to a question is 5+ paragraphs long. With all having such concise non-overlapping information that you end up reading for 30 minutes past finding the answer to your question. That entire time light bulbs and "Eureka!" moments are firing off left and right.

This is the reason I love SO (My friends all think I have share in the stock or something, but really this site is like 50% of the reason I have a job).

The most recent representation I have came across of this would have to be:

**Question:**  [How do multiple clients connect simultaneously to one port, say 80, on a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329641/how-do-multiple-clients-connect-simultaneously-to-one-port-say-80-on-a-server)

**Answer:** All of them (but if I have to pick one, [N0thing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27182584/4616759) probably taught me the most)

The questioner and obviously myself were confused on the underlying logic of how ports are used to transfer data. This is such a fundamentally important concept that is the basis for how all computers communicate, and yet it's glanced over in a couple lecture in most data communication courses and downright ignored in every other course.

The answers go into great detail about multiplexing, TCP vs UDP, the 5-tuple elements of TCP. More importantly (and the reason why I selected N0thing's answer) was the walk-through to create a local server and view the tuple. Following this and actually seeing the tuple first hand. It finally "clicked" something in my noggin and gave me that last piece of knowledge that I've been looking for to fully understand data communication. It got me to the point where I felt comfortable starting up a node.js server, and I'm proud to say I have 3 web apps currently up and running and expect many more in the near future.

I salute you @N0thing

Answer (score 7):

### There is still so much to learn about computing

The Question: [Why is one loop so much slower than two loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547778/why-is-one-loop-so-much-slower-than-two-loops)

The Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547993/937007

This question is interesting to me because it is the most recent case of "wow I had no idea that was a thing." There are so many good questions/answers on StackOverflow that teach you something you never knew on a fundamental level, this just happens to be the one that I remember most recently.

This is a very specific question and probably not likely to be of much use to me in practical development, but the linked answer expanded my understanding of how things work. The answer by [Mysticial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922184) goes to great lengths to a) determine the real cause of the performance difference (with test code, benchmarks, and graphs) and to b) explain why it happens.

When I first read the question I assumed, like many of the initial answers, that it was simply a matter of cache misses. I remember feeling good that I could recognize a situation where cache misses would be an issue. I also remember thinking how myself from just 3 years earlier would have *no idea* why there was a difference and would probably try to refute the OP's findings. Then I read the linked answer and it opened up my eyes to new things like data alignment, false aliasing, data size vs cache size, etc. I still may not fully understand it but knowing what you don't know is better than not knowing at all.

Also [Mysticial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922184) has a history of great answers that go above and beyond. Take this seemingly mundane [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621241/what-does-the-constant-0-0039215689-represent) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22621361/937007): it is a simple answer (1.0 / 255.0) but [Mysticial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922184) also goes on to explain why this manual optimization is necessary and not carried out by the compiler, details that weren't necessary at all to answer the question directly but contribute greatly to the contextual understanding of the actual problem.

Answer (score 7):

I would nominate [Padraic Cunningham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham)'s answer to my question [Import only functions from a python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133278/import-only-functions-from-a-python-file).

**The story:**

The last year I was one of the Teaching Assitant's in the **Python Programming** class at Purdue University for non-cs majors. The class had more than **200 students** and we were four TAs in the class.

We decided to give students around four projects in the semester. So, we went ahead and assigned every TA a project, and a deadline. Just by pure luck, I was assigned to the very last project, which supposed to have the deadline just before the final week.

There was nothing bad about it, however, the TA who prepares the projects, should also grade them. That was the deal in the beginning. And everybody including me didn't have any issue with it.

After the semester started, it was hectic for me since I was taking two theory classes. Happily, I was able to prepare and post the project on time, however, I delayed grading them for awhile. Time passed too quickly, while I was struggling with my own courses and one day I realized I was **two days ahead from the grading-deadline**. So, I decided to write an auto-grader which will makes things easier/faster for me and which will grade homeworks with justice. (hopefully)

So, I went ahead and gave my precious 5-6 hours writing the testers and making them better so that everybody will get the score they really deserved. I had only one day to post the grades, however, I was sleepless for awhile since I was also studying for my own exams. After finishing the tester, I was very happy since I was just going to run it and finish my grading work. So I tried running my tester script.

It turned out almost all submissions were already running the program itself (for debugging purposes) and the programs were opening another window so that my tester was failing to grade them all. I realized that I did not clarify in my project page how exactly the submissions should be. And if I would try to kill the window, the script was finishing before I test some other stuff, so it was a hopeless case.

After giving my 5-6 hours to write the tester, I didn't want to go ahead and manually grade them. I am not even sure I had enough time for that. I am talking about **200+** submissions here. I was already exhausted, so I decided to ask a question on SO and sleep instead of grading all the submissions manually. (I couldn't even wait to see the answers since I was too sleepy.) So I wrote my question nice and clear, and slept.

I woke up the other day, very excited to see if there is any answer... **And yes!** There was [Padraic Cunningham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30134747/547820) which is not a famous answer but **it saved my day**!

I was just able to adapt it to my tester and **boom!** I had all the grades like a charm using my script with the help of the answer with saving at least 5-10 hours. :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Finally grasping image manipulation][1]

<sup>That Eureka moment!</sup>

It's always so obvious in hindsight, but for days I was stuck on manipulating image data using HQ2x to try and upscale images.

I was trying to get this to work with the very verbose Objective-C, however the unfamiliarity of the the library itself, C level file manipulation, C level memory management and the requirement to use another 3rd party library all proved to give me an enormous headache. Just getting the thing to compile was a pain.

When I finally got the hang of the low level pointers and memory management, I turned back to HQ2X and tried to make some pretty images... But no luck! Everytime I tried to create an image, some messy, unknown format was produced. What was I doing wrong?

The brilliance of the Eureka moment is that it's instant. Somebody only needs to say, one word, one phrase or one line number for it to click.

For me, it' was @Jans comment in [chat][2]:

> raw pixel data

![enter image description here][3] Of course! I was passing in an encoded PNG. I needed an array of RGB values. How couldn't I see that?? I had already pointed out that there were two intermingled PNG magic numbers in the output.

Thanks @Jan! For both bothering to take it further than a few comments, and for finding the answer.

---

<sub>I'm always finding little moments like this and proudly occasionally providing them, but this one sticks out in my mind due to the sheer obviousness!</sub>

  [1]:https://stackoverflow.com/a/14480333/916299
  [2]: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7333956#7333956
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIEqe.png

Answer (score 7):

### When I finally understood that "Memoization" was not "Memorization" with a typo

I has been dabbling in Python for a few weeks when I decided to use it to solve a deceptively simple puzzle. A single word was hidden in a several thousand character long string. The puzzle writers provided the basic algorithm to extract the string as well as some samples with solutions for shorter strings, so I figured it would be a great problem to cut my teeth on. I would just implement their recursive algorithm, test it against the sample problems, then run it against the long string and call it a day, right? Not really, no.

It was easy enough (with some SO searches to resolve minor bugs, of course) to get my code to handle the smaller samples. I threw those into nosetests as a basic regression, then passed in the huge string. Nothing happened. My Python module was chugging along on its merry way, but I was getting no output. I killed the process, added some print() lines to see if anything was actually happening, and tried again. It seemed to be progressing, so I figured I would just give it more time. I removed the extra print() lines and left it running over lunch. I came back after lunch and it was still not done yet.

So I dove into Google and Stack Overflow, trying to find the root of my performance problems. Some blog posts advocated rewriting it in C. That seemed to be more trouble that it was worth, especially to solve this "simple" puzzle. I spent the rest of my afternoon applying small performance tweaks that I found here and there, none of them seemed to make much of a difference. I left it running on my work machine overnight, crossing my fingers that it might just need several more hours to finally finish.

But after getting home, I could not get this problem off my mind. I fired up my home machine and dove into it again. I used Valgrind for the very first time and identified that my program was spending the majority of its time in a single spot in the main recursive function. My online research kept telling me to "memoize it", but I had no idea what the hell they were talking about. I tried reading through several definitions and blog entries... none of it made sense.

Then I found this gem, [jason's answer to "What is memoization and how can I use it in Python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1988826).

**It finally clicked.** I applied it and the performance improved drastically. Another optimization and the puzzle was solved. But while I don't remember the puzzle that well, the knowledge of how memoization works and when memoization makes sense to apply has stuck with me, and I owe that to @jason's fabulous answer.

Answer (score 7):

### Answering the question without adding complexity

This is a small thing compared to many of the other epic answers here, but I'll share it anyway.

First I need to tell you about me: I'm *not* an awesome programmer.  I'm...competent.  I've been getting answers to my questions from Stack Overflow for years, and I created an account originally just so I'd be able to upvote the stuff that helped me.  I've asked a couple *meh* questions and gotten answers (yay!), tried my hand at answering a few, but mostly been part of the background noise.

Now on to the question.  Over the years I've heard people talk about encryption and that finding large prime numbers is important, but I never understood why.  I grok how the public key and private key work together in principle, but what do prime numbers have to do with it?  Whenever I'd ask Google or a geek that question I seemed to end up at a page full of math and I'd give up.  It made me feel a little stupid and embarrassed that I didn't understand this "obvious" thing.

Recently I found myself in another conversation about this and when the other person admitted that he didn't know either, we both pulled out our phones to look.  I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/439870/922300), and specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/439895/922300).  The answer isn't long, it's not full of math, and it *told me what I needed to know*.  Once I understood that the private key is a *pair* of prime numbers, I understood why people were talking about factoring large numbers.

And you know what else?  (At this writing) **87 other people** thought that was a good question too.  Whoa, it's not as stupid a question as I'd feared it might be.  Nice.

I know Stack Overflow was created for the experts, but thanks for also helping out the rest of us!

Comment: Thanks for the nomination, made me look at the answer again and improve it a little :)

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt thanks for the answer (and for continuing to maintain your work).  Enjoy your swag. :-)

Answer (score 6):

One of my learning experiences on Stack Overflow was my first attempt at a canonical answer. Granted it was a fairly [simple question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15798360/1947286), but I learned a fair amount about answering questions and sharing knowledge. Most importantly I learned to think about the readers who will find the post in their google results when trying to solve similar problems.

My answer there started as a ["try this: `code dump`"](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15800696/1) and slowly evolved into [one of my better answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15800696/1947286).

I also learned that not all questions/answers need to be profound, difficult, or even terribly interesting to be helpful to the community. Sometimes its the little things that people stumble over when they're starting out with a new language or library, and showing them a good answer to a simple question can inspire them to do the same and help someone else.

---

Another thing that has helped me quite a lot was Stack Overflow's quality standards for asking questions.

I can't tell you how many times I've gone to ask a question and ended up solving my own problem through isolating the issue in an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), checking for errors, and doing the required research. This process has made me a better developer and saved me countless hours of frustration.

Thanks Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

**What is the "purpose" of StackOverflow?**

Millions of developers have traversed these here pages of StackOverflow, posting questions, concocting answers... It seems fairly obvious what most would define as the "purpose" of StackOverflow. If you were to ask someone to define the purpose of StackOverflow, my guess would likely place "to get help with my problem" and "to help others with their problems" as the two most popular responses. And rightly so, those are the two main functions here. However, my story is a little bit more about me realizing, what I think, is one of the more subtle and rewarding aspects of Stack Overflow.

**My own version of SO's purpose...**

Nearly 4 years ago, I was still relatively new to whole idea of sharing knowledge. I was still learning... I am **still** learning every day. But, I didn't realize that at the time. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833314/are-secret-urls-truly-secure/) about secret URLs in regards to security. Scoffing to myself, I was so confident in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4833324/542517), I had written exactly one clichéd sentence within a minute of the question's posting and went on my merry way. As the answer was (initially) heavily upvoted, I probably thought something along of the times of "oooh, shiny reputation!"

Then the downvotes came, the comments questioning the validity of such a broad statement brought up different competing theories and points of view. A better, more thorough answer was submitted and quickly overcame my own, accepted answer. For a while, I sat on it, deciding that I stood by my statement. It didn't require any more explanation, I thought.

The funny thing that happened in the almost *three year gap* between when I had originally answered the question and finally decided to update it was that I had fundamentally changed my mentally as I spent more time growing as a developer and becoming more tuned in with the community. Looking back at the question, my new answer, and the answers of others, it's still pretty hotly contested on what people's opinions are.

**Going above and beyond for yourself.**

The moral of my story is I learned something great by trying to answer a simple question. Whether or not my answer was right at the time, is right now, or is something else completely, I learned that I can grow as a developer and as a problem-solver just by attempting to help others overcome their roadblocks or uncertainties. There's not one person on this site who is perfect, or knows every answer to every question, but the fact that we all band together and attempt to share out knowledge helps us grow in so many more ways than we know.

And therein lies, what I believe, is the true purpose of StackOverflow: **To teach and to learn and to grow.**

Thank you, StackOverflow, for continuing to help us all to grow.

Comment: [Even Jon Skeet asks a question from time to time.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=questions)

Answer (score 6):

Well, my first question asked here was

## [Expecting googlemock calls from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767131/expecting-googlemock-calls-from-another-thread).

**The story**

I was really in urge to find an appropriate solution, without spilling up my test case functions to sleep an arbitrary amount of time, to see if the functions in question were called from a separate thread.

That's a pretty technical issue, but it went to be an ignition for me, how I could actively contribute to the StackOverflow site.

At least [@Fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2556117/fraser)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10776615/1413395) got me on the right track, to solve the problem myself (it wasn't feasible to use a lambda expression with my environment, but I well knew how to overcome, and provide a workaround for lambda expressions replacing these with functor objects).

I've been contributing my answer, and it seemed to be helpful for a number of visitors.

I'm still using the technique with many unit tests of our production code (may have saved my employer a bunch of money up to now).

I had started answering questions [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766838/converting-file-in-utf-8-to-utf-16/10766971#10766971), but I think that was the turn point making me really getting a really active user on StackOverflow.

---

I've later tried to provide some good canonical Q&A, which have been appreciated partially.

Today I'm mostly refrain to try such, because it's likely you find an appropriate duplicate among these +10.000.000 questions and answers around.

Answer (score 6):

[Reorder four points of a rectangle to the correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22698125/1768232)

Possibly my favorite answer is the time when a guy was trying to order the four points of his rectangles, starting with the top left corner, do a lot of really complicated math, and couldn't get it to work out. The problem was that the top corner was not always the top left corner. He even made this great MS Paint picture:

[image: Rectangle screenshot]

I read the question and I wanted to help him, but unfortunately I had never used OpenCV before. There were a few answers that, again gave him really complicated math, and we had a lot of back and forth in the comments. Eventually I went through the OpenCV API and helped him to realize that rectangle's corners could always be taken in a sorted order if he wrote some very simple code based on the angle. I showed him how to set up a good test rig to prove it, too.

I helped this user learn how to write a good question, and to look again at the API and make sure that your first idea for how to solve a problem is not always the best. I also proved that Fastest Gun in the West does not always come out on top.

Answer (score 6):

### The Question

[Is there an actual example where inline is detrimental to the performance of a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24452525/2615940) by [Viclib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031791/viclib).

### The Answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24453267/2615940 by [Art](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939410/art).

### The Story

The question itself is great because it is questioning the status quo. As technological innovators, we should always be asking ourselves, "Does this rule of thumb still apply?" When technology advances, so must our practices. Things have moved so quickly, that we still have people actively working in the industry that were around during the time of punchcards. On one hand, it's a good thing: our industry is full of great minds that have tremendous amounts of hard-earned lessons and experience. But it occasionally comes at the cost of innovation when out-of-date wisdom is applied unquestioningly.

As evidenced by the answer, the idea that inlining C functions can have a performance impact is still very much applicable. Art supported his answer with actual industry experience, citing a single commit he made 10 years ago that showed this particular bit of passed-down programmer wisdom to be true. Not only am I impressed that he could remember and find the commit (I can't remember commits from a week ago), it showed a concrete connection between what we do here and how it can have a real impact on others' work. My favorite questions are ones that ask "Why?", but they can occasionally be esoteric and disconnected from any real application. This question and answer is an excellent example of the very real implications of asking why something is the way it is.

Answer (score 6):

## [Are variables declared with let or const not hoisted in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/4639281)

This question was asked not that long ago, but I ran into this when experimenting with ES6. The question itself is a decent question, but the meat is really in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222689/4639281) by [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi). This answer really goes above and beyond to explain what is happening, where other answers may have also answered the question, but not nearly as in-depth. This user always expends as much effort as necessary to answer the question as fully as possible.

I always enjoy reading posts by this user because, well... I always end up learning something new. Whether it is gaining a better understanding of something that I already knew of, or finding something I have never heard of before, it is always educational.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I nearly was thinking about nominating myself for one of these :-) I have not yet gotten to score a really popular (with hundreths of votes) answer, but I'm always trying to give people a detailed and deep understanding of the concept in question. I'm never sure whether I am not too technical, but apparently a few people like it ;-)

Comment: Honestly, I love reading your answers, and when I see you commenting on a post, I'm always waiting for your next answer. You are a prime example of a user who goes above and beyond on a regular basis to make sure that not only will the OP understand the topic as much as possible, but to make sure that future users will as well.

Comment: @Bergi I was just [checking out this question in Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/367035) to see if the great users of `[javascript]` got nominated and I am pleased to see that you did :) (I ended up nominating Rob W for his great work in `[google-chrome-extension]`, but you were a close second, and I'm delighted to see that you got one.)

Comment: @apsillers: Thanks :-) Felix Kling, TJ Crowder, Zirak and Benjamin Gruenbaum got their share as well (Benjamin even twice :-D)

Answer (score 6):

It's been 3 years since I wrote it, but I very much enjoyed writing the answer to this question:

## [How do x86 page tables work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10671172/541686)

I enjoyed answering this answer because I knew **first-hand** how confusing it was to understand, since I had personally struggled with *implementing* x86 virtual memory on a **toy operating system that I had written** sometime before that. I had refused to even look at GRUB or any other prewritten tools to help me bootstrap the system; therefore, I had stared and played around for hours, on many days, at the Bochs emulator's inline disassembler in order to understand how the paging process worked and how the page tables mapped the virtual addresses to physical addresses. So when I finally got it working, I felt quite triumphant (I felt like a kernel programmer!) and awaited the opportunity to explain it to someone on StackOverflow to help them avoid going through the pains that I went through. I tried to explain x86 paging as succinctly as I possibly could -- I personally love succinct answers -- but while including enough detail to address all the points of confusion that had personally bothered me. So when I found the opportunity, I gladly took it. :)

Part of the reason that it is so painful for many people to learn and implement virtual memory (and specifically, paging) is that it's hard to wrap your head around self-referencing data structures. Traditionally, page tables are initialized so as to map their own virtual addresses to themselves, but when you're first learning this, that makes it difficult to keep track of when you're working with physical addresses and when you're working with virtual addresses. If you mess up along the way, your code will simply crash, and you'll be left wondering what's wrong. And considering how painful assembly is (especially in a boot environment!) it's not surprising understanding how to actually make things work is hard.

The OP seemed very satisfied with my answer, and it made me so glad that the knowledge I'd gained through the throwaway OS I'd written was finally transferred to someone else. Just a few days ago, someone asked more questions about it and I tried to explain things, but I'm not sure how that went (as of this writing, I hadn't received a final reply from them) but I think I was still able to help.  I'm hoping it will be valuable to those struggling to get the details right and not knowing where to refer to for a concise source of the information.

Answer (score 6):

[Object copied to second property via reference persists even after original property deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583696/object-copied-to-second-property-via-reference-persists-even-after-original-prop/26584728#26584728)

I wrote this answer (sorry but no specific self promotion or anything :P) without really knowing what the answer is. I was forever confused about the following:

> Everybody says that JavaScript has no references. We can still do this:
> `var el = document.getElementById(...);`
> `el.style = ...;`
> `// same call to document.getElementById returned the updated object`
> `// is this some magic?!?`
>
> Strings are immutable in JavaScript!
> `var s = "foo";`
> `s = "bar"; // isn't this mutation??`

Although I had settled myself with thinking that "objects are just special", I never really understood what happens in reality.

Then that question appeared and I knew it was related. So I read the first answer to that question, and started experimenting in the console. Suddenly I *got* it. Yes ofcourse, variables are just placeholders for values! Then it hit me: "oh so *this* is what they mean by immutability!" And a lots of "aahs" and "oohs" followed. That 15 minutes of research cleared so much to me. Thanks a lot to the original asker of that question for making me do the research and not sit back with unsatisfied curiosity.

I thought I should put this as diagrams to hopefully help future visitors. That was my first answer which got 10+ votes, and is now at a 50+ score.

I have learned a lot from Stackoverflow, thanks guys!

Answer (score 6):

2 years back when I became active on this site it was impossible for me to write **`I`** instead of **`i`** in SO question as a young newbie but SO teach me to update myself according to industry standard. I have not been part of this for long. At the beginning when I started using SO and was just wandering here to there to gain something without even knowing that there was anything like reputation until I got the first green `+5` on my first question. *[Can I install created Java program on My PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222778/can-i-install-created-java-program-on-my-pc)* which is quite a  silly question but I got a very simple link which helped me to create a jar.

## T*he* `Jon Skeet` answer of [What is the difference between a variable, object and a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-object-and-a-reference/32010236#32010236)

The most inspiring moment was above answer of [`Jon Skeet`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) for me, where he was getting continuous up votes, and as a viewer I was just watching the vote counter. It's not all about up votes but the extraordinary explanation of the very simple question. For me he is a great *teacher* and inspiration.

Because he explained in the answer about the difference of `variable`, `Object` and `reference` and as an example he used ***paper***.

> ***Jon's answers are like suspense stories, every answer will reveal something unusual for you every time you read.***

From that moment I dig into some(*in hundreds*) answers from Jon's profile and found a huge list which I have noted and spending time every day to read at least one of them. I must thank him for this and want to thank him for all mind blowing answers.

---

I felt good when I got a nice answer badge for the answer to the following question [void… params meaning in java function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082358/void-params-meaning-in-java-function-declaration/23082552#23082552)

This answer did not get immediate up votes but slowly it reached to `10` that made me firm believer of good, complete and perfect answer.

That moment was just a spark for my mind to collaborate in this very interesting platform where every single professional get in touch with newbie and even solve problems of newbie or even more answer *Why?* and *How?* to the question which are sometimes not readable, sometimes not formatted properly, but as an ***answering team*** they work in a way such that the OP can surely learn something no matter if his question is closed or marked as duplicated or off topic.

I have seen many conversations in the comment section which contains discussion of OP and other SO user about the closed off topic question. Where some user was still helping OP to solve problem in comments that was fantastic and example of good patience for me at least.

---

## This is what I have learned from `stackoverflow` :

- Answer accurately but instantly
- Read and Write carefully
- Support the best
- Earn reputation with *respect*
- Respect and accept the down vote
- `Google > Read Docs/Books > Try more > Debug > Try more > Try one more time > Ask on SO`
- Do not pay much attention to Jon Skeet's reputation it will demotivate you and on the next moment motivate you
- Don't just ***blindly*** believe, ***prove***

Comment: "Don't just blindly believe, *prove*".  Yes yes. ++ Less magic. There is no magic, just someone else's code. I love this answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is not my question - or answer - but I'm presenting it here because it is a special kind of questions.

## [Why does Gmail use `eval`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762076/why-does-gmail-use-eval)

As the title might suggest, it is one of the very hard to answer questions; to answer it you should at least have an insight into the code of gmail. When I first saw the question I thought that it was impossible to answer such question and that it will be closed in a while (I had no close reason in mind so I just waited).
Several answers, back then, were very low quality including wild guesses and answers that do not directly relate to the problem (most of them are deleted now).

After a while, I was shocked that [somebody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196561/osgx) was not only able to answer the question, but actually provided a very detailed and concise answer. The [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26006978/2) shows how much effort he has done to search for the information.

This was one of the moment where I learned something; not just from the technical side but from many other sides as well. This is what makes StackOverflow different than many other sites and this is why I keep coming back!

Answer (score 6):

**How I learned Android until become an expert**

StackOverflow was (and is!) very important to me. StackOverflow not only help me in a lot of situations given me the correct answers to a crazy problems that make me more crazy, it tech me how to program in Android.

Five years ago I had the amazing luck to select an Android project in my first company. It wasn't very interesting but ey! is in Android and looks good!
I haven't someone to tech me, the information in internet wasn't very good and I needed to learn! How can I learn Android!?!?!
And the answer was `StackOverflow`I enter and start to read questions and answer and try to answer questions. Really I learned a lot only with this!

Years later I become an expert in Android. Well I am not the best one but I am working in one of the best and with more future startup here in Spain. And the best one, I have and answer with more than 150 upvotes :D :D :D

**Question:** [How to use Holo.Light theme, and fall back to 'Light' on pre-honeycomb devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9681648/628447)
**My Answer:** [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9681744/628447)

I really proud of that answer :)

Thanks StackOverflow!!

Answer (score 6):

### [Canvas Rotating Star Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889513/canvas-rotating-star-field)

I’ve only been an active part of the Stack Overflow community for about 2 months, so here is my [favorite question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31889513/2234742) from that time, which was [answered eloquently and completely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31930934/2234742) by [*@Kaganar*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873886/kaganar) with multiple code examples and live demos across multiple edits. His awesome answer is only sitting at +8 right now, and the thread only has 320 views, but hopefully posting here will get him some more of the attention he deserves.

The basic gist of the question is that [*@Alain-Jacomet-Forte*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/890899/alain-jacomet-forte) was trying to create a 3D animated star field in JavaScript, and had a 2D version working, but was struggling with some of the math needed in order to get it to work. [*@Kaganar*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873886/kaganar) stepped in and wrote a complete working demo implementing the matrix math using an extra library. Then, he edited his answer to add another example with keyboard controls. The original poster [*@Alain-Jacomet-Forte*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/890899/alain-jacomet-forte) then asked him a question in the comments about how he would go about doing 3D in general, and whether he would always recommend using matrices. [*@Kaganar*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873886/kaganar) stepped up again, editing a helpful and insightful **4-paragraph+ response to that question** into his answer.

[*@Kaganar*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873886/kaganar) ended up not just providing code for the OP to use, but ended up using his answer to teach OP some of what he can expect when creating 3D effects in the browser. His answer went way above and beyond helping out the OP, not just providing a code dump but teaching him best practices for doing that sort of thing. This is why I wanted to share it!

Here is a gif of [*@Kaganar*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873886/kaganar)'s answer - it's not as pretty as the actual demo (the gif is rather low framerate), but hopefully it will give you an idea of the neat answer that he posted:

[image]

Kudos to [*@Kaganar*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873886/kaganar) for the fantastic response. It makes me feel a bit bad that one of my 60-second answers where I point out that the HTML5 `picture` element exists has more upvotes than his multi-paragraph, multi-example response to this question (his answer probably took at least an hour to write, after all the edits.) Hopefully by [linking his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31930934/2234742) some more people will visit his post, appreciate the awesomeness of his examples, give him some more well-deserved votes, and show him some more attention for his exceptional answer!

If Stack Overflow had a [/r/bestof](https://www.reddit.com/r/bestof/), I would definitely nominate @Kaganar’s post!

Answer (score 6):

I would like to share the history behind my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31567731/3627607) to ['For' loop inconsistencies in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564651/for-loop-inconsistencies-in-r).

While I was digging through the doc as I'm not a [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) expert there was three answer talking about operators precedence but none fixing or talking about the OP's problem.

So I took some time to write a complete answer with a quote and link from the documentation about operator precedence and a fixed version of the OP's code, there was some discussion in comments too which lead to improving the code.

Answer (score 6):

## I'm an idiot

In June of 2013 I was a junior in College. It was the second year of programming for me and I was killing it. Good grades, smartest kid in class, and in an awesome internship. It was also about the time I started participating on Stack Overflow after being a passive observer for some time. Things, as usual, started out great; I had good questions and answers, was skyrocketing in rep, and was happy. And then it hit me. [My first downvote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152243/boolean-logic-order-of-operations-a-and-b-or-c/17152273#17152273).

It was pretty shocking to me. It was my first "failure". Someone down voted my answer? How could this be? I'm so smart! Turns out, not so much. It was the first in a long (and still ongoing) string of total failures that would teach me that most of the time I didn't have the best idea, and that the best ideas came from collaboration. Shortly thereafter I tried to build a regex engine from scratch in Java.... that didn't last long

Stack Overflow continues to teach me how I should always see whats out there before moving forward, because 99/100 times sometime has already done it, and done it better, or at least correctly :).

Answer (score 6):

By far, without a doubt, this is for me the best answer out there:

## [How do I use extern to share variables between source files in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/2793118)

(And [the corresponding question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1433204/2793118))

[Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) has the most extraordinary, in-depth, insightful answers about C that I've ever seen (not only C, but also bash, Linux/UNIX in general, sed, awk, perl, etc.).

I think this specific answer is outstanding and deserves to be mentioned here for several reasons:

- He really did hit the high notes here. It definitely qualifies as *going way above and beyond the call of duty in order to actually teach something to someone*. The details outlined in the answer, combined with the level of knowledge and practical experience make it spectacular.
- More than anything, even though it took me a while to fully understand it, this was the only answer that *finally* made me understand what tentative definitions in C are all about, how they compare with other (more idiomatic) methods to define and use global variables, and how we should structure the code to take advantage of this information. It's not just an answer about how to use extern to share variables; it's essentially a book that teaches a lot of important theory behind the use of global variables annotated with advice coming from an experienced and stellar programmer. FOR FREE!
- The answer was improved over time, and several mechanisms are in place to make sure that the examples compile and work as expected. This was the first (and probably the last) time I saw someone **using version control to keep the answer updated and compilable**. [See for yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c/1433387#comment36605939_1433387). Someone who goes through all that trouble and work to offer the community such a brilliant answer can only be **obsessed** with actually *teaching* and *sharing* knowledge rather than giving you some stuff to try in your editor.
- Critics are always addressed and gracefully acknowledged. Comments such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c/1433387#comment37492281_1433387) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c/1433387#comment39115276_1433387) can easily be demotivating after the effort it took to elaborate this answer, but Jonathan always acknowledges and [addresses issues kindly and thoroughly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c/1433387#comment39115763_1433387). In this particular example, it led him to add "checkpoints" throughout the answer to let beginners know when they should stop reading.

This is how I see StackOverflow: as a community of experts interacting with each other to generate the *best* content. We need more people like Jonathan. Over the course of time, I have learned so much with StackOverflow, and it has helped me so much, that I can only keep contributing to this great community, in the hope that some day my producer-to-consumer ratio approaches (or even goes beyond) 1.

**Thank you StackOverflow!**

Answer (score 6):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27881416/596041) really made me understand main the design principles of the go programming language, and the reasoning behind the changes. (something that I had never seen before). I had spent days trying to understand the language, and was close to giving up and returning to the pythonic realms I came from, when I got frustrated enough with `panic` that I wrote a question on SO and put my head in my hands, trying to calm down.

I didn't really expect a good answer, and I remember having a fight with people casting close votes (thinking that the question was subjective) when [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) stepped in and really turned the question around by writing a great answer. Instead of just pointing out that the language designers made it that way, he managed to dig up the fact that `panic` once took multiple arguments, as I thought it should do, and their reasoning behind changing it. Turns out, panic is a way more rare occurrence than an exception.

Answer (score 6):

#### [Cluster analysis in R: determine the optimal number of clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15376462/2573061)

The question was a fairly open-ended one, because there is no single definition for "optimal" number of clusters.  Adding more clusters will continue to reduce the total within-cluster variance.

The answer provides eight distinct approaches, each complete with reproducible code blocks and graphics.  It is without a doubt the most thoroughly documented and illustrated [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) answer I have come across, and it was very useful to me in my work.

Answer (score 6):

I don't post a question unless I'm really stuck on something, and I remember one time I was. I had a test-suite running against an Angular app in Jasmine 1.3 but once I updated to 2.0 it started breaking.

[I could not understand why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24341544/957731).

I knew roughly what was going on based on the error message (the `$digest` cycle can be a fickle beast) but I was thrown off by the fact that things were going smoothly in the Jasmine 1.x async syntax. I was close to solving it by figuring out that I could use `setTimeout` to delay exiting the spec but remained confused since my assert passed.

My question remained unanswered for 2 months and I had almost forgotten about it untill someone else came across it and [asked if I had figured it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341544/getting-digest-already-in-progress-in-async-test-with-jasmine-2-0/26252040#comment41155747_24341544). I had not.

The answerer [dived into the depths of Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26252040/957731) determined to solve the problem (and unlike me obviously refused to accept the `setTimeout` fate) and the next day posted a well written and well researched answer.

It's always a good feeling when you get a notification on a months old post to get some feedback by another person who ran into your exact problem, and it's extra warm and fuzzy when they went to lengths to find a solution, and that solution in turn helped several other people, something that's evident from the comments on the answer itself.

So, yeah, thank you SO for being SO and thank you deitch for removing a massive code smell from my test-suite.

Answer (score 6):

My story is about a little hidden corner of stackoverflow which can be found under the domain chat.stackoverflow.com. The [PHP chat channel](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) to be precise.

I was having serious issues juggling with IP addresses and subnets in PHP. I needed to know which IP address ranges could be added safely to a system without causing overlap, while taking subnets into consideration.

I was totally stumped on how to deal with this problem and had little clue on how to proceed, which eventually led me to post the question on stackoverflow here:

[Testing if a network in cidr notation overlaps another network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608394/testing-if-a-network-in-cidr-notation-overlaps-another-network)

The question remained open for a little while with little viewers and no answers and I was keen to proceed with my work, so I ended up dropping my question in the PHP Chat channel. (Not "just like that", mind. Be civil there, dont just drop questions because you want special attention)

The people in the PHP chat channel were exceptionaly helpful. They asked for the required details and this guy called DaveRandom ( Hi Dave! ) took it upon himself to provide me with an [exceptional answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608394/testing-if-a-network-in-cidr-notation-overlaps-another-network/13612479#13612479).

This specific answer is memorable to me, since it not only led to the solution of my problem, but it also taught me the simple fact that there is always new stuff to learn. The approach he took to solve the problem was well beyond my skill level at the time. No matter how much we know, there is always so much more to learn.

Answer (score 6):

## [The day I was blown away by an answerer's tenacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351019/select-rows-with-no-date-range-overlap)

With [a single question and 192 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2765666/george-brighton), I'm far more used to helping others than being helped. However, my one question received [a response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19351471/2765666) that blew all of my own answers out of the water, and it is this that I'd like to put forward as an example of going beyond the call of duty.

Back in my second year of university, I was fiddling around with some more exotic joins in relational databases. I'd long found and digested the types of joins available, detailed by endless Venn diagrams and examples, however I was really struggling with this particular problem. As I was genuinely stumped and couldn't find any helpful material online, I thought it would be a good candidate for my first SO question.

Little did I realise, [Sebastian Meine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1130542/sebastian-meine) would step in with one of the most comprehensive answers I've ever seen on the site. I came back to find he'd put my example into SQL Fiddle, and provided a step-by-step guide to solving my problem, starting with a basic query and modifying it in stages it to come up with the finished solution, including the results produced at each step of the way. Not only this, but when I pointed out my table had no primary key, instead of giving up, Sebastian provided a second version of his answer for tables without one. He also pointed out pitfalls and provided further avenues to explore.

I was floored by the sheer willingness to help. Even when I threw him the primary key curved ball, he left his existing answer intact so others could also benefit. Sebastian doesn't know it, but he taught me that the reasoning is just as useful as the final answer. **There is an important distinction between an explanation and a solution.** I now spend much more time fleshing out my responses in the hope that others will benefit in the same way I did.

Answer (score 6):

## *"That ain't possible"* is an answer as well.

<sup>(And the benefits of letting the problem rest for a while.)</sup>

Roughtly 4 years ago, I was determined to basically [change how JavaScript's square brackets work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859399/override-a-objects-bracket-index-getter-setter-in-javascript)

This was back when I was still learning JS, and just trying out different little projects, like implementing a "[doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly-linked_list)", manually.

Whilst trying to figure out how to override something like this, I learned quite a bit about array manipulation, getters / setters, stuff like that. But those brackets kept bugging me.

Eventually (after biting into the issue for way too long), I came to the conclusion that it's [simply not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27484817/1835379).

This applies to *any* programming issue:

## What you want to do *may* actually be *impossible*.

If you can't come to a solution, do something else for a while. Work on a different part of your application, have a chat with your co-workers...

Basically, don't let tunnel vision get you. This is a problem I've ran into plenty of times: Some kind of feature is challenging to implement, so you start to focus on in, getting stuck on one problem after another just to get your new awesome thing to work.

However, you don't have to do it all yourself. There is no shame in asking (for example) co-workers or other students for help if you're stuck at a problem. What also helps is to simply do something else for a while. Eventually, you'll have an "epiphany". Even if the conclusion is that what you're trying to do simply can't work.

---

Another thing I *love* about SO is that the community keeps showing it's appreciation for your answers, long after you've last been active on them. A couple of my highest voted answers<sup>([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643617/create-table-using-javascript/14644462#14644462)[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121719/html5-canvas-background-image-repeat/14121902#14121902)[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891129/regular-expression-pl-and-pn/14891168#14891168))</sup> still get votes every now and then, even though they may not bee "accepted", and the question's long dead (yet apparently, very much alive).

Comment: Someone had to propose a self-answered question :-)

Comment: I'm can't possibly be the first... Am I?

Comment: Well, can't say I've read them all, but not noticed one. Since one swag goes to the question, and one to the answer, I think it's a cool move :-)

Comment: _"I'm can't"_... Geez, I can't believe I wrote that o.O

Comment: @BillWoodger No swag goes to the question asker, unfortunately.

Comment: @KevinBrown I misread that. Thanks. I've had enough of Joel Spolsky's writing, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4342263/1927206. I asked him to remove his answer, and he suggested I do better. His non-answer and bad practice has outscored my answer 7:3 even since then :-)

Answer (score 6):

## Solutions vs SO Answers

I was going through my answers to see if any had a story worth sharing. I found one. It just wasn't mine.

**The question**: [Does the Yii CActiveRecord class have a first() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779763/does-the-yii-cactiverecord-class-have-a-first-method/14780826#14780826)

#### The Story

I usually answer questions for the [yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii) and [yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii2) tags. There are a lot of questions that can usually be answered in a few lines of code or paragraphs.

[andrunix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267180/andrunix) asked this question, about whether Yii had a feature similar to one in Rails. I answered it in [one sentence and a single line of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14780826/428543) to which the OP [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779763/does-the-yii-cactiverecord-class-have-a-first-method/14780826#comment20695331_14780826):

```
This is exactly what I wanted.
```

**The answer**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14781150/428543

Along came [Willem Renzema](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1797579/willem-renzema) who started by explaining to the OP why Yii did not have a `first()` function a la Rails. He then proceeded to write a functioning `first()` function that the OP could use a la Rails, *and* then explained how to integrate it and finished his answer with an example of how to use the method. I pointed out that his code wouldn't break if composite primary keys and he updated the code to throw an exception to handle this, despite the fact that my 125 character answer had been accepted at the time.

I was pretty new to Yii and to answering questions back then. This answer taught me something new about Yii and acted as an example on how answers should be a more than just the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 6):

### [vim, switching between files rapidly using vanilla Vim (no plugins)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082991/vim-switching-between-files-rapidly/16084326#16084326)

I happened to see this come through, and, being a novice vim hater, decided to watch it for a while. When this answer came up, it converted me to vim - I'd tried it before but didn't like exiting it and running ls and then opening another file. This changed that.

Continuous editing? [Check](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16084326/revisions).

There isn't much in the way of questions from the OP, because *the answer already answered them all*. This comment pretty much sums it up:

> This might be the single greatest answer ever. –  Badger Apr 10 at 9:38

Comment: Points are pointless… this is why I'm on SO.

Answer (score 6):

### That Breakthrough Moment

[What does actual machine code look like at various points?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10325033)

Some of my favourite moments come when I am able to describe a concept in a simple way that causes someone to think about it completely differently. I don't often explain a concept well, but every once in a while the pieces fall together in my head, and I can show someone how easily they really fit together.

This question is an example of that. As programmers, we're often reminded of a mysterious realm known as "machine code". Machine code is one of those concepts that is often explained half-heartedly, and it's hard to understand without actually having to learn basic proficiency in it.

The OP was clearly struggling with the concept of code that exists outside of a text editor. Luckily for me, this was one of those times where the question answered itself in my head, and all I had to do was write it down. When the OP realized that the answer was simpler than they had imagined, it cleared up all of those vague analogies and preconceived ideas. To quote the OP, it was "a revelation".

It's so gratifying to see that I am able to not only add to a person's knowledge, but to bring clarity to it as well. I've come to realize teaching knowledge is useless without structure and organization to that knowledge. In the words of Albert Einstein:

> Any fool can know. The point is to understand.

And of course, when you see someone grasp a concept because of you, it's great to know that you yourself have mastered that concept.

> If you can't explain it simply, you don't understand it well enough.

I gotta stop quoting Einstein, but he's hit the nail on the head. Again.

---

*This was but one episode of my never-ending quest to destroy the evil monster Overthinking, and bring simplicity to the world.*

Answer (score 6):

My little story didn't get much attention; it's a [small nitpick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033499/are-negative-lookbehind-in-regex-searches-possible-in-geany/29033957#29033957) that a single developer had with his editor [geany](http://www.geany.org/).

This little bug was weird; nothing could help on Google. So I went onto a quest to the dark side of the internet: IRC. This is where I could find the developers of geany. Oh joy! They were delightfully helpful. They quickly gave me a possible solution. However, this solution didn't work, because *geany had a bug*. OP found a bug in a wildly used and battle-tested editor. Damnit!

After some grepping through the source, the exact cause of the bug was found, and an issue was opened on the issue tracker of geany. A workaround was quickly found, and the bug turned out to be not such a bug. But it's still a bug. Weird software standards and the likes.

This little story still taught me several things:

- The POSIX standard actually defines grep options! And GNU grep/BSD grep don't have the same options. Better use `grep --version` next time I get a hop onto a new computer.
- Open source communities are awesome.
- Open source code means that we could find the bug, find its cause, and find a fix. We could've fixed it too! <sup><sup>but the workaround was good enough</sup></sup>
- StackOverflow makes it possible to unite developers of all kinds around the world.

PS: link to answer, in case that wasn't clear: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29033957/851498

Answer (score 6):

### [Creating range in JavaScript - strange syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949651/401137)

The question asks for an explanation for the following line of code (which acts like `range(5)` would:

```
Array.apply(null, { length: 5 }).map(Number.call, Number);
```

The code there has a bunch of fairly complicated parts if you don't already know / use JavaScript, and I doubt it's self-explanatory to anyone. There are a bunch of things to understand here and [Zirak's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/617762/zirak) answer breaks the code up into all the pieces you need so anyone can follow along.

Just following along is not all he's helping you do, though. He takes you through the process he himself probably followed to confirm his understanding of it, which lets you **learn how to learn** things on your own instead of teaching you that one particular thing.

Things I learned:

- That Zirak is a smart mofo
- Stepping through code is very useful
- That Zirak [has an angelic voice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947892/creating-range-in-javascript-strange-syntax/18949651#comment28158561_18949651)
- A bunch of fascinating JS that I'll probably never want to use again
- That the specification is less inaccessible with Zirak around to link you to things

Answer (score 6):

## Curiosity makes the best questions and answers.

Most SO questions are about code that doesn't work. Standard answers get into explaining why it doesn't work, and how the best solution(s) looks like.

Yet when you are asking about code that works but uses concepts or techniques which you don't understand, that often makes an outstanding stellar question. And
[**How does Bluebird's util.toFastProperties function make an object's properties “fast”?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24987896/1048572)
is definitely one of those, showing genuine curiosity about this obscure piece of code.

But the really cool thing that [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24989927/1048572) is very much in the same spirit. [Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum) went far beyond a simple answer that could have stated the reason for the performance improvement in a single paragraph. But no, instead he did give us an informative explanation of the difference between dictionary and fast mode, with tons of links that detail the subject even further. He goes on to explain the code line by line.
And then, he shows the same curiosity that the asker exhibited:

> *[…] shows us that this optimization indeed works in v8. However - it would be nice to see how.*

As he says, *we have walked the path from the code Petka wrote to the bare metal* - wich was very nice indeed!

In the end, he does not forget to put up the obligatory warning against premature optimisation. Could we expect anything more from this answer? I say no.

---

Unfortunately, this meta post asks us only to tell a single story. There would be many others we could tell about Benjamin. His dedication to the [promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/promise) tag has earned him the first gold badge in that tag. He goes beyond only answering questions quickly and accurately, he does create canonical questions such as [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) or [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) and does not forget to answer them in detail. [Apparently I'm not bad at this myself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303103/1048572), but he still <s>constantly</s> most often outscores me. He totally deserves this swag!

Answer (score 6):

## StackOverflow got me to start one of the most fun side projects I've done in the past year

18 months ago, the tile puzzle game 2048 got really popular and a lot of people started playing it. It didn't take long before people started asking [how to beat the game automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22342854/1204143). Back in March '14, I saw the question and [the top answer at the time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22389702/1204143). That's a great answer, and @ovolve deserves tons of credit for his first (and only!) answer explaining in detail what he did.

But, seeing that his AI didn't reliably win 2048, I resolved I could do better. Just on the basis of the public "challenge" which had been posted as a StackOverflow question, I worked for a week straight to develop my own AI bot and [open-sourced it](https://github.com/nneonneo/2048-ai), explaining [in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22498940/1204143) how the AI worked. In many ways it was the first major AI project I've ever done, and I learned an incredible amount from doing it. It was huge fun watching my pet bot beat my (puny human) high score in a matter of seconds, and the thrill of improving it and watching the results kept me going.

What's even better, though, is the amount of further development this would go on to spur. Shortly after I open-sourced it, I started getting pull requests and emails from all over the world with ideas, fixes, patches, and even new algorithms for improving the bot. People were using the code to study AI algorithms, were extending it for class projects, and just hacking it to run faster, better, stronger. Today, 18 months later, it's surpassed any expectations I ever had for it originally; it is by far my most popular and widely distributed open-source project, and I hear a Taiwanese university even used it as a benchmark for their own 2048 AI bot tournament.

All-in-all, just by answering this single question on StackOverflow, I got to go on an epic learning experience and develop a cool piece of software :)

Answer (score 5):

### The question:

[Default method returns true for a while, and then returns false? (Possible JVM bug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096052/default-method-returns-true-for-a-while-and-then-returns-false-possible-jvm-b) (hi [skiwi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057294/skiwi) )

### The answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22096371/1305253 by [rolfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305253/rolfl)

### The background

Stack overflow is a valuable reference source for solutions to challenging situations. The goal is to provide lasting information and to help people through time.

Unfortunately, times change, and sometimes they change quickly. Information gets old, and problems get fixed.

Still, [this little issue was rediscovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096052/default-method-returns-true-for-a-while-and-then-returns-false-possible-jvm-b) in a new way by a Java 8 programmer and the answer became a dialog, and joint discovery.

This is just to say that the community, the discussion, and the combined discovery became a valuable reference, even if for just a short while, as the underlying bug in Java was resolved.

In addition, the problem and solution spanned multiple sites (Hi [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ) and used not only the question, the answer, and comment features of Stack Exchange, but also the chat. It pooled all the resources, and the result is a win.

Answer (score 5):

One day in 2013 I asked a SQL question that had been plaguing me for days. [How to get average of the 'middle' values in a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100772/how-to-get-average-of-the-middle-values-in-a-group)  By this point in time I had been working with SQL in some form or another for a very long time.  I thought I knew everything I could do with SQL.  It turns out my very informal education in SQL had been sorely lacking.  I didn't know window functions existed, and they were the basic building blocks I needed for my solution.

I received several great solutions to the problem.  The one I selected as "the answer" was absolutely consise and beautiful code.  But, without Roman Pekar's https://stackoverflow.com/users/1744834/roman-pekar answer it would have been lost on me.  He (with some prodding by another user) explained the concepts and turned a light on for me.

I am amazed at how often I use SQL window functions now, and the lengths I went to in server side code before I knew about them.  I upvoted his answer and thanked him, but looking back that doesn't seem adequate.  That was just one of the many "aha" moments I've had on SO, but when I saw this question, it was the one that popped immediately into my head, 2 years later.

Answer (score 5):

It's ***ironic*** you should ask for cases like this:

> You just happened to be around when the answer was posted, and saw
>   them continuously expand their answer to teach the subject more effectively.

Because, until not so very long ago, that fruitful behavior was actively punished on SE sites:

[Stop using community wiki as a reputation denial mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227290/stop-using-community-wiki-as-a-reputation-denial-mechanism/228940#228940)

Ten edits got one dispossessed, the post was force-converted to community-wiki, which was unfair, counter-intuitive and plain nonsense: The more one would work on a post, the sooner authorship was taken away from him / her. I was so frustrated with it, I wouldn't fix a known error in this answer:

**[Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)**

Timestamps and time zones are a confusing matter. Add [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) to it and people get headaches. Even more so with the data type `timestamp with time zone`, defined in the SQL standard and implemented in Postgres accordingly with its slightly misleading type name. ([Even got our most achieved user on the [time-zone] tag confused.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28876266/939860)) In an effort to clarify things I kept editing my answer until I realized: one more edit and it's not my pet any more.

The internal representation of timestamps is a count from an epoch. But unlike the UNIX epoch (1970) Postgres timestamps are based on the year 2000. Thankfully, [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642706/basil-bourque) filled in for me and fixed the mistake. While being at it, he added a whole insightful chapter.

Two months later, in April 2014, the SE team finally saw the errors of their way and [removed the nonsense](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228940/169168). And we all have been happily editing to improve posts ever since. I even got to be among the first [illuminators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator) on the site.

THE END.

This is all for the T-Shirt. I want it.

Answer (score 4):

**The Answer**

One answer that I found particularly useful was [Arthur Ulfeldt's on Clojure Dynamic Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12789958/2499035). There's tons of depth to a lot of the topics in Clojure, and it sometimes seems like an insurmountable task to wrap your head around it, so I'm always grateful to people who can make it understandable.

**What makes it special**

What I like is that it would have been so easy for this to be just a quick and dirty answer. The question is just asking for how to do one thing, and I've seen lots of people in those situations just dump some code, with maybe a single sentence of explanation. But this answer takes the time to make you understand what is happening.

**Going the extra mile**

Just taking the time to break it down would have been enough, but this answer goes beyond that. It gives two examples, shows how they're different, and compares them. All the concepts are explained, in a way that makes it easy to understand. And, in spite of the complex topic, it's not dull to read. The answer is engaging, as well as informative.

It stands out to me that the answer started out as a good explanation. It wasn't just a quick, fastest gun in the west solution. You could see that some thought went into it, with the result being an answer far above what you usually see. And then he went back and improved it, nearly doubling the amount of content. That stands out to me as not being about rep; it seems like a genuine happiness to share knowledge, and make that knowledge easily understandable to others. And, because he actually made that effort, it can still be useful to people, like me, reading it years later.

Answer (score 4):

> *<<< Long post alert >>>*

**Prologue**

I did register an account on SO almost two and half years ago to ask a question. I'm (*now*) not really proud of the question I asked first, but I got my answer and solved my issue. I was happy and did not *bother* about the downvotes I got. My participation to SO kind of *paused*, but I used to be a somehow frequent visitor to get the answers for my other issues.

Some random days later, I logged onto my account and while browsing through the questions, I came I came across a question which I can answer, and I posted the same. Did not quite stick around for the review and all left it there. Same thing for one-two more days, nothing noticeable.

Next to next day, wow, the green pop-up said, `+15` when I clicked the link to the answer, OP had *accepted* my answer. I really helped someone (at least I thought so) and the feeling was quite good. So, I thought, why not try to contribute more so that I can help out people, who are just might be in need of help? This way, [*user 2173917*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh) actually get started....

**The one question and my answer to that,** which made a **big** impression on my motivation to actually making the *contribution*, well, a habit:

> [*Alternative for-loop syntax*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27398503/2173917)

The question *seemed* pretty straight forward and I added one (*ok,ok, poor quality, I know, now*) answer. Was feeling good about that but that feeling did not last long. Downvote 1, 2, 3...... I was puzzled. *"What is going on?"*. As most of the newbies (no offense, please) I ended up adding comments,

> *"and the reason for the downvote?"*

and was expecting, the downvoter will leave a comment. [User anatolyg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509868/anatolyg) replied with a comment that the answer was not clear and confusing.

Being a non-native English speaker, I had no clue *how* to make the answer any better. I tried to add some more lines to clarify, but I got the reply that it was still unclear.

*My immediate thought was, let me delete the answer and get rid of the downvotes, but wait, that actually did not happen...*

Then came in the help, the follow-up comments, suggesting how I can improve my answer. Following them, the first time,

- I did download a draft version of the `C` standard (well, I should say, first serious step to become a better programmer)
- Read that up to actually understand better what is expected out of my answer

and edited my answer. Until that time, I was doing that just to *prove* I was not wrong.

To my surprise, I got 1 upvote, 1 more, 1 more. Two of the downvotes were also lifted. Anatolog reviewed the modified answer, replied that it is clear now. I was happy, but that was just the beginning. I edited twice more to add some more info, quotes from the standard documents, correcting typos, fixing formatting.

In the meantime when I was modifying my answer, the question received other (better) answer(s), and got accepted. I was not hoping anything more from my answer, but I keep on receiving uptoves 2,3,4,5... and to my surprise, my answer, got **accepted**. This was something beyond my thoughts. OP of the question commented on my answer that my answer, in its the then *current form* is much more elaborate and comprehensive. I was very happy and amazed. I could not believe, I actually turned my answer into a better-one that is seemingly helping many others to understand the concept better.

After settling down (*first 10+ voted answer, something for a newbies for sure, no?*) thought, I did a bad thing, posted a bad answer. The downvoters downvoted and *could* have moved on. Why they (atleast, some of them) came back to tell me how I got downvoted? Why'd they bother to tell me how to improve my answer? What is "in" for them? Nothing. Then also, they helped me, I made my answer better and at the end of the day, I'm happy. :-)

I felt I achieved something, I felt I did something helpful to myself and to others which is actually making me happy. I took an oath myself, "I'll try my best to continue doing so". I pledged, I should be giving back to the community which helped me, directly or indirectly to actually improve myself. I learnt something and I should be sharing the same with others, that way, I'll be making the best possible use of my knowledge, whatever I have gathered.

**current situation**

Now, I'm a regular on SO, trying to contribute and learn, each day, any time. I feel, that one question, somehow changed the way I was *into* programming. As I got more and more involved, I came across a great number of great people, using their valuable time to help out others actually to make a difference. The way the answers are provided here, they are *much more* than a quick-fix. They are the the symbol of knowledge and the source of inspiration to many like me, who, in the process of helping others, learned many things and also improves on myself.

Hope we can continue our good deed, together.

**By lifting others, we rise.** Long live SO.

Comment: +1 You helped me with two C questions and I am very grateful. :-)

Comment: @CeceXX Welcome, and I surely hope those contents will be helpful for many more like you, too. :)

Answer (score 4):

[Which features of Perl make it a functional programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046327/which-features-of-perl-make-it-a-functional-programming-language/31051965#31051965)

I first saw a question about functional programming in `C` and `perl` - deleted question I'm afraid: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30977789/why-is-c-not-a-functional-programming-language

The question posted was:

> Why is C not a (fully) functional programming language? .... What is the one basic thing that makes it different from Perl, Haskell or Lisp (or any other functional language)?

My first reaction was "what nonsense is this, `perl` isn't a functional programming language".

But then I waded a bit deeper into the subject - primarily with reference to [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/)

`perl` does have quite a few of the features of functional programming - enough that it isn't actually all that hard to write functional code. Indeed, it's actually pretty common to use "callbacks" as handlers in parsers.

It was this that catalysed my understanding of some of the functions in `perl` that I'd been having a lot of trouble with previously. I'd *done* modules on functional programming at University, but then basically forgotten about them since. Joining the two means I gained a new understanding.

Specifically the thing I always had trouble with wasa `map` (and it's partner in crime `grep` - which unlike the standard Unix variant can take code as well as regular expressions).

`map` is an amazingly useful tool that's used for list transformation, and one I'd previously had a lot of trouble "grokking". Now it's seeing use on a very regular basis, because it makes some very elegant idiomatic code. (And yes, I know there' a lot of scorn for "write once perl" - I still dispute that notion. Just because you can write incomprehensible junk, doesn't mean you *have* to).

Comment: I remember that question and your answer well. I also first thought _wtf_, but found myself agreeing with your answer and looking for similarities. :)

Answer (score 4):

**The answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/31992600/

I use [jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jqgrid) to migrate my currently Access based System to web.

**The truth:** I didn't know anything about jqGrid. I still don't know many things but I am learning. I have learned a fair amount now thanks to SO. One user in particular has been very helpful to me when it comes to jqGrid.

**The Story:** Every time I looked up an answer on SO, I found this particular user [Oleg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg) answer on top, accepted and upvoted. I cannot count how many times Oleg has helped through his answers throughout SO not just to me but to any and all who needs help. Oleg helps each and everyone who has problems in jqGrid. All you need to do is ask. About this answer, there is a long list of comments in the question which he tried his best to answer which can solve my problem. At the end we did come to a solution given by him. I think this explains a lot about how helpful this community is and how people come above and beyond their *call of duty* and help others who actually want to learn.

For anyone looking for help for jqGrid, Oleg is the man to look for. jqGrid was hard to learn because jqGrid is developed by a Bulgarian guy and the documentation was poor and hard to follow at times. (That does not make jqGrid *any* less of a plugin that it is). Being a non-native-English speaker myself, I know how hard it can get to translate and write the content correctly. Oleg being a non-native-English speaker too has trouble at times. But that does not stop him from helping others. If it wasn't for Oleg, I would have never been able to learn jqGrid. This man [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831306/load-local-json-data-in-jqgrid-without-addjsonrows/6833082#6833082), [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469650/jqgrid-incorrect-select-drop-down-option-values-in-edit-box/4480184#4480184), [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850513/how-do-i-customize-the-add-button-in-jqgrid/8854864#8854864), [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437218/jqgrid-what-the-difference-between-loadcomplete-and-gridcomplete-events/15439276#15439276) and [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974324/jqgrid-using-multiple-methods-to-filter-data/3979490#3979490).

Users like Oleg and many others who contribute to SO exceptionally and help people learn something new makes SO a wonderful community and makes this *world* a better place to live for programmers. I am thankful to all the users of StackOverflow and proud of being a part of something so huge and great.

Answer (score 4):

## The Day I Learned How Much I Had to Learn

Let me start with this: I'm young. I'm in high school. I'm not a professional computer scientist with thousands of rep; I'm just this kid who really hopes to one day get there. I'm nothing big in the site (but my 440 rep certainly beats the overwhelming 1-rep population...). I first got drawn here in December 2014, and I've stuck with it not just because it helps me learn, but because the sense of community is unfathomable and the way I can learn and teach by simply browsing through millions of questions and lines of code is overwhelming.

[Here's some abstract math-y stuff for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643934/mathematical-equality-for-funcint-int). This is where the learning begins. I wanted to compare sequences of numbers based on the expressions used to generate the terms of the sequence. I didn't quite understand how difficult that might be until Scott Chamberlain and some other users got involved, talking about Expression Trees and parsers and visitors and what kinds of equality did I need. They helped me refine my question to simplify it and have a more direct answer. But they showed that there was a lot out there that I didn't understand. Scott's answer was phenomenal, but it was more than that. It was a jumpstart into "deep compiler theory," a pretty large topic for an aspiring computer scientist. But it was fantastic.

The beauty of it all is, I wanted to start with playing with things I'd learned about from SO. I'm a big C# fan and user, so I wanted to start trying this fancy `yield return` statement and lambda syntax. Enumerables were a convenient starting point. But little did I know that it would take me into compiler land, where everything is just a memory location. I had so many things to learn. I had no idea what was going on when I looked at this Expression Tree. Scott Chamberlain put up with my simple questions like "How does it handle differently-named variables?"--it doesn't have to. He gave me examples and showed me things I never would have thought of, only to lead me on to bigger and better things which eventually started working.

It's not perfect (the solution). There is a part two, and it is limited in its capabilities. I haven't gone back to work with it for a while, but it will always be for me a legacy with a lesson. Sure, I *think* I know what lambda syntax is and what function delegates are, but do I really? What about all the "stuff" that I've never heard of and won't hear of 'til college, the "fancy stuff" that I want to get my hands on? Scott Chamberlain and the others showed me that this community will help me with the "fancy stuff," and they showed me that I really did want to grow up and do this. I loved it too much not to.

Comment: I just noticed this post, thanks man! :)

Answer (score 4):

## The question

[How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/30180679)

## The answer

[How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30180679/1599751)

## The story

Felix Kling's excellent self-answer to this question has already been nominated but I'd like to highlight the answer by [Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum) that helped me personally the most. I'm primarily an embedded systems programmer and recently for a simple cross-platform mobile app decided to go down the Cordova / AngularJS path neither of which I've used before. After reading the docs I was struggling to understand the concept of promises thoroughly and how they worked but Benjamin's answer quickly made it crystal clear and the concepts snapped into place.

Apart from the clarity of the answer on a subject not always easy to explain in a concise way I was also impressed that Benjamin took the time to add an additional answer specific to AngularJS when sometimes those later answers attract a little less attention. Not to mention he also added a second comprehensive answer when [not using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16825593/1599751) which I wish was around a few years earlier when I was doing something similar in plain JS.

That question and associated answers are a great example of how collaboration on Stack Exchange can provide many different approaches to similar problems and build a great knowledge base that can end up infinitely more useful than official documentation often written by a single author. I ended up completing my project within a week using a multitude of questions and answers on Stack Overflow along the way and I just don't think that would have been possible using the official documentation or books on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

> Talk about the experience a little, how did you feel when the person eventually 'got it'?

This is the greatest feeling, the feeling of having every little piece just *click* together all at the same time, so immensely satisfying both for the learner and the teacher. It was a toss-up to decide which of two answers I wanted to post here, so I just decided to post them both.

- [How is the recursion method adding itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18859642/1223693)

  Ah, recursion. I remember a quote from the very first programming book I've read that just about sums it up:

  > I'm not sure, but I think that the term *recursion* comes from the Latin *recurse, recurset, recursum*, which means to curse repeatedly. I do know that that's exactly what many programmers feel like doing when they're struggling with complex recursive programming problems.
  >
  > <sup>*—Java All-in-One for Dummies, 3rd Edition, by Doug Lowe*</sup>

  My best guess is this is exactly what the OP felt like doing, but the OP was plainly having a very hard time understanding how recursion works in any case. I could clearly relate to the OP's struggle and tone of frustration in the question.

  Then, after a few comments on the answer:

  > OMG ok I get it!!! :) THANKS! –  [David Camacho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1687896/david-camacho) [Sep 17 '13 at 21:44](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859527/how-is-the-recursion-method-adding-itself/18859642#comment27830604_18859642)

  This was immensely satisfying to me; I could only imagine how much more it would have been to the OP.

  And you know what? I think that after working on that answer and that explanation, I understood how exactly recursion works much better as well. Writing up that answer not only benefited the OP, but it was a mutual learning experience. And that's one of the best experiences one can... well, experience on a Stack Exchange site.
- [Javascript conditional not short circuiting like I would expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26919346/1223693)

  I still distinctly remember reading this comment, 9 months later:

  > [...] This is a new concept - not sure how it has averted me for 10 years. [...] –  [Ryan Wheale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264794/ryan-wheale) [Nov 13 '14 at 22:13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26919296/javascript-conditional-not-short-circuiting-like-i-would-expect/26919346#comment42387274_26919346)

  Answering ordinary questions is good and all, but what's even better is that awesome feeling of helping *people*. I'd been programming... what, two or three years when I posted that answer? So having helped someone who had been programming for around four times as long as I have (and around 75% of the amount of time I'd been *alive*) was a really amazing feeling to have.

  This also gave me a look into someone else's perspective. I'd never thought of short-circuiting operators the way that the OP had, and it was really interesting to see how the OP saw it. Going back to the theme of "mutual learning experiences," looking at something from a different angle, more often than not, can actually teach valuable lessons itself.

  The answer went through a few edits to get to its current form, but again, the end result taught both of us, rather than simply being an answer to a question. And of course, there's nothing like that moment when all of the puzzle pieces just... *click* (especially when the pieces that'd been supposed to be clicking had just been mucking about for the past 10 years, failing to so much as graze against each other).

I've had a bunch of other similar experiences among my answers (and questions!) on Stack Overflow, but these are the two that stood out the most to me, and that I thought I'd like to share.

Answer (score 3):

If I may be so triply self-congratulatory, I'll offer my own question and self-answer:

## [How do Mockito matchers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822514/1426891)

I had been contributing to the [mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mockito) tag for a while, in part because I had occasion at work to dig deeply (a full day or two) into the implementation details while diagnosing my own team's test problems. I discovered that Mockito's matcher feature works in a very counterintuitive way (via side effects) that cause them to break with poor error locality and messaging, even when making innocent-looking refactors to working code. The documentation didn't mention this behavior, other than a sentence or two.

After answering [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22614356/1426891) after [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22565302/1426891) after [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21740436/1426891) based on this research, it became clear that others were running into the same trouble I had: Lack of a niche, canonical, comprehensive resource. I got to the point where I was dying for someone to ask a big-picture question, so that I could offer a better-scoped summary and link to it when answering other questions, or so that others could learn the basics in the first place on behalf of their teams. At some point, I realized that [there wasn't anything I should be waiting for](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), and posted the question and instant-self-answer.

After some initial "you didn't give anyone else a chance to answer the question!" hubbub, the answer has proven extremely useful in keeping related answers both complete and concise, to myself ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24145305/1426891), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30633109/1426891), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28061798/1426891)) and others ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28053921/1426891), [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mockito/n_4qrmQGhak)). It has also benefitted from others' updates, who have contributed better and more-specific points than I'd posted initially. As I check and update that post over time, it warms my heart to see favorites and upvotes, just to know that the days I lost in research weren't for nothing.

When reading StackOverflow for answers to my own problems, it makes me all the more grateful to imagine folks learning the hard way, and choosing to share those lost days with the world to make others' own days better. I'm extremely grateful to the community for contributing to and cleaning up this site, and to the StackOverflow team for providing a solid, permanent, clean platform to make it so easy to find, update, and share good answers. Thanks SO, and happy 10M!

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to nominate a double answer. Both answers to [Template partial ordering - why does partial deduction succeed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31394260/2069064), by:

- [bogdan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31735126/2069064)
- [Richard Corden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31558990/2069064)
- [the chat between them](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84079/discussion-between-richard-corden-and-bogdan)

**The Story**

Once you do anything non-trivial with templates in C++, trying to explain what actually happens gets ludicrously complicated. I've been trying to further my understanding of all the corner cases, and was actually introduced this example by bogdan in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391172/this-case-of-template-function-overloading-eludes-my-understanding/31391456#comment50762761_31391456) on an answer of mine. For such a short example, the answer is decidedly non-trivial.

So non-trivial, in fact, that it led to two long series of comments, and a very long and hugely interesting discussion between the two answerers about the fact that the C++ standard itself does not even answer this question, and actually working out how the standard could be phrased better to handle all of these cases.

This is not a popular question. It was never going to be. C++ function template partial ordering rules aren't exactly low-hanging reputation fruit. But this is still two users spending *days* on their answers because they genuinely care. And after spending a long time reading their discussion and their answers, I think I may finally get it. Well, probably not. But at least I have that resource to keep rereading so that someday I will.

Answer (score 3):

## [Simple proofs that GUID is Not Unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705008/simple-proof-that-guid-is-not-unique)

This question is a bad question in many ways and many of the answers and comments are supposed to be in jest. I occasionally re read it for a good laugh.

**BUT**

When I first stumbled across this answer I did not understand pseudo uniqueness or what GUIDs were. I also didn't really understand how combinations for something like GUIDs would grow so big so quickly.

This question is marked as a bad question but good for historical significance. At the same time it does a very good job of explaining why something that is so important for assigning id's works and doesn't have to actually be unique. I just finished college and I taught various computer science courses particularly in backend web development. Students would ask different questions about big data and how to build keys or give unique identifiers. I would sometimes point students to this question because it illustrates what they are very well.

TLDR: This is a question that points to a critical misunderstanding of how something in programming works and ends in answers that are both entertaining and illuminate a somewhat difficult topic.

Comment: I kind of liked [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2978928/5987), there's truth in it.

Answer (score 3):

[My First Question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273937/how-do-i-create-an-instance-of-a-class-in-another-class-in-python)

I came here because one of my developers was talking about how useful this site was.  I remember coming around to asking this specific question,  I had been trying to develop something we now call the TableSnipper.  My goal was to develop a utility that would snip from html documents specific tables based on parameters specified by the user.  I had been working for over eight or ten hours on this specific problem and I finally decided to throw it out to the community.

It was a really cool experience.  I think it took me more than 30 or 45 minutes to frame the question so it made some sense to me (and hopefully to one of the experts on the site).

I posted the question, shut down my computer and then did some grading for an hour or so.  I went home, explained what I was struggling with to my wife, got a beer from the refrigerator and logged into my new SO account to show her my question.  Wow - how amazing, there was an answer.

I was dead but the fact that I had such a complicated looking response to my question caused me to pull an all_nighter.  It was just really neat that a stranger took the time to invest in helping me move forward with a project that most people thought was silly.

It really became my practice to work as hard as I could solving some problem and then if I could not solve it as midnight was approaching I would try to post the problem to SO, go home and get a beer and then log into my SO account from home.  More times than not the answer I needed was ready.

Probably two of the most influential people on my development in writing code are [Steven Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/s-lott) and [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli).  They are very different but wonderful in their own way.  Steven is a -it has to be the right way or hit the highway kind of guy.  Initially it was kind of tough to read some of Steven's comments or answers because he was so brutal if you did not follow PEP something.  But if you could get past that he offered some incredible insights.  And then Alex, seems to be a very gentle soul that would rather help then criticize.   I remember the first time he answered one of my questions.  I had his book on my desk.  Usual stuff, I got home, checked my answers and saw wow the one and only Alex Martelli answered one of my questions.  I yelped for feeling cool, woke my wife up and learned something (and then had another beer).

Gosh I have not seen a lot of folks recently.  I remember many of my early questions were also answered or commented on by  SilentGhost, JFSebastian - amazing folks who for no other gain then something they got internally would spend hours parsing questions asked by people like me who know little about programming and provide some critical insights that help move us forward in solving real problems.

I should note that one of the reasons I singled out the users above is that they seldom were in a rush to post an answer the fastest.  Truthfully, for a guy that has no programming experience they could be frustrating (not Alex).  However, if you carefully parsed their comments and answers they typically had insights much greater than the question or many of the other answers.

Comment: I only hope you stick around a bit longer now after asking a question, responding to the quick first comments. Beer can wait :)

Answer (score 3):

**The Question: [Randomly Generating From Variable Weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019777/randomly-generating-combinations-from-variable-weights)**
**The Author: [@DavidEisenstat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144669/david-eisenstat)**

*Some Quick Background*
I am a High School student that enjoys programming!  I am 100% 'self tought' (I am not sure if that counts considering how many tutorials there are on the internet) and in the past have had some very basic programming questions.  It is crazy the amount of time I have saved by having my questions being answered here.

This specific question goes a little beyond a basic programming question, and the answers on SO did not disappoint.

> P.S. I am aware that this question barley fits in the scope of SO questions.

*The Actual Story*
Two college friends (brilliant kids) and I had been working together to come up with an algorithm that would randomly select items from an array based off of individual weightings. We had been working for a couple of days, going through different algorithms and testing them only to find out that there was something wrong.  Maybe the weights didn't end up having any affect, or maybe the algorithm took an hour.

Eventually we got fed up and I decided to post our problem on SO.

The question has a lot of probability and logic involved, so we got a couple of answers with different approaches, but they had some issues.  Finally David Eisenstat proposes some logic and says that he will be attempting to implement it.

For the next day and a half (about 36 hours) he continued to work with me on his approach.  We constantly bounced ideas off of each other and finally he came up with his solution, and sure enough it worked.  In addition to the code that he supplied, David also broke down his logic into easy to understand steps and explained why he chose to do it that way.  He elaborated on the probability involved.

I know that this question is a bit odd for SO.  But what made me want to share David Eisenstat's answer was the amount of time and energy he put into addressing my problem.  I am just some random person with an odd question, and he took many hours to find a solution, and in the process taught me a lot about probability.

It is this kind of thing that continues to make SO incredible.  The users here are awesome and really want to help.

Answer (score 3):

### The day I understood anonymous inner classes

**Question:** [Double Brace initialization Type Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25602336/1803692)
**Answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/25602404/1803692

Somewhen not too far back, when I was working as a Trainee on a big java application I wrote some tests for a specific utility placed between Controller and View of the application. I had these tests and one of them, that should've definitely worked (at least that's what I thought) produced unexpected results.

The answer by [Simon André Forsberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1310566/simon-andr%C3%A9-forsberg) I recieved only minutes after taking some time to properly write up a question clears up the misassumptions I made about Types, Anonymous inner types and Brace-Initialization in the first third of the answer.

Then Simon proceeds to demonstrate **two** alternatives to solving the problem, both viable solutions and both packed with some more insights. The answer closes with a repetition of the solution to the initial misconception.

*This* is what I love about SO: People that get to explaining what they thought was right, learn so much more when you tell them where the error in their chain was. I'll never make the same mistake again, and I hope someone else finds this Q&A and learns from it as I did.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using Stack Overflow for about two years now (that is definitely not so much in comparison with some other users). I have just started studying and when I got problem, Google usually directed me here. I never thought about this site as something more - it was just a way to find a solution when I was stuck. I wasn't even a registered user back then!

I was (and still am) a huge amateur, but eventually I encountered problems I wasn't able to solve by googling. Looking back, they were also pretty basic, but I have spent a lot of hours trying to figure them out and failed. Since I had no one to ask, I remembered that *hey, there is that great website with questions where I always look, maybe someone there will help me*. And they did. Sometimes even without answering, since I was able to debug it while I was writing the question.

The more I was looking around Stack Overflow after I registered, the more I liked it - people, who put their free time into helping other people they don't even know, not only by answering their questions, but by letting anyone look at it. I am a huge fan of open source, and people sharing their knowledge as "open knowledge" and trying to help random people around the world, without being paid, in their free time was something that I felt (and still feel) very enthusiastic about. I have learned so much not only reading answers, but when trying to answer some questions on my own.

Every time I had a bit free time, I looked here - looking at questions I may answer, reading answers I may learn something from, and, of course, just sitting around meta and reading, how to make the site better. That was when I realized Stack Overflow is not just your normal Q&A site - it's more like a second family or lifestyle. I am sure no one remembers me from here, since I am usually the silent observer, and if I ask (or answer) a question, it's something pretty basic, but I feel home here (not only here, but at other SE sites too). As I have a job now, I don't have much free time, but I always find time to look and read news here at meta, the same way you catch up with a friend you haven't seen a while.

Stack Overflow has taught me a lot - not only with programming problems I have encountered. You have encouraged me to help others, because even the little knowledge I have may help, to *ask* questions when I don't understand something (because it's better being called stupid for 10 minutes than for your whole life - I am really shy, so this really helped me a lot!) and since English is not my native language, being around here helps me with my English skills, too.

The answer I would like to nominate is [this answer to my basic question from Dietrich Epp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311547/g-with-devil-unable-to-link/29312765#29312765). Not only did he help me find the problem (installing additional package), but the rules he wrote are helping me every day. For me personally, this is the type of answer that gives me more than just the specific solution - I don't use that library now, but still apply the advice I was given.

Thank you, everyone, for being here to help. It's an honor to be part of this awesome community!

Answer (score 3):

## [**Making code that runs automatically within a given interval**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559336/making-code-that-runs-automatically-within-a-given-interval/31559626#31559626)

This answer was one of the first answers that I posted. I wasn't expecting it to be *this* popular at first. The OP is asking about how to run code in a certain interval. After looking at his/her question, I found that the OP doesn't need a timer or anything. He/she just needs to check if the players have killed all the monsters in the map. I thought he/she can just check it when the player kills a monster. (Actually that came straight to my mind) So I told him/her to create an interface and event handlers to handle the `KillMonsterEvent`.

After that answer came out, there's a person called Turrican who immediately said that this is the most elegant solution! My reputation was only like 40 something at that time. I was like "whaaaaat?" Before this, I thought I was a noob and knew nothing compared to the others on SO. I was really surprised that a guy said my answer is "the most elegant solution"!

Soon after that, the OP saw my answer and asked me about it. He/She didn't seem like to understand the use of the interface in this case and he never used them before. Since I really like to teach people, I explained the whole thing to him/her. Finally, the OP understood it and my answer got accepted. The comments section is filled with he/she asking me more about interfaces and me answering each of them patiently. That day definetly was the best day of my life.

> Ah, that definitely makes sense. It's a bit difficult to wrap my head around. I can have different implementations with different listeners, right? Each listener might have something that's different, but ultimately I can call the same method on all the implementations and they'll all do different things

And I was like "Oh! he/she finally understands! I was sooo happy!". I felt the happiness when I helped someone. It was very different.

And from then on, I kept answering questions but only *one* of the answers got a higher score than this one. I think that day, July 22, is unforgettable.

Answer (score 3):

#### If you don't solve it, no one does...

I guess many software developers once in a while are struck with this daunting feeling that everything depends on them. So this time it was me, struggling with a problem I really had to solve somehow. I mean, *I* had to solve and if I didn't, we were facing major refactorings to implement a work-around that would virtually throw us back to the drawing board. With waiting customers and all... you get the picture.

Without going too much in detail, it was about a well-know issue with the SQL `IN` statement that gets untenably slow with larger numbers of elements.

I felt somewhat relieved when I found a workable solution, but it wasn't close to satisfactory. Stupid me, it finally dawned to me that I could ask a question at Stack Overflow, which I did:

[Scalable Contains method for LINQ against a SQL backend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24534217/861716)

I didn't know what to expect. But I certainly didn't expect what happened next.

#### ...until someone does

The same day, more precisely, only 9 hours later, in came [this wonderful gem of expression massage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24542812/861716) that exactly did what I needed in a way that I could readily copy and paste into my own code. It would have taken me 9 weeks to get this done! (If ever). The user, having the somewhat indeterminate name [**codeworx**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3762895/codeworx), drily started his answer by saying

> I’ve solved this problem with a little different approach a few month ago

*I've solved this problem*. What do you mean, 'if I don't solve it...'? There was this guy (I guess...), tucked away in the Austrian mountains, willing to respond and freely share what must have taken him a couple of hours, at least.

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516886/where-is-the-bug-in-my-sql-join-logic

So I was stuck on a SQL query late one night , around 3 AM. I had some convoluted JOIN logic I needed to figure out. And I asked a really long and probably painful-to-read question about my issue. Things were looking bleak to me!!!

And although I didn't get an answer, one user - [bluefeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) -  simply gave me a way to simplify how I think about debugging my SQL problem. Not sure why, but this one comment really helped alot. Maybe others don't see that, but I really did.

And it made me really happy that night. so thanks!

Comment: Kind of a buzzkill that the linked content is deleted, for those of us without 10k privileges.

Answer (score 3):

I've been away from Stack Overflow (participation-wise) for a while, and there is an element of it that I missed that continues to draw me back: the sheer power of a simple question and its answer(s). It may sound a bit lofty, but the ability of someone to lay out a problem s/he is facing in front of [millions of developers](https://stackoverflow.com/10m) waiting to provide a solution with the push of a button is truly incredible.

The community sustains itself well with diamond moderators, review queues, and the like, but it all comes back to that Q&A model that is the basis for all interactions on the site, one so powerful that it has spawned [148 sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) (at the time of this writing) with everything from similar to completely disparate subject matter, all utilizing the same basic structure.

In searching for a question or answer of mine that highlighted this principle, [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585480/how-an-i-prevent-the-uialertview-from-appearing-when-a-push-notification-is-rece/29585687#29585687) stuck out in my mind. There's nothing particularly special about it – it's a fairly typical question for Stack Overflow: a couple of upvotes, medium length, mostly code. Perhaps that's why I didn't notice the relatively high rep of the asker, [TIMEX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179736/timex), until I had already submitted my answer.

I'll admit I was fairly shocked when I realized that; [I hadn't ventured very far above my own "rep bracket" previously](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3294927#3294927), and even the best instance of that was fairly low risk, given the multitude of answers and relative simplicity of the question. It's not as if I made a conscious effort to do so, but I guess I had just assumed those with a significantly higher rep than mine had nothing to learn from me.

Answering that question expelled that notion and showed me that, in a community like this, we all have things to learn from each others' experiences in the programming world, since in this area, you can never finish learning.

So, while there are much more extravagant answers I could have chosen with much more interesting stories and follow-ups, I think this one fits the best – a typical question we all see strolling through the site that got a sufficient answer quickly and without fuss, by design of the site and its format. So typical, evidently, that from the outside no one may have guessed that it taught its answerer (and hopefully its asker) something worth holding on to.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, I encourage others **not to fear questions from trusted users** but see it as an opportunity, often its one of those days where the high rep'r cant see the forest for the tree's and needs a second pair of eyes. **High rep user questions are usually more attractive** because they have good karma, know how to pose a question that's easier to answer, tend to maintain a high "Accept Rate", will reward good answers and because its presumed to be a hard question will usually garner more praise.

Answer (score 3):

### The day I learned the problem is with me, not jQuery

Question: [jQuery code behaves wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13316692/1344955)
Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317101/1344955

## The story

I was building a FAQ for my website, and being the jQuery newb I was, I didn't have any idea of the concepts involved, such as DOM traversal and filtering of the found elements. What I ended up with was a huge mess of selectors sprinkled with an unhealthy amount of string concatenations, and as it could be expected, it didn't work, so naturally, I blamed it on the library, and I was expecting one of the developers to answer thanking me for the bug I had just discovered.

When I saw **[@nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn)**'s answer, it was only then that I realized, the one to blame was myself. He offered me a clear and simple solution with more than enough explanation to allow me to start form scratch and see what I did wrong. Thanks to his answer, I discovered that I should first look into myself before blaming my coding mistakes on the tools I'm using. This was the first answer that introduced me to the use of `var $this = $(this);` which I have been using from that day onwards.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 3):

### The question

[Howto call .getContent and .parseContent from bootstrap-markdown.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004007/howto-call-getcontent-and-parsecontent-from-bootstrap-markdown-js)

### My answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25103980/975520

### The story

The OP wants to call `.getContent` and `.parseContent` of bootstrap-markdown.js, at the first sight was a strange question and I don't know the plugin and I goes away, but a few hours later I come back and start thinking...and than the decision I want to work on this!

I always thinked that markdown editors are a great examples of complex made simple so is a good change to know a new one.

So I start with the magical three steps:

1. RTFM: so many times, the docs are not read, so I read deeply the docs and, nothing :-(, is not implemented
2. Google: I start to search on Google and nothing
3. Open the code on Github and go deep in the mud!

The code on Github is well documented, but there is no clue for the implementation.

The requested methods are avalaible only for the markdown element so how can I get it? Tipically in a jQuery plugin the transformed element is stored in a jQuery data object of the original element so...ok check the code if it's the right direction and ok is the first step.

Now I have the markdown element and on it I can call the requested functions, hurray!

### The lesson

Many lessons, first if you don't know an argument (a plugin or other) is not an excuse to not start to learn it; and here on SO is the main concept. Whoever look at your problem is trying to solve it and firstly enter a problem that doesn't belong to him/her.

The second, paraphrasing Forrest Gump,

> Ok I checked the code, I thought maybe I can find a how is implemented
>   and then a solution

Forrest says:

> That day, for no particular reason, I decided to go for a little run.
>   So I ran to the end of the road. And when I got there, I thought maybe
>   I'd run to the end of town. And when I got there, I thought maybe I'd
>   just run across Greenbow County. And I figured, since I run this far,
>   maybe I'd just run across the great state of Alabama. And that's what
>   I did. I ran clear across Alabama. For no particular reason I just
>   kept on going. I ran clear to the ocean. And when I got there, I
>   figured, since I'd gone this far, I might as well turn around, just
>   keep on going. When I got to another ocean, I figured, since I'd gone
>   this far, I might as well just turn back, keep right on going.

https://youtu.be/QgnJ8GpsBG8?t=41s

Third, I earned a bounty of 200, I'm not a bounty hunter, but it's a pretty satisfaction.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

While browsing Stack, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16120977/2826188) on identifying users without using cookies etc. While most of the other answers on that question were brief and just mentioned the name of one possible solution, [Baba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226894/baba)'s answer discussed a number of different solutions to the problem, then went on to suggest and then explain Fuzzy Logic and Artificial Neural Networks, and give some sample code to demonstrate how it could be implemented by the question asker.

However, the answer wasn't specific to the question asker's problem - although there were code samples and a link to a reference library, the post explained it from a language-agnostic perspective, and even gave examples of how the same techniques that are described in the post can also be used outside identifying users, which is way beyond the scope of the original question, but very useful to anyone who happens to come across the question later.

The question asker had asked what probably seemed like a really simple question, and the other answers to it were similarly straight forward. However, this answer went far beyond what the question was asking to give a solution to the problem that the OP, and anyone else who might come across that question again in future, was facing. All Baba needed to do to get the message across was to post link to the class and some code samples, and it would have answered the question, but instead he took it upon himself to actually explain how it would work.

Over the few days after posting the answer, Baba then posted numerous edits, improving the answer from one that already covered most of the important points to one that gave several examples and reference implementations, and could be treated as the go-to reference for identifying users without cookies.

Answer (score 3):

A few years ago, I was realtively new to programming. The first language which I took up was Objective-C, and with no prior programming experience, as well as missed basics in the language, I found myself having a hard time with relatively simple things.

Case-in-point is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17606493/2535467/) which I had asked back in '13.

I had been struggling for hours to perform this simple task, but was getting absolutely nowhere. After very careful thought and over 30 minutes typing and re-checking my question, I posted.

Less than 15 minutes later, the answer to my question was posted as a comment, which also had a question. I answered the comment and 30 minutes later, I was notified that an answer was posted.

I didn't expect to find an answer like [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17607083/2535467)

Now while the question was to handle a very basic problem, which is in no way difficult or obtuse, and the answer simply provides the built-in method of performing the action, I was surprised and amazed by a few things.

[@Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/rob) was *detailed.* His answer was complete, extremely informative and spot-on. He saw that I was new, probably confused easily, and in need of basic help. He took the time to provide this complete answer in which he:

- Answered my question flawlessly. Complete with screenshots and step-by-step instructions.
- Gave me his opinion and best practices on naming conventions, but specifically pointed out that it was just his opinion (instead of asserting it as fact).
- He was kind and patient, even when I had trouble with his extremely detailed answer. He stayed with me and helped out until I had it right.

Additionally, he pointed out a flaw in my program which seemed to present a bad user experience to him. He was right. Just by his comment, he got me thinking with UX for the first time, and I've been in love with it ever since.

Not to mention that his rep showed me that he wasn't interested in answering my question just for the points, but he just wanted to help.

And help he did.

He also taught me to be patient with others, and remember that even though the rep is fantastic, it isn't the reason we're here.

Answer (score 3):

Being a junior dev with little coding experience, I first found out about regular expressions just a few years ago. Since that time, I have learned a lot (much of it by trial and error, after error, after error...) about this extremely useful technology.

Now, there are websites and wikis devoted to regular expressions, but the one I found (and continue to find) the most useful, is no doubt [this community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3650944), contributed to 46% by [aliteralmind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2736496/aliteralmind).

The fact that this answer is regularly updated and maintained for over a year, and that it already extensively covers so many questions I was faced with in learning the technology is why I choose this answer.  It embodies what Stack Overflow is to me. Real, peer-reviewed and helpful answers to any problem you can or ever will think of. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

## The long road to understanding Swift Optionals

The question '*What is an optional value in Swift?'* isn't overly complicated and can even be answered sufficiently in a sentence or two. However,
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24026093/4371019) is one of my most visited and shared answers as the author crafted this answer to perfection. Rather than just answer the question, he *explains* the answer in tremendous detail so that the reader thoroughly understands what optional values are.

Here are some of the things that make this a great answer:

1. Useful and relevant documentation snippets
2. Listed points detailing *where* optionals are useful
3. Code snippets demonstrating syntax
4. Recently updated code snippets explaining new changes to the language
5. Snippets showing *incorrect* use
6. Example use in real life scenarios
7. More documentation inserts
8. Equivalent code converted to Objective-C
9. Links to further reading material
10. Humorous poem at the end

#### Early Days

Before I stumbled across this answer, I was finding optionals <s>confusing</s> impossible to grasp. I had been trying for months to understand what they are, how to use them and how *not* to use them. At the time, the `swift` programming language was brand new so to say documentation was limited was an understantement. The Apple documentation to me is the least detailed and most vague I have ever seen... I found that from other answers/tutorials I was simply copying the correct syntax rather than *learning* how to use them properly. None of the explanations seemed to work for me. Eventually I happened to come across this question and it cleared everything up for me. I finally understood what optional values were, what how to use them and why they are useful. From such a positive experience I was able to refer friends to this question so that they could learn too.

This question helped me and many others to finally grasp something which at one point I thought I was never going to understand!

So [Nevan King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74118/nevan-king), thank you for such a wonderful answer. And Stack Overflow, thank you for teaching me so many useful skills *without* me needing to fork up thousands per semester like I would in school!

Answer (score 3):

## The day I realized being a self-taught programmer was going to be a longer road than I thought

I majored in Information Systems (pretty much a Business Analyst-geared degree) but decided to take a job as an Intern (programmer) at a financial company. I had taken a couple *very* basic programming classes and a Database design class where I learned some SQL.

My first project as an Intern was a Microsoft Access application to be used by the Law Department Administrators to log billable hours per Lawyer per Case/Subsidiary. Here I learned a little, but no a lot.

Then I was the project lead on a Windows Forms application done in C#. Whoa - what the hell? An Intern as a project lead with no assistance from a senior programmer? Yeah - I was confused, too, and almost quit programming because of it.

In Microsoft Access, I was used to being tightly coupled with the Database. Okay, someone wants to add a record somewhere for a table? Let's just create a Form and let everything do its' magic! Windows Forms? **Not. So. Fast.** It was at this point that I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20353332/2679750). Open a connection with a database? *What connection?!?* *What* are all of these Classes and things I am referencing that I didn't write? Why does my application not run? How do I even troubleshoot this? How can anyone find this enjoyable?

At that very moment, my eyes were opened. I started Googling a million things throughout the day and I never gave up. I ended up ditching the Windows Forms and went with a MVC Web App using Entity Framework and KnockoutJS, and I learned it by finding samples online, trial and error, and meeting another person who was also doing web development within my company (which was full of mainframe).

It may seem like such a small and stupid thing for someone to not know or be familiar with, but that's my story of what really got me going on my programming journey and a moment that really lit the spark in mind.

**TL;DR** Databases need to have an open connection to be able to communicate with them. =)

Answer (score 3):

[Excel Date Conversion from yyyymmdd to mm/dd/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13056051/1214743)

Dealing with date data can get really messy, any programmer or database admin can tell you that much, so when I came across an instance where I needed to extract information from a SQL Server table and then insert it all into another table (short version, it was a lot more complicated that).

My question was actually the opposite of a lot of other questions out there, and 
[Daniel Cook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1316573/daniel-cook) Provided the answer I needed to make a good decision on what I needed to do in my situation, and he did it in record time which was great because...Deadlines.

Thank you Stack Overflow, [Daniel Cook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1316573/daniel-cook) and all the other people that help me on Stack Overflow when I have coder's block.

Answer (score 3):

## The time SO taught me what a great Android answer entails

**The Details**
The Question: [How does the mapping between android resources and resources ID work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517151/how-does-the-mapping-between-android-resources-and-resources-id-work)
The Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6646113/1167780

**Why it's great**
The answer is a few years old but does a great job of explaining how resources are generated in Android. Specifically this is what made it great:

- The answer started with an overview that defined how the resources are generated
- The answer then talks about the typical resource format and how they are allocated
- Next, there's an example/walkthrough of a demo resource allocation to break down step-by-step what's happening behind the scenes
- Then there are some notes about gotchas that relate to the OPs question
- Finally, like any good answer it ends with a few links to the source code so the OP can understand what is really going on.

This answer could have been only a few sentences long and still answer the question but he went above an beyond to not only have an example but also to link to the source code.

Comment: Good read, thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 3):

**Answer:**

> [Shape with a slanted side
>   (responsive)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30441123/4813913) by
>   [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry)

I am basically a front end developer who fiddles with basic HTML and CSS, a little bit of jQuery as well and obviously by the detail of the answer mentioned above, the OP(Harry) is a master of CSS shapes. That answer gave me a path or approach to come out of the basic HTML/CSS circle and concentrate more on other web technologies(SVG, Canvas and different CSS hacks) as well.

When you look at the answer bounty given by another user to the *self answered question*, it explains the quality of the answer. Pros and cons explained neatly. In short, one of the best answers I have seen in *HTML/CSS section*.

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much. Your post has made my day today :) I never expected somebody to mention my post here.

Comment: No problem! :) That was coming for you.

Answer (score 3):

## Decoding hash codes

When I started on Stack Overflow, I did not know much. I had absolutely no formal programming education, but was programming for fun. Eventually, I heard something about a "hash code", so I decided to look it up. I did not understand why this nebulous "hash code" was needed, or what it means, or anything of the sort. I learned that it was needed to enable use of Java's `HashSet`, `HashMap`, etc, but I had no idea why. So I asked [Good hashCode() Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16629893/1896169).

[Adam Siemon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16629910/1896169) taught me almost all I currently know about hash codes. Sure, before his answer, I understood that a hash code was necessary for use in a HashSet, but that was about all I understood. Adam made edit after edit to help me to understand it. I ended up realizing that hash codes aren't about creating a seemingly-random number for whatever reason. Hash codes are about encoding an object into an `int` (in Java's case) in order to make object lookup near-constant time via an array. My mind was blown. I had heard that HashSets/HashMaps were faster, but near-constant time (well, at that time, my thought was, "near-instantaneous time")?

Adam Siemon taught me that collisions are (usually) necessary. I foolishly thought that avoiding collisions of 3 `longs` when encoding them into one `int` should be very possible. I thought, "If I write a good `hashCode()`, then I should never have to worry about collisions. But how do I write such a `hashCode()`?" Somehow, through his answer, I learned that the `hashCode` function isn't about uniquely mapping out your values amongst `int`, it's about distributing them nicely over it. Suddenly, everything I'd heard about this "hash code contract" was making sense.

In another note, Adam Siemon was at the beginning of what taught me not to worry as much about implementations. I was under the impression that, as a programmer, my responsibility was to make my code the best it could be. That meant that I had to optimize my hash code method to have a perfect distribution, right? Nay. When Adam compared my hand-coded method to the "one that Eclipse generates," I started to realize that maybe I don't have to code everything. Maybe I can let tools take care of some of these things for me. Maybe premature optimization is evil.

---

I don't know how Adam did it, but he managed to teach hash codes to someone who had never even heard the words "data structures" combined as such. In fact, looking at his answer now, I feel as if he cared more about my understanding the material than any computer science professor I've had so far. Thank you, Adam, for your effort.

Answer (score 3):

## This changes EVERYTHING.

How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript? How do I take what I'm currently doing with the JavaScript in my project and kick it up a notch to the next level of awesomeness? I want to make it more object oriented, cleaner. Sexier. There has to be a way right? I'd like to give a well-deserved mention to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5947280/3130094) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript) by [Jaco Pretorius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121531/jaco-pretorius).

This answer isn't the accepted answer for the question. It doesn't have multiple edits or any real back and forth conversation in the comments. This answer however completely blew my mind and changed my whole way of working. I mean, this guy NAILED it! It challenged what I thought I knew and pushed me to new world of clean, maintainable client-side code. It is clear and concise. It gives you all of the relevant information in a small easy to understand block of text. In fact, I don't think I've ever learnt as much as I did from such a small fragment. Just those few blocks of code and lines of text and I've got it. Coupled with the article link, I had found EXACTLY what I wanted. The excitement over this revelation was intense and I immediately switched to this way of working in my project. Who knew that this could be so easy? You know what? In a world without Stack Overflow I doubt I would have ever found this information, let alone understood it.

**THIS** is definitely what Stack Overflow is all about for me. I find what I need quickly and easily. I learn so much from the crowd sourced brilliance of so many like minded individuals. It pushes me to improve. To be better. To give back to the community so that I too one day might produce something that changes everything for someone else.

Jaco. You rock man. Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge and inspiring me.

Answer (score 3):

### People love to help you! `<3`

**Question** : [Google Cloud Endpoints and user's authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365858/)
**Answer** : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25390994/1376834

One thing that we don't always see, is that on SO, people just helps you. They don't know about your little side project that you've been working on for a few days, or that startup idea that you wanted to give a shot to.

Last year, I've been working with my brother on an awesome project. We put a lot of efforts into this, and for 6 months, it was our little side project, that we were enjoying so much. We even saw some big company for some business opportunity.

As I was more techy than him, I was working on the whole technology part of the project. I chose to use a backend on Google App Engine, developped in Java, to support an Android/iOs application that I was also developping.

I started learning about Google App Engine, and more specifically Google Cloud Endpoint online. Through online courses, the official documentations etc. But sometimes even the documentation wasn't clear, and there was one subject that was ticking me off.

On my application, I needed to be able to authenticate my users through different oauth system (facebook, google, and custom auth.). The problem is that the documentation wasn't clear at all about this point. It bugged me for a few days, before I decided to ask out on stackoverflow.

About a day later I got an answer, that really helped me out. At first, I didn't look at the user himself. What I didn't know is that he was a googler! He probably is one of the person that wrote this class, explaining how he knew about it, despite that lack of documentation.

What really amazed me, is that this user, without knowing it, was helping me building an awesome project, that could have ended up being a startup. Even though my project didn't work as well as I wanted it to be, this answer helped me a lot, and helped a bunch of other users too!

Cheers to him!

Answer (score 3):

## Learning how useful SO actually is

I started not that long ago, and I just experienced the amazing community today.

I was having issues getting an app to run without errors (I'm working on my first iOS project), I had seen other people do what I was trying to figure out, but I just couldn't get it. Then I thought 'Maybe I should post my issue on SO', so I posted [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207637/xcode-is-unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints). Along came @Massimo Polimeni, and he [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207637/xcode-is-unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints/32209607#32209607) it. It wasn't fancy, and he taught me a couple things about posting on SO, but it was just what I wanted. I am so exited be part of this community.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer I am talking about. I'm not sure why the link is not working for you, because it works for me.

Comment: Does my answer follow the guidelines?

Comment: Looks good, I just didn't want you (or someone else) to lose recognition if they just try to parse these responses for links to answers instead of hunting down the links one by one.

Answer (score 3):

### [Change and transition dataset in chord diagram with D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813723/change-and-transition-dataset-in-chord-diagram-with-d3/21923560)

[AmeliaBR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3128209/ameliabr) has provided many great answers on [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js). I'd like to nominate [her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813723/change-and-transition-dataset-in-chord-diagram-with-d3/21923560#21923560) on this question as for me it really demonstrates what it means to go above and beyond.

Instead of simply answering the user's original question, she gives detailed background on several different relevant concepts in D3, the general visualisation technique, and the data required for it. All of this is illustrated with code samples and links to further information (often in Amelia's other posts). It is probably the most detailed answer I've ever seen on SO.

The answer hasn't received a particularly large number of upvotes because it is quite niche -- specific to a particular visualisation in a particular Javascript library. And this is another reason I want to nominate it -- Amelia put obviously significant effort into it *even though it was clear that there wouldn't be a lot of "reward" because of limited scope* (one of the [Unsung Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero)s).

D3 has quite a steep learning curve and especially concepts like the different selections are concepts that are hard to grasp for newbies. Even though the question didn't ask about it explicitly, Amelia went into a lot of detail about this concept (even though she must have explained it about a million times before).

It's one of these answers that I upvote simply because of the effort put into them and the attention to detail.

Comment: Thanks Lars!  I missed this whole exercise back in August, but it's nice to discover it now.  That particular answer was definitely a whopper.  I know I posted it batches, adding each step piece by piece.  In the end, I had to cut out some demo code because I hit the maximum answer length!

Comment: You're welcome! The most difficult part was deciding which one of your answers to nominate!

Answer (score 3):

**Google it... is an old term...SO it...is a latest one and its expanding**

Joined the SO almost 3 years back. SO is great place to learn, share your knowledge. Initially I was just referring to SO to find solution that I was needed, was always looking for hint, code which will solve my purpose. And yes, all the time I got the answer. At work place whenever we stuck we use to ask other people like "Google it" and you will get an answer but now a days I suggest my fellow colleague to go on SO site and "SO it". I know they will get whatever they are looking for. And if lucky they will get entire piece of code. They just need to copy paste it and they are done.

Same thing happened with me as well. I was working on one of the client requirement related to `Bootstrap 3.0` navigation menu bar. Requirement was to add Previous-Next arrows on top of navigation menu so that end user can traverse through all main menus even if they are viewing website on iPad mini like screens which are relatively smaller than desktop/laptop screen. I was struggling with animation for nearly 3 hours; so posted the following question:

[Bootstrap 3.0 Horizontal navigation menu - How can I add Prev-Next arrow on top of it if I have lot of main menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982428/bootstrap-3-0-horizontal-navigation-menu-how-can-i-add-prev-next-arrow-on-top)

And to my surprise I got following answer within just an hour:

[Bootstrap 3.0 Horizontal navigation menu - How can I add Prev-Next arrow on top of it if I have lot of main menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982428/bootstrap-3-0-horizontal-navigation-menu-how-can-i-add-prev-next-arrow-on-top/31986798#31986798)

The answer was perfect. Just needed few alterations to incorporate it in my existing code base. The other person just saved my entire day. How helpful was it.It was Awesome.

Recently I started looking at newer questions, open questions and started posting answers wherever I could. While doing that I observed that sometime people do down vote to the questions which are not so straight forward, or have some confusion in question statement. Just few days ago I came across this question:

[how to call @Html.Action(“”,“”) and @Html.Widget(“”,“”) using javascript,jquery or json into mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133110/how-to-call-html-action-and-html-widget-using-javascript-jquery)

and the answer to this question was:

[how to call @Html.Action(“”,“”) and @Html.Widget(“”,“”) using javascript,jquery or json into mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133110/how-to-call-html-action-and-html-widget-using-javascript-jquery/32134739#32134739)

We know that by reading question statement we really gets confused and thinks like what that person want to achieve. But generally we ignore or don't try to visualize the situation the other person is in. The person might be under tremendous work pressure, dead-line, new comer or don't know exact word, syntax to explain his/her issue. Personally I feel we should think twice before doing that. Also we should always add comments if we are down voting any question or answer explaining why we think that way. By down voting we simply discouraging the people to come forward and help each other. I request to SO team to make "add comment" step mandatory in case of down voting. And if contributor don't provide comment then down vote should not be considered. Number of comments should always be greater than or equal to down vote for any specific question or answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Agreed, I've had a few of my posts down voted. I have no idea what the reason was for the person who did it to do so. In most, if not all cases, I feel that I presented a well written, considered answer. But then someone comes along and clicks the down vote button for no apparent reason (i.e. there was no comment). I've noted a few others reply in the comments with "*WTF, why was this down voted*" style of responses, so I feel that I am not the only one who feels this way.
If SO is concerned about retribution, maybe do not publish the author of the comment who does the down voting.

Comment: Sadly, your links you cite as examples ("how to call ...") have been deleted - there is no specific reason, just a "post has been deleted" page. Sigh :-(

Answer (score 3):

**[How do I use extern to share variables between source files in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/3049655)**

I joined SO in late 2013. In those days, I had very very little knowledge of programming. I started learning C with a bad book. Then, I tried making several programs but they all were hard and there were so many unexpected stuff happening when running the program. I couldn't find the problem.

Then, I googled something and found this site from several of the search results. I inspected the site closely, and became fond of the site. I joined the site, but wasn't active for several months (because I was busy playing games in facebook).

Then I starting looking at the answers and questions and Wow! So many stuff that I don't know about! I read several of them and started posting some answers.

---

I soon became good with C but there was one user whose behavior and attitude has always fascinated me. His excellent answers such as **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/3049655)** is just awesome!

That is one of the longest answers that I've ever seen but the content is very easily understandable and contains lots of information. It made me understand what actually is `extern` and where do we have to use it. It highlights the best practices to be used and things that are to be avoided. It also shows several examples.

Jonathan Leffler has helped me understand several other stuff and the quality of his answers is just excellent! His answers always contain information that I don't know about and is always understandable!

I would like to thank him as well all other users for contributing to SO and sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

My career as a Software Developer started in July, 2008, about two months before the official lunch of Stack Overflow, so it always has been around for me when I needed help for something. Besides using it to find answers for my issues, I frequently checked the most up-voted questions to see what kind of problems developers face during their work and learn something new on the way. However, it was not until two years ago, when a fellow colleague and friend suggested that I start answering questions and try to help other developers on certain topics. And so I did...

The first couple of questions I answered, received little attention, but that didn't discourage me. I searched for questions that I can answer thoroughly and found a question, that I was looking an answer for about a year before that. Although I didn't post the question on Stack Overflow then, I managed to resolve it, so this time I was able to answer it and share my experience.

**The question**

[MEF with MVC 4 or 5 - Pluggable Architecture (2014)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017036/mef-with-mvc-4-or-5-pluggable-architecture-2014/21037036)

**My answer**

[MEF with MVC 4 or 5 - Pluggable Architecture (2014)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017036/mef-with-mvc-4-or-5-pluggable-architecture-2014/21037036#21037036)

The challenge of writing an answer was to split the answer in as many parts as issues I faced when setting up the architecture myself, and all of that to be easy to follow and as detailed as possible. It took me around two hours to write an answer that I'm satisfied with, and since I was relatively new in answering questions on Stack Overflow, I was not completely sure that the others will find as satisfying as I did. In the past I would frequently think of a "perfect answer" for something, that didn't sound that perfect to my colleagues and instead of focus on the problem itself, we would end up in not so productive discussions.

Finally I decided to post the answer and in the next couple of days it was my answer that received most attention. It felt rewarding. It is even more rewarding that more than a year and a half passed since I posted the answer, and I occasionally receive a hangouts/facebook message from developers around the world asking a follow up question or stating that the answer helped them a lot. It really encouraged me to continue answering other questions.

The biggest reward for me was that I finally succeeded to explain something that others find easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

### The question

[**How does str(list) work?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109030/how-does-strlist-work)

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109030/how-does-strlist-work/30109108#30109108)

### The story

The question got a flood of downvotes as soon as it was asked. I added a small and *"to the point"* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30109108/1). However after a few days the OP put a bounty on this. This was the day before my examination. However I left studying for my exam and started improving my answer<sup>1</sup>. It took me two hours to completely get the answer correct. Much to my surprise the OP accepted it as an answer and awarded the bounty!

### The interesting part - What I learned

The most important part to the story that I would like to share here is that the question/answer had -5/+2 votes respectively before the bounty. After the bounty it went to -7/+3 (So I felt sad that the bounty made no impact on the question). However a few days down the line the question and the answer both got nearly 6 votes hence it proved that ***quality answers over the time do get recognised and not only FGITWs***. Hence my bit of advice to fellow answerers is to add more required information to the answer which may help other viewers than just answer to the OP's problem. In this way the quality of your answer also builds up.

### Other Facts

- It was the first time my answer got more votes than Martijn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30109173/4099593).
- It was the first time I gave a long and detailed answer and not a short and to the point answer.

<sup>1</sup><sub>I screwed the exam and got bad marks :-(</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I recently saw this post and I thought I’d share a little story that happened with me just a few days ago actually. First of all, I’m not an expert in HTML or CSS. So I was attempting to refine my skills w/HTML and/or CSS in order to not only have a better understanding of CSS properties but also, learn how these specific properties affect different HTML tags. I was playing around w/the button tag and wanted to get the rounded corners effect that is so visible nowadays throughout the web. After finding border radius helps w/that, I implemented border radius to my CSS but soon I realized that my button was getting “dark” on the sides. I had no idea what was happening. I was pretty lost. The people who helped me out didn’t know that I actually attempted to search for this online for many hours. Not being a HTML/CSS I wasn’t able to describe this problem, hence google was not able to give me the results I wanted. Like there are times when everyone knows the problem but its sometimes hard to write that question out, you know? I guess I was just having one of those days…Anyways, after a few hours of just hitting myself on the head and getting frustrated, I decided to ask that question (hoping someone would understand my reasoning) to the stack community.

Here is my question:

[HTML button (part of button is dark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134869/html-button-part-of-button-is-dark?noredirect=1#comment52160995_32134869)

In a matter of just a few minutes, I received three answers that all conveyed the right answer as well as resources of what else I should look into. I was so happy and delighted just to be able to find an answer to my solution especially since it was bothering me so much. Honestly, I know its a simple question but I can’t even describe the level of happiness and elatedness I felt!

The answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32134923/5140373

Now the interesting comments started appearing…

The user @KhrisAzuaje basically started commenting on how this is such an easy question and how he had low reputation compared to me and his comments honestly, really made me feel very disappointed. Before I had even posted this question, I had this same exact feeling that this is an easy question and that the Stack community is so intellectually advanced that they will see this as a trash question and bash me for asking such a low level question but I mustered up the courage to ask it anyways, because I wanted to learn.

Moreover, the premise of the stackoverflow community was built on the idea to help developers of all skill levels so after thinking for a bit, I realized that there was no problem w/asking this question. As a result, I responded to this user’s comments as you can see from the post. I’ll summarize what I said. This person clearly seemed very disappointed that he would answer questions yet he would never be chosen as the “best answer” hence not earning stack rep. And what I emphasized is that I’ve come across so many answers that have not been selected as the best answer yet I’ve learned so much and I’m sure I’m not the only one who feels the same. But at the end, it seemed like he understood my point of view and I felt glad that he didn’t take anything personally but rather put importance on the premise and learning aspect of Stack rather than Stack rep.

From this, I just want to give a big shout out to everyone on stack who answer questions regardless if it becomes a best answer or even if a best answer has already been chosen. You don’t understand the impact you make on the developers **ALL AROUND THE WORLD** and that’s something to be proud of! People always say they want to help others and make an impact on the world, and I want to emphasize that all the users of Stack make an impact in one way or another EVERY SINGLE DAY. Everyone is a very knowledgeable developer and those who aren’t, become experts through the knowledge that is shined upon by the very highly intelligent individuals. You guys are all awesome and without all you guys, this community would be as large as it is today!

Btw, my intention was not to single out anyone through this post. It was something I experienced and it said to get in detail, hence, I did. I hope the moderator sees this and gives @KhrisAzuaje some swag as well.

Answer (score 2):

**3D DEV for Dummies**

I had to tackle a 3D project in three.js with webGL, and it had been a couple of years since I last had to use that part of my math knowledge, so it was all quite rusty if I'm being completely honest. After a couple of days of searching on my own, I decided to ask StackOverflow and see if someone there could help me out.

That's where I met [TOAOGG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085414/toaogg) who seemed intruiged by my problem and first asked me some basic questions about the problem through comments, and gave a solution short after. *Only*: the solution didn't solve my problem, but did fix something else I was stuck on. I let [TOAOGG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085414/toaogg) know, and decided to contact him in the SO chat. It was the beginning of a 4-hour long chat session where we tried to solve the problem together: trial and error, checking of formulas, rewriting entire parts of code.

[TOAOGG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085414/toaogg) helped me tremendously to get all those dust-collecting math formulas to the active part of my brain again. To rediscover the fun in 3D and, at that moment the most important part: to solve my issue.

Thanks for spending your afternoon, trying to solve a problem of a random stranger!

Answer (score 2):

I am really thankful for all the help I got from other users when it comes to one of my answer, on this question: [Average of 3 long integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23949785/993547).

The answer I provided first was not that long, but it answered the question and it seemed mathematically fine. And it was, but just for positive numbers.

Others stepped in to test the formula for correctness with their mathematical programs, suggesting improvements, etc. I am proud of the end result we all created.

It was a very nice experience to see all the ready-to-help users. Often we hear people complaining about the general population on SO and the lack of kindness or will to help. I have experienced a lot of help that time and I want to give something back.

Answer (score 2):

[How I learned the ListView recycling mechanism with Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844943/android-custom-adapter-list-items-only-populated-when-scrolling)

The question was about how [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) works, something I came across when I started developing for Android.

[S.D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1531054/s-d) added the first answer. While it was not the answer I was expecting, it helped me understand how I could improve my code and the inner workings of one of Android's main framework tools.

[vikki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/790439/vikki) added a good answer, explaining the underlying problem, how the component works and the appropriate solution directly applicable to my question while still being great at explaining the recycling mechanism to other readers.

I suppose this question (mine) and its answers are nothing out of the ordinary for most readers, and in fact, there were probably similar questions around when I asked mine. Nevertheless, [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1267661/sam) posted a comment suggesting I go watch the Google I/O video about ListView recycling. I did and have sent those videos to countless Android beginners ever since.

For me, this illustrates perfectly one of the main strengths of Stack Overflow, regular users giving each other great tips, teaching each other without even knowing it (I'm pretty sure Sam never came back to the post and never knew how much his comment helped me back then). Even if there isn't one great answer with a score of 1000+, a combination of the efforts of several users can often constitute quality content, probably even more so that one "guru".

People are willing to help each other, just because. And Stack Overflow is there to encourage them to do so. I'll never forget that first time I realized: *they just want to help* ...

Comment: It also illustrates one of the weaknesses. You got the information you needed because you asked very specifically about Muenchian grouping. Most people with XSLT grouping problems don't know that they are called by that name, let alone that there is a specific technique (Muenchian) for solving them; as a result, they find it much more difficult to ask the question.

Answer (score 2):

[c# add clickable images to gui using code and not the designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944757/c-sharp-add-clickable-images-to-gui-using-code-and-not-the-designer/29945260#comment48019151_29945260)

I've been on SO consistently for the past year, trying to answer everything that I can. I am usually pretty good at finding answers myself through here and other sites, and I'm not really working on anything cutting edge at the moment: That plus a great team where I work leaves me with few questions unanswered.

So, in an attempt to give back, I'm always looking for questions to answer. I find I learn a lot by researching answers to questions I don't yet know the answer to as well, which is great.

This particular question didn't really stretch my knowledge too much, and it was kind of vague. Nevertheless, it was a good first question by a new user, and I was able to identify with someone trying to learn the tech from scratch themselves, so I answered. This turned into a long discussion regarding other portions of the app they were trying to create, and ended up with us chatting in an AHK chatroom for almost 8 hours while I helped walk him through how to get the other portions of his app working the way he wanted. It was incredibly rewarding, and along the way the user was able to teach me some stuff about how this would work in AHK, which I've used before but never really got into, so win-win there.

Anyhow, he was incredibly thankful and it felt great. Sometimes answering a hard question through lots of research is rewarding; sometimes helping a newbie through the simple things is too. I had a blast teaching him and it's helped me with teaching my kids at home too... It's easy to forget how it was when *everything* you tried to program was a struggle, or hours of reading blogs/articles/SO posts to try to understand why and how things worked. I think about that session every time I'm answering a new question: having a great database of useful info and answers to problems is why SO is here. Helping other people is why *I'm* here.

Answer (score 2):

**Data binning in Hadoop**

Although the tags where I usually post do not get much attention, there is one answer I am really proud of. One year ago, a question about [data binning in a mapreduce job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554529/binning-for-numerical-dataset-in-hadoop-mapreduce/) came across, and I tried my best to help this user. Since he didn't seem to need code, just a guidance on how to achieve it, [I answered as best as I could](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554529/binning-for-numerical-dataset-in-hadoop-mapreduce/21556034#21556034). I tried to teach him about one of the design patterns that are not so common for Hadoop newbies, such as in-mapper combiners.

What the user wanted was to find the minimum and maximum values of different values from a CSV in a MapReduce job as efficiently as possible, so I talked about how to store in each mapper the local minimum and maximum and only emit one `max,min` pair when the mapper ended processing the data, using the `cleanup` method. This would avoid having to send millions of values to the reducers, so that they would try to find the maximum and minimum values of huge lists. With this approach, only one pair for each mapper (and for each column of the data) would be sent.

After my first attempt, the answer was not clear enough, so when the user asked for further clarification I edited the answer to explain it better. However, the user still asked for more information which I tried to answer in another comment. Finally, the user decided to continue the discussion in chat since we were flooding the answer with comments. Luckily, he was able to understand the problem and to code himself the concept we had been discussing.

It doesn't have many upvotes or many views, but it is by far the answer I am more proud of, due to the effort I put into it.

Answer (score 2):

### [Applying Muenchian grouping for a simple XML with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783340)

I found myself at my current job with an opportunity to take over a specialized task. The only problem is it required learning [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) which was something I was not exposed to previously. So I hit the Internet and discovered Stack Overflow.

The experts in the XSLT space are amazing. I learned so much from their answers to other people's questions. And not just the very intricacies of XSLT, but also how to fashion a great answer (for examples, check out almost any of [Dimitre Novatchev's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev) answers, he is like the [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts/9182#9182) of XSLT).

But the one Q&A I learned the most from was about one of the most difficult and yet satisfying concepts in XSLT, [Muenchian grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT/Muenchian_grouping). XSLT v1.0 doesn't have a function or method for grouping similar XML elements together which is where this process comes in. Everyone inevitably runs into an issue where you need to use it, but it's just complex enough to not make any sense the first time you come across this grouping process.

In steps, this question: *[Applying Muenchian grouping for a simple XML with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783340)*. Like I said, everyone has this question at one time, but the reason I liked this one is because of how the community worked together to really flesh this question out.

First, you have [Martin Honnen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784253/1078110) which is to the point on providing the working code. But then [joocer follows up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784420/1078110) by breaking down the important lines in Martin's answer to really drive home the 'how' of the code. And then to [wrap up is StuartLC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784519/1078110) to give the 'why' of how the *Muenchian method* even came into being.

While I feel that [joocer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784420/1078110) was really the linchpin of the three mentioned and the one the best answered the heart of the question; the combined effort of these three really help show one of the things that makes this site special: volunteers sharing their time and experience to make the Internet a much better and well informed place.

Answer (score 2):

**The question:** [PHP/mySQL: Import data and store in hierarchical nested set for use with jsTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797288/php-mysql-import-data-and-store-in-hierarchical-nested-set-for-use-with-jstree)

**And its answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832325/1443080 (written by me)

**Why do I feel this is worth sharing?**

I think this is worth sharing because it is, at least to me, a clear example of how even those who *answer* questions, rather than *asking* them, can always learn something new, and even useful, to be added to their wealth of knowledge.

In fact, when I first saw that question, it was the first time for me I got placed in front of the concept of "nested set", I had *never* seen it before, even though I used to consider myself a somewhat experienced developer.

At first, I really struggled with it, going through many tutorials to understand the logic which formed its basic rules, and only after quite some hours of study I was finally able to glue together the first draft of the answer, which I posted.

However, that was far from being complete, in fact there was more than one issue, which I am happy to say, was finally solved in the end with some tweaking and modifications of the conversion algorithm I came up with.

This all happened more than three years ago, when I was still a fresh and inexperienced *StackOverflow-er*, and the question itself didn't really receive much views or attention, probably because it was really a well known topic for all the other programmers; however I remember feeling so proud to have been able to really help someone solve a problem they had, for simple it might have been, and earn my first bounty :D

And that, helping and be helped, is what keeps me always returning here, searching for new questions to answer, whether they're simple or difficult, if time permits I'll always try to give a hand.

Answer (score 2):

Question - [how to use markdown parsing technique in php to make separate automated process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656992/how-to-use-markdown-parsing-technique-in-php-to-make-separate-automated-process/)

Answer - [how to use markdown parsing technique in php to make separate automated process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656992/how-to-use-markdown-parsing-technique-in-php-to-make-separate-automated-process/21657317#21657317) (By me)

**Why is this low rep answer so important to me?**
Around the time of answering this question was when I started contributing answers to StackOverflow.Initially, I thought this question was simple enough, but as the OP clarified it in the answer's comments, It kinda grew into something a bit complex(atleast for me :P).
So I sat up that night(determined to get a green tick :), learning more about PHP and using regexes and came up with a workable recursive solution  that I was proud of(which eventually got the tick and a thanks from the OP too).
Then I realized how important that was. How much I learnt by simply thinking over how I need to tackle the problem(rather than reading/finding it somewhere). This made me learn a lot of things experimenting by myself 
Seeing soo many posts with extended comments/discussions from incredible people and experts in the field joining in to come up with a viable solution is how learning is done. 
From then on, I tried to be [as helpful as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589725/replace-all-quotes-that-are-not-in-html-tags/22589854#comment34392912_22589854) with my answers(and my limited domain knowledge :p)
Bottom line is this - Being helpful by answering a question is useful because not only does it help the OP, but also the person answering.

**Thankyou SO :)**

Comment: Downvoters, can I know the reason for the downvotes? Did I miss the brief?  (I concentrated on the `You wrote one of these kinds of answers - don't be shy to share your own awesomeness. Talk about the experience a little, how did you feel when the person eventually 'got it'?` part)

Answer (score 2):

## **[Detecting an SSD in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363115/detecting-ssd-in-windows)**

I had asked this question as I found a way to optimize the server load on a gameserver, but this depended on whether the drive was fast enough (an SSD or faster equivalent).

I thought I had it sorted; I had all the code in place, bar *the ability to detect an SSD*. Instead the answers I received helped hugely although they didn't (directly) answer *how can I detect an SSD?*.

Instead, the answers pointed out that I was incorrect to assume that SSDs will offer the best possible performance in my scenario ([in particular, this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23363326/2422013), which I just accepted [by unaccepting the old accepted answer]). The answer lit a lightbulb inside my head where I literally went 'oh!', and because of this answer I ended up scrapping three days worth of code.

Looking back, this answer really did help me an awful lot (and for that reason, I have awarded a 150 rep bounty to the answer), and I *still* look back on it to this day. As a result I still use the context of this answer in the programs I write to this day, *the answer was **that** useful to me.*.

Answer (score 2):

[Fixed digits number in floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197194/fixed-digits-number-in-floats)

---

The reason why I want to share this question is because **I** actually learnt a lot putting [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25242100/2043505) together and revising it. I have to admit I did not fully understand the question at first - and the first version of my answer reflects that. However, eventually it clicked.
Most importantly, in writing the new answer, I learnt a lot about the newer Python string formatting using curly braces `{}` instead of the percentage symbol `%`.

Personally, this is what the stackoverflow-experience is. I like and enjoy helping others. But more so do I like learning myself. I browse new questions in my favorite tags and try to answer those that spark my interest. Often I do not know the full answer when I decide to answer (I won't be the [fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)). But I like trying to figure out something new. Thus, my personal coding skills have improved greatly since I joined this site - all, by trying to figure out answers to questions I find to be interesting puzzles.

Answer (score 2):

## Making complex things simple.

I like helping people and I like learning. Stack Overflow has always been so intriguing to me because I get to do both and usually at the same time. My favorite memory of doing so is when I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25778149/1435655), which I believed I wouldn't be capable of answering for years. I figured those years wouldn't really amount to much if I weren't trying the whole way, so I wanted to at least understand the question and keep an eye out for someone to answer. Fortunately, the more involved I got, the more curious I became and the more I started to understand the realm of the problem. After reading the question repeatedly and messing with the demo for a good length of time, I realized that the problem is complicated because it is made up of many pieces, but that the pieces are individually easily understandable. All that was needed to understand the big picture was to write a few simple lines of code to interact with each of the little pieces and have all of them log what they were up to. At that point, the code explains itself!

It took most of the day, but I was able to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25795883/1435655) the OP's question and leave a helpful resource about Angular's internals. That experience helped develop the way I now see that discouraging difficulties are usually just a series of simple things and that getting past them is more a matter of trying than being a genius. Bonus: the OP (great guy) contacted me and we solved some other mutual problems together (i.e. [this](http://sobrepere.com/blog/2014/10/14/creating-groupby-filter-angularjs/), which is actually kind bad, but we learned!).

It didn't quite fit into the flow of my story above, but I wanted to note that the question was fantastic and I feel that the learning value is more from the well asked question than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## The day I apparently taught someone about arrays

Looking back, I'm not sure why I even [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13587012/1721527) [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13586884/1721527). Maybe it was because I remembered being a beginner developer and wanted to help someone else who was obviously just starting. Normally, I would cringe at the use of eval just to pick which side of a die to show, but for some reason I looked past the syntax errors and use of eval decided to help this JavaScript beginner.

I started by suggesting using an array, offering code that resembled the existing code, but after a comment about a [100-sided die](http://www.unclesgames.com/images/products/N00388_big.jpg), I realized that this wouldn't scale. I decided to help the OP make the leap into a for loop. I even gave a JSFiddle example of a 100-sided die. The user apparently understood my code and was then even able to implement my suggestions without needing me to write the code.

The user has gone on and asked many more questions, and seems to have gotten many helpful answers, but the one I was able to answer was his least popular question, and I was still able to help him, which is the whole reason why I answer questions on Stack Overflow*.

<sub>* Possibly other than working to increase a nearly worthless number beside my name</sub>

Answer (score 2):

**The first vote I received**

I joined around 26 December 2012. Questions in my areas are not common, so I'd answered three and still didn't know what things were all about (I though "reputation" was number of answers given, for instance) before I read the question which lead to my first vote.

I didn't attend regularly, and on January 13 I discovered a new question, from January 11, [AS/400: Using COMPUTE function, inconsistent results with different field definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14272981/1927206). With an answer, that was wrong, but which already had four votes, and from a user who'd answered 7,000+ questions (err, no, see above).

The issue in the question is a simple one, faced by all new COBOL programmers and often "bodged". The issue is that a COBOL `COMPUTE` does not work like a calculator (ddvice given to me 35 years ago). COBOL uses fixed-length fields. The bodge, on discovering you don't get the answer you want, is to include an absurd amount of decimal places on all the source fields (absurd amount = any amount more than the original source fields are already defined with). The correct way is to rearrange the code to ensure that the code *you* have written doesn't lose significant digits. Multiply first. Divide last.

The answer I provided, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14299489/1927206, had two audiences: the questioner; @NealB who wrote the incorrect answer. So it is somewhat deeper than is needed for the question, because Neal had thought the issue was with intermediate results.

At 04:28 on January 14 (no, I don't have this memorised, it comes from the reputation history in my profile) I got my first vote. +10! (immediately reassesses the meaning of +7000).

I had commented on Neal's answer, and he stated it was wrong, and even updated the answer to say that on the first line. A couple more votes arrived for him, a second for me. Then two more for Neal. Then his answer disappeared, and a bounty notice appeared, saying there was an exemplary answer. Rats!, I thought, I'd better try to make sure it is mine, so did some more editing (see, clueless) :-)

As to the OP, they made an interesting closing comment: [AS/400: Using COMPUTE function, inconsistent results with different field definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272981/as-400-using-compute-function-inconsistent-results-with-different-field-defini/14299489#comment20132449_14299489).

In part:

> Next time, I will try my best to understand the manual before asking a question.

Although https://stackoverflow.com/users/1969051/user1969051 has visited the site as recently as 21 August, they have not asked another question.  Hopefully my answer and what they took from it helped with that.

---

A special thanks to @NealB. My answer cost him 180 points, and that behaviour was a good introduction to the good people who answer on my favourite tags, who are both knowledgeable and people who can get along with people.

---

(if you look at my profile, ignore the apparent first answer, and vote: that was a drive-by answer, as an unregistered user which I later merged, made before I knew anything about Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 2):

## Satisfying my curiosity!

The Question: [Chain Increment Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28859460/1398425)

On one glorious summers day developing I wondered firstly if I could chain increment operates. Then secondly after testing why I couldn't. I.E. Why is `i++` allowed but not `i++++`.

There was no situtation in which I thought about using this as where would it end? `i++++++++++++++++++++`. However the question was just to satisfy my curiosity.

The question did receive a couple of good answers but I personally got a little bit of joy from this answer by the skeet man: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28860388/1398425

For me this is what SO is all about asking questions for help with a specific problem or just for the programmings sake. SO has had its ups and downs but when it comes down to it, we really are a great community. I will always try to convince people to signup even just to upvote answers they found helpful.

*P.S: I assume the day was nice I don't really know as obviously I had the blinds closed to stop any glare on my monitors.*

*P.P.S: This Question has more than 30 answers, are you sure you have something to contribute? - Yes Always!*

Answer (score 2):

**The question that made me understand how much answering can mean**

This is a short but true story about how I learned that answering someone's question can really mean the world to the them.

From the day I signed I had seen several questions on the same topic as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31588024/5110359), regarding how Fragments could communicate in Android. There were good answers and suggestions to libraries that would make it easy, but somehow the basics had been left unexplained. Having just solved the issue in my own project, I took the time to write [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31588618/5110359) that would address the communication issue, which really was nothing more than writing an interface and implementing it. And of course I did not nail on the first attempt.

What resulted was a [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84085/discussion-between-mvk059-and-milez) that went on for almost two hours. I ended up receiving code and from the person who asked the question and took the time to really make it work in the way he wanted to, leaving my own projects aside for the evening. But it was really worth it. The words this user chose for thanking me were

> ... People like you is the reason that the world is a better place for us to live. I can't thank you enough. Thank you so so so much for giving me your time. Thank you so much. ...

I am sure many more feel the same towards those that take the time to answer questions as this user. I was just extremely lucky to stumble on one that was gracious enough to put it to words. And it really made my day. I keep coming back to this question when the I feel like "why would I answer something today..?".

So take this write up as a reminder:

> Taking the time to help always means the world to someone, and often for many others out there too! Be proud of your answers :)

Answer (score 2):

A lot of great stories have been posted so far, and I cannot come close to topping them, but I will share my experience because I think it is one that a lot of enthusiastic-but-casual Stack Overflow users can relate to.  Stack Overflow can be a very intimidating place for a newcomer.  A lot of very smart people post a lot of very smart things on a daily basis, and figuring out how one can contribute to this can be daunting.  But that is the great thing about Stack Overflow: it is a level playing field.  Anybody can ask a smart question, and anybody can post brilliant, encyclopedic answers.

Like a lot of people in software development, I am primarily self-taught.  Despite success in my career, like a lot of people have already posted, I suffered a long time from Imposter Syndrome.  Stack Overflow has always been a great resource, and I have learned a lot from many of the brilliant Q&As, but for a long time I did not feel like I had anything to contribute other than some quick answers to low-hanging-fruit questions.  That is, however, until [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229255/confusing-with-the-usage-of-regex-in-python).  It is pretty inocuous, but this question lept out at me for a few reasons.  First, it was asking about Regular Expressions, which I had unwittingly become pretty adept at through writing many a Perl script.  Second, it wasn't just asking 'how' to do something, but asking 'why' a line of code does what it does.

I posted a pretty basic answer, explaining why each regex pattern outputted what it did, expecting someone else to come swooping in with a much more authoritative and elegant answer to bury mine.  Instead, I quickly received positive feedback and a few additional follow-up questions.  Over the next day or so, I kept expanding on the answer and adding links to additional resources.  Before I knew it, I had not just [written the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22229642/1458983), but it had become my highest voted post on Stack Overflow.  This was great, but the kicker was that OP felt like he finally understood why Regular Expressions behaved like they did.  Not only had I helped another user wrap their head around a complicated topic, but my answer had gained the overwhelming approval of the community which had intimidated me so much up to that point.  I can honestly say that this experience made me a more confident developer, and has even ecouraged me to engage in other mentoring activities.  To this day, I am still addicted to SO.

Answer (score 2):

> A little learning is a dang'rous thing;
> Drink deep, or taste not the [Pierian spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierian_Spring):
> There shallow draughts intoxicate the brain,
> And drinking largely sobers us again.
>
> --*An Essay on Criticism*, Alexander Pope

On Stack Overflow, there's nothing I like better than being told I'm wrong.

But let me start with my second favorite thing: my second favorite thing on Stack Overflow is questions that I can't answer.  Those are the questions that help me grow as a developer, either by trying to find the answer myself or by reading answers from other knowledgeable people. Stack Overflow has been the single most important resource for my growth as a professional software developer, and it's been driven by the questions that I can't answer.

The *really* valuable questions, though, are the ones that I *think* I can answer, but I can't. I can read a great, educational blog post or find a brilliant Stack Overflow answer and walk away from it without realizing that I've understood it *completely wrong*. But the moment I turn around and try to apply my mistaken ideas to an answer, the SO community is there to set me right.

In particular, I'd like to give a special shout-out to [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w)'s edits to my answer on the `[google-chrome-extension]` question [Is it possible to inject a JavaScript code that overrides the one existing in a DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12096099/revisions) Content scripts and webpages share the DOM, so when you inject a `<script>` into the DOM, it runs in both places, right? ***Wrong.*** Not only did Rob help to clean up the readability of my answer, he fixed a couple major inaccuracies and handed me a few bonus facts to boot.

I'd read the Chrome documentation and more than a few SO answers on the topic, but I hadn't realized that I'd gotten the finer points *completely wrong*. It's corrections like these that you can only get by participating in a vibrant community like Stack Overflow.

*(Just to be clear, [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12096099/710446) is mine, but I'm nominating [RobW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) for the teaching-award for his phenomenal edits (and general history of being a great SO participant).)*

Comment: Thanks for your kind words about my abilities :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Teaching how to hack the standard streams

**Question**: [How to test code that writes to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26144614/1345223)
**Answer**:  [My answer on testing stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26147074/1345223)

Checking that output actually hit one of the standard streams (aka `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`) is a bit unusual, even for the most fervent unit testing advocate.

And early versions of the question picked up some rather pointed commentary trying to discern what was really being asked.

> What. Are. You. Asserting? What condition do you want to check for?

When you look at the [initial revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26144614/1) of the question, it's quite clear that the OP was quite ***unclear*** in their original question.

But the [community rallied around the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272621/1345223) and edited a terri-bad question into something a bit better.

> A hard question, an interesting question, no. A clear, useful question, possibly.

Which is where yours truly stepped in.  The challenge involved combining a couple of different aspects together.  Specifically, a redirect was required, a file system check was needed, and then that needed to be tied into a unit testing framework.

My answer pulled together those components and also provided reference links showing where the core information came from.

Unit testing the standard streams certainly isn't a common task, but it can be done when you take a moment and reflect upon how the operating system is handling those particular mechanisms.  And that, I think, is what makes my answer notable.  It ties together related, but different concepts and puts them together into a useful whole.

Answer (score 2):

## Life lessons, besides code

I'm a 18 years old italian guy, and I'm not the best developer ever, I just really enjoy my passion, as everyone in here.

I haven't asked many questions in here, since every time I had a problem I instantly found the trouble already solved by someone else, but I signed up anyway, because **I did want to give my (little little) contribution to the community**, as **I received SO much**.

The life lessons I want to tell are about the Good Will we all have inside, and that in life nothing comes for free and without effort, *everything needs passion*. I was picturing in my mind my account with thousand reputation just by saying a couple of words in a few random questions. *Well that was terribly wrong*. I figured out that reputation comes with a huge amount of KNOWLEDGE (what a wonderful word, isn't it) and most of all generosity and patience.

I'll take for instance this question:
[Google Visualization stacked bar chart: colors and labels for each value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022421/google-visualization-stacked-bar-chart-colors-and-labels-for-each-value)

I was having a work experience outside my country, and after a couple of hours spent on a problem I still I wasn't able to figure it out. I looked for an already-asked question but nothing good, so I decided to post my very first question on SO. I was kind of nervous because I was afraid that someone could find my problem really dumb and not answer to it. And... I was wrong again! In a couple of minutes @Balrog30 cleared my doubt, being very kind with me.

Link to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31030974/3771035

What I learned is that knowledge, the most powerful thing in our universe, becomes so great only if shared and used for the others. As for powers come responsability, with Knowledge comes a mission: SPREAD IT! HELP EVERYONE YOU CAN! It doesn't matter if it's free or not, it doesn't matter if you're helping Bill Gates or the most irrelevant fellow in this world, your mission is to teach him that everything we are is nothing else than the result of SOMEONE ELSE SHARING THEIR KNOWLEDGE WITH US! May it be a teacher, a friend or a co-worker! This is not open-source, this is BUILDING! Building a better world becoming better people!

Long story short... On this site you don't only learn software.

Answer (score 2):

[WCF client and server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178434/wcf-client-and-server/15178690#15178690)

Stack Overflow has been a wonderful resource, the above question and my corresponding answer means a lot to me because it was the first time I realized how much the community has taught me.  For countless days, weeks, and months I asked questions about *Windows Communication Foundation*.

Then a random user asked about services, then interconnecting with Windows Communication Foundation.  He received a lot of feedback, though he stumbled since the question was unclear he received varying answers.

So I answered, as I began to respond I realized that a topic I was weak at became a stronger area for me.  He wasn't sure really what or where, so I began to explain the fundamentals and how they work together.  It covered all the required details ending with the piece of information he actually was hoping for which binding to use.

That had major significance, since then several members have made lasting impressions, such as:

- Travis
- Kendall Frey
- Reed Copsey
- Charlie Brown
- Roel
- Spencer
- Ton

Those members have been a tremendous help, as well as the C# Chat Room.  For that Stack Overflow will be a resource I rely on and contribute.

Answer (score 2):

**Question:** [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18746929/3711928)

**Answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/3711928

I started working with iOS right around the release of iOS 8. All of the existing codebase to our apps was written prior to iOS 8, so all of the example code I was going off didn't include a few things - specifically the auto-sizing of UITableViewCells.

When I was given a new project to work on, I decided the best implementation would be UITableView with cells that expanded to show more information if the information was present. I had some sample code to look at and decided it would be easy enough. I needed to calculate myself how big the cell needed to be. I then Googled the problem and every article I found suggested the same thing.

After all was said and done, I had auto-sizing cells that seemed to work about 95% of the time. When I asked a co-worker for help finishing this up, he said to me "why don't you just use auto-sizing cells?" I looked at him and said "I had no idea that existed." After he explained it was new with iOS 8, it was clear to me that all of Google's search results were still showing the best hits for what has been available up until now and didn't include anything regarding any of the new stuff Apple had just released.

So my co-worker tried to explain it to me and nothing we did seemed to work. Nothing worked until we stumbled upon the answer above. I was absolutely amazed at how easy it was to understand the answer. What seemed like such a difficult problem to us, really wasn't. The key was just simply to make sure my content was pinned to the top **AND** the bottom of the cell, letting the intrinsic size of the content do all the work!

**Lessons learned**

I didn't just take away one thing from this answer, I took away *three* things. I obviously learned how to auto-size my cells, but auto-layout finally "clicked" for me. It actually made sense. I now have such a better understanding of such a key feature of iOS.

And maybe more importantly, I learned that while Google may get you a great result, it won't necessarily get you the *best* result, especially in faster moving environments like iOS. An OS update can bring many new features that people just haven't gotten a chance to fully adopt and discuss yet, so don't just follow the first thing you find.

**Building a great answer**

Since the answer was originally posted, it has been edited multiple times, made into a community wiki and has turned into a one stop shop for everything you'd need to know about auto-sizing cells, complete with sample projects. It has garnered over 1.3k votes and has undoubtedly helped many like myself. It is just one of many resources that makes Stack Overflow great!

Thanks to everyone for all the help I've received over the years!

Answer (score 2):

### **The Question:** [Socket options SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT, how do they differ? Do they mean the same across all major operating systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t)

### **The Answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/14388707/1681994

I've run across this answer several times when working with socket programming; in most cases, it has even been more effective at explaining how socket reuse works than the official documentation.

In the most recent case, I was working with what was essentially a C++ UDP "client/server" program. As the client and server components each needed to be able to both send and receive data, they were effectively both servers (hence the quotes around "client/server"), and couldn't run on the same computer at the same time. I was curious to see if there was a way to connect the two programs on a single port (effectively using it as a broadcast address).

I stumbled across the SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT flags, which looked like what I wanted, but none of the documentation I found was particularly clear on how they worked. When I found this answer, everything made sense; the confusion was due to cross-platform incompatibility, where it seemed every OS had decided to interpret the flags differently.

In addition to a solution to my problem (use a different port for the client; none of the implementations had the feature I was looking for), I discovered that SO_REUSEPORT can be used to load balance between application instances within the network stack in Linux, which may prove useful in a later stage of development.

Answer (score 2):

I nominate [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/401684/2828611) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/401656/2828611)

I made research to make a login with php. First I just saved MD5 values to my database, without thinking that could be insecure. When I first read the question, I did not understand everything, nevertheless, I went to the answers. And I found [that beautaful answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/401684/2828611)

The other das I went to that page, I did not even recognized the answer. It totaly changed, the guy actualized the whole thing. At that time I understood a little bit more of that IT-stuff, and even then, I learned more from that answer. This answer is just great and I want to say Thankyou to all those dudes which update their answers to be up to date!

Answer (score 2):

### I got started with interpreters by analyzing Brainfuck 'hello world'

Question: [How does Brainfuck hello world actually work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836860/how-does-the-brainfuck-hello-world-actually-work)

Answer: [answer by Scony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19869651/1522753)

At the time I came across this answer, I was wondering how compilers/interpreters work and had a hard time understanding it. I started reading a book on the topic and found the level of details overwhelming for a beginner.

I knew that a Brainfuck interpreter was supposedly easy to write, but had no idea how Brainfuck worked. It seemed too esoteric at first sight.

The great answer by [Scony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2959795/scony) made it all clear to me. It's very thorough and simple at the same time. It showcases many points of a good problem explanation:

- Use headers to logically divide the text
- Mix the text with short code snippets and examples
- Link to external resources if needed

This is one of my favourite answers on SO, and one that benefitted my overall understanding of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

**The Question**

Submitting hidden field data on Android/iOS browsers does not work

**The Answer**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24654678/5268586

**The Story**

I came to this question the usual route, as a lurker.  As always after reading the question and accepted answer I had enough information to go and fix my own problem.  My issue was with a legacy web-application not working when accessed via an Android device (an issue I was debugging and googling for 2 days).
The question itself is great, it contains detailed analysis on the situation as well accurate description of the scenario and best of all existing code.  This situation mimicked mine and my failure.

The answer became my saving grace.  It allowed me to quickly fix my issue and walk away with some valuable information.  Browsers are weird and like to make life difficult.  Often I wonder how answers like the one found here are found originally, how many hours have gone into debugging it before a user was able to submit such a glorious answer.  How satisfying that developer must feel to then share that knowledge.  I want that, I will have that eventually.  I will find my post to answer a question I reluctantly had to find.

**Extras**

This is just one such story like this, as I am a long time lurker.  Back when I built an app for our local city (Kenosha Area Transit) me and the team used to joke that the app was brought to Kenosha by StackOverflow.  I have no doubt that my degree in Computer Science was only made possible by reading the submissions of people struggling with the same issues I had while learning.  So to you, early submitters, I salute you!

**Thanks Stack Overflow!!!**

Answer (score 2):

#### The Details

The Question: [How to use conditions inside Email template in SugarCRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611988/how-to-use-conditions-inside-email-template-in-sugarcrm/28793261#28793261)

My Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28793261/2775748

## Not every question has an answer

In my beginnings on SO (reputation at **astounding level of 81!**), when I started to realise what community stands behind all those answers I've been using through the years, finally I began **MY** contribution.

Slowly, steadily learning what are all those badges, answers, questions, flags and what's their meaning.

Well, I found this contribution pretty engaging and I started my *conquest* to the questions unanswered for years. Many of my answers to those *almost dead* questions didn't receive any reaction, but some of them **I managed to happily answer** until resolved.

This story however will be about fairly fresh question asked on February this year. OP asked about some way that he could use conditions in his SugarCRM email templates.

I knew absolutely nothing about SugarCRM at that time, so challenge was even bigger. So **for that one question** I started digging into SugarCRM docs. As I found nothing about conditions in e-mail templates (there were only few posts on their forum), I started to *wonder* if they have any templating engine built-in (Smarty for instance).

No information about it can be found on the web, so I took more insightful approach. **I jumped into their open source.** For my convenience I even downloaded repository to my NetBeans so I could use classes insights for it.

What I found somehow scared me.

SugarCRM - one of biggest and well known solutions **have spaghetti code**.

[Try it out](https://github.com/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_dev/blob/3f8126ba8c4d4f60b170199f68e2ee86dc8dd40c/modules/EmailTemplates/EmailTemplate.php) yourself, and try to easily understand `parse_email_template` method. I'm sure it is working, but maintaining this must be a *nightmare*.

When I found that email templating is simply replacing variables, I knew that there's no answer to "How to use conditions?". There was only an answer to "**Is it possible** to use conditions?".

That answer **won OP's heart**, and I won my first StackOverflow bounty.

Answer (score 2):

When I came in the world of coding I was really lost. I think that almost everyone was in this situation, because when you have some kind of experience in any programming language it's easier learning a new one, but du you remember the FIRST time that you saw some kind of code?

So I was in that situation. Almost everything was a challenge for me, everything I tried to code seemed difficult, so I spent hours looking for troubles related on the Internet... And it surprisingly I always ended on Stack Overflow. I didn't ask anything because I always thought that anybody will answer because I couldn't believe that someone could spent his/hers time on answering my newbie questions.

I continued forming as a programmer, and, of course, Stack Overflow kept solving my unasked questions. Suddenly, one day I couldn't find the answer to one of my [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178136/depth-using-opengl-in-xcode). I was about going crazy, so I decided to put my first question and you can imagine my surprise when I got an answer, in less than a couple of hours. After trying the solution, I could prove that it worked. I was glad with Stack Overflow thinking that it saved my life with such [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15179147/2127296).

I kept posting some questions, and I thought that the only way I could help was making clever questions. The other day I came across with one of my questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506228/print-a-value-using-jsp-and-expression-language-el)), and I could see that it had been seen more than 900 times. That made me feel that I had helped a few people with that. Then I went to the unanswered section, and I could see a question that I could answer. This was [**THE ANSWER**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31450596/2127296), it was chosen as the correct one and make me feel good. That feeling made me know that you don't have to be an experienced programmer to help on Stack Overflow. There are a lot of issues which you can solve, **you only need to take time enough to find a question which you can answer**.

*I'm not a very good writer, and I'm even worse in a foreign language, but I do my best.*

Answer (score 2):

I spend some time way out on one of the long tail of little-used, have yet to issue a bronze badge tags, specifically the intersystems-cache tag.

The original poster was asking about how to solve a problem with old MUMPS code that used a particularly poor part of the language - how it deals with I/O such as sockets.  Each implementation of MUMPS has hard-coded ways of dealing with I/O, and there isn't really a way to change it or mock it, and it makes working with such code particularly difficult.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015573/redirect-current-io-device-for-3rd-party-routine-interaction) asked about how to write your own device handler, which is a big missing feature that causes untold pain.  Unfortunately, the language has no way to do this..

Except, it turns out it does.  Someone who works in support at Intersystsems, a MUMPS vendor, published an undocumented but stable way to do this, which solves an enormous problem with no other work around.

This is why Stack Overflow exists.  Before it did exist, that answer would never have been shared where people could find it.  It's not an issue very many people will ever face, but for those that do this will save them a really huge amount of time.

And it's just one question out of 10 million.  A little question, with only a couple of hundred views.  It won't look like much statistically, but it probably is worth hundreds of hours for each of the couple dozen people who actually use it.  Time that would have been wasted if Brandon Horst had answered Chris Smith in an email, instead of on SO.

I would be thrilled if you sent Brandon a T-shirt.  I hope Intersystems does more of its support via SO in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words! I no longer work with ISC or any MUMPS-related thing, but it's such a great feeling to know that I helped somebody. I will wear the t-shirt with pride :)

Answer (score 2):

I like Haskell. I think it’s a fairly well-designed language, and it allows you to express reasonably abstract concepts without much trouble. That abstraction is also a stumbling block for persons learning Haskell: doing so much as printing “Hello, world!” will involve using a monad, and monads, due to their abstractness, have proven to be difficult to understand at first. While monads are the most [notoriously difficult-to-understand](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_tutorials_timeline) concept, they are not alone.

One day, I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347459/constructing-a-tuple-of-length-n-from-a-sequence-of-parser-combinators). I read the title and it seemed to be a relatively simple question with a relatively simple answer: an `Applicative` lift over a tuple constructor and you’d be done (with some explanation about what exactly that does, of course). Now, when I read the body of the question, I was pleasantly greeted by an existing attempt to abstract the problem. Looking more closely, I saw that they were reinventing a specialization of a standard library function.

Going back to monads, [one popular monad tutorial](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html) tries to explain them by showing a common problem, how you might go about solving it, and then showing how what you invented along the way was actually a monad. Creating something without the abstraction, and then bringing in the abstraction as a generalization of your existing concept, seems an effective way of breaking down the learning curve behind abstract concepts. Given that from this question I had just witnessed a specialization being invented, I figured I’d point out how it was a special case of the general existing idea of a `Functor`.

That out of the way, I was able to show how that existing concept had already been extended to encompass one particular type of use case that was asked about. At that point, I think it would have been a good answer to a good question. But the question also brought up something more complicated, something I wasn’t entirely sure how to do at first. I had to think about it a while before coming up with an answer to that part and adding it to my answer. It’s these questions that bring up subtler points that I might not have thought about before, that require some extra thinking to figure out how to do, that I really enjoy answering.

After all was said and done, I received positive feedback from the user asking the question, and another user hailed my answer as the canonical answer on the subject, of which I am pleased. It’s not a very popular question, having only 111 views at the time of writing, but I am sure that anyone else coming across that question having that problem will come away from it having learned something, which is always a wonderful occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

## Back to basics for a beginner

I'd like to share the story of one my answers, on the question [Need to create an array to reveal correct letters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28599083/2316200).

It is neither a popular question nor answer, with a small 51 views, but it is the moment I found the most rewarding in my 'StackOverflow career'.

---

I stumbled upon a user which was "hopelessly lost" with his C# program, on what could be seen as a fairly basic question.

It could have easily been answered with a bit of LINQ or some 'more advanced' C# features and minimal code. However, the user appeared to be pretty new to programming. A quick answer could solve his problem *now*, but would not help him understand at all what is going on.

So I took the long road. Relying only on fairly basic programming notions (arrays, for loops, and so on) that I'm pretty sure he is familiar with, I started from his code and showed him how to improve it to solve his problem, step by step, explaining every detail. I could have easily skipped what he did and solved it right away, but I am sure he worked very hard to get where he was. Instead of ignoring everything he did, I used it as a foundation, to show what could have been improved and why.

That way of answering was quite different of my other 'right to the point' answers, but man, it did pay off:

> You were a big help. I like that you took the time to work with my
> code instead of suggesting a ton of changes that would make all my
> work a moot point. Also the fact that you took it step by step and
> explained it to me was extremely helpful. thank you!

It was the first time that I got feedback indicating I *really* helped someone. Seeing a 'green tick' is always rewarding, but nothing can beat the feeling of having helped someone on that level.

Answer (score 2):

I've thought this over, and I can't really pick out a top Q&A, but I would like to take this opportunity to highlight some of my top answerers.

Looking through my questions, I've roughly been through 3 phases since Stack Overflow started: [F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f#), then [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git), then [Rx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system.reactive) framework.

For F#, I found [Tomas Petricek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33518/tomas-petricek) ALWAYS goes above and beyond. [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19299/brian) too (though he hasn't been back in a while)

For git [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) is the fount of all (my) knowledge, he's the answerer who [just keeps on giving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5855213).

And finally, for Rx, [James World](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87427/james-world) and [Enigmativity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259769/enigmativity) stand out.

*(The question/answer into which I personally put the most effort was probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1747236) one, which was - ironically - mostly for my own interest.)*

Answer (score 2):

## Such a Simple Answer but I Learned So Much

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13433038/1552737) I want to talk about is quite innocuous but it is part of the main reason I have been active on StackOverflow recently, earning [685 reputation in August 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552737/ikavanagh?tab=reputation&sort=graph&StartDate=2015-08-27%2010:45:09Z) and placing in the [top 0.87% for August 2015](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2015-08-01/1552737#1552737).

---

### Why Did I Need This Answer?

In October 2014 I begun my PhD in the area of computational electromagnetics really not knowing what was in store for me. It was to be a continuation of the work done during the project in my Bachelor's degree. During this project I worked exclusively with Matlab implementing iterative solvers, like the Conjugate Gradient, and solving indoor electromagnetic propagation problems. I grew very a depth at the matrix nature of Matlab and utilising shortcuts to write efficient programs. I now know I was naive and didn't understand the pain staking efforts that had gone in to developing Matlab and making it so easy for somebody like me to implement efficient programs without the need for very expensive and elaborate loops.

Anyway fast forwarding over the summer from the completion of my Bachelor's degree to the beginning of my PhD. My supervisor and I thought it would be a great idea and very easy to implement my current Matlab programs in C or C++, parallelise them and run them on a supercomputer. **Oh, how wrong we were!**

I had grown so accustomed to the ease of Matlab and was about to leave it for the complex field of *High Performance Computing*. One of the key optimisation techniques I had used in my programs to accelerate my solutions involved an element wise vector vector multiplication which is exactly what was asked for in [this particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621520/element-wise-vector-vector-multiplication-in-blas). This was something I had searched long and hard for and leveraging the BLAS documentation was unable to see how I could achieve it without using a dreaded `for` loop! **Alas!** My search ended when I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13433038/1552737) by [finnw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12048/finnw). This answer came over 1 year after the question had been asked and answered by the OP but more accurately answers the question and more importantly provides the solution I needed.

### Looking Closer at the Answer

[finnw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12048/finnw) when writing [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13433038/1552737) was very unselfish and only thought of the betterment of StackOverflow and the benefit he would provide to people down the line in years to come. As such his answer has risen to the top of the answers list and garnered 3 times more votes than the accepted answer.

The answer has many good aspects. It is very clear and the succinct pictorial description makes it very easy to understand what is going on behind the scenes. It really made me think about what I am using and how I should keep a more open mind to finding solutions. I also learned about the `extern` keyword which has become quite common in my C programs as of late.

The useful of [finnw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12048/finnw)'s answer has now made me an active member of the StackOverflow community and deserves recognition for that.

Answer (score 2):

**That time I helped someone get over 300 up-votes**

Once upon a time there a question where someone wanted to make custom markers in the Google maps api. [Google Maps API 3 - Custom marker color for default (dot) marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095574/google-maps-api-3-custom-marker-color-for-default-dot-marker/7096844#7096844)

I answered the question with what the OP felt was a less than desirable response, but he accepted it anyways. A few months later someone came a long and was inspired by my answer to get closer to what the OP wanted. This answer was accepted and grew in both fame and fortune.

Sometimes an accepted answer will scare people off. I mean, what are the odds the OP even cares anymore? But this guy saw a dissatisfied OP and was able to get closer to what he wanted.

Answer (score 2):

**[Android Game Loop vs Updating in the Rendering Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14347463)**

I've been on Stack Overflow for a while now, but pretty much all of the time I've been a lurker. I mainly use Stack Overflow as a resource for finding answers to random problems that I've been having while working on various games. I'd like to nominate the answer by fadden.

I saw this post a while ago, when I was just starting to get into Android game development and didn't have any idea where to start, and was already running into stuttering problems right off of the bat. As I was exploring different forms of game loop development, I ran across the answer that fadden wrote in response to the question, and it really described the stuttering problems that I was having.

Although I am nominating fadden's answer on the question, Blackhex's answer also provided some insight into the problem. However, I felt as though fadden definitely went above and beyond in helping not just the OP, but also everyone else that would've stumbled across the post.

Fadden's answer provided not only examples but also really detailed descriptions and explanations on why the framerate was struggling and how to fix it. He also provided links to other resources that provided an even deeper explanation to the problem at hand which helped me achieve a much deeper understanding.

Ultimately, this helped me fix the problem that I had been struggling with for weeks and improved the stability of my game. I am really thankful for the Stack Overflow community and how everyone works together to help each other. I have learned so much from this community and its limitless vault of knowledge and hope to one day be able to contribute my own knowledge to help others as well.

Answer (score 2):

**[Answer to "Global touch gesture in Android?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312790/global-touch-gesture-in-android/27313335#27313335)**

Since I've started developing apps for Android some three years ago I often focused on implementing functionality at the limit of what is possible. 
Usually, this involved root access or exploiting (obviously) unintended behavior of Android's internals, resulting in apps being incompatible with later Android versions where such behavior was changed/fixed.
Still, I found something else in Android opening many possibilities but (mostly in the past) lacking from complete and useful documentation, references, and examples: AccessibilityServices. 
Personally, I like to describe them as one of the hidden gems in Android, little known but very powerful.

When I found the said question, "Global touch gesture in Android?", I already knew two things:

1. Many or even most developers would say "it can't be done" because of platform restrictions like privacy-related limitations, security impact, etc. and
2. It can be done and I've a good idea how.

Detecting gestures within one's own app is an easy task in Android. 
The problems basically start when doing something like this globally, if another app is running.
Having spent much time working with AccessibilityServices I was familiar with their wide-reaching capabilities.
Things "normal" apps can't do like accessing other apps content (Views) and even interacting with them are possible using AccessibilityServices.
Even more, they are the perfect (and maybe only) candidate for a solution to this problem.

After taking a refreshing look at the corresponding information in the reference I quickly found the specific feature (a flag in this case) to enable such a global touch gesture detection in Android.
Together with some additional information, e.g., general hints about AccessibilityServices, I posted my answer.
Promptly, I was rewarded with a comment starting with "This is very knowledgeable. Thank you!" 
As a rather new contributor such a comment was very endorsing.
After a short comment answering a related question by the original poster I was again thanked with "That is understandable. Once again, thank you."
To me, sharing such largely specialized knowledge in an understandable fashion was and still is a great experience, especially being able to answer such a question with "yes and here's how" where others would say "no".

Answer (score 2):

#### [Encouragement works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784294/135978)
<sub>sometimes it takes a few years</sub>

Back in <strike>the heady days of the Internet</strike> Stack Overflow's earlier days, I came across [What does `<![CDATA[]]>` in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean). I fired off a quick answer, with a link to the relevant portion of the specification and called it done.

Unbeknownst to me, [Richard JP Le Guen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248129/richard-jp-le-guen) was in the middle of writing up an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784294/135978). My answer was accepted, but his garnered more up-votes because his was the better answer. (So much so that there was even a comment under my answer "This answer cites the proper sources, but Richard Le Guen's answer is better").

The upvotes kept coming in, and since it was my most highly voted answer, I kept seeing it ... and when I looked at it (now and again) I would see Richard's answer, and the well-earned approbation of the community.

Three *years* later, I went back and wrote the answer I should have finished writing in May of 2010. Thank you Richard for demonstrating the difference between a *sufficient* answer and a **good** answer!

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** I have decided to write this as a short story, just so I can reach more people.

**[The Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64)**

**Into the Dark Forest of `ptrace()`**

> Para 1

How does one define a tough project? Is it the one where you spend a long time coding the solution. Or is it the one where you spend a long long time searching for answers. I was facing a similar kind of dilemma when I first took up a browser security project for my Advanced Web Technology subject. At first when I read the details, it felt really awesome. Intercepting `system calls` made by a browser and inspecting them for malicious behavior.

The real problem started when I started to code. I decided to use the `ptrace()` system call. The problem was the convention that different OS uses to make system calls. Because my OS where I was implementing it as POC was a fairly new one. It was very difficult to find contents online.

> Para 2

I started off by reading the source code of `strace` (as internally it uses `ptrace()`), but somehow when I was using that knowledge, I was constantly getting errors and garbage values in my code. Moreover, as it is known, `ptrace()` handles registers directly, so one slight wrong access and the program use to come crashing down with a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). I was asking in forums (like this one [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54304/c)) and other places for solutions and a clear convention how parameters and return values can be accessed. Looking on the Internet, I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64) post on Stack Overflow.

> Para 3

Now, for a little back story. I started my Masters last year. I had to learn [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) as a new language for implementing projects, and I started to use Stack Overflow frequently for syntax and solutions. I noticed how people help each other, so I decided to contribute something back to the Stack Overflow community. What started as way to give back, quickly became my hobby.

So, before I was going through the Internet, I had already gone through what the Stack Overflow community can do to help, and how people contribute. I was highly impressed by some people, who gave their valuable knowledge and time to help people stuck in something.

So, when I found this post on Stack Overflow, it was surprising that I didn't get it in the beginning. Probably because of wrong keywords I was using to search. This post was very helpful to me. Not only did it provide me with the complete set of registers for the system calls. But, it also showed me the way on which I have to go to find more help.

> Para 4

Let me tell you what impressed me about this post. The effort made the OP who answered can be easily seen in the answered itself. Not only did he post all the details of the convention, but he went an extra mile to validate the information by going through the Linux Assembly Tutorial. The main help that I got from this was because he had posted about different architectures also.

That was something that I wasn't able to find anywhere. I feel the work done by this user was awesome, and it would have helped not just me, but many people. It's evident by the number of upvotes.

> Para 5

In the end, I completed my project, and I got a nice grade for it. But the important part was that I learnt a lot from it. The same goes for the answer posted on Stack Overflow. It showed me the way out of that **Dark Forest**. :)

Answer (score 2):

## Java has type erasure. What about C#?

Looking through C# questions on Stack Overflow, I came across this question about generics:

[What is reification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876372/what-is-reification)

At that time, I knew that Java implemented generics through type erasure, but I had never stopped to think about how they were implemented in C# and the [CLR](http://CLR). For me, C#'s implementation of generics was done through "not type erasure".

[Theodoros Chatzigiannakis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31876747) was helpful beyond what was asked of it, because, besides explaining what type reification was, it also compared it to other languages (C++ and Java) and explained how generics worked in each of those other languages (in C++ it's actually templates, which are a bit different from generics). This explanation gave me an overview of how generics can be implemented and what the pros and cons of each implementation are.

One example of something I learned from this question is why C# allows you to use value types (e.g. `int`, `double`) as generic type arguments without boxing, while Java does not.

#### A stepping stone

Theodoros' answer served as a basis for further understanding of generics. It made me think of why some languages have certain restrictions with generics beyond what was written in the answer. With the knowledge I gained, I was able to reason about further doubts, such as why C++ templates allow you to write code that only works for arithmetic types, but C# does not. Essentially, it's because C++ compiles the code once for each template type, while C# compiles it once and requires all operations on the generic type to be valid for any possible generic type.

Answer (score 2):

**Why Stack Overflow can complete the official documentation of any platform**

It happens very often that you want to accomplish some coding task, and you read the documentation, and the reference, and the examples, but you still can't find how to achieve something that in your head is really simple and should be possible to do. Then you start digging, and apparently nobody has the solution, specially if it is about some new API or framework.

So that was the case with the new Android reveal animations, where you can create an circular animation to reveal a new view or view group, and they were easy to use except in one case where the view you want to show is an Android fragment, because it has an asyncronous way of showing the contents.

This was asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819429/cannot-start-this-animator-on-a-detached-view-reveal-effect/26861930) which I found really challenging and I wanted to try it myself. Applying the expertise I had on Android, I tried different approaches until I finally found [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819429/cannot-start-this-animator-on-a-detached-view-reveal-effect/26861930#26861930) which seems to solve the problem for many people according to the upvotes. I also published an example on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) (deleted now) which was starred by many people too.

So in this case, my answer provided some samples of a technique that wasn't explained in the official documentation, but it was also a valid approach for a common case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure if it fits the criteria or not, and it might be bad form to be posting my own answer, but...

### Answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461418/could-anyone-explain-these-xss-test-strings) made me "get" SO

I work in Web Application Security, and I've been doing it for a few years now; it always kind of upsets me that almost everything I know about my field I learned "on the job" rather than from college or reading I'd done in the past.  I feel like it's an important field, and it really gets neglected by most CS programs and tutorials that aren't specifically geared toward security.

So, when I saw this question come up, asking for an explanation of some XSS injection strings, I thought I'd answer it; my rep wasn't (and over a year later, still isn't) by any stretch very high, and it seemed like a sort of niche question that could potentially earn me some decent rep.  So I wrote [one of the most detailed answers I've ever written](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26168977/2489497) for it.  It's not a super stellar answer compared to tons of the absolutely brilliant ones I've seen on SO, but it's the first answer *I* really put a lot of *effort* into, because I was really interested in teaching the concepts of XSS testing to the asker.

Proud of my formatting, step-by-step explanation, and generally (in my opinion) *very good* answer, I submitted it and waited for the rep to pour in.

And waited.

And *waited*.

That answer has been there for almost a year, and to date it hasn't been accepted, and still only has two upvotes; the answer that I consider to be the best I've ever written hasn't even been accepted.  And at first, I was *really* miffed about it, but then I realized that getting the reputation wasn't the point of trying to teach these concepts, *teaching the concepts was, itself, the point*.  And that's when I realized that I shouldn't be answering questions just to get a higher rep (which is pretty much exactly what I had been doing), but to share knowledge I have that others might not.

I haven't answered a question since then, not because I've given up on doing so, but because I want to answer questions that *mean* something to me, that really *teach* instead of just doing a glorified LMGTFY.

Answer (score 2):

## [How to get Docker to run on a Windows System behind a corporate firewall?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29303930/1228454)

As anybody using Docker in a corporate environment is aware of, its support for running behind a proxy server isn't - uhm - great. When starting to use Docker, I immediately ran into the same issues as in the question (and I'm not even using Windows). When I found the answer, I was speechless - this answer included every possible detail on how to use Docker with a proxy server. The answer had been updated several times with more recent information, and [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) had even created a [GitHub project](https://github.com/VonC/b2d) to open source some of his work in this area.

I think I even left a comment along the lines of "Epic answer" under the answer, but it looks like the comment has been deleted since (might have done that myself - can't be sure...).

Anyway, when looking for answers in the Git tag, you can be sure that VonC is always one of the first to answer, and his answers are always full of information (links to the Git source code, links to other questions/answers, etc.). When I find such an answer, I know that there's valuable information in there that addresses the question - that's a sign of quality. He doesn't simply provide you with a one liner that solves the problem, he goes into detail (why is this working, how does it work, when was this added) to make sure that people learn more about the topic, without forcing his superior knowledge of the topic down your throat :-)

Answer (score 2):

**The question**

[How to update GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7244321/5301198)

**The answer**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244456/5301198

**The story**

A couple of months ago I forked [a GitHub project](https://github.com/Guardiola31337/otto), because I was really interested in the changes of an unresolved [Pull Request](https://github.com/square/otto/pull/121). In order to do that I needed to know how I can get those changes into my fork. What did I do?

Stack Overflow to the rescue!

As a developer, I think this kind of update is not common and I always end up forgetting it. So, whenever I need to apply fixes in a new version of the original project, I turn to that answer!

That's the power of Stack Overflow!

I think, Stack Overflow is a huge technical dictionary in which you can always look for useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

## So, [What’s a Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4247184/3764814)

Do you think you know? Are you sure? Think again. I thought I knew until I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4247184/3764814) by [Tom Christiansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist), a recognized Perl and Unicode guru.

This is a perfect example of an eye-opening answer written with out of the box thinking. If you're looking for a *"Falsehoods programmers believe about numbers"* article, it would clearly be that post.
Most people think this is a *very* simple topic and dismiss it as a solved problem. This answer shows there's much more to it just by asking a few questions which reveal the broadness of the topic and all the details you couldn't possibly think about. The big picture is more complicated than what we're used to.

The whole thing started as being *another* answer to *another "how do I match a number with regex??"* question. I remember I first stumbled on it by simply following a duplicate link...
And the [sand produced the pearl](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) <sub><sub>(pun intended)</sub></sub>. This is a prime example of what I enjoy the most about Stack Overflow: sometimes you find a *really* interesting answer, which goes *way* beyond what's expected. You can tell only by looking at it that Tom put a ridiculous amount of effort into that one, and I want to thank him for that, and for his overall history of awesome answers (just check his [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129/3764814) to date - *if* your browser can cope with it - I could write a similar post about that one too).

Answer (score 2):

**The question**

[How to decide if a phone is a phone or a tablet is a tablet at Android.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android)

**The answer**

No valid questions, all valids, neither of them valids.

**The story**

I had a meeting with some clients trying to decide if a 6" phone is a phone or is a tablet because that clients doesn't want to implement a different UI for phone or tablet, just show a message with a play store link to another application, let's call that "app HD".

So how to do it? What is actually a tablet or a phone in Android? There are many sizes and also there is a new concept "phablet". Stack Overflow to the rescue, as we can see on the thread there are many answers with different approaches to let you think which is the best one. With some of this different approaches I was able to convice the client to implement a different UI for 7" and reuse the same for 10" like the Android design guidelines of the moment told. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

First thank you Stack Overflow for being here and to all the people, a great example of democracy.

### The question

[JavaScript/JQuery: $(window).resize how to fire AFTER the resize is completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854407/javascript-jquery-window-resize-how-to-fire-after-the-resize-is-completed)

### The answer (not the accepted)

[JavaScript/JQuery: $(window).resize how to fire AFTER the resize is completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854407/javascript-jquery-window-resize-how-to-fire-after-the-resize-is-completed/14334146#14334146)

### The story

Some years ago I was building a generic jQuery resize handler, and sadly a good CSS3 grid system wasn't enough, so I wrote a function that made some calculation on resize and move-show/hide many elements accordingly. But the resize event fires too often and sometimes the website hangs...

I was googling for days and finally found this answer. This solution teached me three things:

1. [Underscore.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js): I didn't use it, and it was a good occasion to learn a new, great, library
2. **debouce**: oh dear, the keyword that solved my issue!
3. The great Paul Irish (read more for details)

I was thinking about a timer, but it seemed to be too much "hard-coded", but now I knew the correct key to search more deeply: `debouce`.

But why did this happen? I found the Paul Irish blog and a great post about this (*[Debounced Resize() jQuery Plugin](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/)*), so:

> In IE, Safari, and Chrome many resize events fire as long as the user
>   continues resizing the window. Opera uses as many resize events, but
>   fires them all at the end of the resizing. Firefox fires one resize
>   event at the end of the resizing.

And the explanation:

> This isn’t exactly throttling, but it’s close. Basically debouncing
>   will fire your function after a threshold of time (e.g. 100 ms) has
>   elapsed since the last time it’s tried to fire. Throttling would
>   withhold subsequent firings, but debouncing waits for the last one and
>   runs that.

### What this story teach me

Keywords are not important; they are fundamental! Before starting to search too much, stop, breathe and think if you are searching for the right key concept; thanks again Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

First, is there a prize for someone with the smallest rep even *looking* on SE Meta page? (not trying to be sarcastic, but afraid I have the dubious honor...so far.)

The story is that of the beginning of my participation in the greater SE network in general. As most stories, it began with a question.

I have recently began working with SAS, and as a novice it can be encouraging but also discouraging to see expert awesomeness manifested in forums like SO. The former because it helps to get answers and nudges the learning. The latter because it illustrates the vastness of the knowledge gap. I try to stay focused on the encouraging part.

To the point. I figured I would need help now and then (i.e. all the time) so joined SO as a preventative measure, in case I have questions that nobody asked before. Between this and other forums, it took me about 2 months to realize that it might be years until I have such a question! But I still wanted to *contribute* in some way, in part because teaching is a great way to learn. However, I faced a dilemma.

What could a novice add to a community of experts dishing swift and precise answers to questions regardless of difficulty level? With hope nearly lost, I lazily eyed the daily feed of fresh questions.

**OH MAMMA MIA PRIMADONNA!**

Am I dreaming?! Did someone ask a question I could actually ANSWER?!? Why yes, they did: about [summing observations vertically based on condition.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264677/sas-looping-summing-observations-vertically-based-on-conditionally/29128545#29128545)
Indeed, it had already been answered, and answered well, by [Mjsqu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3388954/mjsqu) (whose response I want to highlight). His response was a great model to follow, because it was (a) correct, (b) highly detailed with complete, unambiguous code examples, and (c) offered several alternative solutions. In fact, it was almost *too* good, tempering my initial hopes of an opportunity to contribute. But I mentally bookmarked that question in case there happened to be yet another answer. Lo and behond, a couple months later I stumbled on another alternative approach. So I went ahead and supplemented the original question with it, modeling my response on @mjsqu's.

I am still in the territory of learning more than contributing, but that experience nudged me to focus my contribution efforts in other areas where I already have experience, and contribute to a few other forums in the SE sphere. As my experience with SAS and other tools builds up, I hope to become a more active contributor to this and other technical forums.

Comment: Having a response on this thread voted down feels like being bullied. Lame. I am confident that on the whole this community knows better. Come on lighten up!

Comment: It's actually a pretty well written answer that you linked to, so I have no idea why this is being down voted.

Comment: [*Stack Overflow* is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).

Comment: Thanks @PeterMortensen, learned something new. Q&A site/platform, then.

Answer (score 1):

**Question**: [Python in vs ==. Which to Use in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422253/python-in-vs-which-to-use-in-this-case)

**Answer**: [Python in vs ==. Which to Use in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422253/python-in-vs-which-to-use-in-this-case/31422431#31422431)

Not only StackOverflow contains a lot of awesome questions, awesome answers, but also awesome people who are not just talented but also vary helpful and eager to learn. I believed that although I can learn a lot from SO, but I am not much of an expert who can really give simple, convincing and elaborate answers to questions that ask in detail about programming language constructs.

SO **helped me build up my confidence** a lot when I attempted to answer the aforementioned question. The question really asked to write and compare in detail in terms of performance, best practice and memory usage of two fundamental functionalities provided by Python.

Not many answers were posted till that time, so I took some time and posted based on simple checks, how **in** compares with **==**. I got some upvotes and this really boosted me that even though I am still a novice, I can help others. Not that every one is expert in every other field. After sometime I thought probably I can help even more by comparing the performance of list with dictionary and tuples as well. I also posted some details about functionality that I knew. And upvotes flooded in. But I was more content because I helped not just for upvotes.

Although, this is my meager contribution, but I ended up helping myself better while trying to help others. Although all answers here will surely highlight awesome contributions, I did not hesitate to highlight how SO helped me become confident, and this answer exemplifies that confidence.

This is what I have learned from stackoverflow :

1. Answer accurately and elaborately.
2. Support the best answer, but don't hesitate to provide your insights as well.
3. Helping is more important than upvotes.
4. Community will reward if you answer properly.
5. It is you who make the community, so reward deserving people.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I was browsing Stack Overflow, as you do, and saw a PHP question about an ORM. Specifically [Using with() in Spot ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783858/using-with-in-spot-orm/28811199#28811199). I'm not too well versed in ORMs, but I've used `Doctrine` and thought I might be able to help. I never heard of Spot before (and still haven't seen it except for that one question). So I thought the odds of someone being able to provide an answer to it was relatively low. The question had gotten an upvote, but wasn't getting much attention else-wise. At first I thought the question was relatively simple, but then I started looking through the documentation. The docs weren't too clear, and it looked like as if it was contradicting itself.

I was intrigued.

So after some researching I found the answer. I don't think it's a great answer, but I learned something from it, and I think OP did too. I learned that with some research you can really provide a clear and exact answer (or to me it feels that way) if you want to. You don't have to know the technology the OP is asking about, you don't even have to have worked with it. It was kind of fun researching how it would work and providing an answer for a question that didn't look like it was gaining much traction. It's still one of my favourite answers I've given. It doesn't have a lot of views, it doesn't have a lot of votes, but it's one of those answers that still make me feel a little proud. Proud to have helped someone in need, who probably wouldn't have gotten much of an answer else-wise. To me that answer describes what SO really can do for someone.

Answer (score 1):

**A journey ...**

I had originally started answering questions on SO to teach *me* something as much as the OP: my theory was that if I understood a topic well enough to understand and then answer a question clearly then I knew I had finally grokked the topic.

One of the early answers I gave (that I thought may not have been worth the effort at the time) turns out to be the one that still rewards me by reminding me on a regular basis that the effort here is worth it. *You can reach more people with a good SO answer than you will ever meet in person in your life.*

**The long answer ...**

Only a few weeks in to my SO journey Rowan Freeman posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16704065/1945631) which was (is) huge. Each part had a very specific answer but there were so many parts.

I had used SimpleMembership before but I didn't really *know* it and could not yet visualise how it all slotted together. I set out to post a minimal answer. Over the course of a day I made time between other work to tie together my knowledge of SimpleMembership, create the answer, and then polish it with a few edits. My "minimal" answer [ended up being 1500+ words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16734651/1945631), nearly 40 external references, and taking periods of research and effort over nearly 12 hours.

I had learned a lot: the effort put into answering it had taught me how all the components of SimpleMembership worked in concert and I was happy with that. I just wasn't sure if writing the answer as well was a day of coffee, lunch and dinner breaks well spent.

**The big surprise ...**

After posting the answer I forgot about it and moved on, and so it sat for 2 weeks. But then Rowan did something that knocked me off my chair: he came back and awarded me a bounty, editing his question to say:

> I have placed a bounty on this question and intend to award it to Andy Brown for an outstanding answer.

***It was an unexpected and unnecessary compliment, and one I will always be grateful for, Rowan, and I am glad I have this chance to openly thank you in return.***

**The long tail ...**

Every now and then the question gets an upvote, and I see it now has 20508 views. Those upvotes remind me that sometimes the best answers are a fish and 12 lines explaining how to catch that fish again, and sometimes going that extra 12 hours to write an essay is worth it. As I said at the start: I now know that, whether it takes 12 seconds or 12 hours to write, a good SO answer can reach a lot more people than I will ever meet in person.

Answer (score 1):

I am still new to this site, but back when I was even newer, I was in a position where I had to use a technology I had no understanding of, namely .NET.

I was having a hard time, and I felt immensely pressured to do well in my internship, but I just couldn't get anything right. My co-intern was not very good at explaining what he didn't understand well either. So I posted a question:

[Does asp.NET call code behind class' constructor at each fired event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327335/does-asp-net-call-code-behind-class-constructor-at-each-fired-event)

My question was poorly formatted for SO, but kind community members edited it. And I got an answer that made .NET much more understandable to me. [hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd) answered my question and explained the reason why it was like that. And I understood. The knowledge I gained made it possible for me to dig in and work hard in my internship again with new energy and new understanding of the technology.

I would also say that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32052827/3572700) answer by  I recently got to a question is very thorough and taught me a lot, even though I had already solved my problem with the help of another answer.

Answer (score 1):

- [DropWizard Auth by Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27393546/2587435)
- [jersey + grizzly + hk2: Dependency injection, but not into resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31967183/2587435)

When learning something new, sometimes I have a hard time grasping concepts of just how the nuts and bolts of something work together. When all the pieces finally fit together for me logically, and I have that "AH HA moment", I feel inspired to learn more. So when I can answer a question thoroughly enough to where I provided that same "AH HA moment" for the OP, *and* it is validated by a comment with the same type of inspiration I feel when I experience that moment, then I feel my job is done.

Also, when I see comments like:

> [Once again, thanks @peeskillet (+1)! I have posted a lot of questions on SO, and you are by far the most thorough, responsive & helpful user I've come across here. Thanks again!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427429/dropwizard-auth-realms/27431182#comment43303860_27431182)

I am inspired myself to continue answering question in great depth. Making no assumptions about the OP's knowledge and explaining something so that all the pieces *just fit* together, also makes the answer more universal for all other readers.

It's hard to pick just one question where I feel I did a good job of teaching, as I believe there are so many. That's not to brag at all. I just feel that you don't really understand something until you can teach it. So often in my answers (when I'm not being lazy :-), I will teach rather then just "answer". If I can explain something to the point where the OP is not just copying code to solve a problem, but actually learning *how* it works, that is more beneficial to the OP, to all other readers, *and* to myself.

The questions I linked to, there was not much interaction with the OP, but that is kind of a good sign, as the OP learned enough from the initial answer to not *need* to ask further :-)

Answer (score 1):

### The problem I couldn't let go

[Determine non-convex hull of collection of line segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830218/determine-non-convex-hull-of-collection-of-line-segments)

This isn't necessarily my best answer, at least not in the sense that it had a clear-cut solution to serve on a plate. But what this answer does is it captures that spirit of letting yourself be drawn into a very specialized and unique problem and not relenting until the asker is taken to a much better place than where they started.

It was variation on the concave hull theme, with a twist: the things to be bounded were line segments, not points. It was such a mind teaser that I couldn't stop thinking about it.

With a first effort, I came up with a solution, which the OP was happy with. But the thing kept rolling in my head; it wouldn't go away. Sure enough, special cases popped up which would make the algorithm fail. Before the OP could accept the answer, I made sure to bring this up. In fact, upon closer consideration and after some discussion in the comments, it turned out that the very problem itself was ill-defined.

I kept coming back to the problem to tweak the solution; more problematic edge cases came up. It went on like that day after day. I knew I had other, "more important" things to do, but I just couldn't let it go. In the end, after almost a week, I had cornered the thing into a place where the remainder of the problem could be dealt with using standard pruning algorithms, at which point the answer was accepted.

Both I and, I think, the OP learned a bit more on how to define and address this type of problem. In my time at SO, I have found that getting answers to one's questions is nice, but that in fact, I learn as much, if not more, when I answer other people's questions.

Answer (score 1):

So I am putting forward my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3884763/300863) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3884733/300863).

It isn't a particularly tricky question or the longest/most complete answer in the world.

However, the comment from [gbn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27535/gbn):

`+1 Over clause is elegant –  gbn Oct 7 '10 at 18:47`

Is what really got me changed my way of thinking.

I was always of the opinion that people who were more "Senior" than me or had a large amount of reputation on Stack Overflow were always right. They always knew more than me, because, well they were Senior / had more rep. I didn't know everything and I was therefore not a very good developer (classic imposter syndrome?). I'd shy away from making my opinions known, avoid any technical suggestions I had.

After reading this small comment, something inside my brain clicked. I realised that just because a person was "senior" or had lots of imaginary "reputation", you simply can't know *everything*.

People who I'd previously assumed would not be interested in what I had to say, well, they didn't seem off limits anymore. GBN had a far higher rep than me and, if you've been active in the [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) tag will know that he really knows his onions.

It was a small, off the cuff, compliment that changed my approach forever. I made my suggestions, I gave my opinions. Not all were right. Not all were accepted. They were all welcomed though.

Answer (score 1):

### [Update two TextViews inside a runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475279/update-two-textviews-inside-a-runnable/31475448#31475448)

This is not a big story, but for me it has a nice meaning since it was my first answer to a Stack Overflow question. For a long time, I have been a user of Stack Overflow who just looked for an answer and never participated. Even, I never had the need to ask anything, since all the questions I happened to have were already solved by someone else before.

However, some months ago, I read the book Apprenticeship Patterns, which I recommend you to read, and I realized that I should try to contribute and help others by documenting my learning progress (so I decided to open a blog) and share the knowledge I have grasped in the past few years (so I started answering in Stack Overflow and opened a GitHub account to open source some pieces of code).

The answer I provided to the question above was not really very complex and many other people could have provided it, but for me, it was a nice feeling knowing that I helped someone in some other part of the planet who I don't know. I think it is some kind of magic that Stack Overflow makes possible, and I has become a tool for many developers to solve issues which might be difficult to solve by oneself.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing lots of complex questions (way above my head at the moment) but SO is not only great for the experts, but for anyone, the beginners, intermediates, whatever, as the question/solution/story I've elected shows.

All in all, thanks SO for helping me (and everyone) and at unholy times in the morning!

**Question** - MVC 5 Dynamic Rows with [BeginCollectionItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700557/mvc-5-dynamic-rows-with-beginitemcollection) - asking what is the best way to add/delete rows to a table when I was starting out with MVC after using web forms initially.

**Solution** - Originally, I didn't use BeginCollectionItem as was suggested in the comments and instead got something working using multiple Partials, it did what I wanted, but isn't the best way of doing this, which is what was suggested to me, I am yet (now-ish) to give an improved answer, using the suggested (and brilliant) BeginCollectionItem.

**Story** - After university I wound up in an IT Support role, however I wanted to get into the programming industry, so enrolled into a course doing .NET to add to my CV. Throughout the course and afterwards in searching for a development job SO was there. Helping me learn, improve, and occasionally managing to help others along the way. Eventually landing a .NET dev role.

I highly doubt this little story is in anyway unique, more to add my gratitude to what Stack Overflow has done and will continue to do, not only for me, but for many others.

Comment: Oh god. I spent *days* trying to get something like that to work. That NuGet packaged helped, but has some issues of its own. I've come to accept that MVC & razor just wasn't meant to do that. Next time, I'll just add a webforms page to the project and be done with it.

Comment: Aha yes - typically it was my first MVC project as I wanted to get away from Web Forms at work and try something new. It would have been so much easier in WF, hey-ho, BCI is a wonderful thing. I don't know why it isn't supported in MVC - sure there's a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

**The time I was waking up at 4-5am EST every day so that developers on the otherside of the world would help me.**

So, at work I was told I needed to develop an Android Application from scratch and I know that was not my area of expertise or familiarity. I'm a software developer but I've been mostly coding in C# and on the .NET framework using Visual Studio. I remember a little a bit of Android/Java from one class I took. That's it.

So, I was given a few tasks and those tasks became the biggest learning curve of my life. Android was just... different. I had to memorize the activity lifecycle , how activities and fragments worked, their concepts of pagers and adapter, writing RAW SQL. Everything frustrated me and this project needed to be done in two months or so :(

I started to ask questions on Stack Overflow like a desperate person, hoping someone would explain why what I've done isn't working or isn't proper.

I want to give a shoutout to [mmlooloo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3805262/mmlooloo) and [stonebird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2312519/stonebird) especially (but really there were so many others that helped me on my Android development path). Both of them helped me with a problem that's been bothering me for weeks! 
mmlooloo helped me with understanding what a viewpager does and how to use one.

From [this answer I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26081936/2182521) to [answering my question on ViewPagers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26639082/2182521).

Stonebird was one of the most memorable ones that stayed on "continue this discussion in chat" when I needed help. Starting [from this annoying problem I had that was hard to explain that I had to upload a video for the answerer to see the behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26879117/2182521) and continuing to help me through another problem I was having.

His snarky response to asking for more help:

*"@KalaJ you don't expect me to walk you through your app, do ya? :P"*

Besides, asking question on SO. I learned the most from the StackOverflow chatrooms. Unfortunately, the main Android chatroom is locked and only for elite Android community members. There's a smaller one called "[iOS][Android][ChaosOverFlow]" and only for users with certain rep. I noticed most of the developers on there are from India or the other side of the world because it would almost always be empty when I'm working or during day here in the US. But they would be most active in the early hours of the morning, 4-8am.

So, I would tell myself, I don't have a mentor or someone to respond to my stupid questions... only them. So I'd wake up at 4-5am everyday asking a bunch of questions about Android and most of them are friendly. [Berserk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2944070/berserk), I remember, helped me quite a bit among others.

Hardest period of my development life was learning Android but it was worth it :)

Now to the present? I'm back to developing in C# and I would love to give out a shoutout to the C# and WPF chatrooms! Very, very friendly people! NETScape and Reed Copsey helped me with my WPF questions and TravisJ, Charlie, Sippy,tweray, Kendall, etc.. with my C# ones. I am even appointed one of the room owners of C# and I would have never expected it (I only noticed after someone pointed it out to me!). I try to help out now when I can either on chatrooms or answering questions on my level on SO. StackOverflow is my virtual family :) The community is amazing and I owe my life to SO :)

I know the more I learn, the more I can give to others looking for knowledge as well :)

Comment: It's difficult to tell which answer in those questions you're recognizing (you forgot to "link to the answer on the main site you're talking about").

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll edit my post :) I assumed the reader to know it would be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### [Gridwise application of the bisection method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098205/gridwise-application-of-the-bisection-method)

Anyone who has worked with `Python's` `spicy.optimize.minimize` branch before knows how utterly complicated things can turn out to be, and how sometimes the cleanest most-senseful code just won't find that minimum or those roots you're after. Even worse, as soon as you try to scale this, and come up with vectorized solutions, you'll bang your head against a wall more often than there are lines in your code.

I was looking for a - duh - vectorized bisection method. Vectorizing the "*Let's see whether `a` is now closer to `0` than it was before, and whether we need to increase it or decrease it*" part was just above my head. I tried, and failed. And failed. Some genius in a different post had come up with a snippet that worked in that way, but I didn't understand what was happening. He gave me a rough overview of "First we do this, then we do that". But It was indexing magic in `scipy`/`numpy`, and indexing magic is just something I cannot wrap my head around. So I could stare at single lines and still not get it. The code worked for some time, and then, it didn't. It was like magic, but the bad kind.

And then [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24152576/1082349) fixed it. He took that snippet - someone else's code, and explained it. That day I learned much about index magic. I've forgot most of it again, but that question is a favorite of mine now. And whenever I need to become an index magician, I have a quick look at it again.

Answer (score 1):

I actually have three different stories to pick from and a real hard time deciding upon one...
... but finally it was the most pleasant moment for me, to [go above and beyond](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20080302/1807643) the usual scope of this site.

It was a low-traffic question asking a something quite unusual and you didn't have to be some kind of magic wielder to see that the OP was more on the beginner level in terms of "thinking like a developer" (no offense!).

After writing a quick answer to OPs original question I remember he had a follow up question in a now deleted comment. As his follow up question was a no-brainer [I quickly edited my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20080302/2) and he was already like "wow cool!".
After this it got obvious that his code had bugs and somehow my personal interest grew a bit, as this project he was working on sounded quite cool: an RPG on a virtual tabletop.
So I began inspecting his code, as he provided most of it in a GIST. I managed to [track down](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20080302/3) most of [the bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20080302/6). While we I was doing this we had a quite lengthy Q&A session in the comments to my answer (that got deleted and deservedly so!) where I explained general programming concepts, JS specifics  and what I do to him.
Two hours into Q&A, bugtracking and answer-editing I went to sleep, although it threw a nasty NaN-exception. Nevertheless I already felt a bit satisfied. It was good to know that I helped someone with my knowledge and explanations.

You know how it is: if you have a big problem (code-wise), sleep a night and you may find the fix in no time. That was the case here. The next morning, when giving the code another look [it struck me](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20080302/8). A nasty little whitespace and a non-capital letter. I edited this into my answer, informed OP by a comment and a few hours later I just had a big grin for the rest of the day after reading

> Awesome you totally rocked it!!

It was just the feeling of knowing that I *really* helped someone out, made them learn something new and showed them a few tricks. This was great and a ton of fun.

Unfortunately I didn't had the time to look at his follow up question and I don't know what happened to his project. Checking his user profile just shows that he isn't active anymore.

Nevertheless, this was by far the most memorable moment for me and an awesome feeling.

---

Now I just have to share another (short) story on how [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290098/meshes-starting-to-jump-on-camera-rotation-movement#comment18120922_13290098) can make you understand a whole world.

It was my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290098/meshes-starting-to-jump-on-camera-rotation-movement) on SO, shortly after I joined this awesome community.
I didn't expect the question to attract a lot of traffic, but after twenty minutes someone finally made a comment... and my brain was just like **boom**. I still know that [@jcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417292/jcoder)s comment opened up the whole world of floating-point precision to me and made me connect the dots.
I knew about floating-point precision. I knew what it was and how it can be problematic. Unknowingly I wrote my own example code that even visualized a float-point precision problem, but I couldn't make a connection between my problem and the so-obvious answer. All it took was a small comment.

So... THANK YOU [@jcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417292/jcoder) - if you ever read this.

Answer (score 1):

### The subtle semantics of Reference and Value types.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6389455/21461) I would like to call out is my own, but the helpful person is Jon Skeet.  This story played out via comments and my own [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6389455/revisions).  I had originally posted an answer that answered the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6389437/21461), but was not technically correct.  Jon Skeet posted a comment dsagreeing with the wording of my answer, and through it, I learned a bit about references and value types.

I remember being frustrated at how picky Jon was being, but reflecting on it now, several years later, I realize that he was just trying to impart knowledge.  I have since learned more about value types, references, objects, and how each are handled by the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Last year I was put into my first web project which used JSF and Java EE. The EE stuff wasn't hard to learn as I had a long spring background and recognized the concepts which I've already used before.

But the JSF stuff was a tough beast. I spent so much time looking for best practices to adopt. Building a basic web application with JSF might be easy but with a claim of building *user-friendly* UIs eg. by providing *early validation feedback*, *keeping states* and so on complicates this a <strike>little bit</strike> pretty much.
Also JSF is one of those technologies were you really have to consider the version *you are using* and the version *a blog post or SO answer is talking about*.

Almost always I googled (or SO'd) for a JSF-related problem I ended up with a stackoverflow question which was answered by [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc). *"Answered"* doesn't fit here very well maybe *"elaborated"* is a better word? (Sorry I'm not a native speaker). What I want to say is that BalusC answers a question which consists of one sentence with an *essay* which fills three screen pages. In that he points out *different ways for different JSF versions* and tells you things which might answers follow-up questions. Instead of just grabbing the answer, upvoting and go on I often had the feeling of really learning something. GREAT!

I am very thankful for answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909382/714965) on [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener).

Answer (score 1):

**[Django i18n_patterns - How to prevent prefixing of non-active languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367954/django-i18n-patterns-how-to-prevent-prefixing-of-non-active-languages/26439433#26439433)**

Django i18n_patterns - How to prevent prefixing of non-active languages?

I came across this question and decided to solve. Since I was not familiar with i18_npatterns, I spent a lot of time reading docs, SO, checking code to solve it. I tried couple of ways but using a third party package seemed to be simple solution.

After 1 hour of research, I posted a solution. I am very happy as I was able to find a simple solution (and I was also expecting a bounty as there were no answers).

After few hours OP posted a comment saying I didn't even understood the question and my answer wont work.

I double checked question & answer, they looked correct. OP was missing something and I don't know what it was. So, I created a demo project using the solution I have mentioned & asked OP to try it once and see if works out.

Later he tried that & found that he had to remove a middle ware to make it work and he was very happy it worked. I am very happy to help out OP :)

Answer (score 1):

## Question

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783160/sieve-of-atkin-implementation-in-python) was about the Sieve Of Atkin implementation and why it was not working.

## How It Helped Me

I was originally just looking for an implementation to calculate    something for school; however, I got interested in how the sieve itself was derived, so as I started to research mathematical functions and their derivations, and it gave me much more appreciation for maths and mathematical programming, and so I've been learning as much math as I could since that point in time (not so long ago), and it has been a large help, both in improving my (lackluster) programming skills by forcing me to try new things when making custom mathematical functions, and my calculus skills (by making those custom functions).

It also got me to give [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) a try (at the time I was using C++), and it has turned from a language I only used for some very basic functions to my favorite language due to its many advantages over C++. Due to this change in the learning curve, programming (and mathematics) went from being something to do when I was dying of boredom to a hobby that I do as often as I possibly can.

That single answer changed my daily life altogether, and I have learned infinitely more than I thought I ever could about computers, in that short journey since that day; and I hope to continue to do so for a very long time.

Answer (score 1):

## The day I stopped feeling like an impostor

I've already discussed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27680107/2359271) a little bit in the [winterbash-2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winterbash-2014) discussion, [Did the Red Baron hat motivate you to be a better Stack Overflow user?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281812/2359271)

In that post, I called the question a "diamond in the rough" and described the steps I took to reveal and polish that content, along with [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27712547/2359271). But I didn't really spend much time talking about how it felt because I wanted to see how others responded, first.

The truth is that every time I write a long, detailed answer, I worry that I'm putting my foot in my mouth. I think that's common enough, and for me it's a product of really valuing that level of knowledge that comes when something "clicks" so that you really understand, but not having the depth of experience myself that's evident in so many of the answers I've learned from.

Well this time, I found a problem that called out to me personally and made a connection with something I was involved in professionally. It was a complicated issue, broad in scope, and one that had led me around in circles on SO for more than a year already, piece by piece collecting and synthesizing solutions and approaches from different Q&A (plus more than a few trips to the library and—*gasp!*—sites other than SO). I was eager to share what I had learned but also afraid, as usual, that one of the giants whose shoulders (or, more likely, shins) I had scaled to reach my current level of understanding would come in and [yank a critical Jenga block from my tower of knowledge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7H6wGy5zf4), leaving me embarrassed and uncertain once again.

I avoided discussing the Q&A openly while the Winter Bash was still on, feeling like an attempt to leverage the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/2359271) to fulfill the hat requirements would only [expose me as a fraud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome#Prevalence). And then, before I had time to write up the debriefing post on MSO, I received a comment from a trusted user with some very solid SQL credentials who said:

> As someone who also does this, I agree. ...you capture the essential points.

If this sounds like a weak endorsement, what you have to understand is that my real-world experience on one project in no way guaranteed that I had taken the right approach. I had struck out on my own in an office that just wanted me to "do the thing" and offered no subject matter expertise for me to draw on, so this small nod from someone senior in the field to me was a huge validation of my efforts. Though the meta effect would bring in views and votes a few days later, it was this innocuous comment on top of the OP's acceptance, cooperation and gratitude that finally gave me that feeling of having passed some kind of entrance exam into Reasonable Competenceville after years of just muddling through.

In the end, maybe that's a big part of what I came to want out of Stack Overflow overall. Sure, it's an incredibly useful site; I got hundreds of answers to questions without having to ask them myself. I've always gotten a kick out of problem solving, sharing knowledge, explaining things and knowing they're understood (hard without body language to read). But beyond that, Stack Overflow provides a feedback loop that lets me assess myself, while constantly reminding me how much room there still is to grow. It keeps me in the game, so to speak, and reminds me in so many ways why I'm on this path at all.

Answer (score 1):

**The day I realised about the power of the Open Source Community**

Question: [Error importing HoloEverywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608539/error-importing-holoeverywhere)

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888882/1397152

**The story**
It was more than three years ago, I was a high school student who was learning programming. I was really interested in Android because I had adquired and Android phone recently and I knew some basic things about Java. It was also dark times, when we (Android devs) had to use Eclipse and import the libraries by hand. I was trying to import a library called HoloEverywhere. This library was a backport of the new Android theme, Holo. But unfortunately, I found some problems. I tried everything I had learned, but I was unable to run my app, so I deceided to ask a question in StackOverflow. And my question had no answers until three weeks later. But the answer was great! Finally, I could do a well designed app even for old phones!

**What I learnt**
I learnt that when you need help, the community is there to help you. Even the developer of the library commented the question! This also indicates that you can be in touch with the people who develop those great libaries you use everyday. And they don't care about if you are a high school student or an awesom developer, they will try to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

[Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

This is one of my most used pieces of logic. My code before finding this answer was very complex. I thought it needed to be to catch all edge cases.

This is one of the answers that taught me that instead of writing lots of code and changing bits as you go, Stopping and having a real good think about the answer you are really looking for produces much more elegant and maintainable code

Thinking and planning code before just jumping in to write it has helped me produce much better code.

The answer both explains the problem really well, and keeps the solution really simple.

Answer (score 1):

#### When I realize I'm not the smartest person on the internet... ;)

[The question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362957/should-my-block-based-api-have-just-completion-or-both-success-and-failure-handl/18363119#18363119) although this is more about the answers.

The question asks if it is better to use two separate blocks for error/success handling or a single one. I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18363119/1429262) arguing for two separate ones. Soon after, another SO user posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18364410/1429262), arguing for a single block.

Me, knowing I was right ;) started commenting back and forth with this user on his answer (worth checking out). Little did I know, [bbum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25646/bbum) is not as naive as I had assumed. After our semi-lengthy dialogue, anther user kindly pointed out: "*bbum is an Apple employee, and was a NeXT employee too if that helps you make up your mind on this topic*". Well, to say the least, I was a bit humbled.

It just blows my mind that I can have the opportunity to have real programming discussions with people of this caliber. I additionally learned that you truly never know who is behind the avatar. Although, I do not feel I was being disrespectful in our conversation, it is a good reminder to respect all peoples on the interwebs.

Thanks bbum and SO!

Answer (score 1):

**The Question**

[How to solve "unable to switch the encoding" error when inserting XML into SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3760788/751158) (2010-09-21)

... and [Using StringWriter for XML Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1564718/751158) (2009-10-14)

... and [Trying to store XML content into SQL Server 2005 fails (encoding problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/384974/751158) (2008-12-21)

**The Answer**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8998183/751158 (2012-01-25)

(Full disclosure - yes, this is my own answer.)

**The Story**

3 near-duplicate questions over 3 years, already sharing over 15 answers - even including some involvement and an answer on the 2nd from the legendary Jon Skeet.  (The dates are specifically listed next to each of the above links, as I think the expanded timeline here is an interesting part of this story.)

Other answers had already provided solutions that technically worked - but could be argued to be more work-arounds that resulted in additional "waste" of running XML through extra conversions (de-deserializations and serializations - to DOM, strings, or otherwise).

> to actually teach something to ... anyone else that desired the knowledge going forward

Well over 1-3 years after the previous questions, I was able to contribute an answer that looks to have helped improve the understanding of what was actually happening here, and offer a potential better way of working with the interface.  This seems to have been validated by voting - and to my surprise, another member was apparently appreciative enough of the information to award additional bounty points to the answer.  This was all against ~3 years of "history" here across the various answers - and this answer wasn't only possible due to the typical advancements in the languages and product versions, etc. - but ideally would have been the approach followed from the onset.

The other part to this story is that this wasn't just an answer to someone else's question - but something that I was running into myself, which is why I found the "old" questions.  At this point, I was taking a break from my regular Java/Oracle focus and working on a different project for a few weeks for another company written in .Net and SQL Server.  As there were going to be some high transaction loads on the project, especially around the XML processing - I knew that performance was going to be critical - and running the XML through any such additional conversions would have been significantly and measurably wasteful.

Coming from more of a Java focus where I've repeatedly worked with similar concerns, I was sure that there had to be a better way of working with this in .Net as well.  In the effort of researching my own original issue, this also resulted in another successful question/answer combination on SO at [Most efficient way to read XML in ADO.net from XML type column in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8933761/751158) - which then further contributed to my above answer.

So besides resolving my own quest for improvement, the completed effort was able to be shared to the benefit of the rest of the community as well.  Additionally, as I always try to strive for - this wasn't only an answer as to "how" (as the other previous answers may have focused on), but an answer as to "why" - I.E., the "teaching" aspect.  So as a credit to SO's advantages - most of the questions and content here are not posts that simply go into archive, or become irrelevant a few weeks past their original posting - but are part of an ongoing collaboration system where content continues to remain relevant across many years.

Stack Overflow is a community that I'm proud to be a part of.

Answer (score 1):

The question that made me learn a lot in an effort to explain something comlicated to a wider audience was [Explain the proof by Vinay Deolalikar that P != NP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436978/explain-the-proof-by-vinay-deolalikar-that-p-np)

This question had an initial massively upvoted (+30) answer (now deleted) by paxdiablo, a user I greatly respect, saying

> That's brilliant! Some uber-math guy creates a hundred page paper on one of the thorniest problems in CS and you expect a bunch of mere mortals to be able to summarise it into a couple of paragraphs on SO.
>
> ...

As well as several comments suggesting that no summary would be forthcoming on Stack-Overflow, as the subject was too complicated.

Being of a math bent, and taking the state of the question as a bit of a challenge, I started wading through the 100 page paper. The result after much digestion and worry that the summary would be overly simplistic, and may have missed some of the subtleties of the paper was my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3437115/221955

Answer (score 1):

## Android ImageView crazy parameters

I was trying to add a border inside an ImageView in Android when I started to experiment strange behaviours if I added it ScaleType parameter. Stack Overflow was there to help me, always there is somebody whose had the same problem before than you so I tried the answer marked as solution, what normally is the best option.

But this time something was wrong. The solution was not a real solution; it was a workaround, and I was completely sure that there must be something that fixes the problem in a clean way, so I went to the Android documentation and surprisingly the solution was there! XD.

So I published the solution there to avoid people to dig into the Android documentation and to save the precious time of a developer.

My answer was never accepted as the solution, but everyone that had the same problem voted it up and took it as the real one.

So one of the greatest things of Stack Overflow is that the community, being critics, can increase the value of the answers even if they are not marked as solutions and helping everyone to improve.

Answer (score 1):

Two members taught me how to dig deeper rather than just giving me an answer, and taught me more than I even knew to ask.

They taught me to not just use a function in MATLAB but to examine toolboxes, open source code, and check how they evolve with each release.  It was a fairly simple [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269985/degtorad-vs-deg2rad-in-matlab) a difference between two similar functions, but they taught me how to [answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31271225/2612195).

I learned that in MATLAB you can view source code by running:

> open('function_name')

I also learned that you can see what MATLAB toolboxes by running your code and then running:

> license('inuse')

It always amazes me that people are willing to take the time to guide a newbie to finding an answer rather than simply giving the 2 second answer.  They also were kind enough to warn me that while I had managed find out how to eliminate the unnecessary use of a toolbox for my current version of MATLAB, I would need to be aware of changes coming with the next release. By teaching me rather than simply telling me, I learned skills that have helped me solve other problems on my own.

THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

Back when I first started at SO (I think less than 100 rep), I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19328508/2850543) asking whether a server running PHP had been hacked. I'm not an expert at security, but it interests me a lot, so I decided I would try to figure out the code that OP posted and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328555/2850543). I spent a few hours doing this, and it was often a tedious process deobfuscating the code. In an effort to provide real time updates to somebody who might have been compromised, I edited the question a LOT (22 revisions). I didn't understand the rules at the time, so it automatically switched to a Wiki while I was working on it. I got dinner in between the start of the answer and the finish (and I received some help from Jonathan Kuhn while I was eating).

What was learned, or at least I hope in any case, was how to figure out for oneself whether some strange-looking, obfuscated code is actually a problem. Instead of saying "yes, this is malicious", I provided a play by play account of how I deobfuscated the code. This involved base 64 decoding, linking to preg_replace issues, replacing variable and function names with meaningful names, and then analyzing the code to explain what it does. Afterwards, I tried to explain how to best clean up the server if restoring it from a backup was not an option. At the end, because you never know what's run on a compromised system, I explained that OP should restore the server from a backup.

My goal was to provide OP with the knowledge to repeat the endeavor himself,  how to clean up the problem, how to prevent the problem in the future, and what's best to do in case any malware is installed. I'm sure the points spurred me on a little bit, but I answered the question to help OP and because it interested me.

Answer (score 1):

#### Question: [Cloning Git repository throwing ArithmeticException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893126/cloning-git-repository-throwing-arithmeticexception)

Although I asked and answered the question, the credit really goes to [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) for helping me research and debug, and I feel that he should get the answer swag for this one.

I was testing various behind-the-firewall git servers such as Github Enterprise and Atlassian Stash to use for some internal git repositories. I eventually came across the open source [Bonobo server](https://bonobogitserver.com/). I set it up and was testing various aspects of it and ran into a problem when performing a clone from it - only on specific repositories, and only during a clone.

I tried a few things and eventually asked [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893126/cloning-git-repository-throwing-arithmeticexception). VonC came along and decided to help, even though he had no straight answer to provide. He researched a few things and added a comment of a similar issue in another git server implementation. Although it didn't answer my question, it helped me debug further and I was able to reply. He then replied, and we went back and forth "talking" this out with each other for a bit. His last comment was very close to the solution, and eventually led me to figure out what the problem actually was. I implemented a fix and confirmed that I was able to clone the previously uncloneable repositories. Not only that, I was able to open a [PR with the solution](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/pull/73) and provide it to everyone.

This, to me, sums up what is great about SO - someone took time out of their day to help me resolve a problem, even though they had no previous knowledge of the issue nor any reason to help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## How I learned about self-sizing cells

@smileyborg's answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/4151918)

One of the new `tableView` features in iOS 8 was self-sizing cells.  Since tableViews have been a common theme in the apps I've worked on, I looked forward being able to eliminate having to calculate row heights in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

@smileyborg wrote [one of the most detailed answers I've come across](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/4151918) which has been viewed almost 200,000 times, and favorited by over 800 people.

As imagined, new features are generally accompanied by a new set of problems, and self-sizing was no different.  Whenever an issue arose, @smileyborg would investigate it and update his answer and sample code.

The time he has invested and the knowledge he has shared has benefited countless developers.  I've come to really appreciate Auto Layout and self-sizing because of his contribution to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

### How I Learned To [Send 100,000 E-mails Weekly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly) And Love The Bomb

A cold, bright October afternoon has found me sipping coffee and idly browsing SO's newest questions in the `php` tag, when suddenly, an unassuming title caught my eye.

> On my blog, I have 100.000 subscribers and I want to send them an update email weekly. How can I do that with PHP ?

This can't be. I wanted to stop the asker from venturing too far into the strange territory of the Elder Gods - for there are horrendous, nameless things lurking in the depths of the Net, thing mortals should not disturb, lest they lose their sanity[.](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/Shub-Internet.html) I should know: I had been there.

Not another programmer walking into the same hellhole into which I have naïvely entered some years earlier. It all flashed back to me: the CPU overloads, the infinite bounce loops, the assumptions of `[a-z]{2,3}`, the CAN-SPAM Act, the routing and delay issues, the fruitless days and nights of debugging, the blacklistings, whitelistings, greylistings and yellow-with-purple-dots-listings, the bit-eating crow, and worse. Moreover, I was sick and tired of describing all these things over and over and over again.

I have set to work, expanding my "Just Don't Do It" answer into something just as collosal and twisted as the unnamed horrors it describes. As the answer was taking shape, I have realized one thing: I have read many articles on Email Considered Harmful, but never a useful technical summary on the problems of running your mailing campaigns in-house. When I was done, the question was already closed as not constructive, its author derided as a spammer, but my job was done: I have tackled e-mail and defeated it. (Look how awesome I am, look at me!)

Since then, I have used this answer many times instead of needing to lecture on e-mails; and the link to the question keeps popping up in various places, which tells me that other people are also finding it useful. This gives me hope that SO has helped to diminish the unholy alliance of PHP and e-mail, doing what it stands for: making the programming world a saner place.

Answer (score 1):

### When Stack Overflow helps settle my disputes

**The Question**: [Literal vs Constructor notation for primitives, which is more proper for starters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395572/literal-vs-constructor-notation-for-primitives-which-is-more-proper-for-starter) posted by myself

**The Answer**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21395784/3149020

---

**The Story Behind it:**

While a good amount of the story is actually in the question itself, I would like to share my personal preferences about how it developed and help me with my confidence. Basically it came down to a dispute between me and a professor for a client-side programming class. Most of the things taught in class I agreed with, but there was one thing I felt was not a proper way to teach. *Note* that the instructor highly appreciates me and takes my comments seriously.

The problem basically is in the question. Before I asked I felt that I was correct and have enough knowledge and experience in web development to know that, but of course I want to see what others think, and better understand where the teacher could be coming from. And so I asked this question on Stack Overflow.

(*This was back then when I was new to the site. I now understand that this question is not a perfect fit for Stack Overflow, hence why it's closed.*)

It turned out most people have agreed with my point of view, and that the teacher was encouraging poor practice that could cause harm or give odd problems to the coded programs students make.

Oddly enough the answer was given by another teacher in the field. This experienced help me have more confidence in when I taught others and talked about web development in general. Along with that helping to improve the education of my school and classes. Of course, I still have much more to learn.

---

**More Notes**

These are just my experiences in general on Stack Overflow. There have been several questions I've answered that were great learning experiences for me and the OP. There are too many to list here, so I'll just give a more general information.

I've had plenty of accounts where I had to gradually teach and explain certain concepts for others, and there isn't nothing quite like seeing a student finally "getting it", both on Stack Overflow and in students I've help taught in general.

Whether it was an easy to answer question, or one where I really had to put along of time and research in to answer; seeing the OP's delight in having a solution (along with seeing others seeing that I've helped them) was always worth it.

Answer (score 1):

### Stack Overflow taught me to be a developer. From scratch.

The Internet is lauded as the "great equalizer". On here everyone can have an equal chance to learn and do. Well, I came from a rural area in Nebraska, and I was home schooled. I didn't know what the Internet was until 2005, and I didn't have a computer until after that, and the Internet was still dial up. 
Fast forward to 2011, when I decided to go to college. For some reason the adviser sent me to the IS&T college of the University and I signed up. I signed up with utterly no technical experience, computer experience, or knowledge of how computers worked, much less a knowledge of programming. 
My first post on Stack Overflow was during a class in C programming. **The only comment I got was "If you are asking this dumb of a question you obviously do not know how the language works".** I repentantly deleted my question and abandoned all contributions to the snobby website Stack Overflow and read the articles from the safety of anonymity.
Then! In 2014 I had the fortune to get a wonderful IT internship for computer hardware support. Within several months I had been assigned several programming projects with ASP.NET and MVC, including SQL Server usage and Visual Studio. I had never even seen one of those frameworks/programs much less used any of them. My school, in its infinite wisdom, only allowed students to program in Unix and Java so I was woefully unprepared for such a task. Stack Overflow was my instruction on everything from Visual Studios shortcuts to overwriting C# classes. I finally joined the site again and I try to help those who "obviously don't know what they are talking about" because that's how you start, right?

I have beeing working on a Single-Sign-On system for multiple in-house sites. I have basically lived on Stack Overflow trying to figure that process out over the past few months. Thanks to stephan.vikal for helping me with [allowing anonymous access to an MVC web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252320/adfs-sso-anonymous-home-page-mvc-4-asp-net) secured with SSO. And thank you to all you other geniuses who taught me to program. I joined again and posted questions just so I would have enough credit to upvote the answers that saved my life every day.

Answer (score 1):

The Question:

*[Getting location for an iOS app when it is in the background and even killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396367/getting-location-when-app-is-in-background-and-even-killed-ios-app)*

I was really really lost trying to get the location of an app that had to locate so many stores. Days and days walking down and up the street testing my app, with no good news. After trying so hard by myself, I decided to write ask my question on Stack Overflow and...voila!! As always in this community, someone, in this case @utsav, give me the clue to solve it.

Finally and after some questions more I found the answer and I made everything work. No more zombie-walking-mobile-in-hand-testing days XD

I have to recognized that I've learned most of my iOS skills thanks to Stack Overflow. I think nobody that works in the development world could live and keep their jobs without it :) So thanks to you all!

Answer (score 1):

### I learn more from answering questions than asking:

My Answer: [how to enlarge text in gagawa graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394113/how-to-enlarge-text-in-gagawa-graph)

**This was actually *my first answer* on StackOverflow, and it was to fulfill a bounty!**

I had seen the problem, and began researching. I found a website that contained the source code for the package this questioner was using, and trawled through that for several hours. Still being new to programming, I was looking for problems to solve and came across that question.

Initially, for me, it was hard. I'm still new to programming in general; it's only my second year in college, and my first in the workforce. I had used standard input/output and had a basic grasp of objects and such, but I never really looked into libraries to see how they worked. For some reason, I really wanted to answer that question, so I set to work. I started by googling for the package name and source, and ended up at the grepcode.com website, where I first met the Javadoc. It was here that I learned quite a lot about patterns, object usage, and was the first time I had met the final keyword.

**It was also here that I learned how distant college curriculum is from real world application. In fact, the most important things I have learned about programming have been from my coworkers and this website.**

I digress; after reading into the source code, I realized that I could not set the Font object since it was a final variable. I also noticed that the class itself was not final, and so I crafted another class that did the same thing, but added that functionality of modifying the Font object. When my answer was accepted and the bounty given to me, I was so pleased with myself. I only noticed afterwards, however, that another user had answered the question with another way of solving the problem.

Unfortunately, the questioner never commented or said anything back, however, I was happy enough with the result. I'm glad to be able to help, even with my limited knowledge. :)

Another one of my massive explanation answers that I enjoy even more is this question: [Java Mahjong Game - Help Implementing a hand reorganizing that shifts JLabels away from where I drag my chosen piece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994793/java-mahjong-game-help-implementing-a-hand-reorganizing-that-shifts-jlabels-aw/31995066#31995066)
Similar, linked: [Shifting the contents of the `ArrayList` to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976100/shifting-the-contents-of-the-arraylist-to-the-right/31976614#31976614)

My answer was the only one, and I even included pictures detailing how the code worked behind the scenes in both questions. The questioner had a bit of trouble understanding my answer at first, but three edits later, he was wowing at how dedicated I was to answering his questions.

I always seem to find myself learning more than the person asking the question, as I often get side tracked during the research I do to provide an answer. It usually starts off with me looking for similar stackoverflow answers, then delving through the googles for more in-depth information.

Answer (score 1):

## The question which turned me into a Stack Overflow addict

The question can be found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783496/how-to-slide-the-actionbar-along-with-the-navigationdrawer) and my answer to it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783496/how-to-slide-the-actionbar-along-with-the-navigationdrawer/23954699#23954699).

### The Story

When I answered this question I already had over one hundred answers under my belt and if I remember correctly a little over 2000 reputation. However Stack Overflow was still pretty new to me. I had created my account just a few months earlier and was answering pretty much as many questions as I could. Most of them were quite simple and of low quality but every upvote I got excited me.

But then came along the question [How to slide the ActionBar along with the NavigationDrawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783496/how-to-slide-the-actionbar-along-with-the-navigationdrawer) from [**Android F0X**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1472269/android-f0x). It took me a long time to write the answer, refine it, test it one many different devices and overall it was the first answer I invested a lot of effort and time into. I feel like I went well above and beyond what the question originally asked for and provided an answer I personally still am very proud of. Suffice it to say that from that point on I was hooked.

I started to care way less about my reputation and started to really care about the quality of my contributions to the site and about Stack Overflow in general. I gradually put a lot more effort into my answers and most of all I started being more picky about the questions I choose to answer. And that drive is still what keeps me browsing Stack Overflow and other sites in the Stack Exchange network multiple times every day.

Reading interesting questions and answers and providing answers to challenging problems or simply helping someone understand how or why something works is what Stack Overflow is all about for me and that is also the reason why I love this site so much. Every time I have a few minutes to spare you can be sure that I am spending them on Stack Overflow.

While I certainly don't post as many answers as I once did when I finally do post one I put a considerable amount of effort into each and every one of them. Because of that I am just really glad that there was this one question which made me discover my passion for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I almost missed this - better late than never.

I've been a Stack Overflow user for almost five years, so there were a lot of questions and answers to sort through. So many people have provided me with excellent answers that I find it difficult to select a single answer. But I finally decided on this one:

> [How to point OpenSSL to the root certificates on an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375577/how-to-point-openssl-to-the-root-certificates-on-an-android-device/30430033#30430033) (answer by [jww](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608639/jww))

I was in the process of porting Git to Android for an application I was developing and needed to enable access to remote repositories over HTTPS. After a significant amount of configuration, I was finally able to compile OpenSSL using the toolchain provided by the Android NDK. After resolving [some more issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516168/how-to-cross-compile-git-for-arm), I finally managed to get Git itself to build.

My excitement quickly turned to disappointment when I attempted to run `git clone` with an HTTPS URL. As the question states, I ended up with the error message: `The SSL certificate is invalid.`.

At this point, I began brainstorming alternatives, such as using SSH. I tried building OpenSSH but ran into [all](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2114) [kinds](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2111) [of](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2085) [bugs](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2113). Even after fixing them (and submitting patches upstream), the `openssh` client would just crash with `SIGSEGV`. In desperation, I returned to the original plan of using HTTPS.

I finally concluded that OpenSSL was validating the certificates against an empty list of root certificates and rejecting everything. Because I use Ubuntu, I'm used to having all of my certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs`. Unfortunately, Android appeared to have no equivalent.

Then I asked my question.

After a few weeks, user [jww](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608639/jww) posted [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375577/how-to-point-openssl-to-the-root-certificates-on-an-android-device/30430033#30430033). And what an answer. It carefully documented exactly where the certificates were distributed in the filesystem both for past and present versions of Android. He also went into detail on why I couldn't simply "point" OpenSSL to these directories and expect everything to work.

The suggested alternative was to use a certificate bundle from cURL or an organization like Mozilla who have already decided whom to trust.

Answer (score 1):

The story I would like to share is about this answer of mine: [How to avoid bash command substitution to remove the newline character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184358/how-to-avoid-bash-command-substitution-to-remove-the-newline-character)

The answer started out by pointing out a common (and trivial) problem of OPs code, where he [forgot to quote his variable](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15184414/1). Being a trivial typo, at that point did not expect the answer to be read by anybody other than the OP.

However, the OP of the question had misdiagnosed the problem, and thought that the command substitution was removing the newlines in his output, so his title asked how to avoid process substitution to remove the newlines. In fact, there is a strange feature of process substitution that removes all *trailing* newlines in the command output, so some people commented on the answer with workaround on how to prevent removing the trailing newlines. Over time, I gathered the different workarounds from the comments, and integrated them to the answer.

Long story short, a trivial typo-question was converted to a way more general and useful question/answer, that since has been receiving a steady stream of upvotes over time, and now is my second highest scoring answer.

The conclusion of this story is twofold: 1) It is often hard to tell from before if a question is useful or not. Sometimes a trivial typo may reveal a more general problem that is useful to many people. 2) That I really want a stack overflow t-shirt :)

[image]

Comment: +1 for t-shirt, please let it be real!

Answer (score 1):

[Kyralessa's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5486/kyralessa) answer to [**how-do-you-undo-the-last-commit**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-you-undo-the-last-commit) is totally awesome.

Several years ago, I was at a college hackathon with two of my friends, and we decided to use Git for version control.  We were all git noobs at the time, but since everyone else was using and preaching git, we *had* to use git :)

All was good until 4am, when our webapp started to throw up left and right.  After an hour of groggy, energy drink fueled debugging, we decided that our best option was to "go back in time".  All of us were confused with how to properly undo several commits.  We were scared to roll back, because we didn't know what we were doing and could potentially nuke our repo.  It didn't help that git provides so many different options to effectively undo our changes.

After searching on Google, we were directed to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-you-undo-the-last-commit/6866485#6866485).  The accepted answer gave a quick and dirty summary of the relevant portion of the git docs, but this answer was different.  The text diagrams with pointers to commits gave us insight to how git works under the hood, in a easy to understand format that our sleepy brains could understand. It was also reassuring that the answer mentioned `git reflog` to find destroyed commits if the worst happens.  After reading that answer, we all had that lightbulb moment:

[image: A HA!]

Armed with this newfound knowledge, we confidently "traveled back in time" to when our webapp worked properly.  We didn't win anything at the hackathon, but we left feeling like winners anyways because we learned how to navigate through the git commit history.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the kind mention!  (I didn't see this until just now, because just now I got an e-mail from JNat about it.)

Answer (score 0):

### SQL by SO

My first job out of college was (and still is) working on maintaining and old ball-o-mud legacy project where the original developers were not the greatest developers ever.  As such, we had a ton of stored procedures in a poorly designed database.  Which meant I had a lot of SQL to deal with.

Before I came to this job, my SQL knowledge was minimal at best.  Thankfully a coworker showed me SO.  And I ended up searching a lot here.  Almost everything I needed I found here.  As such I credit SO and its community with teaching me SQL, which has proved invaluable.

Being both inclined to help and grateful for the help I have received, I try to answer as many questions as I can.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29950337/550062) is just one where I was able to take what I was taught by SO and turn around and share that with someone else.  The question was one where someone had a particularly crazy bit of SQL that was doing what looked like some business logic to pull a report.  The OP was trying to understand what was going on there and because of my experience on my own project and what I had learned from SO I was able to interpret it and put it into English.

Seeing that SO has hit 10M questions is humbling and inspiring.  I am honored to be even a small part of something that has helped me so much and grateful that I can give back.

Answer (score 0):

## Just an answer isn't enough

### Prolog

I always find solutions to my problems here or when building my [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I've never asked questions. To give back, I've been writing answers, so I'm afraid the only Q&A for which I know stories are answered by myself.

My strongest suit are [maths](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1387346/cimbali?tab=tags), since I've been doing a lot of it throughout my life, and it's often a bit of weak spot for other users.

### Discussing to work out the details

Giving the answer and how to use it may not always work for the user. He/she then might end up with getting a wrong or unexpected result, and questioning the answer since it is for them the "unknown" part. This is a pretty usual pattern with newbie math questions, but there are only a few questions or answers where I didn't delete my comments.

In nearly all cases, the initial answer is correct and could help another user encountering the same problem, but taking the time to discuss in comments allows to help the author of the question find out what he's still missing.

#### Chasing out false expectations

For example, [Determine angle of a straight line in 3D space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28052393/1387346) shows that guiding the user to question his/her assumptions allows to make the correct answer work. Here, the expected result was simply false, which the user saw when asked how this expected result was set.

#### Also on the answerer's side

I've answered a number of answers on transformation matrices, and I always assume the "usual" definitions of affine transformations. On [How to find the transformation matrix for given scale, skew, and translation values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058445/how-to-find-the-transformation-matrix-for-given-scale-skew-and-translation-val/28058685#28058685), it turned out after answering, some discussion, aksing for example values etc, that I had to insert an addendum, taking into account the fact that the skew transformation is implemented incorrectly in actionscript.

Answer (score 0):

## A positive experience with receiving down-votes.

No one likes receiving down-votes, but on this occurrence, my experience was ultimately a positive one.

#### The Question:

[Scope of uninitialized variable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27737236/3155639), by [Yamcha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1316459/yamcha)

#### The Answer:

[Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27737255/3155639), by me, [Alexander O'Mara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3155639/alexander-omara)

This isn't a particularly glorious answer, but I decided to chose this answer because it was a unique experience for me, and really exemplifies how the community and voting system produce higher-quality content.

My original version of the answer wasn't a very good answer. The revision history doesn't appear to show it, but I believe it was just the first 2 sentences of the first stored revision. While technically correct (excluding ES6), they were not a very good answer, and I probably should have waited until I wrote something more descriptive to post the answer. What can I say, I fell for the "Fastest Gun in the West Problem."

To my surprise, I received a number of down-votes in a very short span of time. I can't remember how many, I want to say 3-5. Another user commented suggesting the voting was suspicious, but I'm guessing it was just in the VLQ queue. I could have deleted my answer right there and gave up, but I wasn't finished yet. I knew my answer could be better, so I continued improving it. I added examples to help the OP and others understand exactly how the code was being interpreted, and thus explaining the behavior. Even when another answer was marked as the accepted answer, I continued to improve my answer.

Ultimately my answer received a reasonably positive score plus the accepted mark, and all but one of the original down-voters eventually returned and reversed their vote. The question itself has had a mixed reception, currently having 5 votes in both direction for a total score of 0, but I think it's a good question about a specific pitfall to JavaScript's variable scoping.

Answer (score 0):

#### It took me some time and effort to understand the exact OP needs

As originally presented, [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690688/selecting-the-last-instance-of-the-record-but-returning-the-first-instance-of-it) was unclear and gave a wrong impression of being super easy.

We went back and force, and over a course of a couple hours and multiple OP edits, it became much clearer.  The solution was no longer obvious but still not too difficult.  By then I didn't have the time to test and post it.

Since the next day the question was still unanswered, I posted my answer.

I treated original question as the same way I would any other business requirements. Since in real life we almost never get them clear upfront, the whole situation was just *business as usual*.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate when the SO experts recognizes when somebody is asking the wrong question and gets the person back on track. The poster generally seems to ask the same question, re-worded ten different ways. By educating them we stop [the needless questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30940877/1075902)  which will never get an answer because they don't know what they're asking.

Closest example I can think of is when I provided [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653851/how-to-deploy-a-self-building-docker-image-to-make-changes-to-itself-in-respect/31667317#31667317). The poster was trying to do something that didn't make sense to be done within the confines of the application. It looks to me like it finally made enough sense to him to not keep asking the same questions, just worded differently.

Answer (score 0):

**Getting involved on Stack Overflow**

I started answering questions on Stack Overflow this April, a few months after I got my first Android job contract and started gaining experience, and, having used Stack Overflow during my studies, I wanted to contribute and "give something in return".

I still remember one of my first answers, in which I involved myself to solve it and even requested testing of the app. The answer was not perfect (it isn't still), but it was one of my first "voted" answers and one where I got really good feedback. And all the problems were caused by a deprecated permission that didn't throw any error at all.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629232/android-wear-app-no-eligible-devices-for-app-install/29652237#29652237)

Over the weeks I got better at answering, and I can relate to one of my answers that fits in the "teaching, not only solving" level, when I explained a simple concept (for an Android expert) such as HashMaps, to a complete newbie into Java and object-oriented languages.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563384/how-to-display-two-listapplicationinfo-and-arrayliststring-in-a-listview/29563503#29563503)

I'm not a question man (my problems are usually caused by lack of proof-reading code / documentation or by higher forces (library bugs), so I haven't had the opportunity to meet a Java / Android guru to enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

[Fastest way to strip all non-printable characters from a Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161534/fastest-way-to-strip-all-non-printable-characters-from-a-java-string/7161653#7161653)

User [GreyCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487064/greycat) needed to filter out control characters from a large amount of strings.

For that he benchmarked [several possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7161534/1) then posed the question on how to improve his best found method even more.

10 minutes later I came along [posted a method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7161653/731620) which by removing an array allocation got a 24% improvement.

A few hours later [Ed staub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685923/ed-staub) posted [an improvement that cached the allocated array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7166506/731620) for later re-use for another 12% improvement.

There was some back and forth discussion in the comments where it was found out that the real-life data does not always need filtering. Which allows skipping creating a new string when it's not needed.

In that time other users also came along and posted suggestions. Of note is [Voo's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7175771/731620) which used reflection to sell his soul and violate the immutability of java's String class.

Then the OP went and benchmarked all the proposed solutions and provided nice bar graphs.

This is an example of a collaborative search for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

#### The question

[How to change the color of a SwitchCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26714864/4069646)

#### My answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26715076/4069646

#### My story

When I first saw the title of this question I thought it was another classic question about Android styles so I was about to flag it as duplicate. But by reading the post it appears that it was a question related to the freshly (1 week ago) released Android support library v21. As an Android fan I tried this lib in personal project just after the release and haven’t face any problems of tinting. So I started to google this SwitchCompat thing, after diving in the source code of this class and reading articles of (the well known, at least in android community) Chris Banes for half a day I eventually succeed to understand « the why » (which was linked to the tinting process).

But only half of the work was done because as a SO member my goal is to provide understandable answers that explain the How and if it’s possible include the why. So I wrote an answer that take in account Android version fragmentation and also contains important parts of my investigation, moreover as I get multiple upvotes I update my answer 2 or 3 times with solutions based on the new Android support lib releases (thanks to comments or other questions).

*With this question/answer I was going to taught and finally learnt a lot instead, that’s a part of StackOverflow magic!*

PS: Sorry if you find my story not as epic as others, I’m better in programming than in story telling ;)

Answer (score 0):

#### [Creating an Open Source Bootstrap Plugin via Comments and Revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18667336/1366033)

**Full Disclosure**: this is tooting my own horn a little, but it was a wonderful experience that I think epitomizes the iterative nature of providing up to date information in revisionable Stack Overflow answers.

Sometimes I browse [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) questions, not because I have ever consider myself an expert at using Bootstrap, but because they make for fun little puzzles that can generally be answered using only html/js/css, which greatly enhances the ease of reproduction across different machines.  I want to give someone else a working code snippet that *they* can run on *their* machine and see work.  It still might need some tweaking in their source code, but that is more a problem of translation than implementation.

I saw this question on [using bootstrap to provide a context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18666601/1366033).  How terrific, I thought!  With web applications becoming increasingly complex and interactive, it would be great to provide the same level of sophistication as almost any native application. It's something I hadn't even thought of adding before, but I'd love using in my own applications, so I thought I'd spend some time devising a solution.

But before I could even get started, another used, [letiagoalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873446/letiagoalves), posted a simple, elegant solution that made use of the browser's native [contextMenu event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu) and [bootstrap's dropdown menu](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns).  [His answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18667012/1366033) was posted less than an hour after the (extremely open ended) question was posted, and came complete with the [almighty **working demo**](http://jsbin.com/iGaHAtu/2/edit).  I fired it up, and it worked right away!  I was so impressed!  The idea of context menus in web applications have gained a little bit of traction since then, but back in 2013 this was pretty novel.

The user continued providing support in the comments to help the OP wire up some interactions.  I had made a suggestion to add some more polish, but the answer had already more than delivered any expectations I would have had regarding answering the original question.  But I had some time and so I decided to add [my own version with some minor improvements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18667336/1366033) to help ease the learning curve for more people.

Over the past two years I have continued to return this question time and time again.  Providing support for the solution in the same way that a library author might use GitHub issues.

People would point out edge cases or ask questions in the comments, and I'd expand the answer to cover an increasingly sophisticated set of use cases and needs, fixing cross browser issues, issues near the edge of the screen, issues with multiple/dynamic elements, issues with scrolling placement, and dozens of clarifications along the way.

Here are some statistics:

- [24 Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666601/#comment35177896_18667336)
- [15 Revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18667336/revisions)

Eventually, I began to wonder if Stack Overflow was the [right medium for such a long answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231775/209031). Perhaps my 7,763 character long post would be better located in a GitHub repo somewhere?  And that may well be the case, but it was wonderful building something with the community here that would be worthy of a GitHub repo, with testing help from each of the 27,546 times the question was viewed.

There's even now [another "fork" of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31305343/1366033) by another user who has added even more functionality.

The benefit to answers here is that they are not static.  They don't go stale.  They are tried, tested, and improved.  And this example provides a small reflection of that.

Answer (score 0):

## The question

[Using an import and a for loop when passing a program as a string to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25211865/1007939)

## Nominate 2 answers

(can I do that?)

[asmeurer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25211977/1007939)

[CDspace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25212010/1007939)

From the question [Using an import and a for loop when passing a program as a string to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25211865/1007939) one incorrect answer led to the correct answer.

The question was very well written, explaining the problem and the desired outcome, even giving the scripts which were breaking. The question was about trying to get BASH to run a particular python script. I posted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25211977/1007939) before testing it. In the comments, we realized my solution wasn't working. However, [asmeurer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25212010/1007939) expanded on mine, and provided the solution (thanks for the attribution BTW).

After the accepted answer came along, several other answers were also added, giving different ways to accomplish the same task.

## Collaboration

I'm nominating two answers from the same question, because I'd like to point out that developers helping developers is, more often than not, collaboration, and not simply a one on one tutoring session. This collaboration is further shown in the later answers, showing more than one way to get it done.

---

I'm not sure if I can nominate two answers one one question. If not, I nominate asmeurer's answer, since that's the accepted one. I just wanted to show the progression towards the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

On this occasion when Stack Overflow is celebrating for attaining ten million quesiton, I would like to thank all those programmers, coders, well wishers (except demotivators) who have helped me to improve my programming skills.

When I first came to Stack Overflow I was a novice programmer with only a limited understanding of programming (also English) and having only a little knowledge of C programming. But now I can programme in more than five programming languages and databases and these things I learned without paying any extra penny (which would have otherwise cost me thousands of dollars).

The best part of Stack Overflow is the helpful and patient programmers who teached, helped and pointed out the mistakes I made in my programmes with at most respect for the questioners.

THANK YOU

P.S.: I am not a programmer by profession, but by enthusiasm.

Answer (score 0):

When I was learning about the area I currently work in (business intelligence and data warehousing) I found that SO  - which had been a great resource as an application developer - didn't cover my new area in anywhere near as much depth. Some questions were really unclear; I couldn't understand them, never mind any answers they might have, and wasn't sure whether it was me or the question that was at fault. Other times I found people asking the same things I was wondering about, only to see that no one had answered and months had passed. I didn't bother asking anything for two reasons: I suspected I might not get an answer, and I felt like I didn't know enough to even ask well. Ultimately, I learnt largely from other sources.

Once I'd gained knowledge and confidence in my new role, I remembered how frustrating finding good information had been. I set about finding some questions I could answer - simple ones at first, but more recently I've moved towards trying to pick up the kind of questions that I used to see sitting unanswered, where people were in the same boat I'd been in not long before.

The answer I feel proudest of so far is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810372/3964881). The question was a little unclear at first, but I think largely because the poster genuinely didn't know what information would be useful. He'd been given some sensible pointers about database normalisation elsewhere but without a huge amount of context, and I suspect he didn't know what information to look for or where to get started on the topic - very much the position I'd previously been in.

I made an [initial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30810372/1) because there was an immediate aspect I could answer, and the rest I could give some advice on - which might have been enough for the poster. As it turned out, he wasn't sure what steps to take from there, and a comment thread ensued as we tried to clarify the situation. Ultimately, SO prompted us to move to chat, which was a good move - I was eventually able to find the words to both ask for the information I needed, and explain the issue with the existing design, and how it could be resolved.

As it stood, the poster was happy - he'd thanked me in chat, and I think he might have accepted my answer before I edited it. That really felt good, especially as I'd put effort into it; it was also a relief, as I was worried at times that I was failing to explain things clearly. While in some ways the job was done, I knew it was important for this answer to have some ongoing worth. As it stood, I couldn't see someone else stumbling across this Q&A and finding it useful.

I edited my answer to tackle both the specific issues experienced by the poster, and the general concepts that were at play and which could aid further understanding. I made it clear that the example I was giving wasn't the entire solution to all of the issues being experienced, but hopefully a jumping-off point from which to understand the wider problems with the database structure and create a comprehensive solution. I found a free modelling app to create a model and pointed readers to it, along with various resources on the larger topics of data modelling & database design to link to.

I ultimately spent quite a bit of time on this answer, and I felt like the asker and I had really worked together to get to a solution. We'd discussed the issue in comments, moved to chat, reached a point of mutual understanding, made edits on both sides, and cleared up the obsolete comments. While I can't speak for the other person involved, I felt like I'd genuinely been able to teach something, rather than just giving a solution to a single issue - and also felt I'd been able to turn a fairly messy discussion into a clear final write-up.

Aside from being accepted, the answer quickly picked up 3 up-votes. Not bad in a quiet area of the site, an for a question which still only has 65 views. I'm not too bothered about rep, but I do like the fact that I've received positive feedback from not only the asker, but from other people who came across my answer and found it worthwhile. It's nowhere near as impressive as plenty of other answers on this site, but all the same - it was great feeling that I'd contributed something which might help other people learn about a topic I love.

Answer (score 0):

## [Why are interfaces not able to be marked as sealed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890627/why-are-interfaces-not-able-to-be-marked-as-sealed)

Was the first question of mine I remember being answered by someone with an absolute authority on the subject (being on the C# language design committee), [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert): https://stackoverflow.com/a/9890933/360211

The answer is ideal, because it's short and to the point, but still contains enough background information to form a cogent argument. It even manages to impart advice about sealing classes, which is just a bonus for anyone reading the answer.

It's quite a naive question, but in a way that makes it that much more impressive that such a high profile and presumably busy developer took the time to answer it. In general, I think it adds an immeasurable amount of credibility to the community that the top software book authors, speakers, and developers of the ubiquitous tools/frameworks/compilers we use day-in-day-out are here donating their time to answering questions both great and small.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to nominate [@Veedrac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763356/veedrac), for his answer on [Why does tuple(set([1,"a","b","c","z","f"])) == tuple(set(["a","b","c","z","f",1])) 85% of the time with hash randomization enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136894/why-does-tupleset1-a-b-c-z-f-tupleseta-b-c-z-f-1)

Tuples and sets are basic data structures in Python. I had landed on the [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26115765/1860929) from the home page, when [@ZeroPiraeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1014938/zero-piraeus) had answered it. Though @Zero's answer explained things substantially, and even pointed in the right direction (hash randomization), it wasn't until I saw @Veedrac's answer the next day, on a new question he had posted, that I really understood why things were happening the way they were in the original question.

It is one thing to see something and accept it as wizardry happening in the core code (which is what I had done when I saw 85% in Zero's answer), and another to go into the internals to figure out why and where the magic was happening.

@Veedrac did the latter, and gave a very [informative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26136895/1860929)  where he solved the maths behind the seemingly random percentage of 85% actually being the ratio 5/32, and his methodology on arriving at it. That, has been one of the best experiences I have had with SO (which does not involve me directly/indirectly), where a user went beyond the original problem, to find out the root solution of the big picture question.

PS: @Veedrac has [nominated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303249/1860929) another user, but I couldn't find him being recommended.

Comment: No reason to remove your answer if another user already brought the same user up- THat's happened a few times already in the answers here. As I understand it, the point is in sharing the story behind the answer, not in just getting yourself and the other user some SO items.

Comment: @Kendra Oh that's cool :)

Comment: @mu無 Thanks a ton for the comments. These things are half for the self-education and half 'cause of the lovely responses I get :). It seems I'd missed the email I was sent, so I've no swag yet, but luckily GMail's cached it for me. I'll see if I can get a late delivery.

Answer (score 0):

[The Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271286/backbone-boilerplate-events) - [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271286/backbone-boilerplate-events/9304115#9304115)

**The return of a rusty veteran to the industry after a decade hiatus**

After programming for many years throughout the 90s and and early 2000s, I switched careers and worked as a high-school teacher full-time for about a decade, only doing the occasional coding side-project for fun or profit. As browsers finally evolved to a tipping point and single-page web apps and frameworks began to take off, I got excited again about web programming and felt an itch to get back in the game.

Beginning in 2012 I used SO heavily, reading answers about new frameworks and patterns voraciously, trying them out and retraining myself as a programmer. Coming back to the industry after a decade hiatus was very intimidating for a rusty veteran that hadn't kept up with the latest and hottest. My self confidence was pretty low.

I didn't really feel that I was 'back' until I started helping other folks on SO. My [first successful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271286/backbone-boilerplate-events/9304115#9304115) was about what at the time was the hot new (now ancient) 'Backbone' framework. While the answer was at first just pointing out a small error in the questioners code, I also took the extra time to explain a coding pattern that would be useful in that context.

The questioner's feedback convinced me that I could articulate my thought process clearly, and thus had a chance to score well on technical interviews. In fact, the very pattern that I explained in this question came back again as a question in the interview for my first programming job offer in more than ten years! It was a good enough offer to move my family to SF from a small town in the southeast and significantly change the course of our lives.

While I don't mean to say that one answer on SO "changed my world forever," I also can't stress enough how much participating meaningfully in a community and feeling the real value that you've offered, however small, can build your own self-confidence and enable you to achieve more than you would have otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Of my small collection of answers, I'm most proud of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23069603/251011). It deals with a very nondeterministic problem with build servers, where previous workarounds didn't work after a TFS update. After ages of trial and error and some decompiling, I discovered a solution to keep the random build failures at bay. Since I was also doing many searches in my quest and found practically nothing, I knew that I had to share my discovery to help other poor souls. So I attached a detailed answer to the question thread with the most relevant keywords.

Why this is a special answer for me is because every couple weeks I see a reputation notification pop up saying that I got a vote on that answer. And it feels satisfying that somewhere out there someone was able to use my discovery to probably save a ton of time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

**C# Chat leads to knowledge.**

Some weeks ago, while hanging out in the C# chat. A guy ([Kevin Maxwell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4707967/kevin-maxwell)) came by and asked if anyone could help him with his [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672857/how-to-pass-null-value-to-datetime-in-asp-net-identity-user-table/) regarding an exception while trying to persist some data to his database.

We had a nice chat, and I provided him with an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672857/how-to-pass-null-value-to-datetime-in-asp-net-identity-user-table/31675184#31675184) based on what we had talked about. (The answer aren't the best one out there, because it lacks the conversation we had about the problem.)

Over the next few days we continued to chat about different issues/obstacles he encountered while getting ASP.NET Identity running within his webforms application. I answered his questions at my best, and while trying to explain why, what and where, I realized that even though the questions were fairly easy to answer, I learned a few things here and there.

The bottom line is that even if I knew the answer (*or partially knew*), I didn't know it well enough to explain it without having to read up on some documentation, and do some actual research. So helping others made me gain a few bits of knowledge. That is the reason for why I contribute to this community.

> Warning: While helping others, you might learn new things. Proceed with caution.

*If you're reading this @KevinMaxwell: It was fun helping you out, because it made me think about things from another perspective, as well as learning some new cool stuff.*

Answer (score 0):

**Question**

*Oracle 10g: Connect by prior*

**My answer**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22931082/2092052

**My story**

When I saw this question I was actually at the stage of writing a really complex PL/SQL script for a big database and job which was performed every night. During that I was also trying to improve my PL/SQL skills in writing efficient and easy-to-understand and maintainable code. Unfortunately I had some tree-like structure in our database and I had to use complex queries to extract correct data.

Before I have not heard about "Connect by prior" (which was a topic of this question which I saw). I have started searching for the meaning and goal of this query clause. When I saw for what this is, the first thing I did was changing my complex code and instead of using complex queries I started using "Connect by prior". It was working really good and code looks much nicer and cleaner than before.

What is really good in Stack Overflow is that you can be inspire by someone question to learn something or to check something and sometimes it occurs really usable in our own program!

Answer (score 0):

**The day on I got 1st complement from with the help of Stack Overflow**

Question:- [ios-twilio-ip-messaging-initial-integration-steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456701/ios-twilio-ip-messaging-initial-integration-steps)

Answer :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35457572/4910767

**The Story behind them**

Stackoverflow helped me a lot in my programming life especially my 1st month of job when i am alone as iPhone developer in my company.I have only 10 months as worked with iOS development as well as joining in stackoverflow but i am addicted with stackoverflow.

This is not highly voted answer but it was a great experience for me,i want to describe story behind this answer, on the first month when i joined my company senior Php developers discuss regarding Twilio and they are facing difficulties regarding implement it in application. After three months i got a project to integrate Twilio in my application(iOS) and i didn't get much response from senior developer. so, stack overflow is my final source and really stackoverflow questions and answer helped me a lot to solve my problems. I have integrate it successfully in my application after dedicating four months of hard work.As an achievement (because i am fresher and done my project successfully with hard work)my companies provide me increment only after 5 months. This all i got because of stack overflow.At that time i heartily thanks to stackoverflow. Before few days i show question on stack-overflow regarding initial steps to integrate it in Application. Then i Nostalgia my old days. so, i decided to give Answer in more detail as much as i can on this answer so other developer didn't face any difficulties to integrate it in application. Twilio has provide all in their tutorial but it is bit hard to understand for the 1st time users. Moreover, on the other side occasionally , after 2 days i got mail from Twilio like ,

> I’m *** from the Twilio Developer Community team. I spend time on
>   StackOverflow and I’ve noticed that you’ve answered a Twilio tagged
>   question there.
>
> I’d love to send you a t-shirt to show our appreciation for your work
>   and contribution to the community.
>   If this sounds good to you, reply with your shirt size (American
>   Apparel Men’s sizes available) and an address I can send it to.

(Thank you Twilio Developer community)

I can see difference in me when i gave may 1st answer on stack-overflow and currently i gave my all the answer. And one more thing with see my reputation and interest in stack-overflow currently my all colleague have stack-overflow account and they regularly open stack-overflow and help to others.

To sum up, I just really thankful to Stack-overflow for the help in my development life till now.**#soreadytohelp** is true for stack-overflow.As we can say another definition for stack-overflow,

> Stack-overflow = A place where people helping others without his own agenda

Answer (score -1):

**The question**

[Want to animate splash screen on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267541/want-to-animate-splash-screen-in-android)

**The answer**

The first answer

**The story**

This was my first issue on Android and four years ago I didn't know how to resolve this, so looking for it in Google I met Stack Overflow. From then I frequently used that page. I have opened many issues with many answers and also helped to resolve problems. I'm a better profesional thanks to Stack Overflow and all the community. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -2):

### Selected Answer

[Should I always use ViewModel or ViewData (.NET MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647562/should-i-always-use-a-view-model-or-is-it-ok-to-use-viewdata/31647765#31647765)

---

### The Story

I see a lot of similar questions around using Viewdata and Tempdata etc. But it seems there are not that many good high quality answers that actually answer this question.

I see someone post the above question and I thought to myself, I'm going to let this user know excatly why he shouldn't be using just ViewData  in MVC. I just wanted to stop overuse of ViewData in code, I have had to maintain some very awful code that someone just used ViewData all over the place, it's terrible to maintain. I don't want people to experience this. In the answer I tried pointing out all of the possible flaws that using ViewData has (without sounding like I was having at go).

What is excellent about this is that the user fully understood the answer, this means that another developer does not have to attempt to maintain horrible code with ViewData everywhere.

Now this is quite a recent answer so not that many people have seen it, but I really hope other developers come across this answer so we have better controllers in the future!

Answer (score -2):

### Using THE ZONE to answer questions on Stack Overflow

I no longer remember if I was trying to be one of the [faster guns in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533) or just by chance stumbled across *[Array push as the first index PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8340451)* on that day. I do remember I was quite zoned in to PHP arrays from fixing some scripts that some collegues and I wrote months before that should only live a couple of weeks as a proof-of-concept.

Reading the question along with its inherent fact right as the first sentence, my brain locked into auto mode, and I had [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8340499/664563) written in seconds. Usually I cross-read my answers at least twice (I am not a native English speaker, and even in German I tend to speak techno-babble sometimes) - but at this time my brain already chalked up that problem as no longer interesting and went fishing, no other possible solutions came up.

As it was - in essence - not wrong and the use-case of the poster did not ask for a general solution to prepend the array with more items I sent it along. A couple of minutes later I read the other answers and suddenly remembered that function they used. Nevertheless, I kept my answer and not even tried to defend it (*hey, array_unshift() **does** change the keys to be consecutive if he ever uses e.g. 1, 2 and 4 in his array!*), but I was embarassed of being that much in the zone that I was thinking so literally.

I think this is what makes [rubberducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) so helpful. When in the zone you are in line with the machine, sometimes spewing out lines as fast as you can type. But when dealing with other human beings you have to think, reflect and explain.

Comment: It's difficult to tell which answer in that question that you're recognizing (you forgot to "link to the answer on the main site you're talking about").

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thank you, I appreciate your revision  : )

Answer (score -2):

I'll nominate [one of own answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17184969/6521) as it's an example of why I get so much out of answering Stack Overflow questions - a seemingly simple question can lead to a rabbit hole of investigation.

[The question was puzzling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184626/php-giving-wrong-answer-when-using-time-zone-australia-sydney) - why is the number of days between "2013-10-01" and "2013-10-07" calculated as 5 and not 6?

It became apparent this was a daylight-saving issue, but I was puzzled why one possible way of coding it appeared to give the "right" answer of 6 days even though technically, 5 days and 23 hours had elapsed.

If this was *my* problem, I might be happy just to adopt the solution, but because I was writing publicly, I wanted to find out *why* the solution worked. This lead to delving into the PHP source to find out what mystery logic was being applied. As well as learning more about PHP internals, I was documenting some interesting behaviour I hadn't previously been aware of.

It gave me a deeper appreciation of how difficult date calculations can be, but also how useful it is to be able to take a deep dive into open source software.

Answer (score -3):

**Stack Overflow** helped our company not me make wrong decision.

Question: [Transferring ownership of an iPhone app on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671382/transferring-ownership-of-an-iphone-app-on-the-app-store)

An outsourcing company was developing a mobile application related to mobile payments, an was using its own account for application submission. But the client's company wanted to publish the application on its own account.

So, we didn't know how to and if it is possible at all to transfer an application from one AppStore account to another. And this question helped us to save a lot of time and discussions.

Answer (score -3):

**Teaching while learning, the magic of Stack Overflow**

**The Question:** 
[Intent.ACTION_SEND Whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638475/intent-action-send-whatsapp/)

**My Answer:** 
[Intent.ACTION_SEND Whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638475/intent-action-send-whatsapp/8679029#8679029)

**Story behind**

At the moment I answered to this question, I was a first year grade student in Spain. I was learning Java and giving my first steps in Android development. Concretely I was creating my first Android application, a simple funny sounds game.

I was trying to implement the capability of sharing sounds with [WhatsApp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp), and I decided to check Stack Overflow searching for the help of the biggest knowledge community. But something very strange happened, someone here had the same problem but nobody had answered to his question. I step into the shoes of that person, unknown to me but directly connected by a shared problem.

Since that moment, my motivation was to find a solution to the problem, not only to complete my work, but also to help that invisible friend. Finally, I found an answer to the problem and, full of pride, I posted my first answer in StackOverflow.

This story happened about three years ago, now I have much more experience in Java an Android, and each time I find some useful question / answer on Stack Overflow I empathize with that invisible person that makes other peoples' life easier.

Answer (score -6):

### How HTML source-diving made a kid happy a year later

**The post: [Where can I download the software for old RCX-era Mindstorms sets?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/where-can-i-download-the-software-for-old-rcx-era-mindstorms-sets/4455)**

*Disclaimer: This is about a post on Bricks.SE, not Stack Overflow. If this makes it invalid, feel free to delete it. But I think this is "a tale of a Stack Overflow user going way above and beyond the call of duty", so I'm still posting it.*

Almost exactly a year ago I was a young member (4 months) of the bricks.SE site, when I saw an unanswered question, in which a regular member who has been on the site for nearly 3 years asked where could one find software for a long retired LEGO robotics set. My first thought was "*Hey, if someone this experienced couldn't find it anywhere, what chance would a newbie such as me have? Let's go do something more useful.*" But then I did a cursory Google serach. And found nothing. After nudging the search terms around and looking through the dozens of forums where others asked the same question, I was on the verge of giving it up.

But then I saw a promising result, from the preview it looked like as if it was some kind of file server with exactly those files we needed. My joy disappeared though when I opened the site and found a bunch of garbage (broken) HTML, with nothing that resembled the things I was looking for. Then it occured to me that if Google found the site, it must mean that the info is there somewhere, I just need to find it myself. For example by examining the source. And bingo, there were all the items, and the links leading to the files themselves. After verifying the validity of the links (they indeed pointed to the correct files which started to download without error), I copied them over to form an answer. For good measure, I included the other links too which weren't specifically asked for but were relevant to the topic. Then I made the answer into a community wiki to endorse others to expand and correct it in case the links later become broken and indeed there were a number of additions in the following days.

This answer was then accepted and voted up enough, that by now it is the second hit for the relevant terms in Google (the first being a post dedicated to the problems during and after the installation of this software). I moved on to answer other questions and promptly forgot about his one.

Until a few days ago (one year and five days after the answer was posted) I received a notification that someone commented on this answer. It was a regular of SO, a PHP developer who had just made a profile on Bricks.SE to thank me for making their godchild and them happy by solving their "missing software" problem.

Reputation is one thing. Being ranked high on Google is another. But knowing that my work brought joy, happiness and possibly a career-forming learning opportunity to a child is an entirely different form of that warm, fuzzy feeling :)