# Who are the winners in the #SOreadytohelp t-shirt drawing?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

Stack Overflow recently surpassed 10 million questions, and we're giving away a bunch of t-shirts to celebrate:

[image]

Because it's coming up, here's some brief info about the t-shirt contest:

- Twitter applicants must re-enter to be considered for each week's drawing. 1 week = 00:00:01 UTC Thursday -> 23:59:59 UTC Wednesday.
- Profile applicants do not need to re-enter to be considered for each week's drawing. They will only be removed from consideration if they win.
- We will attempt to ship anywhere in the world, but if you live somewhere far away from the northeastern United States, expect delays.
- Winners will be contacted via the email associated with their SO account.
- Shipping will start after all winners have been collected, so expect arrival starting in October.

---

So. Who's getting new swag?

Comment: Just got an email! #SOhappy

Comment: Me too! #SOreadyToWearATshirt

Comment: I won one! #SOwaitingForThePostman

Comment: I'm purging the comments here. I've put answers to the operational questions in the original question above. Further inquiries about this event should be asked in separate questions in the [tag:10m-questions-milestone] tag.

Comment: To add to my previous comment "I don't use Twitter"...is there any other option to enter ?  I would love to be considered for a shirt somehow

Comment: @JeffOrris yes - users with #SOreadytohelp in their user profiles on Stack Overflow will also be entered to win.

Comment: @Qwerty at stackoverflow.com (the main site-programming site) then it is reflected to meta, well the reputation is.

Comment: What about if I have different e-mail for twitter and for my SO account? Is checked the profile "Web presence" info?

Comment: @IrvinDominin I think you need to mention your profile link in your #SOreadytohelp tweet :)

Comment: Looks like I've to to _wear_ pride only. Who's with me? :-)

Comment: #SOLateToTheParty #PleaseSendMeOne

Comment: When will be next contest and drawing?

Answer (score 69):

[Here's a list](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/356546/soreadytohelp-winners-week-1) of the winners of the first week's drawing. Congratulations all around!

The winners have been contacted via email for shipping information, so if you're on that list and you want your swag, make sure you check the email associated with your Stack Overflow profile. (If you're on that list but you can't find the message, let me know via email [abby@stackoverflow.com] and we'll get you sorted out.)

Comment: You just [like being contacted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245361/115866), don't you?

Comment: @balpha Inbox Zero is for the birds. For me it's Inbox Ten Million or bust.

Comment: What's about the people putting their stories along the #SOreadytohelp tag?

Comment: Just to make Abby's list easier to navigate - here's a [sorted version of it](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/356571/soreadytohelp-winners-sorted-week-1)

Comment: Because I'm lazy, here's a sorted list of winners: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/357808/soreadytohelp-winners-week-1

Comment: I'm purging the comments here. I've put answers to the operational questions in the original question above. Further inquiries about this event should be asked in separate questions in the [tag:10m-questions-milestone] tag.

Comment: Interesting that a random pick - one of the winners has only 6 reputation and doesn't appear to have helped anyone/many people at all.

Answer (score 26):

Without further ado, and with many apologies for the delay, [here are the winners of the Week 2 drawing](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/361589/soreadytohelp-winners-week-2). Instructions have been sent to the email addresses associated with the winners' SO profiles. If you're on that list but you can't find the message, let me know via email [abby@stackoverflow.com] and we'll get you sorted out.

(The Week 3 drawing will take place this Thursday and be announced this Friday, rain or shine.)

Comment: Do we get an update [to my question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303862/how-many-people-entered-the-soreadytohelp-contest-the-first-week)? :)

Answer (score 13):

As promised, [here's week 3](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/362593/soreadytohelp-winners-week-30)! As before, instructions have been sent to the email addresses associated with the winners' SO profiles. If you're on that list but you can't find the message, let me know via email [abby@stackoverflow.com] and we'll get you sorted out.

Comment: Your query has 102 UserIds but returns only 99 rows.

Comment: @NormalHuman: I'm investigating. Emails were sent to 100 rows of spreadsheet, but there's some kind of discrepancy happening when loading my Ids into data SE.

Answer (score 11):

Right on time, [here's week 4](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/365657/soreadytohelp-winners-week-4). As before, instructions have been sent to the email addresses associated with the winners' SO profiles. If you're on that list but you can't find the message, let me know via email [abby@stackoverflow.com] and we'll get you sorted out.

Comment: so, this. is. it.

Comment: So excited - will be wearing it with pride.

Comment: #SODisappointed

Comment: #SOnotlucky! :(

Comment: So now can we/do we need to remove #SOReadyToHelp since its all done.. :(