# How many people entered the SOReadyToHelp contest the first week?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

We now know the [winners](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303721/who-are-the-winners-in-the-soreadytohelp-t-shirt-drawing?cb=1) of the #SOReadyToHelp contest.  But, how many people *entered* during the first week - ie, what was the total number of eligible entries (and if possible, split male/female, if that's fully known)?

Comment: And how many of the entries definitely weren't inactive sockpuppets?  Ooh creating sockpuppets to increase raffle odds.  That's pretty low.

Comment: Okay, I've sort of run out of time today to put together a real answer but I'll give you what I remember off the top of my head - there were over 10,000 entries, and about 7500 of them were Twitter entries.

Comment: A list of all 3426 users currently displaying #SOreadytohelp in their about me: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/357967

Comment: Sad reading: https://twittercommunity.com/t/hashtag-count/7043/23

Comment: @JoshuaDwire Wait! So we're supposed to actually _display_ "#SOreadytohelp"? I just added it in the about be and it ended up being some large markdown display of "SOreadytohelp". I didn't see my name  in your list. Should I change it to actually display it _with_ the hashtag?

Comment: so [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/358044)  9515 users where not included in the contest eh?

Comment: SEDE is updated infrequently, but we pull more up-to-date data from the DB internally for this drawing.

Comment: #Everyone uses #hashtags #nowadays, #everywhere. So #why could #someone #think about #submitting #entries without #hashtag?

Comment: I'm on SO everyday but somehow this contest passed me by... :(