# Did I participate in the #SOreadytohelp drawing?

Tags: support

I just noticed that my profile page is still "#SOreadytohelp" and I wondered why that is. So I searched for it and vaguely remembered the drawing when I found this question: [How many people entered the SOReadyToHelp contest the first week?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303862/how-many-people-entered-the-soreadytohelp-contest-the-first-week)

From the comments I see it's unclear whether the `#SOreadytohelp` was supposed to be before or after markdown conversion. On one hand it says:

> A list of all 3426 users currently displaying #SOreadytohelp in their about me: data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/357967 – Joshua Dwire Aug 31 '15 at 22:59
>
> so this 9515 users where not included in the contest eh? – jacky rudetsky Sep 1 '15 at 7:47

On the other hand the drawing list apparently didn't come from that SEDE query:

> SEDE is updated infrequently, but we pull more up-to-date data from the DB internally for this drawing. – hairboat♦ Sep 1 '15 at 18:59

Comment: Of course you participated, still visible from your profile.  That you didn't notice that the contest is over was, well, not a complete accident.  I kinda doubt that tshirtgatearmageddonwherearetheythissucks is going to be repeated any time soon.

Comment: Get ready for #SOreadytodocument. But coming first, #SOreadytohats.

Answer (score 8):

The query we used didn't look for the hashtag at all when searching profiles, it just looked for the text "soreadytohelp" in any casing and included those users in the drawing pool. So if it was in your profile in any form, even without the hashtag or surrounded by other things like "soreadytohelpjustkidding" then the query picked it up.