# What is #SOreadytohelp for?

Tags: support, profile-page

I've seen countless user profiles with "#SOreadytohelp" in the description. What does this mean and why do so many users have it in their profile?

Comment: It's people who want to win t-shirts: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303721/who-are-the-winners-in-the-soreadytohelp-t-shirt-drawing . You can find answers like this pretty easily if you google "#SOReadyToHelp". That's how I found it.

Comment: Are there lots of `#SOabouttogiveup` as well?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is left over from a give away when Stack Overflow hit the 10 million questions mark.

The "SO ready to help" giveaway included putting that string in your profile to be entered into a drawing for t-shirts over the course of a few weeks.

These users just haven't bothered to remove it, out of apathy or just forgetfulness. Or they just stand by being ready to help, and feel the message still stands, regardless of the lack of ongoing contests.

Comment: Better to close as dupe of that other Meta-Q, rather than post redundant content, IMO.  That said, I didn't downvote.

Comment: I'm not too worried about the downvotes. In this specific case, I'm of the mind it's better to have both- A real explanation (since it's been so long) and the dupe. Others will come across this in time, it won't hurt to have this actually spelled out in an answer rather than forcing them to read through the history and piece it together from context. Not to mention that while the other question _technically_ answers this, they do have to do the piecing together on their own. A direct answer doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: This answer is clear. The mentioned duplicate doesn't answer the question _What is #SOreadytohelp for?_.