# Where's my 10,000,000 swag?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

Recently, [the 10,000,000 stories](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey) question reached its deadline. In fact, that was three days ago. I decided I wasn't going to complain over the weekend and give the Stack Overflow staff a break. Maybe they got busy, wanted to enjoy [Labor Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labor_Day) weekend. I was even going to wait until Tuesday, *the day after Labor Day*, to ask where my swag was. But I'm excited about my swag.

I think a lot of others are experiencing something similar--after not receiving an email to request my swag, I posted [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey#comment243487_303045) describing the issue. It currently has received 20 upvotes, indicating that I am not alone in being excited about swag and disappointed about not seeing the email.

So--Thank you to Stack Overflow for everything, all the questions and answers and fake Internet points, <s>but guys, where's my swag?</s> I'd like some information about what's going on. I'm not demanding instant swag, or trying to jump a line. I'd just like an update, maybe from Tim, our resident "lord of swag."

P.S. The deadline is past, and the question is still open. What gives?
--Martijn points out that the open question doesn't mean the competition is still open. Thanks, Martijn.

Comment: Did you see the 6-8 weeks caveat? *Allow 6 - 8 weeks for delivery after the submission deadline*.

Comment: And question open != competition open. Only submissions up to September 4 are eligible.

Comment: Oh, and there are 140 or so submissions. Them's a lot of submissions to sort out.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand there's a lot going on--I just wanted to draw attention to the fact. Also, the "6-8 weeks for delivery" indicated to me that whatever package was being shipped might take 6-8 weeks, not that receiving a form would. I'm trying to show patience. You can't blame a guy for being excited.

Comment: @BenKnoble The more you ask, the further back in the line you go.

Comment: @bluefeet Although fair, your comment makes me sound demanding, and I assure you that wasn't my intention. Besides, my post is close to the bottom of the line anyways. It only received 2 up votes, and was posted 8/25. I'm not trying to jump a line, or anything like that. I'd just like some information as to what's going on. That's all, and I think that's fair and reasonable

Comment: @BenKnoble _your comment makes me sound demanding_ it wasn't [my comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305494/wheres-my-10-000-000-swag#comment243985_305494) that made you sound demanding.  It seems like you think we've forgotten about our 10m question celebration, it's not like it's been 6-8 something since the deadline of Sept 4th....it's been a few days. You know what they say -- **patience is a virtue**

Comment: Closely related: http://www.gocomics.com/printable/calvinandhobbes/1989/03/03/

Comment: @bluefeet fair enough. I'll wait it out. Sorry if everybody thought I was impatient. Excited, yes, impatient, probably. Again, you can't blame a guy for wanting SO swag. I'd think we'd be excited as a community that people love SO that much. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Calvin and Hobbes==modern day philosophers.

Comment: @BenKnoble: 6-8 weeks is a [Stack Overflow meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514). It means there is no fixed schedule, they'll get to it when they get to it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: http://chutzpah.typepad.com/.a/6a00e55180ed5c88340134802df078970c-pi and http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-_-q-F3mDb-g/USjIxvTSHuI/AAAAAAAAMXE/P8wOI8cYaP0/s1600/19890308.gif apply too :-D

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's the answer I suppose I was looking for. Thanks for being patient with me (I guess I'm not as patient as I thought?)... Guess it's time to delete the question? Or should I update it with your info and leave for others wandering to find?

Comment: I think you may as well add an answer, @BenKnoble.

Comment: I wanted one :(

Comment: Dang, -22 votes. I bet you regret this question :P

Comment: @Dayan Eh. It happens. Apparently the community didn't like it. No rep loss, at least. And I (sorta) learned a thing or two.

Comment: @BenKnoble No harm done then, GL!

Comment: @Dayan and look, -20!

Comment: @BenKnoble ;) On your way to 0!

Comment: Didnt actually think id earn a gold badge for this.

Comment: Oh i know @PatrickHofman i know. I just didnt expect it.

Comment: The answer is good. The question is a little impatient.

Comment: Precisely what ive learned.

Comment: Another badge.... Hmmmm...

Comment: See also the possible duplicate (from a month later): [Where's my swag?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310598/1048572)

Comment: hey Ben, how's it going ?
I don't even know what a 'self-answered reversal' on SO is, but apparently this is one.
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/677715/self-answered-reversals

Comment: @orion elenzil it has to do with question and answer scores—see the votes on my question and my self-answer :) i like to think I’ve matured since i asked this question

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**It. has. arrived.**

As you can see from the coordinated contest swag question, [the packages have left the warehouse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272623/295851).

I received a FedEx notification yesterday that a package was in transit, and [it arrived this morning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272621/what-happened-to-that-contest-swag-i-was-promised#comment894782_272623), no signature required.

The package included a charcoal grey t-shirt, mug, padfolio and pen, koozie, and stickers, all bearing the Stack Overflow name/logo.

[image]

**The second swag package has arrived!**

This package included a second t-shirt, water bottle, ruled notebook, and pen, all bearing the Stack Overflow name/logo.

*The first photo was darker, but the t-shirts **are** the same color.*

[image]

Thanks to everyone at Stack Exchange who worked to collect and process the shipping details, for sending out these nice gifts, and for celebrating the 10M questions event with a contest!

*I don't know if packages are shipped from a single or from multiple fulfillment centers.  Mine was shipped yesterday (FedEx Ground), and ended up arriving today, since I happened to geographically live near where the package has been shipped from.*

*I'd imagine people will be receiving their package within the next few days, depending on the transit time from the shipper.*

If you want to track your package, you should be able to sign up for FedEx Delivery Manager, which shows you all incoming packages for your address.

Thanks again, Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you for posting this. The address I gave way back in September isn't the same anymore! Using the FedEx Delivery Manager, I was able to schedule it to be held so it doesn't get delivered to someone else!

Comment: I'm curious: What else is there on that T-shirt other than that SO logo ? (If anything ?)

Comment: @JonasCz Only the logo, no text.  No pocket, nothing on the back -- nothing was obscured by the other swag.  It's a cotton/polyester/rayon blend, if anyone cares to know.

Comment: I got the exact same tshirt for something else and let me say although plain with just the logo these shirts are very comfortable.  I'd love a pack of five of these...

Comment: Thank you StackOverflow!  I think it's hilarious that this question is at -26 but the [duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310598/wheres-my-swag?lq=1) asked two months later is at +64

Comment: I got package number two! 

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Indeed--I saw that and questioned it, but I attributed it to impatient teenager vs. veteran question-asker :P

Comment: May I ask how did you get those items?

Answer (score 37):

For anyone curious, here's the info that answered my question.

> 6-8 weeks is a [Stack Overflow meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514). It means there is no fixed schedule, they'll get to it when they get to it.--Martijn Pieters

In other words, be patient! Your swag will come!

I guess I haven't been around long enough to recognize that.

UPDATE: My package also came; thanks to anyone with the patience to deal with this question.