# Stack Overflow shirt lost in mail?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

Some time ago, I participated in the ["10 million questions"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey/303340#303340) question.

After that, I received an email asking me to complete a Google Form with my Stack Overflow profile link and shipping details.

However, this all happened in September, and we're now in November, and I've yet seen anything.

So I just wanted to check if this is normal for oversea shipping, or if something may have gone wrong!

Comment: @Kendra yeah, I suppose that question is pretty similar to my own... I guess mine is a little bit more "selfish" XD

Comment: Note to self: see also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305494/wheres-my-10-000-000-swag

Comment: The one you linked is from before the emails were even sent, but the "be patient" sentiment probably still applies. (We'll find out if/when a team member addresses one of these new ones, I suppose.)

Comment: I was informed mine arrived yesterday!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is normal for overseas shipping. Additionally, this order is getting out of the warehouse more slowly than usual. We had a few hiccups and delays due to the size of the order.

They started rolling out at the end of October / first week of November.

Comment: Good to hear an update at least! I keep fretting that I entered my address wrong. This is a bit relieving to read.

Comment: @Kendra what if your address is still wrong ? LOL

Comment: @Criesto I die a little inside and cry when I'm alone at night. :)

Comment: abby, is it the same for the boxes of swag from the *How did SO help you* ?

Comment: @TimCastelijns, i think Tim mentioned that boxes for both, will ship at the same time together.

Comment: I don't think the "share your story" orders have been placed yet, but Tim Post will have to confirm that.

Comment: @abbyhairboat is it 6-8 weeks to get across the pond or is is closer to 3-4?

Comment: The million dollar question is *how long does shipping take?* I am located in Kansas City, KS, and a day before December I still don't have anything. Is shipping really supposed to take 4 weeks, *or longer*?

Comment: @CalebKleveter The one with the most realistic answer, gets his shipment first.. The others have to wait 6-8 weeks longer.. :)

Comment: @CalebKleveter I'm also in KCK and still no package myself. Everyday I get a little more nervous but I'm glad to hear I'm not the only one.

Comment: @MatthewGreen, I forget were I found it, but I think I saw something about it coming around christmas.

Comment: Small problem; I'm a college student and my address will change in 2 weeks; how should I handle this? I will be coming back here in January, though.

Comment: I think it's lost on way

Comment: "They started rolling out at the end of October/first week of November." vs: "The list is going out on Friday, which means things will start shipping on Monday." (posted [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310600/4632401) on 19th of November.) And then people say that I shouldn't have trust issues!

Comment: It's nearly Christmas. I hate to complain, but... I was honestly excited. "I am Rubberduck's bitter disappointment."

Comment: I'm in Michigan about six to eight hours away from you guys and have been waiting since September.  I could of driven there and got it faster.

Comment: Still nothing in my mail box, and it's February now .__.

Comment: [What happened to that contest swag I was promised?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272621/what-happened-to-that-contest-swag-i-was-promised)