# Circular duplicate closures?

Tags: bug, review-queues, duplicate-questions

[This review just popped up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/7213). It's for the question [Who has received their 10M swag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309711/who-has-received-their-10m-swag), and the review asks whether it's a duplicate of [Stack Overflow shirt lost in mail? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309770/stack-overflow-shirt-lost-in-mail). But the latter question was already closed as a duplicate of the former. (This is also probably wrong, by the way, as the "master" question here had no answers and the "duplicate" did).

In other words, `A` was closed as a duplicate of `B`, and the review queue just asked me whether `B` should be closed as a duplicate of `A`. I voted to leave open because the circular dependency might accidentally summon [<strike>ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱</strike> TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2057919) or something.

What is the correct approach to this? Was this a bug?

**Edit:** Or is it because I also just got [this review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/7214) asking to reopen [Stack Overflow shirt lost in mail? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309770/stack-overflow-shirt-lost-in-mail). Perhaps someone voted to reopen that question and mark the "master" question as the duplicate at the same time?

Comment: Blame caching. No, but the review queue checks take place periodically, and are not real time, so it may have been a flag that wasn't checked if it was valid or not by the system.

Comment: Interestingly, the question was marked a duplicate by the OP himself, which is surprising considering the master question doesn't have an answer, yet his does.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Abby's answer came in about 20 seconds _after_ the closure, or I'd have suggested the dupe the other way around. :)

Comment: @Kendra Blame caching. Even more. >:D and maybe modessness.

Comment: As a note, and as I commented on Abby's answer for the currently closed question, I feel the dupe closure should probably be reversed, since the newer question has the answer.

Comment: @Kendra You can't flag/close without the other reopened now.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I know that. It should be reversed. In other words, open the closed question and close the open question afterwards. _That_ is entirely possible.

Comment: :( You dont love experiments. I've voted both question as dupes of each other, you should've completed the job. Its impossible to circulardupeclose, so on last vote there would be some interesting error in the review.

Comment: [Here's my uber-meta bug post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150133/179419) on this issue from 3 years ago... Status by-design at this point...

Comment: @Ben Interesting. I looked for duplicates of my own question, but didn't find yours. Too bad there hasn't been any movement on this.

Comment: I was about to mark my question as dupe, cause i discussed this with @Kendra, being that my question has no answer and the newer one does. But I didnt mark it in time, so it wouldnt let me mark mine as a dupe of the dupe of mine... *if that makes sense*

Comment: If the one with an answer gets re-opened I dont mind marking mine as a the dupe, reason why I haven't declined the *"this solved my problem!"*

Comment: @lɘɒɔin theres nothing fancy to it, I just get prompted *"This closure would result in the 'duplicate of' navigation oly leading in a circle"*

Comment: Lol, so there's no choice? Funny.

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton If you post your comments as an answer, I'll accept it. I just didn't try the experiment. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being that the first question was posted by me I don't mind giving some context to the situation:

I posted my question and other than comments I didn't get much feedback. I assume both questions were marked as dupes of each other at the same time, after going to the newer question I saw that the answer technically answered my question(giving me an estimated time of arrival and what not), so I went back to my question to mark it as dupe, but the other question's OP had already marked his as dupe. Reason for which even tho my question has no answer is marked as the "original". If newer question gets re-opened I would gladly mark mine as a dupe of it. Being that my question has no answer.

PS No summons, just a plain "This closure would result in the 'duplicate of' navigation only leading in a circle" (I was brave enough to try)

Comment: The prompt if you vote to close (`"This closure would result in the 'duplicate of' navigation oly leading in a circle"`) is the part that really answers the question. Apparently, SO just doesn't check for potential circularity before putting the question in the queue; it checks if anyone votes to create the circularity.