# Where's my swag?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone, swag

For the [10 million questions post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey) I made a post [on how stackoverflow has helped me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey/303302#303302).  Mr. Tim Post emailed me quite some time ago for address information to send the swag. I've waited more than 12 weeks and still no SO swag.  What gives?  I'm not trying to be greedy here but we are past the 6-8 weeks * 2.

If you're gonna tease a dog with a treat... Please toss it to him, don't hold onto it!

Comment: I'm admittedly a bit concerned as well; I've had a few packages stolen recently and I'm really starting to worry that this was one of them :-(

Comment: They started rolling out [around the start of November](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309770/stack-overflow-shirt-lost-in-mail/309773#309773) and it's been slower because of the large order.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Is that boat the 'HMS Missing Apostrophe'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got my second package today, thanks @spolsky and stack overflow.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can we make @mentions in answers a thing yet, guys?

Comment: What was in the second package? Don't leave us hangin'!

Comment: Thanks @spolsky I didn't know answers don't notify users.  So proud to be part of this community Joel and letting me be part of building such a great system.

Comment: PS I love the shirts...I've got three of them and they are so comfy for sleeping. Wish I had a seven pack of them.  My wife's sick of seeing the shirt but I love it!

Comment: @boltclock I posted some pics although posting via mobile interface isn't so fun :(

Comment: @JonH *My wife's sick of seeing the shirt*. Shirt Overflow. (You better hide the one arriving in the *third* package...)

Answer (score 46):

We just, as in last week, got the last round of corrections and stragglers that contributed but hadn't filled out their details so we could compile everything and send it off to our warehouse to be shipped. Normally, we simply send off orders one-by-one as they come in, but due to the number of people that responded, we had to work something out with the folks that do our fulfillment (it's over 400 packages of swag, we've never had something at this scale before).

The list is going out on Friday, which means things will start shipping on Monday. We'll update this answer as things happen. Sorry for the delay, we just had *no idea* how big the response was going to be, or we would have let folks know to allow a little more time than the usual 6 - 8 weeks.

(Note, we've fulfilled the #SOReadyToHelp and then reloaded, this is the last of it from the events here on meta)

#### Update

The last of this (due to a glitch on our end about how forms were sent to collect info) is on it's way, if you haven't received something check the [What happened to that contest swag I was promised?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272621/what-happened-to-that-contest-swag-i-was-promised/272623#272623) post over on Meta Stack Exchange that keeps you informed about all swag, its status and the employee responsible for getting it shipped to you.

Comment: There should be an updated status somewhere, otherwise this type of question will be appearing again and again.

Comment: Are we getting this? A yes or no would be appreciated at this point. I would rather hear "no" than "..."

Comment: *The last of this...*?? I did not hear anyone saying they got the stuff.. I feel its more like all of it..

Comment: This is very frustrating and disappointing, I never thought that SO would deal with this in such an inefficient way. It's over 400 packages of swag? And so what? Did you honestly expect there to be less than 400 replies to the contest, in a website as big and active as SO, especially considering that SO swag is extremely hard to get? I filled the form with my address on 09/18/15, it's been nearly 4 months. It really looks like you're making fun of us. If you're such a small company that can't handle 400+ packages of swag, then just don't make unrealistic promises.

Comment: @all - There is now [one link to rule them all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272623/194162) for giveaways.  tl;dr is that there were apparently [more problems after this 12/30 update](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314186/stack-overflow-annual-survey-2016?#comment292088_314186)

Comment: I think JNat is handling this. Check [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272621/what-happened-to-that-contest-swag-i-was-promised/272623#272623)

Comment: @TimPost I've got fedex sending me messages asking for a receipt for a package containing *"padfolio, t-shirt, koozie and 2 mugs"* sent via JET MAIL. Is that related to this?

Comment: Got it today and that coffee mug is massive!

Answer (score 27):

Well would you look at that.  My wife called me this morning and was like you got a box in the mail from some stackoverflow company.  I told her..great must be my tshirt!  Tell her to open it up and send me pics...

Great thanks guys!  My daughter will love the SO chapstick :-)...

[image]

[image]
And thanks also to @spolsky...that was a nice touch..and I was going to order that book..now I can read it.  Much thanks, who wouldn't want to work for such a company!  Great class!  Motivates me to file more bugs :-)

Comment: Was there a coffee mug? I was really excited about there potentially being a coffee mug.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ - The first question I asked my wife was `Is there a coffee mug?` sadly the answer was no - so no coffee mug...but I can't complain.  Maybe yours will have a coffee mug.  I too wanted to show the coffee mug at work - I'm not much of a coffee drinker but with this mug I would of become one!

Comment: Shucks. Well, I'll keep my fingers crossed.

Comment: Congrats! @JonH

Comment: Wow.. That looks awesome.. unfortunately I promised my girlfriend the mug.. Anyways.. Are we getting this book also or was it specially for you?

Comment: @Haris the book is for [the authors of the answers mentioned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey)

Comment: I didn't however get a coffee mug, although it says you would get a coffee mug...@TimPost any idea why I didn't get the coffee mug?

Comment: I wonder how you got this - and for what - if the 10M Questions swag [still hasn't shipped](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272623).

Comment: I don't know probably the over 100+ bug reports.

Comment: For reference, [this was apparently separate from the 10M questions giveaway](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272621/what-happened-to-that-contest-swag-i-was-promised/272623#comment889377_272623).

Answer (score 16):

And just when I had given up hope, the first part arrived today!

[image: Swag]

For those of you still waiting, the swag is real!

**Update:**

Another package arrived today!:

[image: More Swag]

Comment: Nice shot of the inside of the folio :)  If anyone wants to see the logo imprint, I shared [a photo of the cover](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317712/4151918).

Comment: we we so excited!

Comment: I received a similar package today.  It was a long 6-8 weeks.  Thank you StackOverflow!

Comment: May I ask how did you get those items?

Answer (score 3):

Now I'm trying to convince my colleagues that I didn't buy these.

Thank you Stack Overflow, much appreciated!

[image: Yeey]

Comment: May I ask how did you get those items?

Answer (score 2):

I got my stuff yesterday.

[image]

[image]

My brother wants to buy a mug, so if anybody knows where to get one, let me know.

Comment: All I got was a t-shirt, so I guess I have that going for me :^)

Comment: @JustDoIt, I guess you won the #SOreadytohelp contest.

Comment: Mine just arrived in .uk. \o/