# 10 Million Questions Giveaway - What happened?

Tags: discussion

First of all I appologize if using a question to ask for a status update is the wrong way to approach this, but I can honestly say I would not know any other way to ask this.

4 months ago TimPost dropped a [Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey) on Meta asking for people's experiences on stackoverflow with some fancy swag as a reward for the effort. Which was pretty unexpected and also very much awesome :)

Unfortunately things went pretty quiet afterwards. Comments have reached 80'ish asking for updates, but hardly any information was given.
People did get an email requesting for address information, but it has been silent ever since.

So I was wondering if things are still in progress? Or did things simply go wrong or got to expensive or what not.

Any answer is welcome, even if it says things didn't go as planned and the gifts can't be given. Somethings things go wrong, thats ok. But some form of a update would be highly appreciated by many.

On a sidenote: I've moved to a new house lately, so the earlier address information is no longer correct. Over the span of 4 months I suppose more people could be in the same predicament. Something to consider.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310598/wheres-my-swag

Comment: Thank you. Atleast that is something. But unfortunately that last response was from Nov 19th saying things would be arriving in two weeks. I don't believe anyone heard anything from it since.

Comment: Nope. Check Tim's edit on his answer. Its from December 30th.

Comment: Ah nice. I did not notice the "edited Dec 30 '15 at 13:12" text there. I will answer my own question on this one to make the information easier to find. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

TimPost updated an answer on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310598/wheres-my-swag) question stating the following:

> The last of this (due to a glitch on our end about how forms were sent
>   to collect info) is on it's way, if you haven't received something it
>   will be going out shortly, give it ~2 weeks.

This update was done on december 30th, so it seems things are actually moving forward!