# Is it too late for swag?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone, swag

I had posted an answer on the [10 million](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey) post, and promptly forgot about it. I got an email from Tim Post in September asking for my address in the email account which I guess I originally linked to my SO account, but rarely check. I replied in November but didn't hear back from him (no big surprise there).

So, I thought I'd ask one last time before going to cry in the corner (again). Is it possible that my swag is in a dusty corner somewhere waiting to be shipped, or is it gone?

Comment: Related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272621/what-happened-to-that-contest-swag-i-was-promised

Comment: Since you've got the direct link to the most up-to-date info, let me also add [this has been asked a lot,](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310598/wheres-my-swag) and that question actually has the link for the MSE post. (Granted, buried in the comments on the top answer.)

Comment: I am waiting for my swag as well. I will drop an email to enquire.

Comment: @Andy thanks, that's good info. I guess everyone is still waiting. I was just wondering if it were possible for me to tell if, since I waited until November to fill out the form, if I missed a deadline, or if my order was still valid and waiting with everyone else's. Guess I'll wait 6 to 8 weeks and find out!

Comment: Nov 19: it's coming.  Dec 30: ~ 2 weeks.  Jan 20: in the process of shipping.  Feb 16: it has not yet shipped, end of the week.  Jeremy Crickets.

Comment: Feb 26: It's actually arriving...

Comment: yeah I was monitoring the other thread, and signed up for the FedEx delivery manager. Mine's out for delivery today!