# User keeps coming back with new accounts, asking dishonest non-questions

Tags: discussion, moderation, users, question-quality

On August 30 I flagged a question by [Ji Cha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5241638/ji-cha). I had noticed that this account had existed for only 12 days, but the user had posted nearly 50 questions, all with the `makefile` tag, all concerning bugs or corner cases in GNU Make, and all of which had immediately received a single upvote (which is unusual in that tag). The user didn't respond much to answers or comments. [Mad Scientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist) noted that these questions did not appear to be genuine questions from someone trying to write a makefile, and that **the actual bugs had not been reported to bug-make@gnu.org**. (Personally I think that some of the "questions" would make valuable bug reports, but that is not what this site is for.) I don't know the result of that flag, but it was marked "helpful". Ji Cha has not posted since.

The next day another user appeared, posting questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305664/use-of-double-colon-in-gnu-make-is-dangerous1) (now deleted), with exactly the same style (subject, tone, format) but without the upvote shilling. I flagged this question, the flag was considered "helpful" and the account appears to have been deleted.

On September 17 [same story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616479/using-all-in-makefile/32621437#32621437), new account, exactly the same style but more overtly a rant against GNU Make, and more willing to argue in comments. Flagged, "helpful", deleted.

This user appears to have the resources to find bugs, shortcomings and corner cases in GNU Make, and some motive (other than reputation) to rail against it, but no desire to actually see it improved. (And clearly this user is not deterred by Whac-A-Mole.) My best guess is that someone wants to promote another tool by smearing GNU Make here.

Anyway, [guess who's back](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5357321/m-curioto).

I don't see much point in continuing to flag this abuse, and in this case it's not all that serious anyway. But do we really have no defense against this tactic?

Comment: I think flagging and reporting is the only way. With patterns like this sooner or later those posts/accounts/IP-address should get a similar treatment as spam. I share your amazement about the form and amount of these questions. And it needs a SME to notice that the questions are not genuine.

Comment: Questions like this need to include the T-shirt size.

Comment: Could elaborate for people who don't know all the intricate details of writing a makefile? Could you enumerate specific reasons why these questions should be deleted? Are they on topic or do they look like spam, rude, unclear, overly-broad, opinion-based, duplicate, low-quality? How does their removal make the internet a better place?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: These are either bug reports or rants thinly veiled as questions. They're not designed to generate useful answers. The OP is only posting them on SO because for whatever reason they won't report them to the right avenues.

Comment: @BoltClock: I don't understand the questions enough to judge whether they are bug reports or just incorrect usage or incorrect interpretation of the documentation. I'll take your word for it and let's assume the issues raised in the questions are actual bugs -- why not answer them: "it is a bug. Report it. Here's a link to the bug tracker. Here's a workaround in the mean time" -- how would it harm SO?

Comment: @rene: Can you expand "SME"?

Comment: This one looks relevant, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900604/shell-function-in-makefile-may-not-work

Comment: Crystallizing the issue a bit, observing this kind of un-checked site abuse can be very discouraging to SO users like @Beta.  This horse shoe cheated with a sock account, no consequences.  He reached his question limit after posting 50 fake questions in a few days, he just created another account to keep going.  Destroy that one, he'll create yet another one.  This completely wears out well-meaning SO users that try to keep the place tidy and useful to other programmers.  I know the feeling.

Comment: @DanDascalescu sorry, SME => Subject Matter Expert

Comment: The questions are intriguing but the poster seems unwilling or perhaps unable to follow up on requests to bring this up as bug reports. I have been wondering about this but did not think to bring it up here. I'm not completely sure these should be closed, but the sock puppeting makes it look even more ... weird.

Comment: @tripleee you know the room than can be of help but I hesitate to offer that help as I would have to follow your, Mad Scientist or Beta's call without being able to make some judgement myself

Comment: It doesn't seem to be too high intensity. [Here's a query I just came up with](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/367395/473443/ji-cha-sock-puppets) but it's clearly not catching all the posts.

Comment: @HansPassant: do you mean the following site abuse: upvoting your own posts, leaving comments, and posting more questions than a limit allows  using sockpuppet accounts? What is the hard evidence? If we ignore the author; do the questions themselves look ok? If not; what are [*specific* issues](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306582/user-keeps-coming-back-with-new-accounts-asking-dishonest-non-questions?noredirect=1#comment250025_306582) (as they are enumerated in the help). The tone of this meta-question is worrisome; people are prone to witch-hunt mentality

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: The *specific* issue is that they are not questions. Please read through the "question" that Beta linked to, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305664/use-of-double-colon-in-gnu-make-is-dangerous1. You don't need to "know all the intricate details of writing a makefile" to see that the OP is not looking for a workaround (or any other sort of help). It falls under the "just a rant in disguise" category at http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: @ruakh: None of my Makefiles contain double colon (`::`) and therefore for me [the \[deleted\] question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305664/use-of-double-colon-in-gnu-make-is-dangerous1) is just unclear ([I'm not the only one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292988/gnu-make-is-inconsistent-in-the-number-of-times-it-applies-a-vpath#comment52463294_32292988) who doesn't understand [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A5241638+is%3Aq)). Many questions that show the code that "doesn't work" may be called  "rants" -- it is too easy to abuse. "ignore the author"

Comment: I tried to help this character for a while, but the lack of response meant it wasn't worth my effort or (what little is left of) my sanity.  The questions are trying to do what seem to me ridiculous things with GNU Make.  (I rather too frequently didn't understand what was being attempted, or why it was thought that what was attempted should work — and I'm not a novice user of Make.)  Since there didn't seem to be any interest in getting answers, I haven't been tracking them for a while.  I did spend some time early on making sure they were tagged GNU Make.

Comment: Example question: [Make freezes when parsing this makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086209/make-freezes-when-parsing-this-makefile) — I retagged it on 2015-08-23; the question was created 2015-08-19.

Comment: I always seem to wonder...where in God's earth do these people have so much time to create hundreds of accounts, posting these sort of questions.  I struggle to shave and brush my hair in the morning, let alone all of this.  What is wrong with people?????

Comment: I don't struggle to shave and brush my hair in the morning - not anymore.  I gave up a long time ago.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Good evening, J.F. As I said, I think some of these "questions" can serve as valuable bug reports, (I'm thinking of forwarding them to gnu.org when I have time). And I don't mind this user being sneaky, duplicitous and hostile-- it takes a lot to make me cry. But I object to the questions for two reasons; 1) extracting good content from diatribes is tiresome (and I have mixed feelings about radical editing of others' questions), and 2) many of the questions aren't really useful, they're about weird 3-cushion shots with Make; they will show up in searches but only as chaff.

Comment: @Beta: is there a reason, not to close these questions as *"unclear what you're asking"*? (to speed up the process, any similar new questions could also be flagged for moderator attention with the link to the current meta-discussion for additional context -- it should promote the ban for the corresponding account). If the question is clear then it doesn't matter who  its author.

Comment: I don't always submit bug reports, but when I do, I go to extreme lengths and spend orders of magnitude more effort than simply working around the problem or even fixing it in the first place.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: For one thing, they aren't unclear, they're *"is this a bug?"* or more precisely *"this is a pretty huge bug, isn't it?"*. For another, people unfamiliar with the situation would not join in to vote for such a closure. *"I am voting to close on the grounds that this is a rant by a known troll"* would work better, but I'm not sure that simply closing questions is the ideal solution, since I hate to throw the good information out with the dross. And banning accounts seems pointless. I don't have an ideal solution, but the picture is getting clearer...

Comment: @Beta: minor detail: nowhere I said that the questions are clear. Moreover I've repeated several times that I don't understand most of them. I said: _"**if** the question is clear"_  (emphasis on "if"). If the question is: "is this a bug?" then what is wrong with [my suggestion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306582/user-keeps-coming-back-with-new-accounts-asking-dishonest-non-questions?noredirect=1#comment250030_306582)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian He clearly believe it's a bug and isn't interested in receiving answers but instead calling attention to the alleged bug. By simply answering and moving on, you're feeding the troll. He has demonstrated his behavior on here is hostile and is not attempting to improve SO but instead to use it as a platform to attack others. Simply answering will not stop that, and that's what's wrong with your suggestion.

Comment: @mason: let me ask you this: if somebody else have asked [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A5241638+is%3Aq) (btw, why are they not deleted?) then is it ok to answer: "it is a bug/feature request. Report here (the link). Here's a workaround"? Also, I don't doubt it but could you link to specific instances of "hostile" and "attack others" behavior (for a specific example)?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian If someone asked an isolated "is this a bug" question, then that's fine. Repeatedly asking "is this a bug" is the attack. Also see his behavior here on this Meta question. Moderators have pointed out they've deleted some of the questions already, and have flat out refuted many of his lies. Have some trust in them. We elected them to their position with the knowledge they would be able to see some things the rest of us wouldn't and shouldn't.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, So-called "witch hunting" has a new name in this era. Some *"[think it's a cool thing to do](http://goo.gl/J7XBtE)"*.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

This user is a known troll. Their only purpose here seems to be the public humiliation of a particular developer on the GNU Make project. The content I have seen them post has been abusive and insulting, and is not welcome on this site.

They are not welcome to participate here, and have been told as much. They did not respond positively to that, and proceeded to create new accounts. At that point, I and other moderators have been destroying their accounts and feeding them into the anti-trolling system. That has slowed them down, but they are determined enough to work around the blocks placed by this system.

If you see new accounts by this user that are posting the same insulting trash, flag them and let us know it's the same person. All you can do with a determined troll like this is make it more and more difficult for them to post their trolling until they eventually grow tired of it and give up.

Comment: I think we need a term for people who skirt the rules on multiple accounts/spam and get caught by a mod.  I propose we call it "Getting Larsoned", as in "Did you see how bad that troll got Larsoned?" or "Watch out spammers, you're about to get Larsoned!" :)

Comment: @theB: Larsony. Wait, that doesn't sound quite right...

Comment: @BoltClock - Larsony would be an offense for which you could be Larsoned.

Comment: @theB: If you could interpret it that way ;)

Comment: I would additionally recommend messages in further flags to refer this meta discussion, to make it simpler for a moderator handling the flag to get to broader context and prior details of the reported issue

Comment: Would getting Un-Larsoned be called "Coming back from _The Far Side_?"

Comment: Would there be a badge called "Grand Larsony" for creating 1000 fake troll accounts?

Comment: "Larsoned" already means writing brilliant code for iPhone hardware. it would be silly to use the term again here for this passing nonsense.

Comment: Goodness, we couldn't possibly have a word with multiple meanings. That [can](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/can) not be allowed!

Comment: @dcsohl I don't see what controller area networks have to do with anything... :)

Comment: are the corresponding posts deleted already? because I've looked at [several questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A5241638+is%3Aq) and I haven't noticed "public humiliation" or anything particularly "abusive and insulting". Though I don't understand the questions: is there some hidden insult in the technical details of the questions?

Comment: **Their only purpose here seems to be the public humiliation of a particular developer on the GNU Make project** is there any proof to back up this claim. I can not understand how "something in a big project does not work" can humiliate a particular developer from this project?

Comment: Perhaps the posts identifying the specific developer have already been Larsoned.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'm in the same boat, I can't find any instances of abusive language. I assume they have all been deleted?

Comment: Even so, of the questions that remain, most are of the form: "Something doesn't work in make. `[Rant elided]` Agree?" Which are clearly primarily opinion based.  Circle file all of them.

Comment: @JoeBlow Oh dear, the word "Larsoned" seems to be overloaded, as it could also mean to have your game show gamed by a contestant who figured out the pattern in your random number generator.

Comment: @Michael - That usage seems to apply here too... (Big Bucks! No Whammies!) I'm still going to try to make it a thing.

Comment: @BradLarson, you may wanna have a look at the other answer on here. The subject of this meta discussion has answered.

Comment: Beware, he'll start finding corner cases in SO and railing against it on Experts Exchange.

Comment: @bishop: Good! No one will ever see that, so...result!

Comment: Can you provide links to back up your claims ?

Answer (score -7):

IMHO it's likely that there's no real [malice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malice_(law)) here. While Ji Cha clearly doesn't understand the rules of SO, there's no evidence that his purpose is to *"**promote another tool** by smearing GNU Make"*.

The underlying purpose may be  benign, which is simply to broadcast/share the findings in corner cases where Make does not behave as documentation dictates.

@JiCha, some pointers:

- SO has a specific format requirement for all questions. Questions must be seeking objective answers, even if they're *is-this-a-bug* questions. A question like *"Should we blame GNU Make?"* is not considered objective.
- Also, if the purpose is to increase public awareness of the *corner cases* where GNU Make fails, that's likely not to work *at all* because people won't be seeing them anyway. A "corner case" bug thread on a project as popular as MySQL [had gained only 100 views in 5 months](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29912352/632951) (equates to averaging less than 1 view per day). The vast majority simply **do not encounter** such corner case bugs.
- Lastly, while you may not have skills in posting in SE, you clearly have skills in GNU Make. [Since it's open source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303084/632951), go ahead fork and fix those bugs rather than file them on SO.

Comment: I've read a few of Ji's questions. They definitely have a condescending and derisive tone to them that is very off-putting.

Comment: @Cupcake, I've read his posts too, some samples (from the last 6 posts): [1](http://goo.gl/kguclF), [2](http://goo.gl/6XLKQI), [3](http://goo.gl/3sBrmW), [4](http://goo.gl/3sBrmW), [5](http://goo.gl/rRfA0u), [6](http://goo.gl/VdBL6i). Whether they "definitely have a condescending and derisive tone to them that is very off-putting" is inherently subjective. Couple that with [his apology](http://goo.gl/E6CqTU) above. Also, the subtle tone of a message may not be so obvious to someone who [doesn't speak English as a first language](https://goo.gl/U1rp8P). In any case, a simple edit will suffice.

Comment: I have seen people write *respectful*, *humble* content in English, when it's not their first language. Whether English is your first language or not, [if you have a poor attitude, it shows in the way you express yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32199375/456814), no matter what language you use. Ji needs to learn how to leave his opinionated rants and venting out of his posts, or he should just stop participating in Stack Overflow.

Comment: As perhaps clearer examples, these posts almost *drip* with sarcasm, arrogance, and scorn, [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32175446/456814), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32163055/456814), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32222204/456814), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32108574/456814).

Comment: @Cupcake, A simple edit would suffice really: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163055/a-tentative-approach-to-execute-oneshell-in-makefile), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108574/command-line-option-what-if-in-makefile-does-not-work). There's no need to respond with vivid profanities.

Comment: @Pacerier We shouldn't have to follow someone around cleaning up their mess. If they have repeatedly demonstrated this behavior (which seems to be the case) then they should no longer cease to be a part of the community, because their effect is a net detriment. In Ji Cha's case, his goal doesn't seem to be to get help with a programming question, but rather to attack the maintainers of GNU Make. That motive doesn't fit in with Stack Overflow.

Comment: @mason, There's no need to clean up the mess. The behavior has changed, as can be seen when you compare the last 10 posts by Ji Cha with his first 10 posts.

Comment: I too would rather see Ji Cha's skills put to constructive use than banished, but I think you're being much too generous to him. I have not yet gone back to see which of his posts were deemed not sufficiently offensive to be deleted, but his "apology" as you call it is not an apology at all, it's "I'm sorry that I was misunderstood, and that so many of my helpful, useful and totally benign and wonderful posts were unjustly destroyed".

Comment: @Beta, The only "generous" thing done was [speaking out](http://goo.gl/oAOBjt) while knowing support is nonexistent within the walls of SE.com. His apology to MadScientist looks genuine enough. I wouldn't know how that could be rewritten to appear more sincere. If we take a look through some of his posts (including the 4 links picked out by Cupcake), we can see that they're mostly harmless. The only real issue is the frequent use of rhetorical questions.

Comment: For that, some had pointed out Ji Cha's posts "almost *drip* with sarcasm / arrogance / scorn", yet in a different environment outside of the SE [group](https://goo.gl/zYnzy6), that exact same description is being used to describe SE's attitude towards members outside of the ingroup. Whose point of view is objective and whose is subjective?