# May I know the reason for getting second T-shirt?

Tags: support, 10m-questions-milestone

Today I received another T-shirt from your side (second time). I don't know the reason for this. Stack Overflow gave me the first T-shirt for getting 100k, but I don't know the reason for the second.

I think I'm mentioned in this content, [10 Million Questions - Let's Share Some Stories That the Number Doesn't Convey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey), but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: There's been a bunch of 'nominate content' stuff - I reckon there's a pretty good chance something you wrote 'came up'.

Comment: I checked the weekly winners thing to see if maybe you'd won there and just forgot, but I didn't see your name in the lists anywhere, so it's most likely the "Let's share some stories" post- Did you get anything else _with_ the t-shirt?

Comment: Stack Overflow can't let you wear the same shirt the entire week, so they send you a second one :]

Comment: @AvinashRaj are you complaining ? :P

Comment: Is the second t-shirt a size larger?

Comment: It has the same size as the first one but  that t-shirt only fit to my father not me. I should alert you on this, if you inform me before sending.

Comment: @Criesto no.. If they give an alert , I should change my t-shirt size.

Comment: If you don't want the shirt, I'm sure someone else would willingly take it off your hands. For free, even! ;)

Comment: eBay. Send me the link, thanks!

Comment: Two Stack Overflow t-shirts, and I have none :(

Comment: We live in the same city. Where can I meet you? `:P`

Comment: "Me, too!"  (for you young-uns, that's the famous 'don't respond to Usenet threads this way' phrase).    C'mon SO:  I'm clearly such an unusual person that I deserve a shirt!

Comment: If you're unhappy with your Shirt you can send it to me and I'll take good care of it :)

Comment: I got none :( Please post a link where I can download your redundant one from ;)

Comment: I just want to know the reason only and I won't give the t-shirt to you guys. It's mine, I'm going to give another one to my father(_lov my dad_).

Comment: @Criesto - Perhaps the OP wants to know if whatever they did to get the second one is repeatable or make sure this wasn't a mistake before giving it to their father. Could be a weird conversation later: "Hey dad, Stack Overflow meant to send it to [X] and wants me to mail it back."

Comment: Where do I commit my size? I can't find anything in my profile where I can enter my shirt size. And if there'd be anything worse than not getting a T-shirt, it would be getting a shirt that wouldn't fit.

Comment: @BSMP Likely the cost of mailing it back and then mailing it to someone else will exceed the cost of the shirt, or just be not worth the hassle.

Comment: @mason - Sure, but I find that I save myself a lot of trouble if I don't assume that a worst case scenario won't happen just because it's illogical/expensive/etc.

Comment: @MrLister I do think they send an email to ask for our T-shirt size if you are among the winners, 100k rep users or whatever you need to earn that.

Comment: SO has literally clothed my entire family by now... ^_^;;

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This was a mistake we made in processing your 100k swag request and it just happens that two got sent out to you, so enjoy your bonus swag. :)

If you were mentioned in the other contests, Tim would have reached out to you to fill out a separate form specific to that contest.

Comment: You can mistakenly send me a shirt as well, if you like. Just accidentally send me a form. I'll fill it out and forget to correct you. =)

Comment: Does "Tim" refer to me, @TimBiegeleisen ?  I only have around 17K.  Can I buy a T-shirt somewhere?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just rep to 100K :D

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Sorry to reveal, but, that "Tim" refers to Tim Post. Better Luck the next time. :)

Comment: I am still waiting for my swag. I didn't receive it yet

Comment: _No, this wasn't meant for you, send it back immediately._