# Got a Stack Overflow mug - Don't know from where?

Tags: discussion

I recently got a Stack Overflow mug with no details of sender.

[image]

Is Stack Overflow giving away these mugs?

Comment: Did you go on a treasure hunt recently?

Comment: No, I didn't :P

Comment: Hmm. How I wish I open the door and someone throws a Stack Overflow mug on my face. *sigh*

Comment: SO has been known to [occasionally make mistakes with sending swag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307478/5337149).

Comment: **BRUH** why are you even complaining? :P

Comment: I just want to know what did I do that I got this. I want to do that damn thing everyday!!!

Comment: You put "SOreadytohelp" in your profile.  Most SO users did so to [win something](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303862/how-many-people-entered-the-soreadytohelp-contest-the-first-week).  It worked.

Comment: I didn't post anything there. I wish I had. :|

Comment: Downvote? Is somebody jealous or what?

Comment: Hah, [my "I hear nebraskas nice" mug](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vRUn4.jpg) is much cooler.

Comment: @Batty your profile *still* has the `SOreadytohelp` text on it, so yes you did do something!

Comment: But then surely you had to reply to an email to give them your address?

Comment: Looking at your Gravatar- have  you stalked, murdered, and horribly maimed anyone recently? Perhaps the mug was in their stuff and you took it without noticing? It can happen, I suppose.

Comment: Maybe you've used the SE mobi app and they've used the GPS to find where you live :)

Comment: If you did win the #SOReadToHelp, they had to contact you for your address (you filled out a google form or somesuch, if it's like the other ones).  They don't just keep addresses of people on file.  Except Jon Skeet anyway, I'm sure Tim has that one in his iAndroid.

Comment: The better question is can I buy this and if yes where I want 10.

Comment: I want to upvote because the mug looks nice- I want to downvote because I haven't gotten my swag yet. :( (Jk, I wouldn't downvote for so petty a reason. I couldn't find your username in the drawing posts, personally, and you don't have an answer to one of the participation posts... Perhaps a goof on their part. Happy accident! =D)

Comment: I didn't fill out any google form or anything like that, at least I can't remember filling any form.

Comment: Perhaps check your email and see if there's one from SO? Maybe it's a case of you did it then something else came up that made you forget you filled it out?

Comment: Any of your frieds or acquaintances active on SO? They might have won this and decided to send to you? Haha, everything's possible!

Comment: @BhargavRao Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoqSDvMMzE8 ? :-P

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Exactly!

Comment: I've got one after having reached 100kpoints. But without the `#SOReadToHelp` and perhaps a slightly bigger one.

Comment: *"Nice cup, but mine is bigger"* ;)

Comment: A couple of thoughts: Wasn't the `#SOReadToHelp` prize a T-Shirt, and not a mug? I thought perhaps this was part of the prizes for [How Did Stack Overflow Help You?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303988/how-did-stack-overflow-help-you) or [10 Million Questions - Let's Share Some Stories That the Number Doesn't Convey](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey), but it doesn't look like you posted in those.

Comment: Yes, i know. That is the reason I am wondering who sent this.

Comment: Though I wish I had posted in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303988/how-did-stack-overflow-help-you and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey. Because now I know it feels great to have something like that. :)

Comment: i am getting jealous.. when i would get it....:(

Comment: Do you still have the shipping label? The warehouse we use is in Hudson, MA and if it came from us there should be a return address on the label (I don't know the exact address off the top of my head). Though I'm not aware of any prize we sent out which consisted of *only* a mug. There would have been multiple things in the package.

Comment: You mug... Dont know from where? Maybe the company with its name on the mug?! Whats next, are you going to lose the mug? http://www.news.com.au/technology/case-of-rio-tinto-worker-edmund-lims-missing-coffee-cup-goes-viral/story-e6frfro0-1226633730172

Comment: I wouldn't say its a prank though, Did you make any SIGNIFICANT contribution lately? Where is your Location too?

Comment: Want! 987654321

Answer (score 25):

Ummm, well, you got us with this one.

Funny thing is, we **didn't** make custom swag for the #SOreadytohelp campaign (I checked), so it's pretty much a sure thing that mug didn't come from us. The only explanation we can offer is that someone you know, who knows your address, custom printed a mug without permission and sent it to you.

We are as baffled about this one as you are.

Comment: This story would be a great opening for a thriller.

Comment: Also, the picture shows the mug has the old six-bar logo.

Comment: You may not be authorized to know who Jeff is bribing.

Comment: What an odd thing. I got my 100k schwag bag not too long ago. But totally different mug w/ no color or hashtag.

Comment: May be I will figure out locally in my office if this was some prank. I would be really hurt if it was. :(

Comment: SO horror story in the making