# Stack Overflow at its finest

Tags: discussion

What kind of image do people conjure up with this title, of SO at its very finest?

For me this is an example: [How to determine whether my calculation of pi is accurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283270/how-to-determine-whether-my-calculation-of-pi-is-accurate/14283481#14283481), where the world record holder of computing `pi` ended up answering a question related to computing `pi`.

Another one to avoid coming off as too elitist is this ultra beginner question: [How can a 3D game render an object without having a sprite for every single angle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880396/how-can-a-3d-game-render-an-object-without-having-a-sprite-for-every-single-angl). This is an extremely beginner-like, but the answer there has a lot of effort behind it and might teach a lot of people wondering the same thing. I don't consider this SO at its finest, but it's pretty good here.

I was trying to put a finger on exactly what I considered to be SO at its very finest, and I realized the answer today. It's when an answer has so much expertise behind it that the answerer can effectively cite himself. If Linus Torvalds answered an esoteric question here about the Linux kernel, that would be another example of what I'd consider *"SO at its finest"*. An easier-to-obtain example that doesn't require such esoteric questions is if any veteran in the industry answers a question on how to best achieve something based on their many years of personal experience (unfortunately those get dangerously close to "best practices").

I've been parading around aggressively on meta trying to push my thoughts of what I think would encourage more moments like this. Sorry about that. Some of it is because I'm becoming really bored with the main site. The tags for the languages I'm most fluent in are drowning in a sea of basic questions which can only invite basic, terse answers to basic issues that beginners trip over again and again in thousands upon thousands of variations of basic MCVEs. Meta is interesting to me since there's a lot of discussions here about making changes, some of which I think could start improving the odds of finding more of these expert answers here and there.

Yet in my aggression, I forgot to ask if people even share the same vision of what exactly constitutes *"SO at its finest"*, and also what others think in terms of how to promote more of those finest moments. So I'm mainly curious as to other people's thoughts here -- what do you think are SO's finest moments, and how do we encourage more of them?

Comment: Did we notice the score [1337](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet) on that answer? Let's keep it that way ...

Comment: @rene Doh, OMG! I'm so slow. I didn't realize 1337 meant something -- it's been years since I saw any leet speak. :-D (wave hands) -- nothing to see here! But yes.. doh, I might screw up that perfect number by casting a spotlight on it.

Comment: Have a look at this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python/2714590#comment2742852_2714590)  :-)

Comment: @BhargavRao Wow, that's very precious! The fact that he was asked about the borg pattern makes it amazing. Seeing those types of things are why I personally joined the site... can't find this kind of stuff in a forum.

Comment: For more inspirational stories, see this [10M milestone Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey).  Otherwise I'd have to put in the obvious [branch prediction answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902), which is also the highest scoring answer on the site.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I like how the Q cites yet another Mysticial answer on branch misprediction. Some of those answers are really interesting. One other thing that I think can make a post amazing is just sheer effort and detail -- like that Mysticial post on branch prediction isn't quite as esoteric knowledge to those who know how to profile and decipher assembly as an answer on computing pi from a record holder, but it has a combo of veteran-style expertise and a great deal of effort put into answering it.

Comment: [John Carmack](https://superuser.com/questions/419070/transatlantic-ping-faster-than-sending-a-pixel-to-the-screen/419167#419167).  [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz), one of the Java language designers, has answered a bunch of questions about why Java 8's features are the way they are.

Comment: Mark Adler likes to answer just about any question on his own Adler-32 checksum algorithm. Including - but not limited to - tips on [how to spell his name](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33914640/2).

Comment: Not an actual answer, only a comment, but still nice in this context- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105827/what-is-a-store-buffer#comment14639203_11130239

Comment: And my personal favorite (though the author was already mentioned above) - someone asks about some comment in an obscure 20-years-old code, and within a day the original author is found - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172402/do-compilers-produce-better-code-for-do-while-loops-versus-other-types-of-loops/20173338#comment30090750_20172402

Comment: I am not sure this is on topic here but best thing I like about Stack Overflow so far is quality of the answers here

Comment: Well Guess many don't know that the Python BDFL is here on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/818274/guido-van-rossum)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For me, the most valuable facet of Stack Overflow is when I'm searching for the explanation of a rather banal, straightforward problem I have: why isn't my table view header laying itself out correctly when the phone rotates? (That was just yesterday; finally solved it when I read the answer to a similar question after poring over dozens of others.)

Stack Overflow has reams upon reams of information on quotidian stuff like this, when as far as you can tell you've got your ducks lined up but the results are not correct. The docs are silent, confusing, contradictory, or just wrong, and the all the inspection debugging you've done only tells you what you already knew.

You need the specific knowledge of a peer who's done this task before; someone on the mailing list, or down the hall. You don't necessarily need a superstar, just a lucid explanation of that one piece you're failing to grasp.

Headliner posts like the one you've linked, and the branch prediction answer, are *awesome*; don't get me wrong. I have great respect and gratitude for Mysticial's knowledge and  eir  sharing of that knowledge with the public like this. I love reading it. But...those answers are blog material. Note, please: I'm *not* saying they don't belong on Stack Overflow -- just that they would fit *equally well* in a format not prompted by someone asking a question. Whereas [the post that clarified the wall I was banging my head against yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18909325/603977) really only makes sense on Stack Overflow.*

There are thousands of little posts like that one, none of which I can remember at this point without looking through my upvote history. None of them are necessarily worth bookmarking or sharing, but they save my sanity nearly every time I sit down at my IDE. To me, that's the whole point, and that's the site at its finest: clicking that top search link, scanning the answers, and having the "ah ha!" moment of that one stupid little puzzle piece falling into place.

---

Editorial P.S.: This is why I like closure-as-duplicate and universal editing *so much*: they allow us to make these little gemstones easier and easier to find.

---

*or a mailing list, but Stack Overflow is way more google-able by design

Comment: Couldn't agree more.

Comment: That's a nice answer, though I think it varies a bit by tags/subject. With iOS/OSX info, the documentation across the web tends to be quite sparse with Apple being the main source (one of the pains I always have porting to OSX), so even a basic question like this related to UI refresh can be somewhat esoteric -- not something easily found with a Google search. In the languages I use like C and C++, most basic questions like this have thousands upon thousands of hits and can be found by a Google search almost instantly, if not in a most basic book on the subject...

Comment: ... that's where I think my interest is skewed more towards those Mysticial-type answers -- they're the one-of-a-kind esoteric answers with info that most average C and C++ developers, and even authors on the subject, don't typically discuss, making it actually rather analogous to this iOS example. With things that are documented and discussed to death worldwide, the exceptional quality information then tends to take on a very advanced characteristic.

Comment: One of my thoughts is that a question with an MCVE often can't be made generally useful. Imagine if that iOS question was phrased into a very narrow context with an MCVE and asking about refresh artifacts on resizing, thrusting it into a code-debugging context of, say, a shooter game. Even if the answer is valuable, it becomes too narrowly-tuned to the author's *exact* problem, and then becomes unlikely to ever be carefully read (if even found) by others experiencing the exact same problem. :-( I haven't been able to put my finger on what makes a good Q, but MCVE Qs seem to be the worst there.

Comment: My point was rather that it's a pretty ordinary answer, but that it's valuable nonetheless. I agree with you about the MCVE problem: the allergic reaction to "gimme the codez" that birthed "show the codez" may have entrenched itself too far. Robert Harvey has expressed this thought too: [Are code troubleshooting questions really what we want to encourage?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107116) (There's a Meta answer of his on this too. that I can't find at the moment. See also: [Should Stack Overflow be awarding As for effort?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840) if you haven't already

Comment: @JoshCaswell Those are some nice links. I think one issue is that the Qs I consider most discouraging towards finer-quality info (including what you cited), are actually not MCVE questions but "SCVE" questions as someone put it. The author actually made no attempt to reduce the amount of code, it's just short because the entire program they're working on and wanting us to debug is short. So they're "short" examples but far, far from "minimal".

Comment: Couldn't agree more with this. Stack overflow is excellent for it's super expertise moments, but the combination of both that and the countless amount of 'trivial questions' which answer really specific purposes, are what gives it the greatness of having such far reach. In some ways, I feel that a small percentage of experts, look down on SO's trivial questions too harshly.

Comment: @AdamCopley Actually I LOVE trivial questions! Example, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880396/how-can-a-3d-game-render-an-object-without-having-a-sprite-for-every-single-angl. Another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo. But these are trivial in a "general" sense -- they're asking a very generalized question that is useful to all kinds of people. That is different from "Fix my code plz for my puzzle game assignment due tomorrow -- I don't know how to debug." Those kinds of Qs benefit no one, hardly even the author of the question.

Comment: @AdamCopley The reason I personally love those expert questions the most is that they're usually the only ones teaching me something new. But I also love beginner questions that are very trivial and very broad/general -- because sometimes people participate and write something magnificent. Even if I don't learn anything new from those, I can see the educational value they might have on thousands of people out there. The reason I don't like "fix my code plz" problems is that they have zero educational value. The people who ask them would actually benefit far more from being directed to a book.

Comment: Agreed there @Ile there definitely is a difference between general/broad far reaching questions, and non-programmer 'help me' posts.  But also then again, even with fix my code pls questions, as long as the asker is interested in learning why their code didn't work then all is good

Comment: @AdamCopley I do have a soft spot for the more earnest beginners out there -- today I just spent 3 hours helping one in a chat (but didn't want to answer his Q directly). But what I worry is that if we flood the site with those kinds of "help me, I don't know how to debug Qs", and we mix them up with the rarer, really interesting questions, I fear we lose the interest of those experts out there like Mysticial. I think that's the only reason to keep the site clean -- because people are telling me they find what they want even with the mess we have.

Comment: Very true - This then calls for a balance, or categorization of question difficulty/interestingness?

Comment: This.  For every super-cool *woo wowee!* answer (that is almost always of no use to anybody for whatever reason), the fact that millions of people get answers for problems they're facing every day--that's SO at its finest.

Comment: @Will I think there are plenty of questions besides, "Wow, this actually taught me something new!" kind which I find great. An example is this which just showed information I already knew: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880396/how-can-a-3d-game-render-an-object-without-having-a-sprite-for-every-single-angl. The problem is that even these basic ones which invite very positive activity and interesting (even if beginner-level) answers are so rare -- even though ones that are educational in my areas are not so common. The killer to me are troubleshooting "fix my code" disposable Qs.

Comment: @Will Another example is the one Josh cited. Even that is *very rare* in tags like C and C++, where a general question on the minds of many will be asked as opposed to a "fix my code plz" question which no one else would ask (the other types are usually extremely API-specific or domain-specific). While my personal definition of highest-quality answers would be ones that teach me something brand new like Mysticial's answers, any answer which has a general educational value > 0 to me is quite wonderful.

Answer (score 19):

For me StackOverflow at its finest is when I have a programming issue, google it, and the first link is a well voted nicely explained stackoverflow answer that solves my problem. This happens nearly weekly for me.

Comment: @Ike Im an apprentice in the first year, so naturally, this is very useful for me.

Comment: I usually add `site:stackoverflow.com` to my google searches to avoid the myriad of forum answers from showing up.

Comment: In my case I have an odd background since my workplace uses almost solely proprietary code (UI, scene graph, rendering engine, etc). So there isn't so much to learn besides the languages (C, C++, and Lua), and our own proprietary engine. So I think that's why I don't find myself with too many questions of our own -- if I don't know how to do something in the UI, for example, I have to search within my team's own documentation -- there are zero answers on the internet. So instead SO has been handy to me to sift through to try to figure out how to do things better.

Comment: I'm also the student/apprentice but lack the specific question due to my particular context... so I end up just browsing through SO mostly looking for an answer that will teach me something I don't already know (which actually happens a lot when I come across an expert answer). I'm the "browsing" type more than the "searching" type.

Comment: Its boring, but this is my choice as well. If I go back in time 10 years I had to pray for answers to the more difficult problems and usually had to stumble upon it myself by accident sometimes several months down the road. Nowadays I have a marginal guarantee that I can find the answer/solution - or a viable workaround, on SO somewhere and solve it within an hour. All you need is a degree in smart searching, enough experience to see result A and B are related, and patience.

Comment: @Gimby Its amazing how stuff that is usually confined to very experienced high paid professionals or expensive books is now merely a google search away from beeing available. I can't count the amount of times I thought to myself: "If I had to find this without Internet QA I could just abandon the project alltogether."

Comment: @Magisch What I like about those ultra expert answers is that we can't find them a google search away outside of StackOverflow. They're some of the cases where I learn something I can't or didn't already learn elsewhere. It's like if John Carmack came on here and wrote about his experiences and design decisions working on doom, that's info we don't find anywhere else typically, at least not in the specific context of the question that was asked. It would be one-of-a-kind info not available anywhere else.

Answer (score 7):

If I spend 5 minutes thinking about something, or have to think in general, it's been done before and documented here. Here's some random query I threw together, I believe the 3rd and 4th link answer my exact question.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! (I want to up-vote but I exhausted mine today, will do later). One of the things that saddens me is that the top question there would likely be closed today (even assuming it wasn't a dupe) as broad or POB or suitable for code review but not main SO, since it's asking a very general question, no MCVE (only snippet), and also how to do things more efficiently.

Comment: @Ike disagree...  the problem is it's clearly a dupe. If really no one had *ever* asked how to merge two sorted arrays then *of course* there would be a need for an SO question to cover it.

Comment: Yeah, I meant if it wasn't a dupe today (just assuming there weren't a boatload of questions on this already). It fails on SOCVR standards by asking how to do things better (more efficiently), being rather broad, and also reviewing code asking how to do it better, and lacking an MCVE and only having a snippet.. at least I think that's the type of questions we'd close vote these days.

Comment: @Ike sure but then someone will eventually ask it better since it's an important question.

Comment: Perhaps so. Sometimes I think we should try to make more canonical ones like that, if they aren't duped. It's kind of hard to force a Q&A though. P.S. -- why the downvote? This is a perfectly legit answer!