# We should discourage comments asking for code when it is obviously unnecessary

Tags: feature-request, comments, new-users

I hope I'll be forgiven something that's about as much of a rant as a real question, but my frustration over this topic has been building for some time.

We seem to have a fair (well, to be honest, completely *unfair*) number of self-appointed "moderators" who've taken it upon themselves to write a comment to essentially *every* question that doesn't include at least one code snippet, telling the poster that he needs to include code showing what he's tried, along with what problem he's had with that code.

In some cases, that's sensible--especially when the poster makes it clear that what they're dealing with is a bug in existing code, that's perfectly reasonable advice.

There are, however, quite a few perfectly reasonable questions that are basically asking what algorithm or approach will work to solve a particular kind of problem. The poster clearly hasn't written code yet--the help he needs is specifically with how to get started solving the particular problem at hand. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407022/how-to-print-all-subset-between-2-indexes-of-array) ([screen shot for the rep-challenged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqhlA.png)) triggered my writing about the problem, but it's just one of *many* in what looks to me like a growing trend.

Now, the reality is that this is a very specific question. There is at least one specific answer that produces correct results. The OP has written enough to make it absolutely clear what the correct results are. [Shog has previously written](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224104/137574) that:

> But many specific, answerable questions don't include attempted solutions because... There's nothing to attempt: either you know the answer or you don't. Indeed, this can be a hallmark of a properly-scoped question: have you managed to narrow it down to the one piece you don't know before asking?

I think this question (among, as already noted, many others) fits that description perfectly. So, in my mind there's no real room for argument that there's anything at all wrong with the question itself.

My question is about what we can do to discourage (undoubtedly well-meaning) people from posting comments like the one on this question, that led the poster to almost immediately delete what was a perfectly good question, and much more likely than not leave SO in disgust over the narrow-minded jack-asses who occupy it (or something on that order).

So, what can we do to make it clear that this sort of comment **needs** to be restricted to cases where it really applies? It *clearly* doesn't apply in this case, and although it's less clear in some other cases, this is clearly far from the first time this situation has arise either.

My own nomination would be that there be a flag reason of "doesn't include necessary code snippet", and we add a review queue for these flags (and the comment added semi-automatically when/if it's approved). I realize that 1) doesn't prevent people from writing comments anyway, and 2) is likely to cause some delay in the comment being added, even when it really is needed. Neither of these, however, strikes me as being (even close to) as problematic as the current situation of losing perfectly good questions (and probably good contributors) just because a few people are over-zealous in attempting to enforce a requirement that doesn't really even exist in the first place.

I'll also note for the record that this clearly is not just a "gimme the codez" kind of question. The OP doesn't request code at all. It's entirely possible to provide an answer that's entirely narrative and describes what needs to be done without getting into a particular language at all:

> For the moment, let's ignore that it's a subset of something else, and only consider the subset you want to work with. Now think of a binary number with one bit for each element in that set. Take that binary number, and count from 1 to 111...1. Each number you generate represents a subset. For each number, a 1-bit represents an element that's present in that subset (and a 0-bit represents an element that's not present).

Optionally, one might want to add references to terms that would help in further research, but they're not really necessary to answer the question itself.

Comment: Doesn't "doesn't include necessary code snippet" == no mcve?

Comment: I agree with you that the "show the codez" comment was out of place on your example question. On the other hand, I strongly disagree that it is "properly scoped" as defined by Shog in your quote. To my eye, the author has done _nothing_ resembling "narrow[ing] it down". Input and desired output are simply presented baldly. There's no attempt to put the problem into any context, such as the term "power set" that comes up if you spend 10 seconds googling. It smells to me like a "send the codez" homework dump, and I'd hope for a better example of what you're concerned about.

Comment: [As I said a while ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312205/stack-overflow-at-its-finest#comment282475_312222), "the allergic reaction to 'gimme the codez' that birthed 'show the codez' may have entrenched itself too far. Robert Harvey has expressed this thought too: [Are code troubleshooting questions really what we want to encourage?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107116)", but in this particular case I can sympathize somewhat.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Yes, once you know the answer it's obvious searching for "power set" will tell you how to get where you're going. Starting from knowledge only of what you need, without already knowing the right terminology is going to be a long exercise in frustration. If we reject this on the basis simply that "the answer is out there somewhere for those who know how to find it", then we might as well shut SO down completely.

Comment: I like algorithm/design questions, given a sane level of broadness.  Unfortunately, all too often, we get 'do all my work' or complete system requirement specs:(

Comment: Searching for ["subset of array"](https://www.google.com/search?q=subsets+of+array) gets you the term "power set" on the very first page. I couldn't include that link in my first comment because I got too long-winded.

Comment: Well, if Googling the OP's exact title gives 'About X,XXX,000 results', with several SO Q&A on the first page that clearly explain the OP's issues, I'm gonna downvote it.

Comment: @Jaco you have to be careful.  Leaving comments can lead to bar fights and YOU will get flagged and suspended. The OP's account will suffer too, but so what - they just open another one.

Comment: I agree, it's not an _illegitimate_ question "on the basis simply that 'the answer is out there somewhere for those who know how to find it'", but it is a _bad_ question; [we have had a standard for a long time that you need to put some effort in before you ask things of your peers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107273/159251). It's answerable, but I just think it's a bad piece of evidence for your case.

Comment: I didn't vote on Jerry's sample question but.. OK, lets have a go. Googling 'C++ How to print all subset between 2 indexes of array'...   oh look!  'About 961,000 results' :(

Comment: @MartinJames: did you actually look at those proposed answers? I did (well, the first page or two, not all 961K). The vast majority of them simply don't apply here at all (and sorting through 961,000 results to find the few that do apply gets us back to "shut down SO because the answer to every question is already out there somewhere."

Comment: @JerryCoffin no, which is why I still have not voted either way.  Sometimes, you just have to go and brew coffee.

Comment: More wisdom from Shog: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286760

Comment: This is so close you would need an eletron microscope to tell them apart.  From the first page of Google results: http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/print-all-combinations-of-subset-of-size-k-from-given-array/

Comment: Anyway, it has webbed feet, waterproof feathers and quacks like a homework duck. prof/TA is prolly after a recursive solution because it's cool and, maybe, because it's a good approach though, obviously, nothing is as important as cool factor:(

Comment: @MartinJames: Sorry, but no--that's not the same thing at all. The difference here is measured in light-years, not microns. And yes, it's probably homework. Doesn't make it any less legitimate a question.

Comment: Pseudocode is fine too.   In questions, it can generate a useful language-agnostic answer.  In answers, it's great!  If i post actual code, I have to compile it, link it, test it and debug it.  Much better if OP does all that stuff:)

Comment: OTOH, you have to be careful.  If I, or some other user, had posted a pseudocode answer to your quoted question, what are the chances of it being accepted?  What are the chances of getting downvoted with 'I wanted the actual code in C++, (to hand in tomorrow morning)'?

Comment: Ugh, that is not a question.  Very hard to guess why you cannot see this.  Just try it, google "site:stackoverflow.com c++ combinations" and try to figure out from that task description which of those 38,000 hits is not a duplicate.  Well, don't say "the last one" :)

Comment: @MartinJames: I've posted quite a few answers that didn't include code, even when the OP made it pretty clear that it really was a "gimme the codez--**now**!" kind of thing. I'm pretty sure my poor little ego will survive the loss of an imaginary internet point.

Comment: @HansPassant: it wouldn't surprise me a bit of this question is a dupe, and I wouldn't object at all to its being closed a dupe (as long as the nominated dupe was accurate, of course). There's a big difference between "here's some help", and "screw you" (which is how a comment like this is likely to be perceived).

Comment: If it's okay for someone to come here and go "Here's my requirements *splat*" it should be okay for me to comment "That's great--now what's the problem with your code?"

Comment: @Will: On a scale of 1 to 10, you're just wrong. There are quite clearly cases where somebody don't have a good idea of how to start at something, and (regardless of whether you think this example qualifies or not) searches that provide useful answers are exceptionally difficult. Cases like that don't justify your acting obnoxious and asinine just because you think your *almost* 100K rep makes you a big thing.

Comment: Well, 'screw you' is a pretty appropriate response to somebody that cannot even be bothered to ask a question.  Lazy deadbeat.  You cannot say that, you have to be nice.  He was.  Strange that you cannot see that.

Comment: Wow, I really put a hurt on your poor tuchus, didn't I?  My sincerest apologies.  Go ahead and encourage all the help vampires you want.  Good day to you, sir.

Comment: @Will: I've dealt with help vampires before--but everybody deserves to be treated as innocent until proven guilty. Here I'm not even demanding a whole lot of proof--but you're jumping to a conclusion based on precisely zero evidence of any sort. That's just not justified at all.

Comment: @HansPassant: So you object based on their lack of skills with respect to grammar and punctuation, even though anybody with an IQ higher than their shoe size knows what the question is without even trying?

Comment: @JerryCoffin To drop a [fresh question in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36409395/determine-last-number-of-3n). Are we talking about this kinda stuff?

Comment: I object against questions that are not actually questions, couldn't care less who asks them.  Strange that you cannot see this.  You've got some kind of personal agenda that you are not disclosing, smells like you like coding exercises to keep you occupied.  That's just a guess.  Maybe you are making the exact same mistake this OP was making, hehe.

Comment: @HansPassant: There's no personal agenda here at all--just an awareness that there are a lot of people in the world whose native language is something other than English (and quite a few people whose native language *is* English, but still don't write well). If I was just looking for coding exercises, I know were the find SPOJ, HackerRank, etc. They don't do a whole lot for me though. Maybe you should stick to coding instead of trying to play amateur psychologist--you seem to be a lot better at it. :-)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: that doesn't strike me as particularly similar, no. There the approach has already been outlined, so the only question is about how to translate that into C++ syntax. I don't think it's reasonable to try to squeeze an entire "intro to C++" course into a single answer.

Comment: So... is this meta discussion about that specific question, or about irrelevant "please post your code" comments in general (of which in that particular instance it's even less pertinent of a problem)?

Comment: It seems this discussion got way too focused on the specific example, unfortunately. Having people try to turn every single question into a debugging question is really annoying, and I wish there was some way to get them to stop it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know this won't help in the particular case you linked, since the poster deleted the question, but one of the best ways I see to counteract an unnecessary "show code" comment is just to answer the question.

If you provide a (good!) answer to the question as written, ideally an answer that doesn't itself involve code, then the comment is demonstrably pointless and obsolete, and should be removable via flagging on that basis.

Provide an example of the behavior you'd like to encourage. After all, that's how these comments got so popular in the first place.

You could also reply to the commenter that their comment is superfluous, giving a reason. Then, again, back it up by answering. No need to get into an argument: just say once "@whoever, no code is needed here, <and here's why>".

I'm not sure about your proposed new flag; I'm frankly skeptical that it would not be subject to the same overextension that led to the comments that you're concerned about.

Comment: In the case of Jerry's quoted question, it's tagged C++ and, if you post a text or pseudocode algorithm, I'm sure some kind souls will downvote you to oblivion for not answering the question:(

Comment: And the OP deletes the question while your answer is only half written :/

Comment: ^^^^^ after some rep-PersonalServicesWorker, or another member of the voting-ring, or one of the socks, posts an answer copied from Google, or sent in an email from the OP.

Comment: Well, sure, @MartinJames; the tag is one of the things that produces an aroma of do-my-homeworkz there. On the other hand, it's a completely irrelevant tag, given that there's no C++ code in the question, no C++ features being asked about, no C++ knowledge required in answering. So it should be edited out, by the answerer or really anyone else. As I said above, that's a terrible example question and I'd just as soon ignore it.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe we should undelete it..

Comment: @JoshCaswell yeah - I did ignore it.

Answer (score 7):

Two things here:

- I'm not entirely sure that the "no code" proviso here entirely applies, and I'll explain this point in detail.
- The OP is clearly looking for building out a power set.

But more to your point on:

> The poster clearly hasn't written code yet--the help he needs is specifically with how to get started solving the particular problem at hand.

This causes some unease with me.  You're likely right in principle, but I'm still uneasy about this since it raises questions about Stack Overflow's appropriate role in the "how do I start solving X" process.

This is *likely* what prompted the visceral, knee-jerk, "Where's your code?" comment.  Here's a question about "how do I do X", but there's really no attempt at solving X.  The way that many contributors quantify "effort" on this front is to see some sort of code or progress at attempting to solve the problem.

Thing is, I don't entirely disagree with that.  Here's why:

- The language is irrelevant; power sets can be solved in any language with arrays
- It's unclear whether or not they're looking for a direct solution or a library to solve it
- There's no attempt at the solution of the problem, which is what makes a question *better* and more accessible to answer, since one would have a base to work from
- There's no attempt made to question the actual algorithm itself, which definitely *does not* require code

> I'll also note for the record that this clearly is not just a "gimme the codez" kind of question. The OP doesn't request code at all.

Probably not, but there's really no indication as to *what* they're requesting.  If one *did* post an answer without code, but the OP came back and asked for an actual implementation, would that change your opinion on the question?

All in all, I personally think it's okay that they deleted the question.  The comment was definitely a knee-jerk reaction to a commonly seen question asking style, but I'm not as upset about this since it revealed to the OP that more clarity would be necessary to figure out what it is they were actually asking about.

---

All of *that* above goes to demonstrate my point:  discouraging those sorts of comments is difficult at *best* and counterproductive at worst, since you're not likely to sway the minds of the tens of thousands of people that *don't* use Meta.

If the comment is pointless and doesn't add anything to that discussion, you can do several things:

- Flag the "where's the code" comment as "not constructive"
- Comment yourself, stating that it's fine if this question doesn't have code since it doesn't require it

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of the suggested solutions was possible--almost immediately after the comment was posted, the OP deleted the question.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: That's likely for the best then.  That implies to me that the user didn't want to engage much further or take the time to clarify their question.

Comment: I'm not sure any clarification was really necessary. Although he didn't satisfy some pedants by using proper grammar and punctuation, if you read through his post carefully at all, what he wanted was entirely clear. I'd also note for the record that the standard stance of SO for years has been that the intent isn't just to answer that poster's question, but to provide an answer for others with similar problems, indicating that *his* skills in English writing should be strictly a secondary criterion in any decision.

Answer (score -6):

Having just had a question answered by you, without a code example... I couldn't agree more.

I look at the answerer's profile before I read the answer. Sometimes I even follow their links (as I did yours).

This answer probably isn't in-line with the stream ... and I apologize for that - I just don't find a lot of people who are in the same area of work, and I get profused when I do.