# Answering Questions With Accepted Answer

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Is it correct/OK/encouraged to submit an answer to a question even if an already existing answer has already been accepted?

Comment: If you think you can write an answer which adds new useful value to the post, then write your answer. But don't just post the same thing, which is already posted.

Comment: I'm new here and figuring out how to approach things so I don't go outside of what's expected, so I've thought about this issue. In my opinion, the litmus test is whether or not it's helpful. If I think my answer is better than the accepted answer or a valid alternative that is truly different, I'd be inclined to post it.

Comment: Oh, and if it's an improvement on the accepted answer, I'd comment on the answer.

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey/303112#303112) post.

Comment: This post provides some very interesting and well written life experiences.

Comment: Where is the vote to close button?  This has been asked umpteen times

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Assuming that your answer is better than the accepted answer then yes, it's encouraged. There's even a gold badge for it, [Populist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist).

Better means adding new information to the question rather than rewriting what's already been written.

Comment: That is very well explained.

Comment: @Ben Regarding 'adding new information to the question rather than rewriting what's already been written' - If a new answer provides the same information but presents it much more clearly, wouldn't that be helpful too?

Comment: It would be @Timothy, yes. My experience is that being able to do this is extremely rare and in the cases where it's happened there's only been one answer, which I edited rather than posting my own. Just in case: your answer doesn't have to be just new information, a (properly attributed - if appropriate) précis of what's gone before is also helpful so that all the information is in one place.

Answer (score 10):

- Accepted answers can get unaccepted. It is not a permanent status.
- The accept status is just one person's opinion abut what works for *them*, possibly in a situation that is much more narrowly defined than what the question appears to be about, or even other than what the question is about.
- Answers are supposed to be useful to future visitors, who may have almost exactly the same question, without the specific quirks or restrictions.
- Sometimes accepted answers are outright junk. If you ever happen to write one, you will be dismayed to find that you cannot delete an accepted answer; it must first be unaccepted. Meanwhile other answers are upvoted higher.
- Sometimes an early answer is accepted almost instantly, before the question has had much exposure.

Answer (score 3):

The OP is the one who accepts an answer - and that's all the meaning there is for this feature.

The OP likely knows best about the his/her problem. But he or she is not necessarily the expert to pick the best answer. And some users have a very short attention span and tend to favor "the fastest gun in the west". See [fastest-gun](/questions/tagged/fastest-gun). That misguided practice produces quite a few accepted answers of questionable usefulness.

If you have something useful and relevant to the question that's not in the answers so far (accepted or not) - and with enough substance to be more than a comment - by all means, write a new answer. The new answer does *not* have to be "better". It has to add something useful addressing the question.