# Can I rollback to a previous, unbroken mug?

Tags: discussion, swag

I proudly and prominently use my Stack Overflow shirt, clipboard, koozie and mug that I received for [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303390/916299) in the 10 million questions giveaway.

Or at least I did. My mug was broken by a careless push, it merged very badly with the floor and now it leaks more than my first program. It was put in the trash and I'm unable to recover it.  I could just commit to a new mug, but I was hoping there's a way to rollback to the old, unbroken one. Can anyone help, please?!

While I'm raising tickets, the pen also has a bug where the clicker-spring interface fails and nothing is output making the system quite useless. I could do with some help with that too!

Comment: *"now it leaks more than my first program"* - really, you made a hello world with leaks? That in itself is an achievement worth another mug and t-shirt.

Comment: +1 dare to ask. I've had a similar experience with a t-shirt that was DOA. A e-mail to the person (community manager?) that originally sent me the stuff resolved the shirt's pattern mis-match.

Comment: @Gimby, haha I wish I could remember what my first program looked like, it was more than a decade ago now. But even if it didn't leak at all, the mug definitely leaks more!

Comment: Did you try to custom mod flag the mug? I hear mods can do awesome things....

Comment: @James so in over a decade of programming you didn't even consider ["glue code"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glue_code)? :p

Comment: Related: When I pulled my swag, instead of a cool mug, I received a large orange drinking cup that I have no use for. Is it possible to amend that one? I would like to change it to a mug

Comment: Restore from backups.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit, as I said, the mug was put in the trash and I'm unable to recover it.

Comment: @JonClements, In over a decade or so of programming, I've learned that glue code usually leads to further problems later down the line. In this case, I feel it may have a negative effect on the user directly!

Comment: At least you still have the memory of the mug... (Unless the memory has been freed and reused of course.) I never had a mug to begin with.

Comment: @MrLister nice one but how about this variation: (unless the mug has been garbage collected of course) :)

Comment: Time for a [hot(glue)fix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotfix)?

Comment: I'm very, very sad for your mug. Awesomely written post though =)

Comment: You could bypass the clicker-spring interface of the pen, and run the core directly ...

Comment: Only one problem per question please :)

Comment: This looks more like a hardware than a software issue. Have you tried turning your mug off and turning it back on again?

Comment: Even when using it for the purpose of Java, a careless push on the stack (overflow mug) can have severe consequences if there is not enough room left. It could lead to a crash if the next thing you do is to call floor(). In this case, the crash could have been avoided by a simple table look-up.

Comment: Sounds to me that you were too quick to 'commit' to your mug....

Comment: @Lundin, who knew there were so many puns in breaking a nerdy mug!

Comment: I am so sad I missed that meta post. :/

Comment: @JamesWebster Coffee mugs are serious business. Don't you know that programmers are the only organisms capable of converting caffeine into source code? Take away their mugs and the whole ecosystem is threatened.

Comment: TL;DR - dropped a mug, new one please.

Comment: I distinctly remember my very first program. The good old days. And **NO** it didn't have any leaks.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

It sounds like your mug is probably too borked for a simple rollback. Luckily, we still maintain physical backups in a warehouse somewhere for just such occasions.

If you shoot an email to team@ (or use [/contact](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)), we'll get someone to send you a backup you can restore from.

Comment: Oh! That's fantastic, thank you! :D

Comment: @JamesWebster No worries - we've all felt the pain of an accidental merge a time or two :)

Comment: Brave!! Do you have a replacement for every broken SO mug?