# How to participate in Stack Overflow contest to get a t-shirt

Tags: support, swag

I'm interested to gain a Stack Overflow t-shirt, so I was finding the way how I can get it. I found a couple of ways

1. Buying, but the shop is closed now
2. Waiting until I get 100K reputation
3. Participating in a Stack Overflow contest [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey)

From all the options I'm much more interested in the third one.

So how often do they conduct events? How do I find them? Where can I get more information about this contest?

Comment: You'll have to subscribe to the blog and/or [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/events+or+swag+or+contest) for contests.

Comment: Which blog? Can you provide link

Comment: You can find these links in the site footer. https://stackoverflow.blog, https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow, https://twitter.com/stackoverflow, https://www.linkedin.com/company/stack-overflow/